# Tips for golfing in F#

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in F#? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to F# (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

Answer (score 10):

Need to provide a type annotation for a variable so that you can call a method on it? Just compare it against a literal of the type you want it to be then throw away the result:

```
let f (x:string)=x.Length
let f x=x="";x.Length
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `function` instead of `match` when possible; it'll save 6 characters for 1-character variable names:

```
let f=function // ... (14 chars)
```

vs

```
let f x=match x with // ... (20 chars)
```

It can also replace any pattern match to consistently save 1 character:

```
match a with|          // ... (13 chars)
a|>function|           // ... (12 chars)
(function| (* ... *))a // (12 chars)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the prefix notation for infix operators when you can - it'll save you from having to define a function to use them.

For example, you can turn this:

```
List.map(fun i->i+2)[1;1;2;3;5;8]
```

into this:

```
List.map((+)2)[1;1;2;3;5;8]
```

Comment: I use it [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147073/15214) thank you!

Answer (score 6):

## Tuple deconstruction

In case you can't get around to using variables, use tuple deconstruction instead of multiple let expressions

```
let a,b ="",[]
```

instead of

```
let a=""
let b=[]
```

## Reading from stdin

F# core library defines an alias for `System.Console.In` called `stdin`. These allow you to read input.

```
// Signature:
stdin<'T> :  TextReader
```

[TextReader on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

The big advantage aside the fact that it's shorter than `Console` is, you don't have to open System either

## Iterating over string

string is basically a `char seq`, this allows you to use `Seq.map` directly with strings. It's also possible to use them in comprehensions `[for c in "" do]`

## Mutables/Reference cells

Using reference cells is not always shorter as every read operation comes with an additional character to deref the cell.

## General tips

- It is possible to write the complete `match .. with` inline

  ```
  function|'a'->()|'b'->()|_->()
  ```
- There is no need for white-space before and after non alphanumeric characters.

  ```
  String.replicate 42" "
  if Seq.exists((<>)'@')s then
  if(Seq.exists((<>)'@')s)then
  ```
- In case you need to left or right pad a string with spaces, you can use [s]printf[n] flags for that.

  ```
  > sprintf "%20s" "Hello, World!";;
  val it : string = "       Hello, World!"
  ```

  [Core.Printf Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.printf-module-[fsharp]#remarks)

Answer (score 4):

## Use id instead of x->x

id is an operator standing for the identity function.

```
let u x=x|>Seq.countBy (fun x->x)
```

can be written

```
let u x=x|>Seq.countBy id
```

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.id%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

I use it [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147073/15214)

Answer (score 3):

## Eta-conversion for functions

Many thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni) for this tip in one of [my solutions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165246/78954).

Consider a function to, say, sum a string with 3 for upper-case letters and 1 for all other characters. So:

```
let counter input = Seq.sumBy (fun x -> if Char.IsUpper x then 3 else 1) input
```

By [eta-conversion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eta_conversion) this can be re-written as:

```
let counter = Seq.sumBy (fun x -> if Char.IsUpper x then 3 else 1)
```

and called in the same way as before:

```
counter "Hello world!" |> printfn "%i"
```

## The function forward-composition operator `>>`

Now suppose our original challenge would be to sum a string with 3 for upper-case letters and 1 for lower-case letters, and all other characters are excluded.

We might write this as:

```
let counter input = Seq.filter Char.IsLetter input |> Seq.sumBy (fun x -> if Char.IsUpper x then 3 else 1)
```

We can use the forward-composition operator (`>>`) to chain the two functions (`Seq.filter` and `Seq.sumBy`) together. With eta-conversion the function definition would become:

```
let counter = Seq.filter Char.IsLetter >> Seq.sumBy (fun x -> if Char.IsUpper x then 3 else 1)
```

Chris Smith did a great write-up on the `>>` operator on his [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrsmith/2008/06/14/function-composition/).

Answer (score 3):

## Prefer new line string over "\n"

This will start to pay off at even a single new line character in your code. One use case might be:

#### (18 bytes)

```
string.Concat"\n"
```

#### (17 bytes)

```
string.Concat"
"
```

Inspired from [Chiru's answer for es6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54368/15214).

Used [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180139/15214)

Answer (score 2):

## Use .NET

.NET offers a lot of nice builtins. F# can use them, so dont forget them!

Example:

```
open System.Linq
```

It can be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid parenthesis when using one parameter and on tuple

```
let f = [(0,1);(1,4)]|>Seq.map(fst)
printfn "%A" f
```

can be written

```
let f = [0,1;1,4]|>Seq.map fst
printfn "%A" f
```

Comment: You also don't need () around tuples:

let f=[0,1;1,4]|>Seq.map fst

Answer (score 2):

When possible `Seq` is shorter than `List`:

```
[[1];[2;3];[4];[5]|>List.collect
```

```
[[1];[2;3];[4];[5]|>Seq.collect
```

is one char shorter...

Answer (score 2):

## Use for...to instead of for...in to walk a range

```
for i in[0..2]
for i=0 to 2
```

- [for in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/loops-for-in-expression)
- [for to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/loops-for-to-expression)

Answer (score 2):

The `module` keyword can be used to shorten module names when used repeatedly. For example:

```
Array.fold ...
Seq.iter ...
List.map ...
```

can become

```
module A=Array
A.fold ...
module S=Seq
S.iter ...
module L=List
L.map ...
```

This is more useful for longer programs where module methods are used repeatedly (and must be fully named each time because they have the `RequireQualifiedAccess` modifier), and allows shaving a few chars off especially when it's more useful to use a regular CLR array (e.g., mutability) than an F# `seq` or `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Use lambdas to save a byte. For example, this:

```
let f x=x*x
```

Can be expressed as this:

```
fun x->x*x
```