# multiplication table in javascript

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

This javascript code:
`for(x=1;x<6;x++)for(y=1;y<6;y++)console.log((y==1?'\n':'')+x+'*'+y+'='+x*y);`

prints the following:

```
1*1=1
1*2=2
1*3=3
1*4=4
1*5=5

2*1=2
2*2=4
2*3=6
2*4=8
2*5=10

3*1=3
3*2=6
3*3=9
3*4=12
3*5=15

4*1=4
4*2=8
4*3=12
4*4=16
4*5=20

5*1=5
5*2=10
5*3=15
5*4=20
5*5=25
```

2 questions:

- Is there a smaller (in bytes) way to do the same?
- What is the smallest code that can do the same without using 2 `for` statements?

Comment: Before the downvotes and close votes come in: [**this is on-topic**](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724/8478)

Comment: @MartinBüttner which doesn't change the fact that this is technically a language-specific challenge ;-)

Comment: Why are there two blocks of `1`s, two blocks of `3`s, and no block of `2`s or `4`s? I don't think that's what the code outputs...

Comment: At least in firebug console, the part (y==1?'\n':'') has no effect (no blank lines to separate runs).

Comment: @edc65 That is because both Chrome and Firebug print the actual value instead of the string representation as Firefox does.

Comment: @jan Dvorak: you are right. There is a bug with my code.

Comment: I hope you actually require multiplication tables of 1 through 5 instead of what your example output says ...

Comment: @Optimizer: Yes, thanks. It was a bad initial paste. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

### Single for loop, <s>80 75 72</s> 68 bytes

I will try to make the code smaller too, but as far as single for loop goes:

```
for(i=5;i<30;)console.log(k=i/5|0,"*",l=i%5+1,"=",k*l,++i%5?"":"\n")
```

Try it in your console! (Although IE gives the best results)

Comment: Don't forget to include the code length in the header

Comment: "Is there a smaller (in bytes) way to do the same?" -- so, it surely is code-golf

Comment: Should I add it?

Comment: There. It's tagged code-golf now.

Comment: Try in your MSIE console! In chrome and firefox and firebug the output is very different... (no problem for me, just to make it clear)

Comment: Yeah, There is a discussion going wrt Fx Devtools to remove the quotes, then it will be equivalent to MSIE. Chrome and Firebug are both buggy though ...

Comment: Assigning and printing the result (`k=i/5|0`) is a neat trick. Thanks.

Comment: @cherouvim - Yeah, there are many other tricks that you can find at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/tips-for-golfing-in-ecmascript-6/ and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript