# Tips for golfing in CoffeeScript

Tags: code-golf, tips

What tricks do you know to make CoffeeScript code shorter?

CoffeeScript is language that compiles into JavaScript ("transpiles" into ES3, to be exact). The golden rule is "It's just JavaScript", meaning there's no runtime overhead. Most of JavaScript Tips & Tricks apply as well.

As a side-effect that also means: developers coming from JavaScript (including myself) tend to use JavaScript constructs instead of shorter CoffeeScript alternatives.

**This thread focuses on tips specific to CoffeeScript.**

Links to related topics:

[Tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2682/42702)

[Tips for Golfing in ECMAScript 6 and above](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37624/42702)

Comment: Can coffeescript compile to ES6? Is it compatible?

Comment: @proudhaskeller It compiles into ES3 in general, with one exception: if you `yield`, it compiles into ES6 generator. Otherwise it tries to be as browser-compliant as possible.

Answer (score 3):

## Use destructuring assignments, if structure elements are used often

Eg. get elements of first argument array

```coffee
func = ([x,y,z])->
    [i,j] = doSomething x, y, x+y
    doSomethingElse i, j

# instead of

func = (a)->
    b = doSomething a[0], a[1], a[0]+a[1]
    doSomethingElse b[0], b[1]
```

This can be combined with splats

```coffee
[first, rest..., last] = doSmth()
```

Comment: It may be better if you separate each tip into a separate answer :)

Comment: @BetaDecay Deal.

Answer (score 2):

### Short-circuit evaluation in place of ternary operator

CoffeeScript does not have JavaScript's [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx) `?`, however the functionality of [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) can sometimes be used instead:

```coffee
foo = a && b || c

# Long form:
foo = if a then b else c
```

Is somewhat equivalent to in JavaScript:

```js
foo = a ? b : c
```

It will **not** work if b is (or can evaluate to) a falsy value such as `0`.

Answer (score 2):

### Integer division operator `//`

Saves up to 10 bytes by avoiding the need to floor numbers when dividing.

Using the `//` operator:

```coffee
foo = 61/3                 # foo = 20.333333333333332
foo = Math.floor 61/3      # foo = 20 (15 bytes)
foo = 61/3|0               # foo = 20 (6 bytes)
foo = 61//3                # foo = 20 (5 bytes)
```

Compared to JavaScript:

```js
foo = 61/3                // foo = 20.333333333333332
foo = Math.floor(61/3)    // foo = 20 (16 bytes)
foo = 61/3|0              // foo = 20 (6 bytes)
```

Comment: `(61/3|0)` works just as well for vanilla JS.

Comment: @ETHproductions I've added it into the post to indicate the difference in bytesize

Comment: `//` is actually `a .floor()`, so it works differently for negative numbers:
`foo = -61//3   # -21`, while `foo = -61/3|0 # -20`

Comment: You can also use `//1` for a plain floor.

Answer (score 2):

## Space is fun. Space is significant for calling functions

```coffee
a=b[i]  # get i-th element of array b
a=b [i] # a = b( [i] ) # pass [i] to function b

m=n+k   # simple math
m=n +k  # m = n( +k ) # convert k to number and pass to function n
m=n -k  # m = n( -k ) # pass -k to function n
m=n + k # simple math again


a(b c)+d   # a( b( c ) ) + d
a (b c)+d  # a( b( c ) + d )
a (b c) +d # a( b( c )( +d ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

## Omit parentheses when possible

```coffee
func1 func2 func3(a),func3 b

#instead of

func1(func2(func3(a),func3(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Not `null` but possibly falsy (`0`, `NaN`, `""`, `false`, etc.)

If you need to check if a variable is defined and not `null`, use the trailing question mark:

```coffee
alert 'Hello world!'if foo?
```

Compiles to:

```js
if (typeof foo !== 'undefined' && foo !== null) {
    alert('Hello world!')
}
```

This probably won't apply to many code golf entries but might be useful if you need to distinguish from a zero, false, empty string, or other falsy value.

Answer (score 1):

### Exponentiation operator `**`

Saves 9 bytes:

```coffee
foo = 2**6
# foo = 64
```

Compared to JavaScript:

```js
foo = Math.pow(2,6)
// foo = 64
```

Comment: For powers of two, this is irrelevant as `1<<x` is equal to `2**x`

Answer (score 1):

### Searching arrays

Save approximately 8 bytes if you just want to check if an element is in an array, you can use the `in` operator.

```coffee
y = x in['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Compared to alternatives in JavaScript:

```js
y = ~['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].indexOf(x)   // ES5, returns Number
y = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].includes(x)   // ES7, returns boolean
y = ~$.inArray(x,['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) // jQuery, returns Number
```

However in the rare case that you need the index of the element then this trick won't work for you.

Comment: Same applies for searching strings, or detecting if character is in specific set: `b = c in'|-+'`

Answer (score 0):

## Use splats

```coffee
obj.method a, params...

# instead of

obj.method.apply obj, [a].concat params

# especially useful with new objects

obj = new Obj a, params...

# alternative is complicated, unreadable and not shown here.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Safe accessors: `?.` and `func? args...`

Existential operator `?` has many forms and uses. Apart from just checking if variable is set, you can access object methods and properties without prior checking if object is null:

```coffee
obj.property?.method? args...
```

will execute `obj.property.method args...` only if `obj.property` and `obj.property.method` are defined and not null.

Useful if you iterate over several sparse arrays at the same time:

```coffee
arr1[i]?.prop = arr2[i]?.method? args... for i in[0..99]
```