# Roller coaster of numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, random

Write a program that generates a sequence of numbers starting with zero and then 100 random integers between -9 and 9.

That sequence will be displayed like a roller coaster.

Any increasing number in the sequence will go up and any decreasing number will go down

Sample sequence:

```
0 1 8 5 -1 -5 7 1 3 3 4 6 9 -2 ...
```

Sample output

```
                                                9
        8                                   6       -2...
    1       5                           4
0               -1      7       3   3
                    -5      1
```

This is code golf. Shortest code in bytes by November 5th wins.

Comment: [Very similar.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55593/26997)

Comment: Can we use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)?

Comment: This is essentially a special case of the challenge that Calvin's Hobbies linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ruby, 167 bytes

```
l={}
y=p=n=0
101.times{|i|
d/=d.abs if(d=n-p)!=0
l[y-=d]||=Array.new 101," "*4
l[y][i]=n.to_s.ljust 4
p,n=n,rand(18)-9}
puts l.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last).map(&:join)
```

First time golfing Ruby, so I'm sure I'm missing something.