# Get the Systematic Chemical Symbol

Tags: code-golf, string, chemistry

#### Background

The [systematic chemical symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_element_name) is defined as such for \$ 118 < n < 1000 \$:

- The first letter corresponds to the first digit, capitalized.
- The second letter corresponds to the second digit.
- The third letter corresponds to the third digit.

This can be generalized for all \$ n > 0\$:

- For each digit, get the corresponding letter.
- Capitalize the first character.

#### Task

Write a function or full program that takes an integer or a list of digits \$n > 0\$ and returns or prints the corresponding systematic chemical symbol.

```
Digit | Letter
--------------
0     | n
1     | u
2     | b
3     | t
4     | q
5     | p
6     | h
7     | s
8     | o
9     | e
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so ***shortest code wins.***

#### Test Cases

```
In - Out
----------
119 - Uue
120 - Ubn
123 - Ubt
999 - Eee
6859 - Hope
1 - U
92 - Eb
987654321 - Eoshpqtbu
1010101 - Unununu
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element names above 118](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60208/element-names-above-118)

Comment: @pppery That challenge requires getting the entire name, rather than just the abbreviation; answers from this challenge could not easily be ported over to fit that one, and so, in my view, this isn't a duplicate

Comment: Duplicate vote retracted.

Comment: Presumably the input will never have leading `0`s, if we can take it as an integer?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `987654321 -> Eoshpqtbu`?

Comment: Shouldn't 92 -> Eb ?

Comment: @AZTECCO yeah it should be

Comment: @Noodle9 yes [10 chars]

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing no leading 0s in either case (integers or list of digits)

Comment: I was planning to post the Mathematica built-in answer `#~ElementData~"Abbreviation"&`, but you changed the lower bound from 118 to 0 (and it would print the actual names for small inputs) :(.

Comment: 121031 -> Ubuntu

Comment: 5680928836 -> Phonebooth

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

Input is a list of digits.

```
.•*Š"—Êo•sèJ™
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDIq2jC5QeNUw53JUP5BQfXuH1qGXR///RhjoKQGQZCwA) or [Try all cases!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRf@V/vUcMiraMLlB41TDnclQ/kFB9e4fWoZdF/nf/R0YY6hjqWsTpA2kjHAEobA2lLHUuwuJmOhY4pRAVY1AhMWuiY65gBxU10jIHqDcH6DHTgODYWAA)

**Commented:**

```
.•*Š"—Êo•      # compressed alphabet string "nubtqphsoe"
         s     # swap to implicit input
          è    # index each digit into the string
           J   # join into a single string
            ™  # apply title case
```

See the step-by-step output [here](https://tio.run/##Zcw9CsJAEAXg3lMMKSXY@IMKYu8VxGKyWZIJ6@6SWVG7FFbWHkBSeY/gRXKRdVFiQF/34HvPMCYkvR@1VT183qO2ujVXEwpEwuxtKZllCqhsjol0wK4knS0hGk@K9WrA0CXiI1pwBmhvFQlyQNoe3Fc2j56STuUJJIocUsreNAxdLn/vN/2mMKQ/DoGDUX@4vdQ9R2vVGRy54ASy7JT321kM8ximMSx2Lw).

---

[Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal) has suggested another 13-byter with a nicer input format:

```
.•*Š"—Êo•ÅвJ™
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDIq2jC5QeNUw53JUP5BxuvbDJ61HLov//zSxMLQE)

This uses `Åв`, which converts the input integer into the custom base defined by the string.

Comment: [Alternate 13 byter](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDIq2jC5QeNUw53JUP5BxuvbDJ61HLov//zSxMLQE "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @Lyxal Thats the first time I've seen `Åв` used, very nice!

Comment: @Lyxal D'oh! I can apply that to Charcoal, saving me 2 bytes!

Comment: You could get another 13 bytes alternative using the transliterate builtin: [`žh.•*Š"—Êo•‡™`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4MvUcNi7SOLlB61DDlcFc@kPOoYeGjlkX//xsaWgIA).

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
f(h:t)="NUBTQPHSOE"!!h:map("nubtqphsoe"!!)t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7LasMwELzrKxTTQwIbkOzYsQK5FAw59EmaUzDFNnJV6shKJf1@1ZVaSllWMzszi1Z19kNOUwjjUu3cap89nG5fnp8Ox8cmWyzU7tKZZaZ9765G2VmitnLBSeteh85KS/f0fObAQbSAmAP7xQKRAUtzBTWUPwlsAXl6a9hChfoGCszztMfgr9uWXLp3jR/gCffUeHd0n3ea3sSZjoj/rgicC7qmJy8Jz1lkvUZWJOaIENFtpCRVXUZ6mA0mo0tEHq2eiHpblZsij2ozW2WurveEs1QxqX0s8jWMU/dmw3ow5hs)

Input is a list of digits. Yes, the code really just writes out the string once in uppercase and a second time in lowercase. This kludge seems shorter than other things I tried. Haskell without imports doesn't have built-ins to capitalize and is really clumsy in working with characters.

**43 bytes**

```hs
zipWith(!!)$"NUBTQPHSOE":repeat"nubtqphsoe"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5Na8MwDL37V7ihhw1UsJ0mjQe9DAI97JO27NCG4gRnCUsdt7Yv@/Hz7GyMIaT3pPeE1AnzIYfBt@uj/@z1W2@7m9nsdp487e93ry@b7XOZ3F2llsImytX2ojszysRbaeypEUYavMaHAwUKvIKADMgvpgEJkKnPoYDsxxGSA5tqASvIw3wJafDTaY/AX1YVOotehQNnoR@xdnZrrw8Kz2OP24D/vvCUcrzAeycRZSSyWgWWTswizqNaSonyIot0M@rgjCriLEo14sUqz5Ypi9NyNJ2@2NohSqaITuVioK@mHcS78YtG628)

Taking [Lynn's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214057/20260) and making it more boring. We can also write:

**43 bytes**

```hs
zipWith(!!)$"NUBTQPHSOE":l
l="nubtqphsoe":l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7LasMwELzrKxSTQwMbkOTYsQq@FAw59BXS0ENqim3k2lSRlUq@9OOrSmopZdmd2ZkR2qEx70JK15cv7nPUz6MdrhaL1TK5P9487R93h4cquZZIlomaW3vRg5mEF5wVxr52jREGl/h0okCB1@CRAfnF1CMBEvccCsh@Er45sDgL2ELu9Q2kPk/jOwJ/Xdfo3IzKf3Bu9B3Wsz3Yj1uFl2HHvcd/VzhKOV7j4ywQZSSwVnmWRmYR58GthEB5kQW6m7RPBhdxFqwW8WKbZ5uUBbWazKAvtp0RJbFCUs2h0FfXy@bNuHWn9Tc)

**47 bytes**

```hs
(%0)
(h:t)%i=["NUBTQPHSOE"!!h..]!!i:t%32
_%_=""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7baoNAEH3fr1ilQgKTsJdo3IAvBSEPvZLmyYqorFVqzLa7/n7t7raUMsycM3POMNPX@l2O49Jlr8sqImu06g9mHQ1ZET6cb1@en46nxzwMgn67LYNgOJiIM1RFVRaGi5HaVG2tpcYZLgoKFEQJFhmQX@QWCRDfJ5BC/OOwKYD5msIeEjvfAbd@6vcI/GVZoks9TPbApVb3WM3mZD7vJnzjetxZ/PfFQqnAG3yeJaKMONZMlnHPDBLCqbmUKEljR49XZZ1ORYI5qUEi3SfxjjM3za@6Vx@mmRElPpxzml2gr7Yb6ze9bFqlvgE)

Based off [Lynn's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214057/20260). Handles the capitalization by passing in an offset `i` of 0 initially, then updating it to 32 in each recursive function call.

It doesn't seem like Haskell has a nice function to title-case a string even with imports, which are probably too lengthy anyway to be competitive. The below with `Data.Text` doesn't work because it operates on `Text` not `[Char]`. `Data.Char` only has `toUpper` to capitalize a single character.

*44 bytes (non-working)*

```hs
import Data.Text
toTitle.map("NUBTQPHSOE"!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5Na8MwDL37V7hlhw3UYjtNGh96KQv0sE@ankoYTnDXsHx4tQL79fNsr4whpPek94R0VvZDd51zbW/GC9J7hWpZ6i8kOJYtdnrZK3M7fzpsy9eX3f65mM9mdw61xbdGWW3phh6PHDjICjwKYFdMPDJgsc8gh/TX4VOCiDWHNWR@voLE@3ncY/CXVUV61Q7@gP/gkZoJ93h5GOhN6OnJ478vHOeSLuhh0oQLFlg9eJZEhkTKoBZakyxPA92NxjuDSqQIUk1kvs7SVSLCtBjt2XxiPRHOYgTnMIUg382pU@/WLRpjfgA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ị“ubtqphsoen”Œt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7u5HDXNKk0oKCzKK81PzHjXMPTqp5L/L4fZHTWsi//@3tDA3MzUxNjLUUTA0tAQSRgYgwhgA)

Inputs as a list of digits, which the Footer does for you.

As it appears the string can't be compressed, this is likely to be the shortest approach in Jelly

### How it works

```
ị“ubtqphsoen”Œt - Main link. Takes a list l on the left
 “ubtqphsoen”   - Yield the string “ubtqphsoen”
ị               - For each digit in l, index into the string (1-indexing)
             Œt - Title case (capitalise the first character)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>80</s> <s>72</s> 56 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to Kirill L.

-16 bytes thanks to Giuseppe.

```r
sub("(.)","\\U\\1",chartr("0-9","nubtqphsoe",scan()),,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0SUNJQ09TSUcpJiY0JsZQSSc5I7GopEhDyUDXEiiaV5pUUliQUZyfqqRTnJyYp6GpqaMTovnf0sLczNTE2MjwPwA)

First we translate the digits to the relevant letters thanks to `chartr`, then `sub` switches the first letter to upper case. This last part is possible thanks to the option `perl = T`, a nice trick found by Giuseppe.

Also, note that all the functions are vectorized the way we need them to be, so we can handle several inputs at a time, which is rather unusual in R golf with `scan()`.

Comment: You can use `0-9` shortcut in `chartr`. Also, I tried titlecasing with utf-int conversions, but apparently it only saves 1 more byte and does not vectorize as nicely: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2tCTNIiTfM69EIzkjsaikSEPJQNdSSUcprzSppLAgozg/VUmnODkxT0NTU9O6Itow1hZE6BobWWfmlYTkhwK1a1Ro/jc0tOQyNDIAYmMuS0tLLjMLU6AAl6URl6WFuZmpibGRIZehARj@BwA)

Comment: @KirillL. Neat shortcut, thanks!

Comment: The `x<-` seems redundant so you can save three bytes on the stringr version. The language for that one should probably also be listed as R + stringr package since it’s not just base R.

Comment: @NickKennedy Thanks! Indeed, the `x<-` was left over from the previous version, and the language is R+stringr.

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0SUNJQ09TSUcpJiY0JsZQSSc5I7GopEhDyUDXEiiaV5pUUliQUZyfqqRTnJyYp6GpqaMTovnf0sLczNTE2MjwPwA) in base R using `perl=T`. I've never been able to use that flag as a golf, but reading through the docs for `sub` reveals this hidden gem: "For `perl = TRUE` only, it can also contain `"\U"` or `"\L"` to convert the rest of the replacement to upper or lower case"

Comment: Bonus: it's also vectorized.

Comment: @Giuseppe Beautiful, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input as a digit array, output as a character array.

```
mg`eo¢pqt¿n`w)vu
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bWdgZW%2bicHF0v25gdyl2dQ&input=WzEsMSw5XQ)

```
mg`...`w)vu     :Implicit input of digit array
m               :Map
 g              :  Index (0-based) into
  `...`         :    Compressed string "eoshpqtbun"
       w        :    Reversed
        )       :End map
         v      :Modify first element
          u     :  Uppercase
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
⭆⍘Ｎnubtqphsoe⎇κι↥ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaDglFqdCeBqeeQWlJX6luUmpRRqaOgpKeaVJJYUFGcX5qUpAbkhqUV5iUaVGto5Cpo5CaEFBalEyUK9GpiYQWP//b2ZhavlftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Lyxal's comment on @ovs's answer. Explanation:

```
  Ｎ                 Input number
 ⍘                  Custom base conversion using
   nubtqphsoe       Literal string
⭆                   Map over characters
              κ     Current index
             ⎇      If not first character then
               ι    Current character
                ↥ι  Else uppercased character
                    Implicitly print
```

Comment: It's great when I manage to inadvertently provide golfing suggestions for other answers!

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
zipWith(\i d->["NUBTQPHSOE"!!d..]!!i)$0:k
k=32:k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzvyqzIDyzJEMjJlMhRdcuWskv1CkkMMAj2N9VSVExRU8vVlExU1PFwCqbK9vW2Mgq@39uYmaebUFRZl6JRppCtKGOkY6xjomOaazm/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>20</s></sup> 17 bytes

```
§:oa←tm!¨Ḃ+q²"ṗen
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9odXNr///CpzpvYeKGkHRtIcKo4biCK3HCsiLhuZdlbv///1sxLDEsOV0)

input as a list of digits.

There's probably a better way to do the titlecasing part.

-3 bytes from Dominic van Essen.

### Explanation (old)

```
§:oa←tmo!¨nḂ+q²"ṗe¨→
                   → increment input to accomodate 0-indexing
      mo             map each digit to
        !¨nḂ+q²"ṗe¨  it's index value in the compressed string
§:                   join the
  oa←                first letter uppercased
     t               with it's tail
```

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9odXNr///CpzpvYeKGkHRtIcKo4biCK3HCsiLhuZdlbv///1sxLDEsOV0) anyway, without managing to improve the titlecasing...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen ah, circular indexing.

Comment: Would base conversion help? It's already been exercised in 2 answers already and it helped save two bytes for Neil.

Comment: @Lyxal Husk doesn't have custom base conversion, from what I know.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
lambda a:"".join("nubtqphsoe"[x]for x in a).title()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEADAq4hfCktQ9oZOUn0oJRm1mm1Qp7eZ8NHmUSU7TOnQp1k00z3n2e4dCo6PoStst1/5@M7WR/Yyh0zLjBwdq5ApRIckrBg7aKGBGiooQUEB@Sxl@gE)

---

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 42 bytes

```python
a=>"".join("nubtqphsoe"[x]for x:a).title()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEADAq4RfCovQ@wF2EfHDQMkI12wDb28zKSNhrF5Vq3bG5IUhcha/g550vuiYLsZjbspmhaRAt@Oiphwicc/1CgvMMMEIA/TQQWuEqD8)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>51</s> 49 bytes

Apparently I can get rid of the customary "assign to first parameter" because I only care about a false/non-false answer from this function. Interesting to know!

```c
f(n){n&&putchar("nubtqphsoe"[n%10]^32*!f(n/10));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7bCoJAEIbvfYpJKHY90O6apiw@iRhsWx6gVvNQF@Krt40xzMD3Mfz8Oqy1trYihi7mcOjnSTdqIK6Zr9Orb8bu7hZmz1l5iYS3w7cjZ5TK1bZmgqdqDXl37Y3C4gBsSg1DUeYL51kAXLDtRAFkGWKSxptEErjpOYlPkUDk7D8BsDUAT@UYIR2Mq7qBSBQSsNVIXJdSqIinfJ9KZ7VfXT1UPdrw8wM)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 37 bytes

```ruby
p$_.tr("0-9","nubtqphsoe").capitalize
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchNCoAgEEDh/RxDWhSUOPY7pwmLICHU0hZ1@KaIx7d5xzldzCEbZTpyoSoSpXDnlPawRr@IQs4m2GQ2ey/MiASo1acGIoJuaL8BpIGGvmubWiOg@nt8SNa7yJXbXg)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 27 bytes

```perl
y/0-9/nubtqphsoe/;$_="\u$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79S30DXUj@vNKmksCCjOD9V31ol3lYpplQlXun/f0NDSy5DIwMgNuaytLTkMrMwBQpwWRpxWVqYm5maGBsZchkagOG//IKSzPy84v@6BQA)

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79S30DXUj@vNKmksCCjOD9V31olPs5WRen/f0NDSy5DIwMgNuaytLTkMrMwBQpwWRpxWVqYm5maGBsZchkagOG//IKSzPy84v@6BQA)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul – Nice! I thought about bit fiddling, but that didn't came to mind.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54 bytes

Expects an array of digits.

```javascript
a=>a.map((c,i)=>"nNuUbBtTqQpPhHsSoOeE"[c*2+!i]).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBND4IgGMDxe5@iOmk9mdmrBz20tXXqZeWptQVEZTOgkL4@YZutiTBuv/H84Y7eSJJXKvIe42eqL5FGUYy8BxKOQyB1o7jNVirB83z/3IrNbSl3fE0X7QPpBN1WenS9O0/Z6aQJZ5Jn1Mv41bk4hwEMIDy6bvN/9fvNRNGGRQPw6yhmdXRYS/MqDSGsDVhQK2ACMxhXsaFLLuzY6pVlgT0/sKmBK2zLGUxhYhJGMDQP/I4oSrm8iWeOlf0LPvxOOaRoYKrY@gM)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
«/
∨+Ċ≤«βǐ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%AB%2F%0A%E2%88%A8%2B%C4%8A%E2%89%A4%C2%AB%CE%B2%C7%90&inputs=999&header=&footer=)

I finally turned my suggested 13 byte 05AB1E answer into a Vyxal answer.

### Explained

```python
«...«βǐ
«...«    # the string "nubtqphsoe"
     β   # convert the input to bijective-base 10 using the above string as the alphabet
      ǐ  # titlecase that result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 26 bytes

```
T`d`nubtq\p\hs\oe
T`l`L`^.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyQhJSGvNKmkMKYgJqM4Jj@VKyQhJ8EnIU7v/39DQ0suQyMDIDbmsrS05DKzMAUKcFkacVlamJuZmhgbGXIZGoAhAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`d`nubtq\p\hs\oe
```

Translate each digit to the appropriate letter. The letters `h`, `o` and `p` have special meaning, so they need to be quoted.

```
T`l`L`^.
```

Translate the first letter to upper case.

Comment: christ that speed

Comment: The symbols' first character needs to be capitalized, as per the spec

Comment: @bigyihsuan oh sorry, there's a bug in the test suite

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
~{"nubtqphsoe"1/=}%()[32-]|\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v65aKa80qaSwIKM4P1XJUN@2VlVDM9rYSDe2Jub//2gzBQsFUwXLWAA)

Input as a digit array.

```
~                             # Parse the input to an array         [6 8 5 9]
 {               }%           # For each digit
  "nubtqphsoe"1/              # Split each letter of this string    6 ["n" "u" ... "e"]
                =             # Get the corresponding letter        "h"
                   (          # Get the first letter                ["o" "p" "e"] "h"
                    )         # Get the ascii value                 ["o" "p" "e"] "" 104
                      32-     # Subtract 32                         ["o" "p" "e"] "" 72
                     [   ]    # Put it in an array                  ["o" "p" "e"] "" [72]
                          |   # Convert to ascii                    ["o" "p" "e"] "H"
                           \  # Swap the two elements in the stack  "H" ["o" "p" "e"]
                              # Only the strings are outputted      "Hope"
```

Comment: If it helps, you can take input as a list of digits, rather than as a single number

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 39 bytes

Prompts for a character vector of digits with index origin = 0

```
⎕av[(↑n),32+1↓n←⎕av⍳'NUBTQPHSOE'[⍎¨⍕⎕]]
```

Explanation:

```
[⍎¨⍕⎕]] Convert input to individual digits

⎕av⍳'NUBTQPHSOE' Find index positions of all upper case characters in atomic vector
and use result above to select those according to input

(↑n),32+1↓n Concatenate first index to remaining indices + 32 to apply appropriate case

⎕av[...] Use the above indices to select required characters from atomic vector
```

Answer (score 3):

## x86 machine code (MS-DOS .COM format), <s>35</s> 33 bytes

The program will terminate at the end of input from the command line.

For fun, I decided to use `XLAT` to index each digit's representation as the translation array easily fits into an 8-bit index and everything is 1:1.

Byte representation:

```
0000    B4 20 BB 19 01 BE 82 00 AC 2C 0D 74 09 D7 32 C4
0010    CD 29 32 E4 EB F0 C3 6E 75 62 74 71 70 68 73 6F
0020    65
```

Assembly code (TASM):

```
IDEAL

MODEL TINY
CODESEG
ORG 100H

SYMS_M EQU OFFSET SYMS-23H

MAIN:
    MOV AH,20H
    MOV BX,SYMS_M
    MOV SI,82H
VAL:
    LODSB
    SUB AL,0DH
    JZ  QUIT
    XLATB
    XOR AL,AH
    INT 29H
    XOR AH,AH
    JMP VAL
QUIT:
    RET

SYMS DB "nubtqphsoe"

END MAIN
ENDS
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>47</s> 40 bytes

```scala
_+""map(d=>"nubtqphsoe"(d-48))capitalize
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc1NC4JAEIDhu79i8KSE@G1aKHgQ6tCxc@zqioaNa67RB/12ow7bytzmZZ4ZS9KRuadnVgo4kBaB3QXDaoSc85d2Ix3UG9ijgDSDHB@QzqeVrl8IN6o003GiYuDN2DPdqKwgNs2S8FaQrn2yeavxa4uiQ6M2XDcxTbBtsOA4MTV4jgwUF8H/B6GEJJFUwVQqikNZdj1ffJGUCnnSoeo6Xkdh4HvypujHhg@CTiro/EayOH1He88f)

- -7 Thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)!

Comment: You can save [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##Vc1NC4JAEIDhu79i8KSE@G1aKHgQ6tCxc@zqioaNa67RB/12ow7bytzmZZ4ZS9KRuadnVgo4kBaB3QXDaoSc85d2Ix3UG9ijgDSDHB@QzqeVrl8IN6o003GiYuDN2DPdqKwgNs2S8FaQrn2yeavxa4uiQ6M2XDcxTbBtsOA4MTV4jgwUF8H/B6GEJJFUwVQqikNZdj1ffJGUCnnSoeo6Xkdh4HvypujHhg@CTiro/EayOH1He88f) by using `_` and infix/postfix operators

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 105 bytes

Terrible implementation, it works at least, input is each digit of the number then any other character to terminate. Feel free to suggest any optimisations.

```
~::68*`vnubtqphsoe
 v+4*96_@
 `
@_68*8--0 v
   v        <
v:~<,-*84g<
>:68*` v
 v+4*96_@
 `
@_68*8--0 g,^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v87KysxCK6EsrzSppLAgozg/lUuhTNtEy9Is3oFLIYHLIR4obaGra6BQxqWgoFCmAAU2XGVWdTY6uloWJuk2XHZgQ0BKsOtN14n7/9/MwtQyBQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 29 bytes

```sh
<<<${(C)$(tr 0-9 nubtqphsoe)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpVrDWVNFo6RIwUDXUiGvNKmksCCjOD9Vs/b/fzMLU0sA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>63</s> 60 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)!!!

```c
f(a,l)int*a;{l--&&f(a,l)+putchar("nubtqphsoe"[a[l]]-!l*32);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZPfboIwFIfveYquiYZiyRQUIWy7W7IX8MqRhT91kjBAgcTM8Oyu0FLgDKPAx3d6fi01Nr/j@PE46SHNSJrXRujfM9NcLgVZlU0dn8OrjvMmqi/luSoYPobHLAjMp8ywLeK3D16GfsI014l21xA/OlCzqv4KN8cAvaL7hm6o11IJrQFadK2gPUJbwa2AHvUm5TsBHerS3QQ7cgAF9kOxpZA7IJfuqcPLt9TmDccab0ixpurb@sOkDGkJSc5QzUrNRKVXiVVGlU0lUp3HNoJkokuV/rLipMtm5FneGwOgaGZY0LCgYUPDhsYWGlto7KCxg4YDDQcae2jsoeFCw4WGBw2PyGXsNq2B2K1kcc0SsZT40DBMET5EuTjV3emd9fCjKMXDnkX9b1Gdy0sdNT3Pm@6D5fin4qp3ryrNE3bjg699efkyTwgDEh@tVr1JkPizzPYWH0lusd4J/KmCMpYPQvZPUImSIU/SpeE1fctk1rA7yivXTzpeJFhswiOXAjKO2GpQReYbwhNDzJLyHhOoZH1Rkc9uqdVrEJml22rt4w8)

Inputs a pointer to an array of digits and its length (since there's no way to know how long an array passed into a function as a pointer is in C) and prints the corresponding systematic chemical symbol.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnRzMzr0Qr0bo6R1dXTQ0iol1QWpKckVikoZRXmlRSWJBRnJ@qFJ0YnRMbq6uYo2VspGld@/8/AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online") you can save 3 by using recursion!

Comment: @AZTECCO Very nice - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>264</s> <s>157</s> <s>150</s> 100 bytes

-107 bytes by replacing `if` statements with a JavaScript object to match each number with a corresponding string.

-7 bytes by using ES6 `for` loop through a string, and shorter arrow functions.

-50 bytes by replacing JavaScript Object with ES6 string indexing.

```js
a='';o='nubtqphsoe';x=c=>a+=o[c];for(let e of prompt())x(e);alert(a[0].toUpperCase()+a.substring(1))
```

Comment: I made it shorter (from 157 --> 90) (idk im new, do I comment on this or make a new answer?): `a='';o="nubtqphsoe";[...prompt()].map(n=>a+=o[n]);alert(a[0].toUpperCase()+a.substring(1))`

Comment: Also just got rid of another 4 characters: `a='';o="nubtqphsoeNUBTQPHSOE";[...prompt()].map((n,i)=>a+=o[Number(n)+!i*10]);alert(a)`

Comment: So I kept finding ways to condense this, with `alert([...prompt()].map((n,i)=>"nNuUbBtTqQpPhHsSoOeE"[n*2+!i]).join\`\`)`, and then I realized this is very similar to @Arnauld's answer, which I guess happens on CodeGolf eventually

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 41 bytes

```
V.T,.T]."buÞ“;UØ".T]."09I–Ò"=:zeNhN;rz3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0wvREcvJFZPKamU4/C8Q5OtQw/PUAILGFh6HprGdHiSkq1VVapfhp91UZXx//9mFqaWAA)

### Explanation

The main part of the program is `.T,.T]."buÞ“;UØ".T]."09I–Ò"`, which returns the list `[['u', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['t', '3'], ..., ['n', '0']]`. `."buÞ“;UØ"` is the packed string `ubtqphsoen`, and `."09I–Ò"` is the packed string `1234567890`. `.T]` splits them into characters, and `.T,` zips them together.

## Pyth, 24 bytes

```
Vz=+k@."bu\nL‘"vN;rk3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P6zKVjvbQU8pqZSNIybP59BEcaUyP@uibOP//80sTC0B)

This one is a port of [HyperNeutrino's Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214049/91569).

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v6jYwUdPKamUjYPL59BEcaVA4///o810LHRMdSxjAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 24 bytes

```
q~{"nubtqphsoe"1/=}%(eu\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7CuWimvNKmksCCjOD9VyVDftlZVI7U05v//aAMFCwUzIDZVsFQwVzAGsiwUjIAsEM8cyDaIBQA)

Input in the form of a digit array string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 29 bytes

```
*.trans(^10=>'nubtqphsoe').tc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfS6@kKDGvWCPO0MDWTj2vNKmksCCjOD9VXVOvJPm/tUJxYqWCkkq8gq2dQnWagkp8rZJCWn6Rgo2hoaWCoZEBEBsrWFpa2v0HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <del>142</del> <del>100</del> 94 bytes

```powershell
$k=[string]$args;0..9|%{$k=$k.replace([string]$_,'nubtqphsoe'[$_])};get-culture|% t*o|% *se $k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXbNrq4pCgzLz1WJbEovdjaQE/Pska1Giiukq1XlFqQk5icqgFXEq@jnleaVFJYkFGcn6oerRIfq1lrnZ5aoptcmlNSWpRao6pQopUPJLWKUxVUsv///29oaAkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 101 bytes

Map a digit to its respective letter.

```
Class D {\0,\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9}
a:
@D=>{N,U,B,T,Q,P,H,S,O,E}/$ _
@D=>{n,u,b,t,q,p,h,s,o,e}
```

Answer (score 1):

### bash + coreutils, <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```bash
c=`tr 0-9 nubtqphsoe<<<$1`
echo ${c^}
```