# Cat goes "Meow"

Tags: code-golf

## `cat` goes  "Meow"

We are all familiar with the concept of a `cat` program. The user types something in, it is echoed back to the user. Easy. But all `cat` programs I've seen so far have missed one fact: a `cat` goes "Meow". So your task is to write a program that copies all `STDIN` to `STDOUT` **UNLESS** the input is `cat`, in which case your program should output `cat goes "Meow"`.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so your score is your byte count, with a few modifiers:

- If your program works for any additional animals other than `cat` (e.g. `cow: cow goes "Moo"`), for each additional animal: -10
- If your program doesn't use the word "cat": -15
- If your program responds to `fox` with "What does the fox say": -25

#### Animals and sounds that go together:

`cow goes moo`
`duck goes quack`
`sheep goes baa`
`bees go buzz`
`frogs go croak`

Anything else on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_sounds) is allowed.

### Rules

- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply
- You must not write anything to `STDERR`
- You can use single quotes/no quotes instead of double quotes.

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=62500;var OVERRIDE_USER=46470;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(-?\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: For the bonuses: What does the fox say?

Comment: For the bonuses: can each additional animal be singular, or does "bees" always have to be plural, as in your list?

Comment: @ProgramFOX It doesn't matter.

Comment: Should this replace each line (or word?) individually, or only the whole input? (I.e. if the input is `cat\nduck`, should the output be the same or `cat goes meow\nduck goes quack`?

Comment: [Cats say meow.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndsaoMFz9J4).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Only if the input is only the animal (your input would output `cat\nduck`).

Comment: Instead of double quotes, can you use single ones? Also, can you output to stderr?

Comment: Can it be a function, and can it take command line args instead?

Comment: @muddyfish Um... I didn't write the snippet myself, but I'll have a look.

Comment: @muddyfish No idea, sorry.

Comment: [Why is there no link to this in this challenge?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE)

Comment: You can use single quotes, but can't output to `STDERR`

Comment: I'm going to revise bonuses.

Comment: @Dennis - Yeah, sorry, that was my suggestion, but I wasn't expecting he'd actually change it this late in the game.  That was more of a recommendation for future challenges.  Admittedly, the old scoring method was subject to serious abuse, since a longer program could easily get a lower score, which is very un-golf-like...

Comment: @Dennis Point taken, I'll rollback. Didn't think it would have so great an effect.

Comment: Is [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82699/53917) eligible for the -15 bonus?

Answer (score 18):

### Pyth, 231-255 = -24 bytes

#### -24*10 extra animals, -15 for no "cat" string

```
pzI}zJv.Z"xÚ]ArÃ E¯âñMOÛ|°
Ø¢mÞ½`&ÉR¯'_ãPÍm1;ñÝ|,F ¹×z#½öÂ÷ÜAPúõMh#Ì©UOC *CÑ°k%¹ö´qÌzj,å<&{jàRFÖ(¥s    ñ`GÂ:çkô#ù\M+üqíéaw ÑuW6Lã,¶w/'87ö×_r]¢:jkz»ÚFÙ¦ÈcÅËØíëûÖOa¿Þµ´6 ø¡ãEþþ:"jk(" goes "N@JzN
```

[Link to code](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=pzI%7DzJv.Z%22x%C3%9A%5D%C2%90Ar%C3%83+%0CE%C2%AF%C3%A2%C3%B1%C2%86MO%C2%90%C3%9B%7C%C2%B0%0A%0C%C3%98%C2%A2%12m%16%C2%9D%C3%9E%C2%BD%60%26%C2%89%C3%89R%C2%8F%C2%AF%27%C2%89_%C3%A3P%C3%8Dm1%3B%C3%B1%C3%9D%7C%2CF%09%C2%B9%C3%97%16%C2%92z%C2%9D%23%1F%C2%BD%C3%B6%C3%82%C3%B7%C3%9CA%C2%80P%07%C3%BA%C3%B5Mh%11%23%C3%8C%C2%A9%C2%83%10UOC+*C%C2%81%C3%91%C2%B0k%25%C2%B9%C3%B6%C2%B4q%C3%8Czj%2C%C3%A5%3C%26%7B%C2%81j%C3%A0RF%C3%96%C2%85%28%C2%A5s%09%C3%B1%60G%C3%82%3A%C3%A7k%C3%B4%23%C3%B9%5CM%2B%C3%BC%C2%9Cq%C3%AD%C3%A9%C2%94a%1Cw+%C3%91uW%17%1D6L%C3%A3%2C%C2%B6w%2F%27%C2%948%C2%8B7%C3%B6%C3%97_r%12%5D%C2%A2%3A%C2%89jkz%C2%BB%C3%9AF%C3%99%C2%A6%C2%8C%16%C3%88c%C3%85%07%C3%8B%C3%98%C3%AD%C3%AB%C3%BB%C3%96Oa%C2%BF%C3%9E%C2%96%C2%B5%C2%9D%C2%82%C2%B46+%C3%B8%C2%A1%C3%A3E%C3%BE%C3%BE%01%C2%8E%07%C2%89%3A%22jk%28%22+goes+%22N%40JzN&input=cat&debug=0)

Pseudocode

```
Auto assign z to input
print z
J = decompress animal-sound dict
if z in J:
    print " goes ", J[z], '"'
```

Animals it knows:

```
{'hare': 'squeak', 'seal': 'bark', 'lion': 'growl', 'rook': 'hiss', 'sheep': 'baa', 'hamster': 'squeak', 'moose': 'bellow', 'grasshopper': 'chirp', 'rhinoceros': 'bellow', 'cat': 'meow', 'tiger': 'growl', 'stag': 'bellow', 'crow': 'caw', 'okapi': 'bellow', 'snake': 'hiss', 'cicada': 'chirp', 'badger': 'growl', 'dog': 'bark', 'cricket': 'chirp', 'tapir': 'squeak', 'bird': 'chirp', 'sparrow': 'chirp', 'lamb': 'baa', "frog": "croak", "raven": "croak"}
```

Comment: I feel like the bonus should be -10%, not -10 bytes.  That would give a diminishing return to prevent abuses like this.  (And that's 10% multiplied each time, not 10% of original added up, otherwise you'd only need 10 animals to get a score of 0 no matter how long the code was...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I'll bear that in mind for all future challenges.

Comment: Well, you successfully made my head explode, and I no longer know what the fox says. +1

Comment: The raven goes croak?

Comment: @carusocomputing According to wikipedia it does. I think they go `squalk` myself

Answer (score 7):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 29 - 15 = 14 bytes

Doesn't use string `cat`.

```
xr(/^c\at$/,'$& goes "Meow"')
```

"What does the fox say" (length = 21) is longer than the bonus is worth.

Comment: The fox bonus is now worth it!

Answer (score 7):

## PXLCODE, 114 bytes

I SHOULD GET BONUS BECAUSE THIS IS CAT LANGUAGE RIGHT?

ALSO FEED ME BUTTER

```
HAI 1.3
I HAS A V
GIMMEH V
BOTH SAEM V AN "cat",O RLY?
YA RLY,VISIBLE "cat goes meow"
NO WAI,VISIBLE V
OIC
KTHXBYE
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Go- _wait a second_

Answer (score 7):

## APOL, 34 bytes

`p(¿(=(i "cat") "cat goes meow" ⋔))`

BEEP BOOP I AM NOT A ROBOT

Comment: Once again, I posted this to get this account enough rep to chat.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 12 bytes

```
q_:)"dbu"=" goes \"Meow\""*
```

The program is **27 bytes** bytes long and doesn't use the word `cat` (**-15 bytes**).

Try it inline in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q_%3A)%22dbu%22%3D%22%20goes%20%5C%22Meow%5C%22%22*&input=cat).

#### How it works

```
q_                e# Read all input and push a copy.
:)                e# Increment all code points of the copy.
"dbu"=            e# Push 1/0 if the result is/isn't "dbu".
" goes \"Meow\""* e# Repeat the string that many times.
```

Comment: I like the smiley `:)`

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <strike>45 - 15 = 30</strike> / 264 - 235 = 29

```
alert((s=(d='MeowBuzzSongMooMooCawBarkQuackCroakHissOinkBaaSingRoarLowCooCawBarkBaaHissCryRoarSingC\x61tBeeBirdCattleCowCrowDogDuckFrogHorseHogLambLarkLionOxPigeonRookSealSheepSnakeSwanTigerWhale'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/))[d.indexOf(i=prompt())-23])?i+' goes "'+s+'"':i)
```

**Downside: you have to write the name of the animal with the first letter in uppercase and the rest in lowercase. Look below for another version which fixes this.** This version escapes the `a` in cat with `\x61` and includes code for the 22 extra animals from this list (all the allowed animals which had short enough words to be worth it):

> bee buzz   7
>   bird song  8
>   cattle moo 9
>   cow moo    6
>   crow caw   7
>   dog bark   7
>   duck quack 9
>   frog croak 9
>   horse hiss 9
>   hog oink   7
>   lamb baa   7
>   lark sing  8
>   lion roar  8
>   ox low     5
>   pigeon coo 9
>   rook caw   7
>   seal bark  8
>   sheep baa  8
>   snake hiss 9
>   swan cry   7
>   tiger roar 9
>   whale sing 9

(thanks to my friend for helping me with the tedious task of making this list)

Ungolfed code:

```
data = 'MeowBuzzSongMooMooCawBarkQuackCroakHissOinkBaaSingRoarLowCooCawBarkBaaHissCryRoarSingC\x61tBeeBirdCattleCowCrowDogDuckFrogHorseHogLambLarkLionOxPigeonRookSealSheepSnakeSwanTigerWhale'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);

input = prompt();
index = data.indexOf(input);
sound = data[index-23];
result = sound ? input + ' goes "' + sound + '"' : input;
alert(result);
```

---

### First version, 45 bytes - 15 bonus = 30

```
alert((i=prompt())=='\x63at'?i+' goes "Meow"':i)
```

Yes, I know. I went from 30 to 29 with ALL that extra work. It was fun!

### Version that allows full lowercase input, 294 bytes - 235 bonus = 59

```
alert((s=(d='MeowBuzzSongMooMooCawBarkQuackCroakHissOinkBaaSingRoarLowCooCawBarkBaaHissCryRoarSingC\x61tBeeBirdCattleCowCrowDogDuckFrogHorseHogLambLarkLionOxPigeonRookSealSheepSnakeSwanTigerWhale'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/))[d.indexOf((i=prompt())[0].toUpperCase()+i.slice(1))-23])?i+' goes "'+s+'"':i)
```

I also tried removing casing from the data array with `.join().toLowerCase().split(',')` but it ended up taking 297 characters instead.

Comment: edit: fixed quote marks and capital on meow (although the question isn't consistent with capitals)

Comment: And... my work here is done, proving that the -10 bonus was just enough :)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 28 - 15 = 13 bytes

```
{⍵,' goes "Meow"'/⍨⍵≡⌽'tac'}
```

Input followed by  `goes "Meow"` if input is equivalent to `tac` reversed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///Pzmx5FHbhOpHvVt11BXS81OLFZR8U/PLldT1H/WuAIo@6lz4qGeveklisnotWLWCukdqTk6@jkJ4flFOiqI6F1gMSKgDAA)

`{`…`}` anonymous function

`⌽'tac'` reverse the string (to get the -15 bonus by avoiding the characters `cat`)

`⍵≡` Boolean for whether the argument is identical to that

`' goes "Meow"'/⍨` use that to filter the string (i.e. returns empty string if false)

`⍵,` append to the argument

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>81</s> <s>70</s> <s>55</s> 46 - 15 = 31 bytes

Thanks to Stewie Griffin for saving 15 bytes

Thanks to grc for saving 8 bytes.

Not using the string `cat` gives -15 bytes.

```
y=input()
print(y+' goes "Meow"'*(y=="ca""t"))
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, <s>81 - 20 - 15 = 46 bytes</s> 50 - 15 = 35 bytes

```
(o=prompt()=="ca"+"t")&&o+=' goes "Meow"';alert(o)
```

Comment: You can drop the double-quotes around *Meow*.

Comment: no, that's actually part of the question

Comment: How about `'c\at'` instead of `'ca'+'t'`?

Comment: `alert({'c\at':'c\at goes "Meow"',fox:'What does the fox say'}[a=prompt()]||a)`. Why not even drop the alert? It already returns the result to console.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stack](https://github.com/StackLanguge/stack-language), 51 bytes

```
'' input dup 'cat' = { 'cat goes "meow"' } if print
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 391 -595 = -204 bytes

-58*10 extra animals, -15 for no "cat" string

```
"goes"Q.dt偮晪ꅢὐὥ墵셞᳙ᄷ쟿䁔漲ᬰ䵙ꄨ塋튖თ᠞鮔૪爟㍅爟⼱]꣟勒〥鴞᫠⬻䋥ュ⣹邦㺓堚퀦잓號漲ქ︆䦙ᔯ漲ᠥ쏔っ鮔牔鶇Ƒ䂝雥⬻⯎偮燩巺䯥봽鮔튖➒゗ᨼ䄇嚕㮷鮏ᘽ挳ᖘ漲睴윿꒲⬻鼤㨂ᘽdc2cY@]3J
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%22goes%22Q.dt%F0%9B%A7%B7%E5%81%AE%E6%99%AA%EA%85%A2%E1%BD%90%F0%91%88%B6%E1%BD%A5%F0%91%88%B6%E5%A2%B5%F0%91%88%B6%EC%85%9E%F0%91%88%B6%F0%B8%A3%8C%E1%B3%99%E1%84%B7%EC%9F%BF%E4%81%94%F0%94%A3%A9%F0%95%95%84%E6%BC%B2%F0%94%B5%B8%EE%AF%87%E1%AC%B0%E4%B5%99%EA%84%A8%EE%AF%87%E5%A1%8B%ED%8A%96%F0%B4%8F%B5%E1%83%97%E1%A0%9E%E9%AE%94%E0%AB%AA%E7%88%9F%E3%8D%85%E7%88%9F%E2%BC%B1%5D%EA%A3%9F%E5%8B%92%E3%80%A5%E9%B4%9E%E1%AB%A0%E2%AC%BB%E4%8B%A5%E3%83%A5%E2%A3%B9%F0%93%AB%8C%E9%82%A6%F0%B4%BD%A9%E3%BA%93%F0%92%80%BD%EE%91%8E%F0%93%AB%8C%E5%A0%9A%ED%80%A6%EC%9E%93%EE%AF%87%E8%99%9F%E6%BC%B2%E1%83%A5%EF%B8%86%F0%90%8A%B7%E4%A6%99%E1%94%AF%E6%BC%B2%E1%A0%A5%EC%8F%94%E3%81%A3%E9%AE%94%F0%90%A9%81%E7%89%94%E9%B6%87%C6%91%E4%82%9D%E9%9B%A5%F0%90%BB%B3%E2%AC%BB%E2%AF%8E%E5%81%AE%E7%87%A9%E5%B7%BA%EE%A9%9B%F0%91%B3%A6%E4%AF%A5%F0%92%80%BD%EB%B4%BD%E9%AE%94%EE%BF%A0%ED%8A%96%E2%9E%92%E3%82%97%E1%A8%BC%F0%93%AB%8C%E4%84%87%F0%93%AB%8C%E5%9A%95%F0%93%AB%8C%E3%AE%B7%E9%AE%8F%F0%90%93%A7%E1%98%BD%E6%8C%B3%E1%96%98%F0%AF%83%AE%E6%BC%B2%F0%91%99%8C%F0%92%80%BD%E7%9D%B4%EC%9C%BF%EA%92%B2%E2%AC%BB%F0%A6%BC%8E%E9%BC%A4%E3%A8%82%E1%98%BDdc2cY%40%5D3J&input=hamsters)

Uses dictionary-based compression to store the words. Pyke is older than the question.

Animals it knows:

```
{'seals': 'bark', 'turkeys': 'gobble', 'mosquitos': 'whine', 'curlews': 'pipe', 'dogs': 'howl', 'sheep': 'bleat', 'elephants': 'trumpet', 'eagles': 'scream', 'raccoons': 'trill', 'goats': 'bleat', 'donkeys': 'bray', 'monkey': 'whoop', 'snakes': 'hiss', 'wolves': 'howl', 'grasshoppers': 'chirp', 'ferrets': 'dook', 'geese': 'honk', 'ducks': 'quack', 'chinchillas': 'squeak', 'oxen': 'low', 'pigs': 'snort', 'lions': 'snarl', 'antelopes': 'snort', 'crows': 'caw', 'hamsters': 'squeak', 'ravens': 'croak', 'leopards': 'snarl', 'tapirs': 'squeak', 'lambs': 'bleat', 'horses': 'neigh', 'jaguars': 'snarl', 'crickets': 'chirp', 'moose': 'bellow', 'cattle': 'moo', 'deer': 'bellow', 'rooks': 'caw', 'dolphins': 'click', 'whales': 'sing', 'owls': 'hoot', 'walruses': 'groan', 'cicadas': 'chirp', 'tigers': 'snarl', 'chickens': 'cluck', 'giraffes': 'bleat', 'mice': 'squeak', 'peacocks': 'scream', 'songbirds': 'sing', 'geckos': 'croak', 'frogs': 'croak', 'pigeons': 'coo', 'swans': 'cry', 'bitterns': 'boom', 'rhinoceros': 'bellow', 'cats': 'purr', 'badgers': 'growl', 'magpies': 'chatter', 'vultures': 'scream', 'elk': 'bleat'}
```

Comment: Why is this marked as noncompetitive?

Comment: At the time of writing, there was a rule where languages older than the question were non-competing

Comment: languages *older* than the question? or languages *newer* than the question? because im pretty sure it was the latter :P either way, you can take off the noncompetitive mark, site has new standards :-)

Answer (score 3):

### [LOLCODE](https://esolangs.org/wiki/LOLCODE), <strike>100</strike> 109 Bytes

```
HAI 1
I HAS A I
GIMMEH I
BOTH SAEM I "cat",O RLY?
YA RLY,VISIBLE "cat goes Meow"
NO WAI,VISIBLE I
OIC
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it out online](https://tio.run/##PYoxCgIxFAX7f4pH6m08gfxI8D/cGDCLmlLWYLOQQsHjx9XCagZmlrbM7V57NyU2QphmKCh7xhhsFZ8mQ9YQQbj59nJDwmksWyn65XBmph/Dr@HR6hOxtreTY8JF@c@UxJ0cJrv6Enpf5w8)

My first post on this platform, as well as my first code-golf challenge and my first code in LOLCODE, so there's probably lots to improve. I tried avoiding the "cat" with casting the equivalent hex-code `":(63):(61):(74)"` instead, but it didn't work out for me. If you know a solution to this, please let me know!

*+9 Bytes because I didn't read the instructions clear enough

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Your TIO link appears to be blank, though the code itself looks valid

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @JoKing I fixed the link, it should include the code now.

Comment: the code turns "cat" into "Meow", but it should instead turn it into "cat goes Meow". Still nice code though!

Comment: Thanks @Belhenix. I fixed it for the price of adding 9 bytes. Sadly the use of a variable for "cat" would've turned out to be 5 bytes longer, so I chose to stick with the uglier code.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 58 -  15 = 43 bytes

Pretty straight forward, with bonus for not using `cat` in the code:

```
x=input('');if isequal(x,'dbu'-1);x=[x ' goes "Meow"'];end;x
```

Input must be given inside single quotes: `' '`.

Comment: In its current form, this doesn't output correctly if 'cat' is given as input. You probably forgot __x=__ within the if-statement.

Comment: But I'll also give you a tip to win back these bytes plus an additional 2: replace your entire if-statement by: **if~any(x-'dbu'+1)**

Comment: @slvrbld, thanks for noticing, it happened after I made an edit. BTW: your suggestion doesn't work for inputs that aren't 3 characters. =)

Comment: Ah, you're correct. I was too focused on the cat and fox and forgot about the rest.

Answer (score 2):

## C++11, 316 - 11*10 - 15 = 191 bytes

```
#include <map>
#define t(a,b){#a,#b},
using s=std::string;int main(){std::map<s,s>m{t(cow,moo)t(crow,caw)t(dog,bark)t(hog,oink)t(lark,sing)t(lion,roar)t(oxen,low)t(rook,caw)t(seal,bark)t(sheep,baa)t(swan,cry){"c""at","meow"}};s l;while(int i=~getchar())l+=~i;printf("%s",(m[l]==""?l:l+" goes \""+m[l]+'"').c_str());}
```

Compiles well with VisualStudio. GCC wants me to `#include <string>` and `#include <cstdio>`. It would be shorter if I wouldn't go for bonuses, but I still hope author revises bonuses. I can't think of language where defining `cow -> moo` or so is way way shorter than 10bytes. Mine cost `3+key+value` bytes for additional animal and flat `22+17` bytes for defining structure and so.

Ungolfed

```
#include <map>

#define t(a, b) { #a, #b },
using s = std::string;
int main()
{
    std::map<s, s> m{
        t(cow,moo)
        t(crow,caw)
        t(dog,bark)
        t(hog,oink)
        t(lark,sing)
        t(lion,roar)
        t(oxen,low)
        t(rook,caw)
        t(seal,bark)
        t(sheep,baa)
        t(swan,cry)
        { "c""at", "meow" }
    };
    s l;
    while (int i = ~getchar())
        l += ~i;
    printf("%s", (m[l] == "" ? l : l + " goes " + m[l]).c_str());
}
```

Comment: "t(crow,caw)" has a length of 11.  So getting rid of that to "t(swan,cry)" would drop 14 bytes.  And admittedly make it less fun :(

Comment: @user, As I said,  I still hope author revises bonuses.

Comment: You should state C++11 in the headline. Python 2 and 3 are also always distinct noted. While the `using` is no big deal, the initializer list is.

Comment: @KarlNapf Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You can also change `#include <map>` to `#import<map>` for -2 bytes. The space before `<` can be omitted and `#import` throws some warnings but is accepted be GCC and MSVC

Answer (score 2):

## GNU sed, 37 - 15 = 22 bytes

```
sed -r 's/^(\x63at)$/\1 goes "Meow"/'
```

Comment: sed '/^c[a]t$/s/$/ goes "Meow"/' saves a few bytes. But the new 5% bonus is worthless compared to the original 15 byte bonus for not having "cat".

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Not any more!

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, 117 bytes

```
for(c=0,s="bee.Buzz.bird.Song.c\at.Meow.cow.Moo.crow.Caw.dog.Bark.oxen.Low.owl.Who.rook.Caw.sheep.Baa.swan.Cry".split('.'),p=prompt(),a=![];c<s.length;c+=2){if(p==s[c])a=c}if(!a)alert(p=='fox'?'What does the fox say':p);else alert(s[a]+' goes "'+s[a+1]+'"')
```

I definitely haven't won here, but I've covered a lot of extra animals.

### Javascript, 31 bytes

```
p=prompt();alert(p=='c\at'?p+' goes "Meow"':p)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [HALT](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HALT), 71 - 15 = 56 bytes

```
1 IF "cat" 2 ELSE 3
2 TYPE "MEOW";HALT
3 SET 0;NEXT
4 INCREMENT;STORE 0
```

HALT is a language I (@Downgoat) made designed for string processing, the only problem is that it's a bit long

### Formatted

```
1              IF "cat" 2 ELSE 3
2 TYPE "MEOW"; HALT
3 SET 0      ; GOTO 6
4 INCREMENT  ; STORE 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>62</s> <s>58</s> 48 - 15 = <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 33 bytes

<sub>Thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string) for -10 bytes!</sub>

```python
x=input()
print(x,*['goes "Meow"'][:"c""at"==x])
```

0x61 = a.

### Try it online!

Revision 3: [with cat](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfYauUnFii9F@5wjYzr6C0REOTq6AoM69Eo0JHK1o9PT@1WEHJNzW/XEk9NtpKKVlJCajY1rYiVvP/f2MA) [without cat](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfYauUkp@u9F@5wjYzr6C0REOTq6AoM69Eo0JHK1o9PT@1WEHJNzW/XEk9NtpKKVlJKbFEyda2Ilbz/39jAA)

Revision 2: [with cat](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfYauUnFii9F@5wjYzr6C0REOTKzNNocIWKBxTYWZYomRVUJSZV6JRoaOenp9arKDkm5pfrqSuyZWaU5wKk9P8/98YAA) [without cat](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfYauUkp@u9F@5wjYzr6C0REOTKzNNocLWVik5psLMsETJqqAoM69Eo0JHPT0/tVhByTc1v1xJXZMrNac4FSan@f@/MQA)

Revision 1: [with cat](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfYauUnFii9F@5wjYzr6C0REOTKzNNocIWKBxTYWZYomRVUJSZV6KhDuEqpOenFiso@abmlyupa3Kl5hSnQhVUaP7/bwwA) [without cat](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPpfYauUkp@u9F@5wjYzr6C0REOTKzNNocLWVik5psLMsETJqqAoM69EQx3CVUjPTy1WUPJNzS9XUtfkSs0pToUqqND8/98YAA)

Comment: The first `cat` is there

Comment: @l4m2 Sorry, that will be fixed.

Comment: [62-15](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8I2M6@gtERDkyszTaHC1lYpOabCzLBEyaqgKDOvRKNCW10hPT@1WEHJNzW/XEldkys1pzgVJqn5/39yYgkA)

Comment: [-2 by spinning the comparison around and using adjacent string literal concatenation over an escape sequence](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8I2M6@gtERDkyszTSlZSSmxRMnWtsKqoCgzr0SjQkc9PT@1WEHJNzW/XEldkys1pzgVJqf5/39yYgkA). Or, [all the way down to 48](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8I2M6@gtERDk6ugKDOvRKNCRytaPT0/tVhByTc1v1xJPTbaSilZSSmxRMnWtiJW8/9/08pSBbNSAA).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>49</s> <s>46</s> 50 - 15 = 35 bytes

Pretty straight-forward I guess. Not using cat.

```
$<.map{|l|puts l==?c+'at
'??c+'at goes "Meow"':l}
```

Edit: Thanks for @w0lf for saving 3 bytes!

Comment: apparently there's no need for `chop`: http://ideone.com/lTpShD

Comment: @w0lf "cat\n" != "cat" (At least it doesn't work for me)
I'm guessing that ideone's STDIN doesn't have a trailing newline

Comment: Fair enough, I see where my example was wrong. Then your could consider doing [this](http://ideone.com/SJopbR) to shorten the code.

Comment: @PeterLenkefi, there are still a few cats left in your code... Did you forget to update it or...?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Damn it I did! My multitasking is not on top today. However in 5 mins I'll update it again.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Updated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 48 - 15 = 33 bytes

Uses `\x61` as a substitute for the `a` in `cat`.

```
i=prompt();alert(i=="c\x61t"?i+' goes "Meow"':i)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 46 - 15 = 31

```pl
$_=join'',<>;s/(?<=^ca)t$/t goes "Meow"/;print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Beam](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beam), <s>208</s> 206 - 15 = 191 bytes

Not a competitive entry, but a bit of fun to do.  It checks the first for letters of the input against `cat`.  If it gets a mismatch it will shortcut to the standard cat program.  If it matches it will append `goes "Meow"`

```
'''''''''>`\/n@>`)'''>`++\
/++++++++++/r /SP''+(++++/
\+)'PSrn@--S/ \rn@`>`)rn'''''>`++++++)++@P'p++++@'p-----@`p++@'p-@``p@++@'''''>`+++++++++)--@'p++@'p-----@++++++++@``p++@H
/@<  (`<     < `<    ''<
>ruH
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 23 - 15 = 8 chars / 58 - 15 = 43 bytes

```
ïċɘ㴃탵ˠⓀ㐀攁退胦ްおр夁䰰ᷗȿ 쨀#
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=cat&code=%C3%AF%C4%8B%C9%98%E3%B4%83%ED%83%B5%CB%A0%E2%93%80%E3%90%80%E6%94%81%E9%80%80%E8%83%A6%DE%B0%E3%81%8A%D1%80%E5%A4%81%E4%B0%B0%E1%B7%97%00%C8%BF%E2%80%80%EF%88%85%EC%A8%80%23)</kbd>

The byte to char ratio is real.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 1204 - (10 * 64) - 15 - 20 = 529 bytes

```
<?php $i = $argv[1];$s = json_decode(gzuncompress(hex2bin("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")));echo array_key_exists($i,$s)?"$i goes {$s->$i}":($i=="fox"?"What does the $i say":$i);
```

I use a json encoded gz compressed array of animal sounds. 
This means it works with all 65 allowed animals, but my script is huge.
Also works with fox and doesn't have the word cat in it.

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB, 46 bytes

```
regexprep(input(''),'^cat$','cat goes "Meow"')
```

Admittedly trivial. The input must be given in single quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `ans = .. ` is generally not accepted, if the challenge is to print something. I'm not sure if it's a consensus, but it's quite common to use `disp` or something similar.

Comment: +1 though, for being shorter than mine =)

Answer (score 1):

### Java = 222 bytes (compressed)

```
public class A {public static void main(String[] args) {Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);for(;;){String b=a.nextLine();if(!b.equalsIgnoreCase("cat"))System.out.println(b);else {System.out.println("meow");System.exit(0);}}}
```

Or I could decompress it.

### Batch = 52 bytes

```
set /p k=
if "k"=="cat" (echo cat) ELSE (echo %k%)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript: 48 Characters, 48 Bytes

```
function(s){return (s=="cat")?"cat goes meow":s}
```

#### Test

`=>`"Dog"

`<=`"Dog"

`=>`"cat"

`<=`"cat goes meow"

Comment: Good work! You could drop the parentheses around `s=="cat"`. Also, the cat's string is supposed to be `cat goes "Meow"`, so `'function(s){return s=="cat"?'cat goes "Meow"':s}` is completely valid.

Comment: If you wanted to save even more, you could use ES6: `s=>s=="cat"?s+' goes "Meow"':s` (30 bytes)

Comment: @ETHproductions OOooh, that's good! I don't know that kind of syntax though, a link perhaps?

Comment: @Fuzzyzilla it's part of a new version of JavaScript called "ES6", link to the [new function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [overview](http://es6-features.org/#Constants). Here are also [tips for ES6](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/tips-for-golfing-in-ecmascript-6) and [tips for JavaScript in general](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 52-15 = 37 bytes

```
c"\99at"="\99at goes \"Meow\""
c s=s
main=interact c
```

Using `\99` as a substitute for c in “cat” so as to get the 15 bytes bonus.

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog, 48 bytes

```
p:-read(X),write(X),X=cat,write(' goes "Meow"').
```

Attempts to bring more animals to the party made the program longer even with bonuses.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 26-15 (no "cat") = 11 bytes

My first ever Pyth program!

```
Iqz_"tac"+z" goes meow";Ez
```

### [Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Iqz_%22tac%22%2Bz%22+goes+meow%22%3BEz&input=cat&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=sadsadsadad%0Acat%0Atac&debug=0)

#### Explaination

```
   _"tac"                   # Reverse the string "tac"
Iqz                         # If the input equals "tac" reversed
         +z" goes meow";    # Append " goes meow"
                        Ez  # Else, use the input.
                            # Implicit: print the input, if it's used.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 82-95 = -13 bytes

```
+z*}zKc."atÜiÃ'4ãl¾Eªîiû<-È&e"\jjk[d"goes"dNr@c."bw««[áÅ3ÏB"\c%x`Kz3 3N
```

I finally got around to converting my new functional Python 2 entry to Pyth. It doesn't beat the top contender. Turns out zipping together more animals into a larger dictionary reduces score faster than cleverly associating animals with sounds. This supports 8 animals in addition to cat: rhino, okapi, moose, lion, tiger, badger, hippo, and stag.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bz%2a%7DzKc.%22at%1C%08%C3%9C%18%1Ai%C3%83%7F%274%C3%A3l%C2%BEE%0B%C2%AA%C2%8F%C3%AEi%C2%9D%C3%BB%3C%1A-%C3%88%26e%22%5Cjjk%5Bd%22goes%22dNr%40c.%22bw%03%C2%AB%C2%AB%5B%C3%A1%C3%853%C3%8FB%C2%97%22%5Cc%25x%60Kz3+3N&input=stag&test_suite_input=%5B24%2C+6%5D%0A0+++%0A%5B24%2C+6%5D%0A1%0A%5B24%2C+6%5D%0A2%0A%5B24%2C+6%5D%0A5%0A%5B100%2C+50%5D%0A10%0A%5B1%2C+1.41421356237%5D%0A10&debug=0&input_size=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o), <s>22</s> <s>16</s> 14 bytes

**29 bytes - 15**

```
Q"tac"`J=J" goes \"Meow\""+Q?
```

It's long and can be golfed more

Answer (score 1):

### Japt, <s>25-15=10</s> 24-15 = 9 bytes

First time trying Japt:

```
N¦`¯t`?N:`¯t goƒ \"´ow\"
```

`ƒ` should be replaced with unprintable character `U+0083`
Compiles to:

```
N!="cat"?N:"cat goes \"meow\""
```

Old solution:

```
N¥`¯t`?`¯t goƒ \"´ow\"`:N
```

[Try it here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=TqZgr3RgP046YK90IGdvgyBcIrRvd1wi&input=ImNhdCI=)

Comment: Pretty nice! Sorry the backslashes are necessary, I thought I had fixed that.

Comment: Since the code contains an unprintable character, which Markdown discards, could you please add a link?

Comment: Added the link, also why does `U+0083` get replace `U+0192` or `ƒ` when you run this snippet: `"\u0083".charCodeAt()`

Comment: I have no clue. I can't seem to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: -136 (214 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) - 31*10 - 15 - 25)

```
'¨›Qi“What‚à€€ ÿ…è“ë“ÓÕŸâÍÝ¹ÐÀ¼ÛË—Ä¬…Ð§ÀÛÆÓ‹·»ÑÐœ²èàæÑåî€žÚÆÚØåÊÓ³âÌ–ÔÄ¤•ã‚í„ÄŠêÂÝ¢“#sk©di.•QÃ€}£≠‰ŒΛ(Ïûвrüéä[ñøuF½3¡üÃïßåιQÊçdï€]Üвβ`šŠû©ª«ĀLΩÝβ\à¨TĆηÎ.₄₆öª$γâôΘ:Æ™{¹и5|Âć®λ¬¡¸αâË::´óýÏƶ5~¦m.škα†#Ð6λ•#®è™s“ÿ—± "ÿ"
```

Bonuses:

- -15 for not using `cat`
- -25 for outputting `What does the fox say` when the input is `fox`
- 31 times -10 for the animals and sounds: `["bat screech","bear roar","bee buzz","tiger roar","lion roar","jaguar snarl","cat meow","chicken cluck","cow moo","cricket chirp","deer bellow","dog bark","wolf howl","duck quack","eagle screech","elephant trumpet","frog croak","horse neigh","mouse squeak","monkey scream","pig oink","rabbit squeak","seal bark","sheep baa","snake hiss","turkey gobble","whale sing","ass heehaw","rat squeak","goat bleat","lamb baa"]`

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##FVDdSgJBGH2V0KCuvIm68AG66kYIuqggwyKRCLIg6IdhW4yyH2sLxKzW1UzNLDdRt9WE77hdDj7DvIh9C8PAnDnfOec7O8noenxjPJ6iihI/kbgS@aWt6J4SOZhKq/OZwECJMvg7j3f/MvDgdWHhCk/kIANBPTwircQ9dKr73Ay9QTCWgqGEQx1ycYuMZ5CNCkyU@fWKBmt7v8gxK4csAxcw6Jt1L5Uw4GuVlLBQ9KN8KPEM3TNRg8auFscIJhNUjcVDzInglLWOqajOTSW@vDv5OI0buCN7Fz1UUVpGE939eerPUIGRU3ziBa/SibDnWwyfPL2K/MiW9ppXYBeXqlSj96FYkFU8SXsFJlUWhynZwXVIabrSUmhTbVL6cVsyG0ZK6dYhOaPu7BG04Rk1pEt1KlBXNpmSDoephW/0cfPXnj2h8nbIKyRkUwkziMycdHmJIDW4Y91K@hVz4/fUnAhgEBiPN3cO/gE) or [verify all used animals](https://tio.run/##HVBNT1NBFP0rk9ZEF6Ybgws27NzopomJCzVx2g7tsx@vee9VJIqZlKZGUakUE1KKtgVKCwi2EGgtSHIPz@ULv2H@SL3PZHIyc@6559y5tisTlppGXy3ORYSpronI3CJqqE1vU8/o33HL6OaTjPSMbqBlyod8BK6M7oLLTRyEUMc3f4QOPmOLxtys6QKbWDF6HRU6DLU12oNmroq60WM6pwm@oubXaYgeWujyaxdH7O3/QYNVDWww8RF1OmHfT0bXEXrtGN3BdjjKT6O/o@K3sI8yp3Z4jKibpX7KirEmjmX2WqJt86Fl9C9/Ldi8g1VMboYOLtDHzlMMMCo9oMt71GZmGcf4gd1gHOfMvRSOufs5mjfDYPjCb3PKhPq0TwfX@lHQx1YwfIYW9R5fV4NzfImZcsWUqzij/VtBOO5psDGLqql03tD4ZjTzFuXr93QUTOiQ2jQKBixZmZ2lU5zgEqt/z2beUTcf89vZYGB0K4ra/WDCn4jSEe@40nHDFfPG12kgIriKTPm9tERnD@9OE9ITCSUdBiU8K60ckbPsgngp0yVmk1xOZqxkVhVE0l4QSSe8eyKlWJiy02LBzs2LVCmZFUqmc0qonCpmZMET8w5XM7bjKpG3S/@xkFWLomilhSMTCcsTrpI54WaUKgq3ILOcX3JCyUJGspN0XRZ6Im0z5GQ@Iebt18wUUnb@Hw).

**Explanation:**

```python
'¨›                  '# Push dictionary word "fox"
   Qi                 # If the (implicit) input-string equal "fox":
     “What‚à€€ ÿ…è“   #  Push dictionary string "What does the ÿ say"
                      #  (where the `ÿ` is automatically filled with the implicit input)
   ë                  # Else:
    “ÓÕŸâÍÝ...ÄŠêÂÝ¢“ #  Push dictionary string "bar bear bee ... rat goat lamb"
    #                 #  Split it on spaces
    sk                #  Get the index of the input-string in this list (-1 if not found)
    ©                 #  Store this index in variable `®` (without popping)
    di                #  If this index is non-negative (>= 0):
      .•QÃ€...Ð6λ•    #   Push compressed string "screech roar ... bleat baa"
      #               #   Split it on spaces
      ®è              #   Index variable `®` into this list
      ™               #   Titlecase this sound
      s               #   Swap to get the (implicit) input-string at the top of the stack
      “ÿ—± "ÿ"        #   Push dictionary string 'ÿ goes "ÿ"'
                      #   (where the first `ÿ` is the input at the top of the stack,
                      #    and the second `ÿ` is the titlecased sound below it)
                      # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result,
                      #  which will be the (implicit) input itself for any other input)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why:

- `'¨›` is `"fox"`
- `“What‚à€€ ÿ…è“` is `"What does the ÿ say"`
- `“ÓÕŸâÍÝ¹ÐÀ¼ÛË—Ä¬…Ð§ÀÛÆÓ‹·»ÑÐœ²èàæÑåî€žÚÆÚØåÊÓ³âÌ–ÔÄ¤•ã‚í„ÄŠêÂÝ¢“` is `"bat bear bee tiger lion jaguar cat chicken cow cricket deer dog wolf duck eagle elephant frog horse mouse monkey pig rabbit seal sheep snake turkey whale ass rat goat lamb"`
- `` .•QÃ€}£≠‰ŒΛ(Ïûвrüéä[ñøuF½3¡üÃïßåιQÊçdï€]Üвβ`šŠû©ª«ĀLΩÝβ\à¨TĆηÎ.₄₆öª$γâôΘ:Æ™{¹и5|Âć®λ¬¡¸αâË::´óýÏƶ5~¦m.škα†#Ð6λ• `` is `"screech roar buzz roar roar snarl meow cluck moo chirp bellow bark howl quack screech trumpet croak neigh squeak scream oink squeak bark baa hiss gobble sing heehaw squeak bleat baa"`
- and `“ÿ—± "ÿ"` is `'ÿ goes "ÿ"'`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 132 - 150 (animals) - 15 (no `cat`) = -33 bytes

```
pJjb.zp.x++" goes \""r@.dmcd\ic."ay-ÝÏåâšB²ÅuŠ°µ²¦DÄ²Öì |t`2“‚Êôë¨}èÔèw:ÿÊ_OƒÄ<Ú›ø‚î½ùÛ&L°„6a<9-¾¹™,Uø0é6Œû²Ù²ËyÊ·%C"\lJ4\"k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AcQAO/9weXRo//9wSmpiLnpwLngrKyIgZ29lcyBcIiJyQC5kbWNkXGljLiJheS3DncOPw6XDosKaQsKyw4UMdcKKwrDCtcKywqZEw4TCssOWw6wgBXx0YDIHwpPCgsKBw4rDtMOrGsKofcOow5TDqHc6w7/Dil9PwoPDhBQ8w5rCm8O4woLDrsK9w7nDmyZMwrDChDZhPDktwr7CucKZLFXDuDARw6k2wozDu8KyD8OZwrLDi3nDisK3JUMiXGxKNFwia///Y2F0)

Uses a packed string to fit in animals for less than 10 bytes each

Full list:

```
parrot goes "Squack"
cat goes "Meow"
rook goes "Caw"
ass goes "Bray"
goose goes "Honk"
dog goes "Woof"
duck goes "Quack"
sheep goes "Baa"
ox goes "Moo"
raven goes "Caw"
goat goes "Baa"
swan goes "Cry"
frog goes "Croak"
toad goes "Croak"
monkey goes "Chatter"
```

Edit 1: Almost forgot the no cat bonus :P

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 25 - 15 = 10 bytes

```
."c""at"+=" goes 'Meow'"*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X08pWUkpsURJ21ZJIT0/tVhB3Tc1v1xdSev//@TEEgA)

#### Example

```
."c""at"+=" goes 'Meow'"*   # Input: cat
."c""at"                    # Duplicate input, push c and at. Stack: cat cat c at
        +                   # Concatenate, Stack: cat cat cat
         =                  # Check if equal, Stack: cat 1
          " goes 'Meow'"*   # " goes 'Meow'" pushed onto stack n times, Stack: "cat" " goes 'Meow'"
                            # Implicitly print
```

#### Alternate Example

```
."c""at"+=" goes 'Meow'"*   # Input: asdf
."c""at"                    # Duplicate input, push c and at. Stack: asdf asdf c at
        +                   # Concatenate, Stack: asdf asdf cat
         =                  # Check if equal, Stack: asdf 0
          " goes 'Meow'"*   # " goes 'Meow'" pushed onto stack n times, Stack: "asdf" ""
                            # Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 65 - 15 = <s>56</s> 50 bytes

Does not use the word cat. Supports only cat and then "Meow", no other animals.

```
while 1>0:
 var i=readLine stdin;echo if i=="ca"&"t":"Meow"else:i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCgIxEAD7fUXYQrAQtJNIBHt9xJJsvNWYwCWa_MUmID7qfuPB2c4w8_5EefT-fRa_2U-nOkhgtTtuNagXjUrMyOTOElnl4iQe2A5JiZ-FQUu4woIaL5wqcsisZRn9f31au3QFcrcklF24U3CZwKYKPpNpYKkAtEYzXYof)

(-6 bytes thanks to Steffan)

Comment: [65 byets](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCgIxEAD7fUXYQrAQtJNIBHt9xJJsvNWYwCWa_MUmID7qfuPB2c4w8_5EefT-fRa_2U-nOkhgtTtuNagXjUrMyOTOElnl4iQe2A5JiZ-FQUu4woIaL5wqcsisZRn9f31au3QFcrcklF24U3CZwKYKPpNpYKkAtEYzXYof)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 285 - 310 - 15 - 25 = -65 bytes

```
`∷¾`=[`λ⟩ ƛ∪ λλ ∷¾ ∨¶`|`Ḃṙ ∞¨ εċ ṗµ √₇ Ṁ⋎ ¢₌ β¡ ¦‹ √⊍ ₃⇩ •ƈ ṡƒ ¦ø ḟ₇ Ẇ⟑ µɽ ½ż Þ‡ ₃⅛ Ḣ⟨ ₈Ḋ ġṄ ⁋ė Ċṁ ∴† Ẏ₇ ass ₀⌈ ⌊ṫ Ȯ⁰`⌈?ḟ:£0≥[`s⇩⋏↳⋎ r⋎« Ȧ¨ r⋎« r⋎« sn₴£ m□ŀ cḟĿ moo ch↲Ṗ Ǎ⟩⟑ṙ •øk h⋎₄ qꜝ½k s⇩⋏↳⋎ t≥⁋⌐¨ crβ⁰ ne⋏ṫ sȧ‛ak s›‹ o›₌ sȧ‛ak •øk baa λµs £⁋ǎʁ ⟩ɽ hee¥↓ sȧ‛ak bl↓⟑ baa`⌈¥i`% ¢₃ `?%$+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 42 - 15 - 25 = 2 bytes

```
`¢₌`=[`¢₌ ¢₃ "M□ŀ"`|`∷¾`=[`λ⟩ ƛ∪ λλ ∷¾ ∨¶`
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgwqLigoxgPVtgwqLigowgwqLigoMgXCJN4pahxYBcImB8YOKIt8K+YD1bYM674p+pIMab4oiqIM67zrsg4oi3wr4g4oiowrZgIiwiIiwiZm94Il0=)

Bonuses:

- -15 for not using `cat`
- -25 for responding to `fox` with `What does the fox say`

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 19 - 15 = 4 bytes

```
`¢₌`=[`¢₌ ¢₃ "M□ŀ"`
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgwqLigoxgPVtgwqLigowgwqLigoMgXCJN4pahxYBcImAiLCIiLCJjYXQiXQ==)

Bonuses:

- -15 for not using `cat`

#### Explanation

Most of it is just string compression:

- `` `¢₌` `` is `cat`
- `` `¢₌ ¢₃ "M□ŀ"` `` is `cat goes "meow"`
- `` `∷¾` `` is `fox`
- `` `λ⟩ ƛ∪ λλ ∷¾ ∨¶` `` is `What does the fox say`

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 48 bytes

```
Input Str1
Str1="cat
If Ans
Disp Str1+" goes Meow
If not(Ans
Disp Str1
```

All those lowercase letters are increasing the bytecount by a lot.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 31 - 15 = 16 bytes

You can try it out [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=In%2BC99%22at%22zz%3BE%2Bz%22%20goes%20%5C%22Meow%5C%22&input=cat%0A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=cat%0Ahi&debug=0)

```
In+C99"at"zz;E+z" goes \"Meow\"
```

Explaination:

```
I                                # If-statement
 n                               # not equal
  +C99"at"                       # Adds the char 99 with the string "at" = "cat"
          z                      # z, the user input
           z                     # Print the user input
            ;                    # Ends all open parentheses
             E                   # Else-statement
              +z" goes \"Meow\"  # Adds ' goes "Meow"' to z and prints the result
```

Comment: `C99` can be replaced with `\C`. It's still `+\C"at"`, so you can keep the bonus.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 76 bytes

```
main(){char a[99];gets(a);printf("%s%s",a,strcmp(a,"cat")?"":" goes meow");}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 70-15 = 55 bytes

```
<?=$l=rtrim(stream_get_contents(STDIN),~òõ),$l==~œž‹?~ß˜šŒßÝ²šˆÝ:'';
```

(saved as ISO-8859-1)

Uses inverted undefined constants as string literals:

- `~òõ` == `"\r\n"`
- `~œž‹` == `'cat'`
- `~ß˜šŒßÝ²šˆÝ` == `' goes "Meow"'`

Everything is combined in a single echo statement, shorthanded with `<?=`

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 35 + 2 (-p flag) - 15 = 22 bytes

```
$_==?c'at
'&&$_[-2]+=' goes "Meow"'
```

Inspired by trying to improve [Peter Lenkefi's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62502) solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 110 + 2 (-p flag) -60 (cow, ox, dog, bee, pig and crow) -15 (no cat) = 37 bytes

```
(h=Hash[*%W(cow Moo ox Low c\141t Meow dog Woof bee Buzz pig Oink crow Caw)][$_.chop])&&$_[-2]+=' goes "'+h+?"
```

Multiple animal Ruby solution...  As long as the animal+sound is <8 characters, it shrinks for each one added.  Gross abuse of Ruby. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 26 + 1 = 27

With command-line flag `-p`, run

```
sub /^cat$/,'\& goes Meow'
```

Getting the no-cat bonus costs 2 bytes, which isn't actually worth it:

```
sub /^c at$/x,'\& goes Meow'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 67 Bytes

```
func main()if((x=input())=="cat")print(x+" goes meow")else print(x)
```

See expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=ab0a8369a4a78fca2376f798bf1df2bb)

Comment: It's fine to link to an online interpreter so that readers can test the code themselves, but you should still include sufficient explanation or expansion in the post such that a casual reader could convince themself that your submission is correct.

Answer (score 0):

## [JacobFck](https://github.com/JacobMisirian/JacobFck), 31 Bytes

I really like the golfed version of this.

```
"cat"<|=_e>!:e"cat goes Meow">
```

See commented and expanded [here](http://hassiumlang.com/Paste/get-paste.has?hash=48e0912b2dfe5a3af3be80d88f0b36da)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 149-95 = 54 bytes

#### -8*10 extra animals, -15 for no "cat"

```
u=raw_input()
l="ca""t badger rhino okapi moose stag tiger hippo lion".split()
print u+' goes "%s"'%["Growl","Bellow","Meow"][`l`.find(u)%3]*(u in l)
```

Supported animals:

- moose, stag, okapi, rhino (all Bellow)
- tiger, badger, lion, hippo (all Growl)

This is not the shortest Python answer, but at least it does bother to try at some other animals! I add it here because the answer i had previously did not work, and I'm confident this will become the shortest Pyth answer once I translate it and golf it there.

#### How it works:

1. Take input
2. Create a list of animals in a very precise order.
3. Print the input, and if the input is in the list, use the location of the input in the string representation of the list to index an array of sounds, and append the appropriate "goes" string.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 35 - 15 (-p no cat) = 20 Bytes

```
c=i=>(i=='c\at')?i+' says "Meow"':i
```

Can someone check to see that I did the header right?

Answer (score 0):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/Nazek42/arcyou), 38 bytes (non-competitive)

*Since this version of the language was made after the challenge was posted, it is not eligible.*

```
(: s(q))(?(= s "cat")"cat goes Meow" s
```

Arcyóu is a LISP-like golfing language.

Explanation:

```
(: s(q))           ; Set the variable s to the contents of STDIN
(? (= s "cat")     ; If-statement. Condition is s == "cat"
  "cat goes Meow"  ; If true: return the string "cat goes Meow"
  s                ; Otherwise, return what was entered
```

Arcyóu automatically prints the result of the last expression evaluated. In this case, it is the `?` statement. It also allows you to leave off trailing close-parens.

Answer (score 0):

## Emacs Lisp (67 Bytes)

```
(set'a(read-string""))(message(pcase a("cat""cat goes meow")(_ a)))
```

It uses pattern matching to distinguish cats from other input. This could be extended to fit other animals in as well, but as most of them take up more than 10 characters, there is not much to be gained from that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Milky Way 1.5.16](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 29 bytes - 15 = 14

```
"c""at"+'?{b_" goes Meow"+_}!
```

Doesn't use a `"cat"` string.

---

#### Explanation

```
"c""at"      " goes Meow"      # push string to the stack
       +                 +     # add the TOS and the STOS
        '                      # read input from the command line
         ?{ _             _}   # if statement
           b                   # equality of the TOS and the STOS
                            !  # output the TOS
```

---

#### Usage

```
python3 milkyway.py <path-to-code> -i <input>
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl](https://github.com/BrendanGalvin), 13 bytes

The string "cat" does not appear in my code (Special thanks to Dennis for shaving 15 bytes off of the code, and teaching me some new Perl tricks):

```
s/^(c)at$/$& goes Meow/
```

Comment: Neither of those are mentioned in the OP, unless I am missing something? It simply needs to take input and replace "cat" with cat goes Meow. I'm not sure if I missed something but I think my answer is valid.

Comment: In other words, unless the string is exactly the string "cat" it should not be reached.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Very well, I'll make a minor edit to it.

Comment: Alternatively, `s/^(c)at$/$& goes Meow/` with the `-p` switch.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 2.0, <s>71</s> 68-15 (no "cat") = 53 bytes

```
func a(s:String)->String{return s=="c\u{61}t" ?s+" goes \"Meow\"":s}
```

For some reason, a compilation error is thrown if there isn't a space before the ternary operator `?`

#### Ungolfed

```
func a(s: String) -> String{
    return s == "c\u{61}t" ? s + " goes \"Meow\"" : s
}
```

This doesn't use "cat" in it by replacing the a with the unicode literal `\u{61}`. You can [test this code here](http://swiftstub.com/156692825/)

Answer (score 0):

### [DIG](https://github.com/UnderMybrella/DIG), 163 - 15 = 148 bytes

Disclaimer: Due to the fact that DIG was created after the challenge, this answer is non-competing.

[image: Beautiful cats]

Zoomed in (Note: This file will NOT compile, due to the nature of the language)

[image: Impossible Cats]

While I have no idea if this is considered a valid language for PPCG, it *does* complete the challenge. Documentation for the language can be found [here](https://github.com/UnderMybrella/DIG/blob/master/Schematic.txt) and the interpreter can be found [here](https://github.com/UnderMybrella/DIG/blob/master/DIG.jar).

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! This language is pretty cool but I think the community and readers would benefit if you took [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66420/46231) approach and included as well an enlarged version of the image -- even zooming on this one is too small.

Answer (score 0):

## C#6, 302 - 110 - 15 = 177 bytes

This works for 12 different animals, including cat.  It does not include the word "cat" verbatim.

```
using static System.Console;class P{static void Main(){var a=ReadLine();var d="bee,Buzz,c\x61t,Meow,cow,Moo,crow,Caw,dog,Bark,hog,Oink,lamb,Baa,lion,Roar,ox,Low,owl,Hoo,pig,Oink,rook,Caw,seal,Bark,sheep,Baa,swan,Cry".Split(',');int i=22;while(--i>0&&d[--i]!=a);Write(i<0?a:d[i]+" goes '"+d[i+1]+"'");}}
```

Indentation and new lines for clarity.

```
using static System.Console;
class P{
    static void Main(){
        var a=ReadLine();
        var d="bee,Buzz,c\x61t,Meow,cow,Moo,crow,Caw,dog,Bark,hog,Oink,lamb,Baa,lion,Roar,ox,Low,owl,Hoo,pig,Oink,rook,Caw,seal,Bark,sheep,Baa,swan,Cry".Split(',');
        int i=22;
        while(--i>0&&d[--i]!=a);
        Write(i<0?a:d[i]+" goes '"+d[i+1]+"'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Retina, 23 - 15 = 8 bytes

```
^ca\0*t$
$& goes "Meow"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pylongolf2, 33-15=18 bytes

```
"tac"╨1cd_@0=b?" goes Meow"¿~
```

Explanations:

```
"tac"╨1cd_@0=b?" goes Meow"¿~
"tac"                         push "tac" to stack
     ╨1                       reverse it
       cd                     read input and then select latest item in stack
         _                    duplicate input
          @0                  select first item in stack
            =b                compare then swap places
              ?               if true,
               " goes Meow"¿  push " goes Meow" to stack and end if statement
                            ~ print it.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Lua 5.3.2, 229 - 25 - 15 - 80 (extra animals) = 109 bytes

```
r={...}a={['\99\97\116']='Meow',duck='Quack',sheep='Baa',bee='Buzz',frog='Croak',bat='Screech',elk='Bugle',swan='Cry',pig='Oink'}print(r[1]=='fox' and 'What does the fox say' or(a[r[1]] and r[1]..' goes "'..a[r[1]]..'"' or r[1]))
```

#### Ungolfed

```
local Args = {...}
local Sounds = {
    ['\99\97\116'] = 'Meow',
    duck = 'Quack',
    sheep = 'Baa',
    bee = 'Buzz',
    frog = 'Croak',
    bat = 'Screech',
    elk = 'Bugle',
    swan = 'Cry',
    pig = 'Oink'
}
print(
    Args[1] == 'fox' and 'What does the fox say' or (
        Sounds[Args[1]] and Args[1] .. ' goes "' .. Sounds[Args[1]] .. '"' or Args[1]
    )
)
```

I tried to make the logic a little clearer by putting it on multiple lines.
It's essentially a ternary operator `?:`

Answer (score 0):

### AWK, 32 - 15 = 17

```
/^[c]at$/{$0=$0" goes 'Meow'"}1
```

I think this counts as not using "cat".  Could have saved a couple bytes if "cat" were allowed to be anywhere in the line.

For giggles I also put together one with more animals, but it's not competitive, especially with trying to capture the correct verb to use, but here's what I came up with :)

```
{for(;I<split("ca""t,Meow,bees,Buzz,bird,Song,cow,Moo,crow,Caw,dog,Woof,duck,Quack,frogs,Croak,hog,Oink,ox,Low,pig,Oink,sheep,Baa,swan,Cry",a,",");)
m[a[I-1]="'"a[I+=2]"'"}
m[$0]{$0=$0($0~/s$/?" go ":" goes ")m[$0]}
/^fox$/{$0="What does the fox say"}
1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 174 - 15 = 159 bytes

```
interface a{static void main(String[]A){for(String s="";;s=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine())System.out.println(s+(s.equalsIgnoreCase("ca"+"t")?" goes meow":""));}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
interface a {
    static void main(String[] A){
        for (String s = "";;s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine())
            System.out.println(s + (s.equalsIgnoreCase("ca"+"t") ? " goes meow" : ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 44 - 15 = 29

```
i=input();print(i+' goes Meow'*(i=='ca''t'))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [0815](https://esolangs.org/wiki/0815), 132 - 15 = 117

```
}:(:!~>^:(:}:):{~$>^:):{=<:63:-^:
:{=<:61:-^:
:{=<:74:-^:
:{=<:0:-^:
:<:20:~>$<:67:~$<:6F:~>$<:65:~>$<:73:~${~$<:4D:~$&{~${~$<:77:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 47-15=32 bytes

```
<?=($s=fgets(STDIN)).[" goes Meow"][c.a.t!=$s];
```

4 bytes longer than on `$argv[1]`, and: it works only on the first line of input (including the linebreak).

**69-15=54 bytes** to take all lines:

```
while(false!==$n=fgets(STDIN))$s.=$n;echo$s,[" goes Meow"][c.a.t!=$s];
```

Comment: @user46470: I guess that `echo$argn,[" goes Meow"][c.a.t!=$argn],~õ;` using `php -R '<code>'` (execute code for every line of input) would be a little cheating ... but it´s 5 bytes shorter. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Pepe, 244 - 15 = 229 bytes

*Bonus -15 for not containing the word "cat"*

```
rEeEEeeeEErrEEREEeererEeEEeeeeErrEEREEeererEeEEEeEeerrEEREEeererErrEEreeEEeeeEEreeEEeeeeEreeEEEeEeereeeEeeeeereeEEeeEEEreeEEeEEEEreeEEeeEeEreeEEEeeEEreeeEeeeeereeeEeeeEereeEeeEEeEreeEEeeEeEreeEEeEEEEreeEEEeEEEreeeEeeeEeREEEEeEEErEeREEeREReEReee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#$!c6@E!l$!c2@E!l$!d4@E!l$_@EXyXuYwU8Y6YmY2YuU8UcWqY2YmZ2UcRzCT&BH)

Commented version

```
re  # fix syntax highlighting, doesn't affect the program
rEeEEeeeEE  # push "c"
rrEE  # func

REEee re  # pop "c"
rEeEEeeeeE  # push "a"
rrEE  # func

REEee re  # pop "a"
rEeEEEeEee  # push "t"
rrEE  # func

REEee re  # pop "t"
rE
rrEE  # func

# Output the text
reeEEeeeEE reeEEeeeeE reeEEEeEee reeeEeeeee reeEEeeEEE reeEEeEEEE reeEEeeEeE reeEEEeeEE reeeEeeeee reeeEeeeEe reeEeeEEeE reeEEeeEeE reeEEeEEEE reeEEEeEEE reeeEeeeEe

# Clear the stack
REEEEeEEE

rEe  # end-pop

# Loop
REEe RE  # Take input, add a trailing null
ReE

Reee
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 50 - 15 = 35

```
D q?=1l" "\>
Rlril1-{=?/:1´759E" "=?@"goes Meow"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99FodDe1jBHSUEpxo4rKKcoM8dQt9rWXt/K8NAWc1NLV6CErb2DUnp@arGCb2p@uZLD///JiSUA)

In general, for a zero-length animal name and zero-length sound, the overhead for another animal is 10 bytes (roughly, `:0""=2*?""`). The fifteen bytes we get for cat makes it worth spending a net 1 byte encoding "cat" as the numerical value `1759` and extracting "cat" from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 81 - 15 = 66 bytes

### Text input version

Does not contain the word "cat", so gets that bonus. All attempts at further bonuses made the program larger.

Assumes a little-endian machine where `sizeof(int) >= 4` and where signed integers are of the two's complement variety.

```c
q;main(c){for(;c=~getchar();)q=q<<8|putchar(~c);q^6513012||printf(" goes meow");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/QOjcxM08jWbM6Lb9IwzrZti49tSQ5I7FIQ9Nas9C20MbGoqagFCJSl6xpXRhnZmpobGBoVFNTUJSZV5KmoaSQnp9arJCbml@upGld@/9/cmIJAA)

```c
q;main(c){
for(;c=~getchar();)         Read bit-flipped character from STDIN into c. getchar()
                            returns -1 on EOF, and with two's complement, ~c == -c - 1,
                            so we stop on EOF.
q=q<<8|putchar(~c);         Insert character at LSB of q, moving the current values along one
                            byte, while also sending it to STDOUT.
q^6513012||                 Is q non-equal to "cat"?
printf(" goes meow");}      If no (it IS equal), print addendum, otherwise ignore.
```

The above is fine for text-only input, and most binary input. The only (known by me) corner case is if the file happens to end with a NUL character followed by "cat" (`\0cat`), which will give a false positive. I am not 100% sure if we were meant to deal with anything but text, so here is the safer version too:

### Binary-friendly version, 90 - 15 = 75 bytes

```c
q,x;main(c){for(;c=~getchar();x++)q=q<<8|putchar(~c);x^3|q^6513012||printf(" goes meow");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchLCoAgFADAq0QrxYI@FIF2lUAeZi7UNKMg6@oWNMuBUgKk5IqTaq4MAnzN1iMK4yNFgIV7hOlJCHajY2yI6/7nA19PbXRT39VtVTcxrl6ZMKM8k1ZsmRb2yDG9UwIeXg)

Comment: [86-15 binary-friendly](https://tio.run/##JcixCoAgEADQXwknr2hIyIjLXwnkMGso04yGrF@3oTc@qi1Rzh5XvWyc4J5c4EjqtSbSrAMHBK/8MPSpqUS5n/@@BOjHVggpO9GntIdlixNnhXXmKFbjLgb45Ew6fg) storing count in `q`

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 516 - [10 x 53] - 15 = -29 bytes

```python
lambda i:([i+f' goes "{a.split(",")[0]}"'for a in("bark,dog,wolf,seal,zebra bellow,alligator,moose,okapi bleat,deer,elk,giraffe,sheep,goat,lamb bray,donkey,ass buzz,bee,mosquito caw,crow,raven,rook chirp,cicada,cricket,songbird chuckle,linnet croak,frog,toad cry,swan hiss,goose,snake,tarantula meow,c"+"at moo,calf,cow,ox oink,pig,hog roar,badger,bear,lion,tiger,jaguar,leopard scream,monkey,peacock,vulture screech,bat,eagle,owl squeak,hamster,mouse,rat,rabbit,hare,tapir").split()if i in a.split(",")[0:]]+[i])[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZXBjuM2DIbvfgpWl4kbTTGz27kEyKnY8wK7hx4GOdAybatWJFeSN8ks9tmnlO1YHqCn8CMtmjL5M8Mtds5@fleupqMQ4t3guaoR9GH3qvfNA7SOAoif@EcYjI47IUX5@nT6JR4a54GfsztRoe9l7Vp5caaRgdDIN6o8QkXGuItEY3SL0Xl5di6QdD0OGipDGGVN5CWZXrbaY9OQDB3RIFvHsVQKcJ4bJ7c93SSGANX49iYrIs4V/h11dKDwIpXn93j8QVZ653pQnfaDVFphjRzUqqcog7NtpX3N0VH1hqTR1lIEPoy9bDzfIDrksL/JcEELnQ6BS0k1B4s9yYgebRwNwpn4hUrsBUbgW0mFfHXFPncFp20vB93KzrXAub2ssG75nhWxbbSzMurE/2A7Jg@5AbmsoDzhmS82XXYgVE718sdo4uhpipLqOFeUhC2X7y4G@BsQF9/hOURKH3jkYj0/4rGqdOSAT2UP2otyaWGpG9DcOPjY08PptH/Vp9Tddx6E1@fD4/OpoCupnVAYj2KfZqQsipc/PxdFUI5rOoIhu5v9kyfSNbI3RL9bI3xEse@pqKmBSCHuQnkooDWuQgOqgMFrG3f8Dg6UBXB5AX47wuzgJ0HB/gjPRTEdFmh5ZrVtgUwgUd699yHLnhBWe27ABmO2uSkbyBlTSzeQT8xjldFdsj2P2oY3wTTrGVy7sVPHV5y6m8n0q51mdIU0qyss8snsNgVPI7zSMisb9pvg5gXzeK6Y5JhhntnMk5Q26OwK54/XO3@o5i7jjWPchKddkemazYtZ7UUqmXW@xKyDDW5t3heZeG@skJZYhrSSMqVNkGnZKdnBiyO3aBbeSsv2yB69ncpF6SundbrCtFGZFuU9siCe4HeWT9Ydi6QR8JgCV/ipfomiYC1NowvWxST5JEhWVM7xssA9wXT@ZT6ZBCia9M3heARe@Nfl3@DvjrdenczYESR/wJt42Cb@9H@JP6XEs9rL5Vd8/@vrty8HIfPTEsTxzuX7fw)

Started with all the animals on the list, sorted into optimal groupings by sounds they make, then culled down animals whose bytes use more than 10. The final list contains 54 animals, for a bonus of -540 bytes.

It doesn't contain `cat` for another -15 bytes.

It's an anonymous function that works like a table with the animal sounds as headers, and finds the corresponding header for the animal in the table, otherwise returns the input.

If I'm allowed to respond to `cat` with `cat goes "hiss"` as in the [list of animal sounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_sounds), I can pull off another 5 bytes.

-3 bytes thanks to Reinstate Monica.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Thanks, I had it that way to handle multi-word animals, but I've removed them all. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r`^¯t$`È+` go ´ow
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cmBer3QkYMgrYCBnb4MgtG93&input=ImNhdCI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 24 characters - 15 = 9

```
\Ac\Lat\Z=$0 goes "Meow"
```

`gema` works like a filter, so an empty `gema ''` is the same as `cat`.

To avoid using the word “cat” literally, inserted a pointless `\L` (turns on line mode, like an inline `-line` switch, meaning following arguments can't cross line boundary).

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -n cat | gema '\Ac\Lat\Z=$0 goes "Meow"'
cat goes "Meow"

bash-5.0$ echo -n cats | gema '\Ac\Lat\Z=$0 goes "Meow"'
cats
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/P8YxOcYnsSQmylbFQCE9P7VYQck3Nb9c6f//5MQSAA)