# Generating the alphabet in JavaScript

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

I'm pretty sure there's not a better way to do this but figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

I'm tired of typing out `a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`.

Cool languages have `Range('a'..'z')` or similar

What can we come up with with JS that's as short as possible??

```
for(i=97,a='';i<123;){a+=String.fromCharCode(i++)}
```

is longer than just the alphabet - but guarantees I don't screw up somewhere.

I'm hoping there's a nasty bit-shifty way to produce a-z in less than 50 characters.

I messed around with `i=97;Array(26).map(x=>String.fromChar....i++`

but it was always way longer by the time I joined then split the array(26) to be useable

---

Edit: I've gotten it down to

```
[...Array(26)].reduce(a=>a+String.fromCharCode(i++),'',i=97)
```

60 bytes

Comment: @muddyfish, LuisMendo: This is [on-topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724/3808) per meta.

Comment: `[...Array(26)].map((q,w)=>String.fromCharCode(w+97))` is 52 bytes and add another 7 for the `.join\`\``

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl

Comment: @dev-null a='';i=97;[...Array(26)].map(b=>a+=String.fromCharCode(i++)) is 60 but takes care of the join
how are you doing join in 7 without getting commas in the result?

Comment: @CharlieWynn `[...Array(26)].map((q,w)=>String.fromCharCode(w+97)).join\`\``

Comment: @dev-null join`` is new to me!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Alternative to String.fromCharCode

... if you are happy with a lowercase only alphabet.

```
for(i=9,a='';++i<36;)a+=i.toString(36) // 38, cannot be used in an expression
[...Array(26)].map(_=>(++i).toString(36),i=9).join`` // 52 directly returnig the string desired
[...Array(26)].map(_=>a+=(++i).toString(36),a='',i=9) // 53 assign to a variable
(i=9,[for(_ of Array(26))(++i).toString(36)].join``) // 52 ES7 direct return
i=9,a='',[for(_ of Array(26))a+=(++i).toString(36)] // 51 ES7 assign to a variable
```

Comment: Oh dang, that is clever.  So it's starting with 10, converting to base 36 and printing it? so a-z!

Comment: Are those a='' and i=9 arguments of map function call? Checked Array.prototype.map() on mdn and it doesn't look like map support such arguments..

Comment: @JaySomedon those are argument for map function call, in a way, Javascript functions tipically don't care and discard parameters they do not expect. So I initialize a variable I need, while adding a parameter that is of no use for the called function

Comment: @JaySomedon see also this answer and related comments https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2684/21348

Comment: @edc65 aha I see! That's neat! So here, when javascript evaluates arguments like i=9 in map(), it actually creates a global variable i then assigns 9 to that?

Comment: @JaySomedon correct

Comment: @edc65 One more thing, are these same: `var a = [...Array(26)]`, `var b = Array(26)`, `var c = new Array(26)`? In console, `a` prints `[undefined, undefined..]` and b and c print `[empty slots...]` but all `a[0]``b[0]``c[0]` evaluate to `undefined`. But only calling `map` on `[...Array(26)]` gives me alphabets, calling on the other two give me nothing, wonder why. Also on mdn, I can't find any example about `Array(n)`, so I wonder how `Array(n)` and `new Array(n)` are related with each other?

Answer (score 18):

**Note:** All of these techniques assign the alphabet string to variable `a`.

---

I am 99% certain that the shortest way to achieve this in JavaScript is indeed:

```
a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" // 30 bytes
```

But there are several other interesting methods. You can use string compression:

```
a=btoa`i·?yø!?9%?z)ª»-ºü1`+'yz' // 31 bytes; each ? represents an unprintable
```

You can get the compressed string from `` atob`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx` ``. The `'yz'` must be added manually because if you compress the whole string, while the result is only 27 bytes, it will turn out as `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyw==`.

I believe the shortest way to do it programmatically is also the method you suggested:

```
for(i=97,a='';i<123;)a+=String.fromCharCode(i++) // 48 bytes
```

You can do it with ES6 features ([template strings ``` `` ```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), [spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)) if you want:

```
a=[...Array(26)].map(_=>String.fromCharCode(i++),i=97).join`` // 61 bytes
a=[...Array(26)].map((_,i)=>String.fromCharCode(i+97)).join`` // also 61 bytes
a=[...Array(i=26)].map(_=>String.fromCharCode(++i+70)).join`` // again, 61 bytes
```

You can do one better with a variable instead of ``` .join`` ```:

```
[...Array(26)].map(_=>a+=String.fromCharCode(i++),i=97,a='') // all 60 bytes
[...Array(26)].map((_,i)=>a+=String.fromCharCode(i+97),a='')
[...Array(i=26)].map(_=>a+=String.fromCharCode(++i+70),a='')
```

Or ES7 with [array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), which is another byte shorter:

```
a=[for(_ of Array(i=26))String.fromCharCode(++i+70)].join`` // 59 bytes
```

Creating the variable beforehand saves yet another byte:

```
a='',[for(_ of Array(i=26))a+=String.fromCharCode(++i+70)] // 58 bytes
```

Also, `String.fromCharCode` accepts multiple arguments and will automatically join them. So we can golf each ES6 version down to 57 bytes:

```
a=String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(26)].map(_=>i++,i=97)) // all 57 bytes
a=String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(26)].map((_,i)=>i+97))
a=String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(i=26)].map(_=>++i+70))
```

And the ES7 one down to 55:

```
a=String.fromCharCode(...[for(_ of Array(i=26))++i+70]) // 55 bytes
```

If you'd like to learn more about golfing ranges, check out [this set of tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61505/42545). There's also one about [ES7's array comprehensions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61489/42545).

**EDIT:** As edc65 has pointed out, most of these become shorter using `i.toString(36)` instead of `String.fromCharCode(i)`:

```
for(i=9,a='';++i<36;)a+=i.toString(36) // 38 bytes
a=[...Array(26)].map(_=>(++i).toString(36),i=9).join`` // 54 bytes
[...Array(26)].map(_=>a+=(++i).toString(36),i=9,a='') // 53 bytes
i=9,a=[for(_ of Array(26))(++i).toString(36)].join`` // 52 bytes
i=9,a='',[for(_ of Array(26))a+=(++i).toString(36)] // 51 bytes
```

I believe this one is the shortest possible that can be called as a function return value:

```
eval("for(i=9,a='';++i<36;)a+=i.toString(36)") // 46 bytes
```

It's three bytes shorter than manually returning it from a function:

```
x=>eval("for(i=9,a='';++i<36;)a+=i.toString(36)") // 49 bytes
x=>{for(i=9,a='';++i<36;)a+=i.toString(36);return a} // 52 bytes
```

Of course, `x=>"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` still beats everything else.

Comment: I really like where this is going - just wish I could ES7 in chrome :(

Comment: @CharlieWynn Yes, it's a shame that not all browsers support all the latest features. But after all, Chrome wasn't built in a day... ;)

Comment: Most of these solution can be shortened using .toString instead of String,.fromCharCode. See my answer

Comment: @CharlieWynn I think Chrome Beta now supports all of ES7 and all of ES6 except modules and tail call optimisation.

Comment: Here's a 42-byter that can be called as a function return value:  `(f=(i=9)=>++i<36?i.toString(36)+f(i):'')()`

Comment: @ETHproductions for this code `[...Array(26)].map(_=>String.fromCharCode(i++),i=97).join()` how is `i` iterating? It's not even declared? Even if it were how is it that it's not set back to 97 each loop? I'm really confused. I looked at documentation but I must be missing something.

Comment: @zfrisch It's declared as the second argument to map (which doesn't affect anything): `i=97`. Then each time the function `_=>String.fromCharCode(i++)`, it's incremented by 1.

Comment: @ETHproductions cool! I would've expected, since the second parameter looks like it's a `this` context, that if it wasn't a valid `this` context that it would have just thrown an error. The more you know.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another approach, a 51 byte ES6 expression:

```
String.fromCharCode(...Array(123).keys()).slice(97)
```

50 bytes in upper case of course.

Comment: For upper case: String.fromCharCode(...Array(91).keys()).slice(65)

Answer (score 7):

```
(36n**26n*351n/1225n-1n).toString(36)
```

37 bytes, as an expression. Uses the same base-36 method as many others, but further,  obtaining all the letters from a single number. Requires BigInt support.

Answer (score 3):

36 bytes, using a trick I just learned about (from this post: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176496/64538):

```
for(i=9;++i<36;)name+=i.toString(36)
```

`window.name` is an empty string by default.

Of course, this is even less practical than the 38-byte solution since it uses a longer variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Using what may or may not be defined at global scope

39 bytes for object properties to array matching `a-z`

```
a=`${Object.keys(top)}`.match(/[a-z]/g)
```

48 bytes for an unsorted `Set`

```
a=new Set(`${Object.keys(top)}`.match(/[a-z]/g))
```

55 bytes for a sorted `Set`

```
a=new Set(`${Object.keys(top)}`.match(/[a-z]/g).sort())
```

67 bytes for a sorted string

```
a=[...new Set(`${Object.keys(top)}`.match(/[a-z]/g).sort())].join``
```

Comment: `\`${Object.keys(top)}\`.match(/([a-z])(?!.*\1)/g).sort().join\`\`` is still shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I like this answer from above, but just throwing this small addition out there:

```
const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
```

The other answers are great but consider this example:

```
const excelSheet = sheet('whatever.csv')
const headers = excelSheet.meta.headers // ['First Name', 'Last Name']
headers.map((header, i) => {
    console.log(`${header} is column ${alphabet[i]}`)
})

// First Name is column A
// Last Name is column B
```

It's more usable and readable for beginner/intermediate JavaScript developers. But this **is** code golf so I understand if this gets downvoted.

Comment: If you want an array, `[...'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']` is shorter than `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('')`. And although getting the column names from Excel is original, it's indeed far from shorter. 

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I learned something new, thank you! Humbly noted.

Comment: The excel headers is extremely clever!