# Simulate a sock drawer

Tags: code-golf, random

### Background

I have a collection of "weekday socks", which are seven pairs of socks labeled by the days of the week.
When I wash my socks, they end up in a pile, and I must arrange them into the correct pairs before putting them into the closet.
My strategy is to pull one random sock from the pile at a time and put it on a drawer.
Whenever there's a matching pair of socks on the drawer, I tie them together and put them in the closet.
Your task is to simulate this random process and return the number of draws required to find the first matching pair.

### Input

Your input is an integer **N ≥ 1**.
It represents the "number of days in a week": there are **N** pairs of socks in the pile, and each pair has a distinct label.
If necessary, you may also take a PRNG seed as input.

### Output

Your output is the number of socks I have to draw before the first matching pair is found.
For example, if the first two socks already form a matching pair, the output is `2`.

Of course, the output is random, and depends on the drawing order.
We assume that *all drawing orders are equally likely*, so that each time a sock is drawn, the choice is uniform and independent from all other choices.

### Example

Let **N = 3**, so that we have 6 socks in total, labeled **A A B B C C**.
One possible run of the "sock-drawing protocol" is as follows:

```
       | Pile   | Drawer | Pairs
Begin  | AABBCC | -      | -
Draw B | AABCC  | B      | -
Draw C | AABC   | BC     | -
Draw B | AAC    | C      | BB
Draw A | AC     | AC     | BB
Draw A | C      | C      | AA BB
Draw C | -      | -      | AA BB CC
```

The first matching pair was found after drawing the second **B**, which was the third sock to be drawn, so the correct output is `3`.

### Rules and scoring

You can write a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.
Input and output can be in any reasonable format, including unary (string of `1`s).

You may assume that your language's built-in RNG is perfect.
You don't have to actually simulate the sock-drawing protocol, as long as your outputs have the correct probability distribution.

### "Test cases"

Here are the approximate probabilities of all outputs for the input **N = 7**:

```
Output       2     3     4     5     6     7     8
Probability  0.077 0.154 0.210 0.224 0.186 0.112 0.037
```

To test your solution, you can run it for, say, 40 000 times and see whether the output distribution is reasonably close to this.

Comment: Real Life, 42 bytes -- `Draw all socks. End up with an odd number.`

Comment: See [How to pair socks from a pile efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently)

Comment: So n=8 is not equal to 1->7 and then 1 again? i.e. 4 socks labeled 1

Comment: @ViktorMellgren No, you would have 8 distinct labels.

Comment: I have a drawer full of identical socks, so there is no need to sort through them.

Comment: In which universe *"all drawing orders are equally likely"* for socks? Not in ours, that's for sure!

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḤX€Ṛ<RTḢ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bikWOKCrOG5mjxSVOG4og&input=&args=MTAw) or [verify the distribution for **N = 7**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bikWOKCrOG5mjxSVOG4ogrigJjCteKAmXg0yLc0w4figqzEi8OQ4oKsUsO3NMi3NMW8QFJH&input=&args=Nw).

#### Background

Let **n** be the number of pairs; there are **2n** individual socks.

For the first draw, there are **2n** socks and **0** of them would result in a matching pair. Therefore, the probability of success is **0 / 2n = 0**.

Since the first draw wasn't successful, there are **2n - 1** socks on the pile and **1** of them would result in a matching pair. Therefore, the probability of success is **1 / (2n - 1)**.

*If* the second draw wasn't successful, there are **2n - 2** socks on the pile and **2** of them would result in a matching pair. Therefore, the probability of success is **2 / (2n - 2)**.

In general, if the first **k** draws were unsuccessful, there are **2n - k** socks on the pile and **2** of them would result in a matching pair. Therefore, the probability of success is **k / (2n - k)**.

Finally, if none of the first **n** draws was successful, there are **2n - k** socks on the pile and all of them would result in a matching pair. Therefore, the probability of success is **n / (2n - n) = 1**.

#### How it works

```
ḤX€Ṛ<RTḢ  Main link. Argument: n

Ḥ         Unhalve; yield 2n.
 X€       Map `random draw' over [1, ..., 2n], pseudo-randomly choosing an integer
          from [1, ..., k] for each k in [1, ..., 2n].
   Ṛ      Reverse the resulting array.
     R    Range; yield [1, ..., n].
    <     Perform vectorized comparison.
          Comparing k with the integer chosen from [1, ..., 2n - (k - 1)] yields 1
          with probability (k - 1) / (2n - (k - 1)), as desired.
          The latter half of elements of the left argument do not have a counter-
          part in the right argument, so they are left untouched and thus truthy.
      T   Truth; yield all indices of non-zero integers.
       Ḣ  Head; extract the first one.
```

Answer (score 8):

### Jelly, 8 bytes

```
Rx2ẊĠṪ€Ṃ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Ungy4bqKxKDhuarigqzhuYI&input=&args=NQ)

```
R    generate [1, 2, ..., n]
x2   duplicate every element (two socks of each pair)
Ẋ    shuffle the list, to represent the order in which socks are drawn
Ġ    group indices by value. this will produce a list of pairs of indices;
       each pair represents the point in time at which each of the corresponding
       socks were drawn
Ṫ€   take the last element of each pair. this returns an array of n integers
       which represent the points in time at which a matching sock was drawn
Ṃ    minimum, find the first point at which a matching sock was drawn
```

To verify, [here is a version](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Ungy4bqKwqnEoOG5quKCrOG5gizCrg&input=&args=NQ) that displays both the desired output and the result of the "shuffle list" operation (to see what order socks were drawn in).

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 66 bytes

```
from random import*
f=lambda n,k=1:k>randint(1,n*2)or-~f(n-.5,k+1)
```

Dennis thought up a clever way to rearrange things, saving 5 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
Q:"r@qGEy-/<?@.
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UToickBxR0V5LS88P0Au&input=Mw) Or [observe the empirical distribution](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MWUzOiJHClE6InJAcUdFeS0vPD9ALgpdXV0Kdkc6UT1ZbTVNd3Y&input=Nw) for 1000 samples in the *N*=7 case (it takes a while).

This **directly generates the random variable** representing the result, based on its probability distribution. Let *N* be the number of sock pairs, and let *p*(*k*) denote the probability that the *k*-th draw is successful, conditioned on the fact that the *k*-1-th draw was not succesful. Then (see also [here](http://gondolin.blogspot.com.es/2009/04/socks-problem.html)):

- *p*(1) is obviously 0. You can't have a pair with a single sock.
- *p*(2) is 1/(2**N*−1). At the second draw there is one winning sock that may be chosen out of 2**N*−1 remaining socks.
- *p*(3) is 2/(2**N*−2). At the third draw there are 2 winning socks out of 2**N*−2. The number of winning socks is 2 because the two socks you got after the second draw were different.
- In general, by the same reasoning, *p*(*k*) is (*k*−1)/(2**N*−*k*+1)
- By the above formula, *p*(*N*+1) is 1. If you get to the *N*+1-th draw you are guaranteed to succeed then.

So the code iterates for a maximum of *N*+1 draws. At the *k*-th draw a random variable is generated that equals 1 with probability (*k*-1)/(2**N*-*k*), or 0 otherwise. Whenever the random variable equals 1 (the draw has been succesful) the process stops and the current *k* is output.

```
Q:      % Input N implicitly. Generate [1 2 ... N+1] (values of draw index, k)
"       % For each
  r     %   Random variable uniformly distributed on the interval (0,1)
  @q    %   Push iteration index, k-1
  GE    %   Push 2*N
  y     %   Duplicate: push k-1 again
  -     %   Subtract: gives 2*N-k+1
  /     %   Divide: gives (k-1)/(2*N-k+1)
  <     %   Push 1 if random value is less than (k-1)/(2*N-k+1), 0 otherwise
  ?     %   If we got a 1
    @   %     Push k
    .   %     Break loop
        %   End if implicitly
        % End loop implicitly
        % Display implicitly
```

Comment: You and I had the same idea, but you know MATL :)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
EZ@G\&=XRafX<
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=RVpAR1wmPVhSYWZYPA&input=Mw) Or [observe the empirical distribution](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NGUzOiJHCkVaQEdcJj1YUmFmWDwKXQp2RzpRPVltNU13dg&input=Nw) for 4000 samples in the *N*=7 case (it takes a while).

```
E      % Input N implicitly. Multiply by 2
Z@     % Random permutation of [1 2 ... 2*N]
G\     % Modulo N: random permutation of [0 0 1 1 ... N-1 N-1]
&=     % Compare all pairs for equality. Gives an N×N matrix
XR     % Upper triangular part excluding the diagonal
a      % True for each column if it contains at least one true entry
f      % Get indices of true values
X<     % Take minimum. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>77</s> 73 bytes

```js
n=>{p={};for(i=n;i--;p[i]=2);while(--p[n*Math.random()|0])i++;return i+2}
```

**Explanation**

```js
var f = (n) => {
    var index;      // used first to initialize pile, then as counter
    var pile = {};  // sock pile
    
    // start with index = n
    // check that index > 0, then decrement
    // put 2 socks in pile at index
    for(index = n; index--; pile[index] = 2);
    // index is now -1, reuse for counter
    
    // pick random sock out of pile and decrement its count
    // continue loop if removed sock was not the last
    while(--pile[n * Math.random() | 0]) {
        index++;    // increment counter
    }
    // loop finishes before incrementing counter when first matching pair is removed
    // add 1 to counter to account for initial value of -1
    // add 1 to counter to account for drawing of first matching pair
    return index + 2;
};
```

Comment: You can save four characters replacing `f=(n)=>` with `n=>` (or two, if you want to keep the assignment, [some keep it](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37720), [some remove it](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69046)).

Comment: Nice catch, I've fixed it.  Although, when I read "You can write a full program or a function" in the rules, I thought that was a requirement.

Comment: As per [consensus on Meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9031/unnamed-functions-in-code-golf/9032#9032), unnamed functions that are not bound to a name are acceptable by default.

Comment: Shouldn't this be JavaSock? (yes, lame)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>142</s> <s>105</s> 104 bytes

Thanks to *Eʀɪᴋ ᴛʜᴇ Gᴏʟғᴇʀ* for saving one byte!

My first answer:

```
import random 
i=[x/2 for x in range(int(2*input()))]
d=[]
a=0
random.shuffle(i)
while 1:
 b=i.pop()
 if b in d:
  print(a)
  s
 d=d+[b]
 a+=1
```

My new answer:

```
from random import*
i=range(int(input()))*2
shuffle(i)
j=0
for x in i:
 if x in i[:j]:print(1+j)+s
 j+=1
```

Both exit with a `NameError` on `s`.

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 17 bytes

```
ri,2*mr{L+:L(&}#)
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%2C2*mr%7BL%2B%3AL(%26%7D%23)p&input=7)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 49

```
N=scan();which(duplicated(sample(rep(1:N,2))))[1]
```

I'm sure there must be a better way of doing this in R! I tried doing something cleverer but it didn't work.

Edit: Improved by @bouncyball since it doesn't have to be a function.

Comment: do you have to use `function(N)`? using `N=scan();` would save 2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 101 bytes

```py
from random import*
d=[]
p=range(input())*2
shuffle(p)
while list(set(d))==d:d+=p.pop(),
print len(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

### VBA, 61 bytes

```
Function K(D):While 2*D-K>K/Rnd:K=K+1:Wend:K=K+1:End Function
```

- models the shifting probability of sock match given previous failure to match. At the point of evaluation, K is "socks in hand", so draw number is one more.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
lhfnT{T._.S*2S
```

Explanation:

```
       ._        #Start with a list of all prefixes of
         .S      #a randomly shuffled
           *2S   #range from 1 to input (implicit), times 2.
  f              #filter this to only include elements where
   nT{T          #element is not equal to deduplicated self (i.e. it has duplicates)
lh               #print the length of the first element of that filtered list
```