# Let's make a map of dungeon

Tags: code-golf

Long time ago, when I was spending more time playing RPG, one of the issues what some players had, was to track party movement and to draw proper map.
So I come with idea, to check how you guys come deal with this issue.

Task is to write a function, which takes as input parameter list of directions (passed as structure of your choice) `^v<>`, display map of dungeon.
In example for input: `>>>vvv<<<^^^` output will be:

```
+----+               +----+
|    |               |>>>v|
| ++ |               |^++v|
| ++ |  because      |^++v|
|    |               |^<<<|
+----+               +----+
```

Testcases

```
>>>>>>vvvvv<<<<^^^>>v



 +-------+
 |       |
 +-+---+ |
   |   | |
   | + | |
   | +-+ |
   |     |
   +-----+


^^^^^vvv<<<^^vv>>>>>>>>vv>><<^^^^v>>>>v^<^

          +-+ 
       +-+| | +-++-+
       | || | | ++ ++
       | ++ +-+     |
       |        +-+ |
       +--+ +-+ +-+-+
          | | |   |
          +-+ +---+
```

As it is golf code challenge, shortest code wins.

Happy golfing.

**EDIT**
Sorry for late edit, I didn't have much time recently.

Map is generated based on movement.  It should contain only corridors which were visited during walk. Hence creating one big room won't be a valid answer.

There are three valid symbols in the map:

- `|` vertical wall
- `|` horizontal wall
- `+` intersection of vertical and horizontal wall.

Maximum length of the path is 255 character (but if you can, do not limit yourself).

More test cases:

```
 ><><><><

 +--+
 |  |
 +--+

 >^<v

 +--+
 |  |
 |  |
 +--+
```

I hope now everything is clear.

Comment: You need to provide a description of the task. The two test cases aren't even handled in a way that appears consistent -- the first adds a disconnected region for no apparent reason.

Comment: Your second example has a closed-off room, which I initially thought was because the outer border should be rectangular, but then the third example disproves that idea. Please use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get feedback on a challenge before posting.

Comment: @feersum sorry about that, it's fixed now

Comment: @El'endiaStarman that was my mistake, sorry about that.

Comment: Excellent. I'd still suggest being explicit about how the dungeon is constructed from the movements.

Comment: What do you mean by "display map"? Is returning the map from a function allowed?

Comment: Any limits to input length or map size? Any rules on spacing (e.g. why does the second example have extra space on the left or is it an error)? I'm sure we each see the problem as straight-forward but still these details can avoid even innocent technicalities.

Comment: Is this challenge to generate the minimal floor-space dungeon that contains the movements? IE- The generated dungeon can't just be 1 giant room?

Comment: This looks interesting. Any chance of editing to get it re-opened? Things to look at in particular: from the examples, it looks like you don't mind extra whitespace around the output but it would be good to clarify. Also if you explicitly describe the wall appearance and answer milk's question it should make the question sufficiently clear. One thing I think you haven't covered is what output `vvv>>^^^<<` would produce (crosses? pipes?)

Comment: @Dave I edited this question, and i hope i cleared everything.

Comment: I think @Dave is still onto something, when do you have to use `|`/`-` over `+`? Can a corner be formed by two `+`s instead of one? Can an intersection be a `-` next to a `|` instead of a `+` next to either? etc. Unfortunately I can't layout these things in a comment.

Comment: How much spurious whitespace at all sides of the dungeon is allowed ? Several of your examples have unnecessary whitespace

Comment: @TonHospel i might miss something, but tell me in which example you have unnecessary white space?

Comment: @user902383 The `^^^^^vvv<<<^^vv>>>>>>>>vv>><<^^^^v>>>>v^<^` example is indented more to the right than the example above. The number of lines between the control string and the map is also different.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>261</s> <s>254</s> 243 bytes

```
s=>{v=Array(w=32);p=526;b=n=>v[n>>5]&(1<<(n&31));B=(n,i)=>b(p+n)|b(p-n)?i:0;[...0+s].map(c=>v[(p+=[0,1,-1,w,-w]['0><v^'.indexOf(c)])>>5]|=1<<(p&31));for(z='',p=0;p<w*w;z+=' |-+'[b(p)?0:B(1,1)|B(w,2)||B(31,3)|B(33,3)],p++%w||(z+=`
`));return z}
```

#### **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arnauld/pe9kduk2/3/)**

Comment: You can remove the `return` by replacing the `;` with `,` and the `{}` with `()`

Comment: @Cyoce - There's a `for` loop in there which cannot be embedded that way.

Comment: then replace the `{` with `eval("` and `}` with `")` to remove the return http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80967/41042

Comment: @Cyoce - Unfortunately, I think I'd need to escape the literal linebreak as `'\\n'` if I do so. If I count correctly, that actually leads to +1 byte. Or is there a better way to embed the linebreak in the eval?

Comment: You would only need `\n` since template strings support literal new lines, but that would still leave it at the same byte count. Oh well

Answer (score 3):

## C, 246 bytes

```c
n,y,*g,*p;main(c,v)char**v;{for(n=c*2+3,g=calloc(n*n,8),p=g+(n+1)*(c+1);c--;y=*v[c],p-=(y>70?n:1)*(y%5%4?-1:1))*p=1;for(y=n-1;--y;)for(c=n-1;c--;putchar(c?" |-++|-+"[*p?0:p[1]|p[-1]|(p[n]|p[-n])*2|(p[1+n]|p[1-n]|p[n-1]|p[-n-1])*4]:10))p=g+y*n+c;}
```

Takes input as separate characters, for example:

```sh
./mapper '>' '>' '>' 'v' 'v' 'v' '<' '<' '<' '^' '^' '^'
```

Or more conveniently, this (intentionally unquoted!) format:

```sh
./mapper $(echo '>>>vvv<<<^^^' | fold -w1)
```

Or for (pretty inefficient) random input:

```sh
./mapper $(LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc '0-3' < /dev/urandom | tr '0123' '<>^v' | head -c 10 | fold -w1)
```

And finally, using `awk` to crop the result means we can get much bigger:

```sh
./mapper $(LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc '0-3' < /dev/urandom | tr '0123' '<>^v' | head -c 500 | fold -w1) | awk '/[^ ]/{l=match($0,"\\+");if(l&&(l<L||!L))L=l;v[i++]=$0}END{for(;j<i;){l=v[j++];print substr(l,L,match(l," *$")-L)}}'
```

---

```
 +-----+
 |     |
 |     +-+  +-----+
 |       |+-+     |
++       +|      ++
|         |      |
|         +      +-+
+--+               |
 +-+               +--+
 |     ++             |
 +-+  +-++           +-+
   ++   |+--+          |
    +-+ | |        ++  |
     ++ | ++   + +--+ ++
     |  |  +---|      |
     |  |     ++  +---+
     ++ |-+   |   |
      | | +--+-+  |
      | +    +    |
      |        +--+
      +--------+
```

---

Outputs to stdout. Uses the fact that padding is allowed around the map (produces a map which has edge length 2*n+1, putting the final position in the middle).

#### Breakdown

This works by looping over the arguments in reverse and moving in reverse. It actually uses the fact that arg 0 is the program name; it doesn't matter what the name is, but it allows us to visit both the initial and last cell (as well as all cells in-between) without needing special handling.

```c
n,                                  // Size of internal grid
y,                                  // Loop counter / current character
*g,                                 // Internal grid memory
*p;                                 // Current working pointer
main(c,v)char**v;{                  // K&R style function declaration
    for(                            // Step 1: identify visited cells
        n=c*2+3,                    //  Set output grid size
        g=calloc(n*n,8),            //  Allocate map storage space
        p=g+(n+1)*(c+1);            //  Start at centre
        c--;                        //  Loop over directions in reverse
        y=*v[c],                    //  Get current direction
        p-=(y>70?n:1)*(y%5%4?-1:1)  //  Move in reverse
    )*p=1;                          //  Mark cell visited
    for(y=n-1;--y;)                 // For each row (except edges)
        for(c=n-1;c--;              //   For each column (except edges, +1 for \n)
            putchar(c?" |-++|-+"[   //   Print wall using lookup table
                *p?0:p[1]|p[-1]|(p[n]|p[-n])*2|(p[1+n]|p[1-n]|p[n-1]|p[-n-1])*4
            ]:10)                   //   Or newline
        )p=g+y*n+c;                 //   Set current cell (happens first)
}
```

Comment: [236 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY6NisIwDMdf5RCENm1g9TxOVusepOxgBJwHGoPooKh79bqWP/n4JSEJ4UiUM9tkYbQg/jL8syI7aToNN4DJP4/XmxoDDefzlRTDznIg2JhvbSWMZmaYyROiTwGmSL0VDCodfpuOW6dBpfXPetuhW0CDBOfLvhQYnUdMXhekimWJPO7lsKJu9fVCYxZbRZCuaSW6/iURF68kcs2517Ap6EwtOKyBsY7Opb3tW9doXV5NwIb8O@d8qJqq9lV/RR8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")