# Let's get ready for Halloween

Tags: code-golf, string

I don't know about you all but I'm *not* preparing for Halloween––never did never will––but, my neighbor is, so we'll help her out.

She needs help figuring out which brand of candy she has, but she has so much candy she would not be able to finish before Halloween.

She has:

- Snickers
- KitKat
- Starburst
- GummyBears
- Twix

**Input**

A multiline string (or any other reasonable form) containing only letters and spaces.

**Output**

A falsy value if it is not a valid candy, or which candy it is if it is a candy.

**How to decide which candy it is**

A candy is valid if it says one of the above brands on it. However, it's not that simple, because this is a valid candy:

```
K i t
       K a
           t
```

A valid candy is one where:

- the letters are in order from left to right
- the letters are capitalized correctly
- the letters, going from left to right, do not *both* ascend and descend
- the letters with whitespace removed form one of the above brands

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in byte wins!**

**Examples**

Truthys:

```
1.
              kers
           c
        i
       n
    S    

2.
  Kit K a t

3. 
St a
    r b u
         r st 

4.
         Bear s
G ummy

5.
T w i
                          x
```

Falsys:

```
1.
SNICKERS

2.
 C   n

   a   d y

3. 
xiwT

4.
S C I
       ss o
              r       s

5.
Kit
Kat
```

Comment: Can the input be padded with spaces?

Comment: Also, does throwing an error count as returning a falsely value?

Comment: @Loovjo, yes and yes

Comment: Can we assume no blank lines?

Comment: @anonymous2, the input will not be empty

Comment: Your neighbour should have had lollipop, marshmallow and nougat along with KitKat...

Comment: I think @anonymous2 meant with no blank lines something like this: `Twi\n\n\n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;x` (`&nbsp;` = space, comments aren't showing property regarding spaces).

Comment: With the rule "_the letters, going from left to right, do not both ascend o̶r̶  and? descend_", do you mean a test case like `T i\n w x` is a false test-case, since it's starting at line 1, goes to line 2, back to line 1, back to line 2?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, oh well there could be an empty line in the input (only whitespace). Also, yes. The second falsy test case addresses that rule. I'll fix my wording.

Comment: @Dopapp Ah, regarding the second falsey test case, I thought it was false because it was "Candy", which isn't in the list of candies she has (Snickers; KitKat; Starburst; GummyBears; Twix)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, well that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pyth - 72 bytes

I hope I caught all the edge cases. Will base compress candy list.

```
&sSIM_Bmxdh-d;fnd{TK.tQd}-sKdc"Snickers KitKat Starburst GummyBears Twix
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26sSIM_Bmxdh-d%3Bfnd%7BTK.tQd%7D-sKdc%22Snickers+KitKat+Starburst+GummyBears+Twix&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%22K+i+t%22%2C+%22+++++++K+a%22+%2C%22+++++++++++t%22%5D%0A%5B%27++++++++++++++kers%27%2C+%27+++++++++++c%27%2C+%27++++++++i%27%2C+%27+++++++n%27%2C+%27++++S++++%27%5D%0A%5B%27++Kit+K+a+t%27%5D%0A%5B%27St+a%27%2C+%27++++r+b+u%27%2C+%27+++++++++r+st+%27%5D%0A%5B%27+++++++++Bear+s%27%2C+%27G+ummy%27%5D%0A%5B%27T+w+i%27%2C+%27++++++++++++++++++++++++++x%27%5D%0A%5B%27SNICKERS%27%5D%0A%5B%27+C+++n%27%2C+%27++++++++++y%27%2C+%27+++a+++d%27%5D%0A%5B%27xiwT%27%5D%0A%5B%27S+C+I%27%2C+%27+++++++ss+o%27%2C+%27++++++++++++++r+++++++s%27%5D%0A%5B%27Kit%27%2C+%27Kat%27%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>221</s> <s>218</s> <s>216</s> <s>212</s> <s>208</s> <s>205</s> 201 bytes

```
f=a=>(c=d=L=0,e=1,s=[],[...a].map(a=>a=='\n'?c=L=0:c++-(a!=' '&&(s[c]?e=0:(!L&&(d?d-1?e&=c>Q>d-3:d=c>Q>2:d=1),L=s[Q=c]=a)))),e&&'Snickers0KitKat0Starburst0GummyBears0Twix'.split(0).indexOf(s.join``)+1)
```

## [Try it here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf0xhtpx/7/)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and great first answer! Unfortunately, I don't believe this is valid; it returns a truthy value for `Snick`, `ears|T`, etc. I think you can fix this by adding `.split('|')` before `.indexOf`.

Comment: This is valid now.

Comment: @ETHproductions. The `ears|T` is not the problem because only letters are allowed in test cases. However, you are right, for `Snick`.

Comment: [Use this for -2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript/11699#11699)

Comment: You can also use [this trick](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52204/42545) to save several bytes.

Comment: @ETHproductions. Correct. It actually saves 4 bytes.

Comment: You can also remove the parentheses around `(e&=d-2-(c<Q))` and `(d=2+(c>Q))`, and replace ```a.split``.map``` with `[...a].map`.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 446 bytes

```
(let((lr list-ref)(ls list-set)(sl string-length)(ss substring)(l(string-split s "\n")))(let loop((changed #f))(for((i(sub1(length l))))
(let*((s(lr l i))(r(lr l(add1 i)))(n(sl s))(m(sl r)))(when(> n m)(set! l(ls l i(ss s 0 m)))(set! l(ls l(add1 i)
(string-append r(ss s m n))))(set! changed #t))))(if changed(loop #f)(begin(let*((l(for/list((i l))(string-trim i)))(l(string-join l))
(l(string-replace l " " "")))(ormap(λ(x)(equal? x l))cl))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s cl)
  (let ((lr list-ref)
        (ls list-set)
        (sl string-length)
        (ss substring)
        (l (string-split s "\n")))
    (let loop ((changed #f))
      (for ((i (sub1 (length l))))
        (let* ((s (lr l i))
               (r (lr l (add1 i)))
               (n (sl s))
               (m (sl r)))
               (when (> n m)
                 (set! l (ls l i (ss s 0 m)))
                 (set! l (ls l (add1 i)(string-append r (ss s m n))))
                 (set! changed #t))))
        (if changed (loop #f)
            (begin
              (let* ((l (for/list ((i l))
                          (string-trim i)))
                     (l (string-join l))
                     (l (string-replace l " " "")))
                (ormap (λ(x) (equal? x l)) cl)))
            ))))
```

Testing:

```
(f "
              kers
           c
        i
       n
    S"
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))


(f "  Kit K a t"
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))

(f "St a
    r b u
         r st "
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))

(f "         Bear s
G ummy"
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))

(f "T w i
                          x"
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))

(f "SNICKERS"
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))
(f " C   n
          y
   a   d"
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))

(f "xiwT"
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))

(f "S C I
       ss o
              r       s"
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))

(f "Kit
Kat"
   (list "Snickers""KitKat""Starburst""GummyBears""Twix"))
```

Output:

```
#t
#t
#t
#t
#t
#f
#f
#f
#f
#t
```

Comment: I think you named your output "Ungolfed"

Comment: Yes. I have corrected the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 139 bytes

```
a=>/^(Snickers|KitKat|Starburst|GummyBears|Twix)$/.test(a.reduce((s,t)=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>c<'!'?t[i]:t[i]<'!'?c:'!')).replace(/ /g,''))
```

Accepts input as an array of space-padded strings.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 254 bytes

I'm sure this can be golfed more. Input is an array of lines `s`.

```
x=len
p=lambda a:x(a)-x(a.lstrip())
g=sorted
a=map(p,l)
j=''.join
z=[i.replace(' ','')for i in l]
if g(a)==a:q=j(z)
elif g(a)==a[::-1]:q=j(z[::-1])
else:q=''
if x(set(a))<x(a):q=''
print 1if q in('Snickers','KitKat','Starburst','GummyBears','Twix')else 0
```

[Try it here!](http://ideone.com/aNChZv)

Comment: You can take the input as a string array/list, so there is no need to split it in the first line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 199 chars

```
function(M){if(any(outer(z<-diff(apply(M,1,function(r)which.min(r==" ")))),z<0))return(F);C=c("Twix","KitKat","Starburst","Snickers","GummyBears");C[match(paste0(gsub(" ","",c(t(M))),collapse=""),C)}
```

Input is in the form of a character matrix.

`match` takes care of *which* candy it is (it checks capitalisation too).

To check that the letters are an "ascending" or "descending" sequence, we just need to check that the locations of the first non-space character (if there) in each row is increasing or decreasing. To do, this we

- take the first location of a nonspace character in each row, using `apply`
- take the `diff`. This might have some zero in it, otherwise should either be all positive or all negative
- name the `diff` `z`, and take the outer product with itself. If the diff had mixed positive and negative entries, there will be a negative entry somewhere in its outer product. If so, return FALSE.

Note that cases like

```
"    i "
"   w x"
"  T   "
```

will return an empty character vector (in particular not "Twix"), since `match` will be trying to match "Twxi".