# Display a Digital Clock

Tags: code-golf

### Display a Digital Clock

(I see there are many clock challenges, I have tried to read them all, I'm pretty sure this is unique)

Write some code that continuously updates a digital clock displayed in the format `h:m:s` where `h`, `m`, and `s` can occupy 1 or 2 characters each. The restrictions in simple terms as @BlueEyedBeast put it, I basically want it to replace the time shown.

- Newlines are not allowed
- Trailing spaces are allowed
- Other trailing characters are not allowed
- No seconds should be missed (57 -> 59 is not allowed)
- Numbers beginning with "0" are allowed, as long as they don't occupy more than 2 characters
- The code must not accept any input
- If your language can't get the current time without input, you may use for input up to 8 bytes in a standardly allowed way
- Output must be to stdout
- This is codegolf so the shortest answer wins!

**Example**

<s>I'm working on a language named *><> (starfish) because programs like this aren't possible in ><> (just wait for file i/o) . Here's a working digital clock program in it (ungolfed).</s> This program is written in [*><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish):

```
s":"m":"hnonon"   "ooo88888888888ooooooooooo1S
```

<sup>Note: Everything is identical to ><> in this except, s = second, m = minute, h = hour, S = sleep(100ms*x)</sup>

This outputs:

```
14:44:31
```

Updating every 100ms until terminated.

**Disallowed Examples**

The following are not allowed:

1:

```
14:44:3114:44:32
```

2:

```
14:44:31 14:44:32
```

3:

```
14:44:31
14:44:32
```

The time must remain on the first line it was outputted with no visible trailing characters. Clearing the terminal though, would be allowed as that still wouldn't have any trailing characters.

Comment: do we have to wait 100ms or can we just update constantly forever?

Comment: you don't have to wait, the wait is just what the example does.

Comment: The challenge requirements seem too strict to me.

Comment: I just thought without restricting the output this would have been too easy. There are a multitude of ways to write the time to one line. Why is this too strict?

Comment: @mbomb007 I removed "The program must be able to exit on user input that isn't a signal/interrupt" as the current answers didn't seem to follow it anyways.

Comment: Does it have to be in local time?

Comment: How does your example program stop when enter key is hit? Is it the `S`? And why do you print three spaces after the time? (Just curiosities)

Comment: Can the program rely on a specific local setting of the OS?

Comment: @Leo ah an older revision did that. I updated the description to no longer say it exits on enter (It used to have `i1+?;` or something).

Comment: @Winny, it can be any timezone as long as it's actually the time (or at least reasonably close, so it can be used to tell time).

Comment: @raznagul, I'm not sure what you mean, do you have an example? I'll probably allow it.

Comment: @redstarcoder: In C# `DateTime.Now.ToString("T")` would return `19:43:16` on my PC as the region setting is set to Germany. But on a PC with a region setting of US the result would be `7:43:16 PM`.

Comment: @raznagul, that's fine, just specify the conditions to make your output valid!

Comment: Isn't this the same as "output the current time"? I'm on a phone so cant edit a link, sorry

Comment: @ev3commander it's similar, but not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
Ctr\ J
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Ctr%5C+J)

I think this is valid. Replace the space character with carriage return for valid output (does not work online)

Comment: Sorry it's not. No newlines are allowed or trailing characters after the time. I'll put 2 examples to be more explicit.

Comment: I don't see that in the spec?

Comment: The first line says newlines are not allowed, the third says no trailing characters. I'm sorry if that's unclear, I'd appreciate advice on fixing it.

Comment: So you want it to replace the old time shown?

Comment: Yes exactly! Your current code seems perfect.

Answer (score 10):

## HTML + JS (ES6), 8 + 60 = 68 bytes

Tested in Chrome.

```js
setInterval`a.innerHTML=new Date().toLocaleTimeString('fr')`
```

```html
<a id=a>
```

-1 byte (@ETHProductions): Use French time format instead of `.toTimeString().slice(0,8)`

---

## HTML + JS (ES6), 8 + 62 = 70 bytes

This will work in FireFox.

```js
setInterval('a.innerHTML=new Date().toLocaleTimeString`fr`',0)
```

```html
<a id=a>
```

-3 bytes (@ETHProductions): Use French time format instead of `.toTimeString().slice(0,8)`

Comment: How does this work? I've never seen the backtick syntax before. I can't find anything on it either after some quick searching.

Comment: Working for me in Inox (Chromium)

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's part of the latest JavaScript spec, ECMAScript6. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @darrylyeo Thanks. I could find things on the literal syntax, but I couldn't see how it was applied here. I need to read the spec again. I still don't understand how the function that precedes the backtick is used.

Comment: @edc65 Aww man!

Comment: The second snippet is missing its HTML ;-)

Comment: You can save 3 bytes in the Firefox one with ``new Date().toLocaleTimeString`fr` `` (1 byte in the Chrome one with `...TimeString('fr')`)

Comment: Wow, I never would have thought of using the French time format!

Comment: @Carcigenicate you already are in the right place http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52204/21348 read the comments too

Comment: Hey Darryl! Funny seeing you here. :3
That template literal syntax blew me away!

Comment: Huh? Isn't 60 + 8 68?

Comment: @Oliver Whoops, not sure how that happened!

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 50 bytes

(Python 2.1+ for `ctime` with no argument)

```python
import time
while 1:print'\r'+time.ctime()[11:19],
```

`time.ctime()` yields a formatted string, from which the hh:mm:ss may be sliced using `[11:19]` (it remains in the same location whatever the date and time).

`print`ing the carriage return `'\r'` before the text and making the text the first item of a tuple with `,` effectively suppresses the implicit trailing `'\n'` and overwrites the previously written output.

`while 1` loops forever.

Comment: I think this needs a `,` at the end to supress the newline otherwise in Python 2.7.12 I get newlines.

Comment: Oops, yes you are correct... updated

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>48</s> <s>41</s> <s>37</s> 28 bytes

```
Do[s=Now[[2]],∞]~Monitor~s
```

The output will be a `TimeObject`, refreshing continuously.

Looks like this: [image]

**Alternative versions**

48 bytes:

```
Dynamic@Refresh[TimeObject[],UpdateInterval->.1]
```

53 bytes:

```
Dynamic@Refresh[DateString@"Time",UpdateInterval->.1]
```

Comment: With it updating every second, did you ensure that it never skips seconds? (Ex: 11:11:11 -> 11:11:13)

Comment: `Dynamic@{DateString@TimeObject[], Clock[]}[[1]]`

Comment: @redstarcoder it updates every ~1.002s, so I changed to updating every 100ms

Comment: Welp, I just realized I don't actually need `Pause`.

Comment: `Dynamic@{Now,Clock[]}[[1]]` is 26 bytes and shows a datetime object. `Dynamic@{DateString@"Time",Clock[]}[[1]]` is 40 bytes and outputs only hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 5):

I see that the requirement for a non-signal UI input to stop the program has been removed.  So now we can do:

## Bash + coreutils, 28

```bash
yes now|date -f- +$'\e[2J'%T
```

`yes` continuously outputs the string "now", once per line, into a pipe.

`date -f-` reads interprets each "now" as the current time, then outputs in the required format.  The format string includes the ANSI escape sequence to clear the screen.  `date` *does* output a newline after the date - I'm not sure if this disqualifies, since the screen is cleared every time anyway.

If it disqualifies, then we can use `tr` instead:

## Bash + coreutils, 31

```bash
yes now|date -f- +%T|tr \\n \\r
```

---

Previous Answers:

## Bash + X, 32

```bash
xclock -d -update 1 -strftime %T
```

Unfortunately this can only update every second.  If that disqualifies, then we can do this instead:

## Bash + coreutils, 43

```bash
until read -t0
do printf `date +%T`\\r
done
```

Comment: Updating every second is fine, as long as it doesn't ever skip seconds (IE: 12-> 14).

Comment: I'll allow your newline! I never expected this case to happen heh.

Comment: Is this allowed? `date +$'\e[2J'%T;$0`

Comment: @EvanChen no, because each iteration recursively spawns a new process and will eventually use up available memory or PID space, analogous to a stack overflow.  However you could do `date +$'\e[2J'%T;exec $0` for 24 bytes...

Answer (score 4):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 6 bytes

```
{_C?_d

{      Starts a DO-loop
 _C    CLS
   ?   PRINT
    _d TIME$
```

Constantly clears the screen and prints the system time in the format `22:03:41`.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 28 bytes

```
for(;;)echo date("\rH:i:s");
```

The `date` function prints everything literally that it doesn´t recognize.

`\r` is the carriage return, sets the cursor to the first column.

Run with `-r`.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + watch, 19 bytes

*watch* is not a part of *coreutils*, but is available  out of the box on virtually every Linux distro.

**Golfed**

```
watch -tn1 date +%T
```

[Try it online !](https://goo.gl/5Ayb7t)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
`XxZ'13XODT
```

Infinite loop that clears the screen and prints the time in the specified format.

You can try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=%60XxZ%2713XODT&inputs=&version=19.5.1). This compiler is experimental; if it doesn't work refresh the page and press "Run" again.

Answer (score 3):

## Clojure, <s>150</s> <s>136</s> 141 bytes

### V3: 141 bytes :(

+5 bytes to fix a bug. Since the times aren't zero padded, the clock can "shrink" and expand when the time changes. It was "smearing" when it shrunk because the last digit was no longer being cleared. Fixed it by adding some spaces at the end to ensure everything is being overwritten.

```clj
#(while true(flush)(print(str(apply str(repeat 9"\b"))(.format(java.text.SimpleDateFormat."H:m:s")(java.util.Date.))"   "))(Thread/sleep 99))
```

### V2: 136 bytes

```clj
#(while true(flush)(print(str(apply str(repeat 9"\b"))(.format(java.text.SimpleDateFormat."H:m:s")(java.util.Date.))))(Thread/sleep 99))
```

-14 bytes by switching to using `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date. Still huge.

### V1: 150 bytes

```clj
#(while true(let[d(java.util.Date.)](flush)(print(str(apply str(repeat 9 "\b"))(.getHours d)":"(.getMinutes d)":"(.getSeconds d)))(Thread/sleep 100)))
```

I realized I'm probably using the worst way possible to get the date. Definitely room for improvement here.

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn -main []
  (while true
    (let [d (java.util.Date.)]
      (flush)
      (print
        (str
          (apply str (repeat 9 "\b"))
          (.getHours d)":"(.getMinutes d)":"(.getSeconds d)))
      (Thread/sleep 100))))
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, <s>134</s> <s>116</s> <s>89</s> <s>80</s> <s>76</s> <s>75</s> 73 bytes

```c
main(n){for(;time(&n);)printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d",n/3600%24,n/60%60,n%60);}

---- Old versions:
main(n){for(;;)n=time(0),printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d",n/3600%24,n/60%60,n%60);}

n;main(){for(;;)n=time(0),printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d",n/3600%24,n/60%60,n%60);}

---- 

n;main(){for(;;)n=time(0),printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d",n/3600%24,n/60%60,n%60);}

----

Saved 9 more bytes thanks to @nmjcman101 again:
n;main(){for(;;)n=time(0),printf("\r%02d:%02d:%02d",(n/3600)%24,(n/60)%60,n%60);}

----

Saved 27 bytes thanks to @nmjcman101
n,b[9];main(){for(;;){n=time(0);strftime(b,9,"%H:%M:%S",localtime(&n));printf("\r%s",b);}}

----

I figured out I don't need to put `#include<stdio.h>` into the file :)
#include<time.h>
main(){for(;;){time_t n=time(0);char b[9];strftime(b,9,"%H:%M:%S",localtime(&n));printf("\r%s",b);}}

----

#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main(){for(;;){time_t n=time(0);char b[9];strftime(b,9,"%H:%M:%S",localtime(&n));printf("\r%s",b);}}
```

Comment: It looks like (for me) you can remove `time.h` as well.  This removes the time_t type, so you need to make n an int instead.  This can be done by declaring it outside of main (like `n;main...`), which removes the need for the `int`.  You can also get rid of the `char` with the same trick: `b[9];main...`.  They're both int type now, but it's flexible enough.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, I didn't know this would work. Thank you

Comment: Please stop me if you'd like to golf it yourself, but I also took out the `strftime...` and the `b[9]` and just made print into this: `printf("\r%d:%d:%d",(n/3600)%60-29,(n/60)%60,n%60);`  I'm not sure if the parens are needed or not.  Also you can take out a set of `{}` by putting commas between your statements so it's `for(;;)a,b,c;`

Comment: I'll just go try it, I've never golfed in C before so I don't know most of those tricks, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you please explain why you calculate hours that way (`(n/3600)%60-29`), the result is wrong for me but correct when I subtract `24`

Comment: I screwed up.  Hours should be `(n/3600)%24` NOT `%60`.  I think that gives you GMT, so then I would have to -5 to get EST.  Just using GMT might be fine though?

Comment: These parentheses are annoying. `(n/60)%60`, seriously?

Comment: @anatolyg yeah, you're right. Those aren't necessary

Comment: You can save 1 byte by declaring `n` as parameter of `main`, say `main(n)` instead of `n;main()`

Comment: @JayDepp, please don't suggest or make edits to others' code

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC 3.3.2, 38 bytes

```
@L?TIME$;" ";
GOTO@L
```

UTF-16 sucks :(

Anyway, this repeatedly prints the local time in HH:MM:SS with a space after it, no newline afterward. It doesn't update every second though, it just repeatedly prints forever.

Comment: Sorry this isn't valid, it needs to replace the output, this doesn't. Setting the first line to  `@L?TIME$` and appending a line after (for a total of 3 lines) that reads `LOCATE 0, 0` does the trick (does SmileBASIC support carriage return?).

Comment: Also you forgot to score the newline, making this 40 bytes (UTF-16 is brutal for code golf). You can get the character length very easilly via Python REPL `len(""" YOUR CODE HERE """)`, then just do *2 for UTF-16.

Comment: No SB doesn't do CR actually, I would have to drop a LOCATE statement into there which would absolutely destroy my score :P Or a CLS:VSYNC which is just as bad.

Comment: Yeah, sadly this solution is invalid without it. Good news though! [SmileBASIC is scored as UTF-8](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11147/62670).

Answer (score 2):

## WinDbg, 73 bytes

```
.do{r$t0=0;.foreach(p {.echotime}){r$t0=@$t0+1;j8==@$t0'.printf"p \r"'}}1
```

It continually updates a line with the current time until the user presses Ctrl+Break.

How it works:

```
.do                          * Start do-while loop
{
    r$t0 = 0;                * Set $t0 = 0
    .foreach(p {.echotime})  * Foreach space-delimited word in a sentence like "Debugger (not 
    {                        * debuggee) time: Mon Dec  5 14:08:10.138 2016 (UTC - 8:00)"
        r$t0 = @$t0+1;       * Increment $t0
        j 8==@$t0            * If $t0 is 8 (ie- p is the current time)
        '
            .printf"p \r"    * Print p (current time) and \r so the next print overwrites
        '
    }
} 1                          * Do-while condition: 1, loop forever
```

Sample output (well, you get the idea):

```
0:000> .do{r$t0=0;.foreach(p {.echotime}){r$t0=@$t0+1;j8==@$t0'.printf"p \r"'}}1
14:10:12.329
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 82 bytes

```
()=>{for(;;)Console.Write(new string('\b',8)+DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));};
```

Anonymous method which constantly overwrites 8 characters with new output. Can be made 1 byte shorter if modifying to accept a dummy parameter (`z=>...`).

Full program:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Action a =
        () =>
        {
            for (;;)
                Console.Write(new string('\b', 8) + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        };

        a();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it allowed not to import `System`? Some people do it, and some people don't :/

Comment: He didn't in his actual solution, just in the demo program, so yes, it is ok

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 65 bytes

```cs
()=>{for(;;)Console.Write("\r"+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());};
```

Works by overwriting the same line within an endless loop

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 39 bytes

```
for(){write-host -n(date -F h:m:s`0`r)}
```

Because I dislike using cls in Powershell. From briantist's post @https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102450/63383

Answer (score 2):

## Pascal, 61 bytes

```
uses sysutils;begin while 1=1do write(#13,timetostr(now))end.
```

Free pascal has nice time routines in SysUtils unit. Ungolfed:

```
uses
  sysutils;
begin
  while 1=1 do
    write(#13, timetostr(now));
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore BASIC (CBM/PET, C64, C128, VIC-20, C16/+4), <strike>64</strike> ~62 BASIC bytes (tokens), <strike>64</strike> 62 PETSCII characters with keyword abbreviations

```
?"{CLEAR}":FORI=0TO1:?"{HOME}"LEFT$(TI$,2)":"MID$(TI$,3,2)":"RIGHT$(TI$,2):I=0:NEXT
```

**Edit** I realised that this is what I would call a *zero liner*, or in other words, it does not require a line number to run, so I've taken this out. Once you break it though, you need to type it in again.

**Changes** Line numbers in Commodore BASIC take up I think at least two bytes (though I need to check), so by actual byte count is an estimation, however, removing the line number and using the `LEFT$` command for the first two digits, rather than the `MID$` command, has shaved off two whole characters from this.

Some notes: if you are entering this on a Commodore C64 then you will need to use keyword abbreviations (see the screen shot below). Some other Commodore 8-bits, like the C128 and VIC-20, accept more than 80 characters entered per line, but to be sure, use the keyword abbreviations anyway.

To set the time first, use `TI$="112233"` as `HHMMSS` format as 24 hours (`000000` being midnight).

### How it works

`TI$` is a system variable which fairly accurately keeps time. 8 BIT Show and Tell explores this in some depth in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/VkabHdR15xs) and is well worth a watch if you are interested.

An unbroken loop is set with resetting the `I` variable per iteration by setting it to `0`. We then use the `MID$` and `RIGHT$` function to print out each relevant time segment, being `HH:MM:SS`. A list of BASIC keywords can be found [here](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/BASIC).

[image: Display a Digital Clock, Commodore C64]

Comment: I can save a few bytes by using the `LEFT$` command in place of the first `MID$` command, because of the way that Commodore BASIC tokenises each keyword.

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 26 bytes

```
qqS<C-r>=strftime("%T")<CR><esc>@qq@q
```

This creates a recursive macro (e.g. an eternal loop) that deletes all the text on the current line and replaces it with the current time.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 28 bytes

Kinda longish, because pyth  has no strftime.

```
#p+"\r"j\:m.[`02`dP>4.d2.d.1
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <s>30</s> <s>28</s> <s>24</s> 20 bytes

Changed my computer's region to Germany based on [raznagul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42502/raznagul)'s comment to save 4 bytes. :)

```
for(){date -F T;cls}
```

#### Previous version that works in all locales.

```
for(){date -F h:m:s;cls}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 45 characters

```groovy
for(;;)print(new Date().format("\rHH:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
13Ọ7ŒTȮß

13Ọ        chr(13), carriage return
   7ŒT     time string, which extends the previous character
      Ȯ    print
       ß   call the whole link again
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MTPhu4w3xZJUyK7Dnw)

The carriage return doesn't work online, and I can't get the interpreter to work, so its kinda untested, but it works as expected when I use printable characters in place of the CR.

Answer (score 1):

## ForceLang, 123 bytes

```
def s set
s d datetime
s z string.char 8
s z z.repeat 16
label 1
io.write z
io.write d.toTimeString d.now()
d.wait 9
goto 1
```

`datetime.toTimeString` is backed in the reference implementation by Java's `DateFormat.getTimeInstance()`, which is locale-dependent, so you can set your default system locale to one that uses 24-hour time.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 67 bytes

```
for(;;)System.out.print("\r"+java.time.LocalTime.now()+"\b\b\b\b");
```

We loop infinitely, grabbing the current time and outputting to screen. The quad backspace is for easy formatting, because otherwise we'd have to do something like this:

```
for(;;)System.out.print("\r" + java.time.LocalTime.now().truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
```

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 69 bytes

```
while 1 {puts -nonewline \r[clock format [clock seconds] -format %T]}
```

[Try it here!](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUkdTRkhVUDRFbkU)

Answer (score 1):

### C 65 (prev 64) bytes

Guaranteed to work on Linux machine. :)

@Marco Thanks!

```
f(){while(1){system("date +%T");usleep(100000);system("clear");}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 14 bytes

```
CLS?TIME$EXEC.
```

`CLS` clears the screen, `? TIME$` prints the current time, and `EXEC 0` runs the code that's in slot 0.
It's a bit flickery, but there's nothing in the reqirements about that, so it should be fine.

Format is `HH:MM:SS` 24 hour time :(

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>71</del> 69 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: b81c 35cd 2153 06ba 1901 e806 00b4 08cd  ..5.!S..........
00000010: 211f 5ab8 1c25 cd21 c3b4 2ccd 218a c5e8  !.Z..%.!..,.!...
00000020: 0800 91e8 0400 8ac6 b2ff d40a 0d30 3086  .............00.
00000030: e0cd 2986 e0cd 2984 d27c 05b0 3acd 29c3  ..)...)..|..:.).
00000040: b00d cd29 cf                             ...).
```

Listing:

```
B8 351C         MOV  AX, 0351CH             ; AL = 1CH, AH = 35H 
CD 21           INT  21H                    ; get interrupt vector for 1CH into ES:BX
53              PUSH BX                     ; save old vector
06              PUSH ES                     ; save old segment
BA 011D R       MOV  DX, OFFSET GET_TIME    ; DX = interrupt vector of time proc 
E8 0117 R       CALL SET_VECT               ; setup new vector
B4 08           MOV  AH, 8                  ; DOS read char from stdin without echo
CD 21           INT  21H                    ; wait for user to press the "any key"
1F              POP  DS                     ; restore old segment
5A              POP  DX                     ; restore old vector
            SET_VECT: 
B8 251C         MOV  AX, 0251CH             ; AL = 1CH, AH = 25H 
CD 21           INT  21H                    ; set interrupt vector from DS:DX
C3              RET                         ; return to DOS 
            GET_TIME: 
B4 2C           MOV  AH, 2CH                ; get DOS time 
CD 21           INT  21H                    ; CH = hour CL = minute DH = second 
8A C5           MOV  AL, CH                 ; display hour: AL = CH 
E8 012E R       CALL OUT_TIME               ; write time
91              XCHG AX, CX                 ; display minute: AL = CL 
E8 012E R       CALL OUT_TIME               ; write time
8A C6           MOV  AL, DH                 ; display second: AL = DH 
B2 FF           MOV  DL, -1                 ; set DL to -1 so doesn't display ':' 
            OUT_TIME:    
D4 0A           AAM                         ; BCD convert: AL = AL % 10, AH = AL / 10 
0D 3030         OR   AX, '00'               ; ASCII convert 
86 E0           XCHG AH, AL                 ; endian convert 
CD 29           INT  29H                    ; write tens 
86 E0           XCHG AH, AL                 ; swap digits 
CD 29           INT  29H                    ; write ones 
84 D2           TEST DL, DL                 ; when DL = -1, it is seconds digit 
7C 05           JL   DONE_TIME              ; if last number, write CR not ':'
B0 3A           MOV  AL, ':'                ; write ':'
CD 29           INT  29H 
C3              RET                         ; return from near call
            DONE_TIME: 
B0 0D           MOV  AL, 0DH                ; carriage return 
CD 29           INT  29H                    ; move cursor back to beginning of line
CF              IRET                        ; return from interrupt
```

A standalone PC DOS executable COM program.  Uses DOS to hook the hardware timer interrupt which calls the program every 18.2ms to update the clock on the screen.  Exits when any key is pressed.

Runtime:

[image]

(A key was hit after 5 seconds, exiting the program)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
i@OqK¤¯8
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=aUBPcUukrzg)

```
i@OqK¤¯8
i            :Every 0 milliseconds
 @           :Run the following function
  Oq         :Replace the output with
    K        :Date object
     ¤       :Convert to time string
      ¯8     :Slice to the 8th character
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[žažbžc':ý13ç«?
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//1vFvmHFvmLFvmMnOsO9MTPDp8KrP//Rgi5XTjUwUSP/) (The TIO doesn't support carriage returns, so every line is printed without overwriting the previous line. I also included a footer with a 0.1 sec sleep and which stops after 5 seconds, so the output won't be flooded with the same outputs and you won't have to wait 60 seconds for it to timeout.)

*Here a gif to see it in action:*

[image]

**Explanation:**

```python
[                # Loop indefinitely:
 ža              #  Push the current hours
   žb            #  Push the current minutes
     žc          #  Push the current seconds
       ':ý      '#  Join the entire stack with ":" as delimiter
          13ç    #  Push 13 and convert it to a character: '\r'
             «   #  Append this carriage return to the time-string
              ?  #  Pop and output this string (without newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Windows Batch Scripting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting), 55 bytes

```
@echo off
:l
cls
echo %time:~0,8%
timeout 1 >nul
goto l
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 36 bytes

```
@set/p.=␈␈␈␈␈␈␈␈%time:~0,8%<nul
@%0
```

Where `␈` represents the ASCII BS character (code 8).

Answer (score 0):

## Racket, 71 bytes

```
(require srfi/19)(let l()(display(date->string(current-date)"↵~3"))(l))
```

Where the `↵` is actually a CR (hex `0d`). Hex dump of the program for further clarification (notice byte at position hex `4d`):

```
00000000  28 72 65 71 75 69 72 65  20 73 72 66 69 2f 31 39  |(require srfi/19|
00000010  29 28 6c 65 74 20 6c 28  29 28 64 69 73 70 6c 61  |)(let l()(displa|
00000020  79 28 64 61 74 65 2d 3e  73 74 72 69 6e 67 28 63  |y(date->string(c|
00000030  75 72 72 65 6e 74 2d 64  61 74 65 29 22 0d 7e 33  |urrent-date)".~3|
00000040  22 29 29 28 6c 29 29                              |"))(l))|
00000047
```

Uses [SRFI/19](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-19.html) included with the Racket distribution. `(current-date)` gets the current local date & time. The `date->string` format `~3` is ISO-8601 hour-minute-second format. `(let l () ... (l))` in an idiomatic infinite loop. `(require srfi/19)` loads the `srfi/19` module.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 156 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(){time_t a;struct tm *b;char c[9];for(;;){time(&a);b=localtime(&a);strftime(c,9,"%H:%M:%S",b);printf("%s\r",c);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [*><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Starfish) (Starfish), 22 bytes

```
"   ::"s@hm@donononooo
```

[Try it here!](https://starfish.000webhostapp.com/?script=EQAjC52BnABALAtrAJgewHae2tQ)

**Ungolfed**

```
>s":"m":"hnonon"   "ooo1S\
\                 ;?+1iod/
```

### Explanation

```
d                      push \r to the stack
 "   ::"               push "   ::" to the stack
        s              push seconds to the stack
         @             move seconds back 2
          hm           push hours and minutes to the stack
            @          move minutes back 2
             n         output a number
              o        output a character
```

First, we build the initial stack with `d"   ::"s`, giving us `["\r", "   ", ":", ":", seconds]`, building the stack this way saves two bytes by removing 4 `"`, and adding two `@`. It's important to know what the `@` instruction does here, it simply changes the end of the stack in such a way so `[1,2,3,4] @ [1,4,2,3]`. So we run `@` giving us a stack of `["\r", "   ", seconds, ":", ":"]`. Then we run `hm@`, which adds the hours, then the minutes to the end of the stack and executes `@`, giving us `["\r", "   ", seconds, ":", ":", hours, minutes] @ ["\r", "   ", seconds, ":", minutes, ":", hours]`. In `nononoooo`, `n` outputs a number from the end of the stack, `o` outputs a byte.

Then the ><> simply loops back around to the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 17 Bytes

Outputs current time to cell `A1`

```vb
Do:[A1]=Now:Loop
```

Note: The above subroutine does not exit so either holding `Esc` to terminate the process or adding a `DoEvents` call to the sub above (`Sub a:Do:[A1]=Now:DoEvents:Loop`) to allow for hitting the stop button is recommended

Answer (score 0):

### TI-Basic, 40 Bytes

(In TI-BASIC, many characters are 2 byte tokens, and colons at the beginning of a line are 0 extra bytes)

```
:ClrHome
:Output(1,6,":
:setTmFmt(24
:While 1
:Output(1,1,getTmSrr(0
:getTime
:Output(1,7,Ans(3
:End
```

Comment: I have a TI calculator (TI‑82) but it does not feature the time commands. Could you indicate the minimum hardware requirements?

Answer (score 0):

## R, 41 bytes

```
repeat{cat(format(Sys.time(),"%T"),"\r")}
```

Has one trailing space (because of `cat` default separator being a space).
Because of the refresh rate of the R GUI, running this in the GUI will occasionally skip some seconds, but if you save it to a file and run it on the command line it will display correctly every single seconds.
Will run forever until user interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 25 bytes (not including newline)

```
:k
@echo %time% && @goto k
```

Example output:

[image: example output]

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not a valid answer: `The time must remain on the first line it was outputted with no visible trailing characters. Clearing the terminal though, would be allowed as that still wouldn't have any trailing characters.` - see the disallowed answers section of the prompt for more information

Answer (score 0):

### HP‑41C series, 9 Bytes

This program requires an HP‑41CX or an HP‑41C/CV with a time module plugged in.
Press the `R/S` (run/stop) key to interrupt the program.
Press the `⭠` key to return to the regular display with the current time now being the value of the `X` register (`HH.MMSSss` format).
Pressing any other key will clear the display, too, but also execute the key’s associated function.

```
01♦LBL⸆T           5 Bytes  global label requires 4 + (length of string) Bytes
02 CLK24           2 Bytes  select military time format
03 CLOCK           2 Bytes  show the current time refreshing every second
```

The default setting is showing a 12‑hour clock (using AM/PM) and a calendar date (`MM/DD`).
You may need to insert the `CLKT` command (2 Bytes) to revert to this setting (i. e. omitting the calendar date) to see the current seconds value, too.

Remember, if you are running low on batteries (indicated by the `BAT` annunciator and flag 49 set), the `CLOCK` command turns the calculator *off*.
The continuous clock draws about 2 mA of power.