# Implement a Stopwatch

Tags: code-golf, date, base-conversion, interactive

Implement a simple digital [Stopwatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopwatch),
which will display the time elapsed in seconds and minutes, as described below.

> **Important**
>
> Please read both *Display* and *Controls* sections !

**Display**

Time elapsed, should be displayed in the `MM:SS` format,
by replacing the previously displayed time string "in-place"
(clearing the whole or a part of the screen is also allowed).

The stopwatch must be updated at least every second.

*Examples:*

0 minutes, 0 seconds

```
00:00
```

0 minutes, 33 seconds

```
00:33
```

1 minute, 50 seconds

```
01:50
```

Initially, you can start with '00:00' or with any other value in range [00:00-59:59].

Once your Stopwatch reaches `59:59`, it should reset to `00:00` and continue afresh.

You can use a different base (instead of decimal) or even a different numeral system if you wish, as long as you follow the general pattern.

For example `13:03` can be displayed as:

[Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)

```
13:03
```

[Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

```
0D:03
```

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

```
N:D
```

[Quater-imaginary base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quater-imaginary_base)

```
10101:3
```

[Roman Numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)

```
XIII:III
```

Beware that if you use a non-decimal numeral system/base, it must be encoded using printable ASCII (or Unicode) characters, e.g. using two binary (unprintable) bytes for minutes and seconds is not allowed.

You must also left-pad your output with zeroes as appropriate, if your numerical system allows for that.

Replacing the separator character `:` with any other printable character (including digits) is also acceptable.

**Controls**

The stopwatch should start *paused*, and stay in this state, until user explicitly *starts* it, by pressing the *'control'* key (see below).

If, while stopwatch is counting, user presses the *'control'* key again, the stopwatch should *pause* (keeping the current time), until the *'control'* key is pressed a one more time.

The *'control'* key can be a single keystroke, e.g. `s`,
or any combination of keys, e.g. `Ctrl+Shift+X`, but it must be 'atomic', pressing multiple keys in sequence, e.g. `s` then `Enter`, is *not allowed*.

The same *'control'* key (or combination) must be used to *pause* and *resume* the stopwatch.

You must use a specific *'control'* key, i.e. 'any key' is not allowed.

Alternatively, you can use a single or double mouse-click, instead of a keypress for 'control'.

---

**Rules**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer in bytes wins;
- Standard code-golf loopholes apply;
- Your program must (theoretically) be capable of running forever.

Comment: Can the 'control' key be enter?

Comment: @Loovjo Yes, any single key or combination of keys will do, including Enter (as long it can be paused and then resumed using the same key).

Comment: [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102251/display-a-digital-clock/102283#102283)

Comment: Do we need sub-second granularity? I.e. if the user pauses approximately 7000 milliseconds after `00:05` is printed, and then at some point resumes again, must the `00:06` appear 3000 milliseconds after the resume key was pressed, or is it okay to print it a full second after the resume key was pressed?

Comment: @smls It is ok to wait a full second, after the resume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## SmileBASIC, <s>86</s> <s>77</s> 71 bytes

```
@L
N=N!=DIALOG(FORMAT$("%02D:%02D",F/60MOD 60,F MOD 60),,,N)F=F+1GOTO@L
```

`DIALOG` displays a textbox on the touch screen. `N` is the number of seconds the text box will stay on screen before it disappears. If `N` is `0`, it stays until the user presses the button on the touch screen.

`DIALOG` Returns `1` if the user pressed the button, and `0` if it closed automatically. So when the user pushes the pause button, it returns `1`, and the display time is set to `0`, pausing the stopwatch. After the user presses the button again, we set the display time back to `1`, resuming the timer. Basically, every time `DIALOG` returns `1`, the display time is switched between `1` and `0` using `!=`, which is eqivilant to a logical XOR as long as both inputs are 1 or 0.

Comment: This looks awesome ! If you could also provide an animated "screencast" of how it works, that would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Ok, I'll do it soon

Comment: It could also be tested on this emulator: https://citra-emu.org/game/smilebasic/

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2, <s>167</s> 129 bytes

-36 bytes mostly* from using [Maltysen's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108487/53748) of catching `ctrl-c` using an exception - go give credit!
-4 bytes thanks to DLosc (init `n` and `b` to 0 rather than `f()`)
-1 byte thanks to FlipTack (use `p^=1` rather than `p=1-p`)
-2 bytes thanks to Felipe Nardi Batista (remove precision specifiers)

```python
import time
f=time.time
n=b=p=0
while 1:
 try:n=[n,f()][p];t=n-b;print'\r%02d:%02d'%(t/60%60,t%60),
 except:b=[b-n+f(),b][p];p^=1
```

Works the same as my original, below, but with the control key sequence of `ctrl+c`.
(Tested by me with Python 2.7.8 on Windows 7, 64bit;
Tested by Brian Minton with Python 2.7.13 on linux, 64bit)

* also collapsed `if` statement to a list lookup in order to get the `try` as a one-liner.

My original:

```python
import time,msvcrt as m
f=time.time
n=b=p=0
while 1:
 if m.kbhit()and m.getch()==b'p':b=[b-n+f(),b][p];p^=1
 if p:n=f()
 t=n-b;print'\r%0.2d:%0.2d'%(t/60%60,t%60),
```

(Tested by me with Python 2.7.8 on Windows 7, 64bit - this code, however, is Windows specific due to the use of the `msvcrt` library)

The control key is 'p'.

`n` and `b` are initialised to the same value at start-up, giving an "offset" of 0; `p` is initialised to 0, indicating a paused state.

Whenever the control key is pressed the value of `p` is switched. When switching from a paused state to an active state `b` is updated to a new value keeping any current offset from the previous active state(s) with `b-n`.

During an active state `n` is repeatedly updated to the current time by calling `time.time()`.

The difference between `n` and `b`, `t`, is then the total number of seconds (including a fractional part) elapsed during active state(s).

The minutes elapsed are then `t/60` and each of the minutes and seconds are displayed mod 60 with `(t/60%60,t%60)`. Leading zeros are prepended for each using string formatting of the integer part with `'...%0.2d...'`. Printing a tuple (the trailing `,`) where the first item has a leading carriage return (the `\r`) causes the previously printed text to be overwritten.

Comment: Ah yes, good catch, I originally did have `^=` but switched at some point during formulation.

Comment: @DLosc indeed, thanks...

Comment: It's not Windows specific.  I just tested this on linux 64 bit with Python 2.7.13 and it worked. (with the control key of Ctrl-C)

Comment: @BrianMinton thank you for letting me know!

Comment: what's the need for the `.` in `%0.2d` ? it works just fine as `%02d`

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista You're right, they are redundant (precision specification does not do much for decimal integers!) I shall remove them - thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## Python - <s>160</s> <s>159</s> 143 bytes

*Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving me 18 bytes!*

Only uses builtin libraries, so the control key is `ctrl-c`, catching it with an `except keyboardInterrupt`.

```
import time
Z=0
print'00:00'
while 1:exec"try:\n while 1:\n  %s\nexcept:1\n"*2%(1,"print'\033c%02d:%02d'%divmod(Z%3600,60);Z+=1;time.sleep(1)")
```

Comment: Oh nice. I think maybe it could shorter with just `except:`? I have a working version of mine doing it...

Comment: @JonathanAllan oh cool, didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 5):

## QBasic, <s>213</s> 211 bytes

Control key is tab. Leaving this running may cause laptop fires. You have been warned.

```vbs
DO
WHILE k$<>CHR$(9)
k$=INKEY$
LOCATE 1
?CHR$(48+m\10);CHR$(48+(m MOD 10));":";CHR$(48+(d MOD 60)\10);CHR$(48+(d MOD 10))
IF r THEN
n=TIMER
d=v+n-b+86400
m=d\60MOD 60
END IF
WEND
k$=""
v=v+n-b
r=1-r
b=TIMER
LOOP
```

Here it is in action, pausing at  10, 15, and 20 seconds:

[image: Stopwatch running]

#### Ungolfed and commented

```vbs
' Outer loop runs forever
DO
  ' The WHILE-WEND loop runs until tab is pressed
  WHILE key$ <> CHR$(9)
    key$ = INKEY$
    ' Output the stopwatch value at top left of screen
    LOCATE 1
    ' Unfortunately, QBasic's PRINT USING doesn't have a format for printing
    ' with leading zeros, so we have to do it manually by printing the
    ' 10s digit and the 1s digit
    PRINT CHR$(48 + minute \ 10); CHR$(48 + (minute MOD 10));
    PRINT ":";
    PRINT CHR$(48 + second \ 10); CHR$(48 + (second MOD 10))
    ' Update the current time if the running flag is set
    IF running THEN now = TIMER
    ' Take the difference between now and the last time we started the
    ' stopwatch, plus the amount of saved time from previous runs,
    ' plus 86400 to account for the possibility of running over midnight
    ' (since TIMER is the number of seconds since midnight, and QBasic's
    ' MOD doesn't handle negative values like we would need it to)
    diff = saved + now - lastStarted + 86400
    second = diff MOD 60
    minute = diff \ 60 MOD 60
  WEND
  ' If we're outside the WHILE loop, the user pressed tab
  key$ = ""
  ' Add the previous run's time to the saved amount
  saved = saved + now - lastStarted
  ' Toggle running between 0 and 1
  running = 1 - running
  ' If we're starting, we want to put the current time in lastStarted;
  ' if we're stopping, it doesn't matter
  lastStarted = TIMER
LOOP
```

Note that values of `TIMER` are floating-point. This doesn't affect the output, since `MOD` and `\` truncate to integers. But it does add accuracy to the amount of saved time: if you pause the timer right before a tick, you'll see when you start it up again that the number changes in less than a second.

Answer (score 5):

## bash + Unix utilities, 90 or 93 bytes

**90-byte version:**

```
trap d=\$[!d] 2;for((n=0;;)){((d|!n))&&dc<<<DP60dod*d$n\r%+n|colrm 1 4&&: $[n++];sleep 1;}
```

**93-byte version:**

```
trap d=\$[!d] 2;for((n=0;;)){((d|!n))&&dc<<<DP60dod*$n+n|colrm 1 4&&n=$[(n+1)%3600];sleep 1;}
```

Ctrl-C is the resume/pause character.  A space is the delimiter between minutes and seconds.

The difference between the two versions is that the 90-byte program will work for 2^63 seconds (at which point, bash will give me an integer overflow).

The 93-byte version will truly work forever.

The original problem included the requirement: "Your program must (theoretically) be capable of running forever."

If running for 2^63 seconds is sufficient to meet that requirement, then the 90-byte solution works.  That duration is more than 20 times the age of the universe!

If the program needs to be able to run for longer than that, I'll have to go with the 93-byte solution.

---

I should probably point out that this solution, as well as at least some of the others posted, will *very* slowly fall behind the true elapsed time.  This slippage is because the program is sleeping for one second between each execution of the body of the loop, but the body of the loop does take some tiny amount of time to execute.  This will be inconsequential in practice.

Comment: It looks like this will not display an initial value on the screen, until you "unpause" it.

Comment: "The stopwatch should start paused, and stay in this state, until user explicitly starts it, by pressing the 'control' key (see below)."  Is there a spec I missed?

Comment: yep this is correct, but it should still display an initial value `Initially, you can start with '00:00' or with any other value in range [00:00-59:59]`, which will stay on the screen until you press 'control' for the first time. Sorry if I have not been able to formulate this clear enough !

Comment: OK, that makes sense -- I'll modify it.

Comment: I've changed the programs to start with an initial display of 00 00 (still in the paused state though). I also made a couple of other changes (a 1-byte improvement and a copy-and-paste error fix).

Comment: Looks all good now !

Comment: Why is the backslash in `\r` needed? It seems to work without it.

Comment: The 93 byte could be reduced by using `(n+d)` instead of `(n+1)`. No need for `((d|!n))`. The code becomes: `trap d=\$[!d] 2;for((n=0;;)){ dc<<<DP60dod*$n+n|colrm 1 4&&n=$[(n+d)%3600];sleep 1;}` at **84** bytes.

Comment: Furthermore, as it is assumed that `d` starts at `0`, the same could be assumed for `n`, removing the need for `n=0`. The code then reduces to **81** bytes.

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 132 bytes

```
set/ar=0,m=s=100
:l
cls
@choice/t 1 /d y /m %m:~1%:%s:~1% /n
set/as+=r,m+=c=s/160,s-=c*60,m-=m/160*60,r^^=%errorlevel%-1
goto l
```

Pressing `n` will (un)pause the timer. The output flicker can be reduced at a cost of three (or four) bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Pure bash, 141 bytes

```bash
set -m
while ! read -t 1;do printf '\r%02i:%02i' $[s=s>3598?0:s+1,s/60] $[s%60];done&trap 'fg>/dev/null' TSTP
printf '00:00'
kill -STOP $!
read
```

This uses nothing but Bash builtins (no external tools). The control character is <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>, so that standard `SIGTSTP` handling pauses the stopwatch.

- [`set -m` enables job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), which is usually off in a script.
- A [subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment) process is [backgrounded (`&`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists).

  - [`read -t 1` waits one second for input from the user](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read), then fails.
  - The [`until` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs) continues as long as `read` keeps failing.
  - [`printf` outputs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf) the correctly-padded and -formatted time
  - `$[s=s>3598?0:s+1,s/60]` arithmetic expansion first [computes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) the updated time, checking whether to wrap and otherwise incrementing the seconds counter `s`, and then returns the floored division `s/60`.
  - `$[s%60]` gives the seconds remainder.
- The outer script sets up a [`trap` handler](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-trap) for `TSTP`, the signal <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> generates. When <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> is pressed while the outer script is running, it will run [`fg>/dev/null` and put the subshell back into the foreground](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-fg). `>/dev/null` is necessary to stop `fg` printing out the subshell command every time.
- The script prints the initial `00:00` and [sends a `STOP` signal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-kill) to the [child process `$!`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0024_0021), which will pause the process.
- `read` waits for input forever, keeping the script alive.

If <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> is pressed while the subshell is foregrounded, it will pause execution and return the outer script to the foreground, where it will wait silently. If the outer script is foregrounded, the trap handler will resume the subshell's execution, and it will count up again.

Answer (score 3):

## HTML + JavaScript (ES6), <s>191 192 187 183</s> 174 bytes

```
<b onclick='b=b?clearInterval(b):setInterval("a.innerHTML=`${(d=(((c=a.innerHTML.split`:`)[1]>58)+c[0])%60)>9?d:`0`+d}:${(e=++c[1]%60)>9?e:`0`+e}",1e3)'onload='b=0'id=a>00:00
```

#### Explanation

Click the timer to start or pause the stopwatch. As such, a single click is the *control* key. The separator between the two values is a colon.

Whenever the user clicks the click, the value of `b` is checked. It is initialised to `0` which evaluates to `false`, so a string of code is evaluated every 1000 milliseconds. This sets the variable to the id of the interval, so it can be stopped later. If `b` contains a number, it evaluates to `true`, so the interval is stopped. This returns the value `undefined`, so the cycle continues.

The string of code changes the html of the element with id `a` (the stopwatch). First the minutes are parsed by taking the previous stopwatch value, splitting it by the colon, and getting the minutes value, which is increased by 0 if the value of the seconds is not 59 (greater than 58), and 1 otherwise, modulo 60. Then this value is padded. Then comes the colon, and lastly, the seconds. The code simply gets the old value, increases it by 1, takes modulo 60 and optionally pads it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. I just get ReferenceError: d is not defined

Comment: You can probably also save a few bytes by removing the href=# since it's not actually needed since you're using onclick.

Comment: I just fixed that. I also removed the href, because you were right. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you put the onclick on the b tag and specify so in the answer?

Comment: I suppose that works. It saved 9B. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

### C <s>309</s> 179 bytes

```
f(){m=0,s=0;A: while(getchar()^'\n'){if(s++==59){if(m++==59)m=0;s=0;}printf("\r%02d:%02d",m,s);sleep(1);system("clear");if(getchar()=='\n'){break;}}while(getchar()^'\n'){}goto A;}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
void f()
{
   int m=0,s=0;

   A: while(getchar()^'\n')
      {           
       if(s++==59)
       {
         if(m++==59)
           m=0;

         s=0;
       }
       printf("\r%02d:%02d",m,s);
       sleep(1);  
       system("clear");

        if(getchar()=='\n')
        {
          break;
        }
      }

       while(getchar()^'\n')
       {}
       goto A ;
}
```

Usage: Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to *Pause* and *Resume* the Stopwatch.

Explanation:

- Wait for <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke, `break` the first `while` loop and wait until next <kbd>Enter</kbd> comes.
- Upon next <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke, `goto` first `while` loop and resume counting.

Now, I know `goto` is a bad coding practice in C, but I could not figure out another way.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Furthermore, `getchar()` blocks until some character is pressed.

Comment: compiles and runs on a linux machine

Comment: The ungolfed version perhaps, but the golfed version does not. Already at `m=0,s=0;` it fails, because you did not declare these variables anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript in Chrome console, 143 bytes

```
f=document,m=s=g=i=0;setInterval(()=>{if(g%2){m=(i/60|0)%60;s=i++%60}f.write((m>9?m:'0'+m)+':'+(s>9?s:'0'+s));f.close();f.onclick=()=>g++},1e3)
```

When entered in console it inits the counter to 00:00 and then enables the control which is keypress on the document.

Not much magic going on, notably the `(i/60)|0` floors the number

Done and tested in Chrome console

Comment: Nice answer. You can remove some bytes by using a dummy argument for the functions that don't take an argument, and you can replace the first argument in the setInterval by a string containing the code.

Comment: 132 B: `m=s=g=i=0;(f=document).onclick=_=>g++;setInterval("g%2&&f.close(f.write(\`${(m=i/60%60|0)>9?m:'0'+m}:\`+((s=i++%60)>9?s:'0'+s)))",1e3)`

Comment: Ohh, nice :) Learned a couple of things here. String in interval and the _=>g++ . Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, 124 bytes

```
s=i=1,setInterval("s&&(d=document).close(d.write(`0${i/60%60|0}:`.slice(-3)+`0${i++%60}`.slice(-2))),d.onclick=_=>s=!s",1e3)
```

The 'control key' is a click on the document. 
To test this, paste the code in the console or in a html file inside the `<script>` tag.

*Explanation:*

```
let s = 1
let i = 1
setInterval(() => {
    //If s = true then check after the "&&" operator else false
    s && (d = document).close( //put the document variable inside the d variable, so now i don't need to use anymore the long word 'document, then i close the document
            d.write( //Write into the document the next string
                `0${i/60%60|0}:`.slice(-3) + `0${i++%60}`.slice(-2) //Here is the magic, here I update the 'i' variable and convert the 'i' value to minutes and seconds
            ) 
        ),
        d.onclick = _ => s = !s //Add onclick event to the document, if s = true then s = false, if s = false then s = true
}, 1e3) //1e3 = 1000
```

Tested in Chrome

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would it be possible to edit in a link to an online testing site, such as [Try it online!](https://tio.run), so that other users can verify your answer?

Comment: Thanks @cairdcoinheringaahing, this is with jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjw7o0ps/

Answer (score 2):

**C# 220 Bytes**

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.DateTime;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var l = Now;
        var d = l-l;
        for( var r = 1<0;;Write($"\r{d:mm\\:ss}"))
        {
            if (KeyAvailable&&ReadKey(1<2).KeyChar == 's')
            {
                l = Now;
                r = !r;
            }
            if (r)
                d -= l - (l = Now);
        }

    }
}
```

Golfed

```
using static System.Console;using static System.DateTime;class P{static void Main(){var l=Now;var d=l-l;for(var r=1<0;;Write($"\r{d:mm\\:ss}")){(KeyAvailable&&ReadKey(1<2).KeyChar=='s'){l=Now;r=!r;}if(r)d-=l-(l=Now);}}}
```

Using the `s` key to start/stop.
Whole program works by remembering the TimeDelta using `DateTime.Now`

Most C#-Magic here comes from the C# 7.0 feature `using static`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>94</s> 91 bytes

I assume that 32 is the key code for the space bar (which it probably is not);
I currently have no way to test ncurses. But the rest of the code works fine.

```php
for($s=[STDIN];;)echo date("\ri:s",$t+=$r^=stream_select($s,$n,$n,1)&&32==ncurses_getch());
```

starts at `00:00`, but increments immediately when pause ends

If You (like me) don´t have ncurses, You can test by replacing the second `date` parameter with `$t+=$r^=!rand(sleep(1),19);` or `$t+=$r^=++$x%20<1+sleep(1);`. (`sleep` always returns `0`.)

**breakdown**

```php
for($s=[STDIN];                     // set pointer for stream_select
    ;                               // infinite loop:
)
    echo date("\ri:s",                  // 5. print CR + time
        $t+=                            // 4. increment $t if watch is running
        $r^=                            // 3. then toggle pause
            stream_select($s,$n,$n,1)   // 1. wait 1 second for a keystroke
            &&32==ncurses_getch()       // 2. if keystroke, and key==space bar
    ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash, 65 bytes

`trap d=\$[!d] 2;for((;;)){ printf "\r%(%M:%S)T" $[n+=d];sleep 1;}`

Note that it must be written to a file script to work correctly, or else, try:

`bash -c 'trap d=\$[!d] 2;for((;;)){ printf "\r%(%M:%S)T" $[n+=d];sleep 1;}'`

Extended version to explain it:

```
trap d=\$[!d] 2                     # flip d for each INT (ctrl-c) signal.
for((n=0;;)){                       # repeat forever the code inside the {...}
                                    # The n=0 is not strictly needed.
    printf "\r%(%M:%S)T" "$[n+=d]"  # Print Minute:Second string calculated from 
                                    # the n value, increment by the value of d.
                                    # If IFS is not numeric (0-9), then, the
                                    # quotes around "$[n+=d]" could be removed.
    sleep 1                         # wait for 1 second.
}
```

The `%(...)T` format to printf is valid in bash 5+.

Comment: Doesn't work. Just prints `00:00` and increments a counter when you hit `Ctrl-C`. There's no animation of the timer. (Tested on bash 5.0.7)

Comment: Did you write the code to an script? Or else please try: `bash -c 'trap d=\$[!d] 2;for((;;)){ printf "\r%(%M:%S)T" $[n+=d];sleep 1;}'`. @roblogic

Comment: Ahh, that worked! The script has to be run with `bash -c` :)

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore BASIC (C64/TheC64 Mini, VIC-20, PET, C16/+4) - 147 tokenized and BASIC bytes

```
 0?"{clear}":geta$:ifa$<>" "thengoto
 1ti$="000000"
 2fori=.to1:?"{home}"mid$(ti$,3,2)":"mid$(ti$,5,2):geta$:b$=ti$:i=-(a$=" "):nE:pO198,.
 3geta$:ifa$<>" "then3
 4ti$=b$:goto2
```

`{clear}` in the listing is `SHIFT+CLR/HOME` which outputs as one PETSCII character when following an opening quotation mark, whereas `{home}` is the `CLR/HOME` key without the shift on the same condition of following an opening quotation mark.

Use the space bar as the control key.

To work with the Commodore 128 in BASIC 7, change the listing in the following lines:

```
 0?"{clear}":geta$:ifa$<>" "thengoto0
 2fori=.to1:?"{home}"mid$(ti$,3,2)":"mid$(ti$,5,2):geta$:b$=ti$:i=-(a$=" "):nE:poK198,.
```

Adds an extra seven tokens to the count (as all numbers are stored in BASIC as 7 bytes, so `goto10` is 8 tokenized bytes whereas `goto` is only 1).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>121</s> 115 bytes

```c
p,r;g(){r^=1;}main(t,b){for(b=time(signal(2,g));;r?p=t:(b+=t!=p))t=time(0)-b,printf("\r%02d:%02d  ",t/60%60,t%60);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrBCsIwDADQX5mDQYIZ1h12WAj@iAhrdaXgaom5jX17Vby80wt9DKHWQsoRcNObnHlf55TByOO2vBS8WFof8E4xz08YKCIy66WITeCPYgcpiPZPDntPRVO2Bdqrdm64Tz@apiU7ja4bHdkX5L3WDw)

Sets a signal handler for SIGINT, which is triggered by pressing control-C. We keep a time offset in `b`, and display the wall clock time minus the time offset. If we are paused, increment the time base everytime the wall clock ticks to freeze the displayed time.

Thanks to @ceilingcat for shaving off 6 bytes!

Answer (score 0):

## Zsh + Gnu date, 242 bytes

Featuring 1/100ths of a second! It requires an interactive terminal, but [here's a TIO link](https://tio.run/##RY5PC4JAEMXv@ymWWCUpbTPo0OihQ7eI6BYqrOn6h7LMXYmK/ey2CtXl8d7wm5n3EkXXtWPrXfssT2PJ8cQQDO7/tGOgUKaJhscptiV16Nw0hwQnrWcF7VVwiQ@b/faoUK7RR1FeOF7BuwXpk6C24wiENtJY0ggq7cbSWCwptYU10yPEk@KGR2HD6qa8ygwb1E1XvWBSYSKYQ@7BfOpGYTKCDJRCnuf1DZ4w9Ggh9kmNfm8z@B4MeeCu@60B0U1kBDmorvsA) anyway. 

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start/stop the timer; <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to exit.

```zsh
u(){p=`gdate +%s`;q=`gdate +%N`;}
f(){read -t0.01&&{read;break};unset REPLY}
g(){while :;{u;t=$[p-a];s=$[t%60];m=$[(t%3600-s)/60]
echo "\r`printf %02d:%02d $m $s`.$q[1,2]\c";f;}}
<<<ready;read;u;a=$p
while :;{f;echo "\r\e[2A\c";u;a=$[p-t];g;}
```

Comments (a bit out of date):

```zsh
u()echo $[`gdate +%s%N`/1000]       # fn:unix timestamp extended to µs
v()gdate +%s                        # fn:unix time, in s
f(){read -t0.01 -r&&{read -r;break;} # fn:listens for "Enter"
                      ;unset REPLY;}

g(){while :;                        # fn:rolling stopwatch
    {q=`u`;t=$[`v`-a]               #    t=time diff from baseline (s)
    ;echo "\r`printf %02d:%02d      #    format output
    $[(t%3600-s)/60] $s`            #    minutes:seconds
    .${q:10:2}\c";                  #    .xx = partial seconds
    f;}}                            #    listen for "Enter"

                                    # Execution starts here!
<<<ready;read;u;a=$p                # Wait for "Enter"; get baseline $a

while :;{                           # Main program loop
         f;                         # listen for an "Enter"
           echo "\r\e[2A\c"         # go up 1 line of the console
a=$[`v`-t]                          # reset the baseline
                ;g;}                # begin the stopwatch
```

Comment: @Isaac, there's no way I could beat your answer for brevity & elegance, so I thought I'd add features instead...

Comment: That is an excellent goal @roblogic :-) .... .... still understanding your code ....