# Can this number be written in (3^x) - 1 format?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, arithmetic

**Challenge:**

Create a program that accepts a positive integer and checks if it can be written in the form of (3^x)-1, where **X is another positive integer**.

If it can, output X

If it can't, output -1 or a [falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2190/34718) statement.

**Example inputs/outputs**

Input:

```
2
```

It can be written as (3^1) - 1, so we output x which is 1

Output:

```
1
```

Input:

```
26
```

26 can be written as (3^3) - 1, so we output x (3)

Output:

```
3
```

Input:

```
1024
```

1024 can't be written in the form of (3^x) - 1, so we output -1

Output:

```
-1
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so least amount of bytes wins

---

Related OEIS: **[A024023](http://oeis.org/A024023)**

Comment: I ask to output X because I believe it's more challenging that way. Simply finding if it  is of format 3^x - 1 would be too easy for a challenge, in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe instead of `-1` can we output some other distinct falsy value?

Comment: Yes you can. I edited my question, and now you can output a falsy value.

Comment: Would this kind of "magic formula" make sense? `if (OEIS Sequence contains the number) return number; else return -1`

Comment: Can 0 be returned instead of -1, seeing as the result will never be 0 (because X has to be positive)?

Comment: Unless if it's a falsy statement in your programming language, then no.

Comment: You said it should output `-1` or falsy, so why is `-1` invalid?

Comment: @devRicher I never said -1 is invalid, I answered to FlipTack who asked if 0 is valid.

Also I didnt understand your question. What do you mean if oeis sequence contains the number. The sequence for 3^x-1 is obviously infinite

Comment: May I want the number to be input in ternary?

Comment: @JanDvorak No you may not. Most programming languages can't accept base3 numbers / convert decimal to ternary or vice versa easily  (having a built-in method) so it would be unfair for them

Comment: How large of a number does our program need to support?

Comment: having to handle non-negative intergers would make 0  `3^0-1`  a valid output and thus not useable as false,

Comment: anyone thinking of using `log()` in their answer should confirm it giives the correct answer `5` when `242`  is input.

Comment: @AlexL. The input should only be limited by memory to store the number. If the algorithm would work with any number in real life, it would be fine to use any integer max value.

Comment: does that mean bignums, or is it ok to use a normal integer type? and if so how small?

Comment: @Jasen Just use the "average" integer size. By average I mean, not "long", not "short". Eg, in VB.NET you have int16, int32, int64. In that case, you would use int32. Of course, if you want to use "long" becase it is less bytes, go ahead. Size doesnt matter, if you use something that was designed to store numbers.

Answer (score 24):

### Mathematica, <s>21</s> 16 bytes

```
-1&@@Log[3,#+1]&
```

Makes use of Mathematica's symbolic computation. If `#+1` is a power of three then `Log[3,#+1]` will compute an integer result which is an atomic value. Otherwise we'll get `Log[#+1]/Log[3]` as is. Since this is not an atomic value, it's an expression which is always of the form `head[val1,val2,...]`. In this case it's actually something like `Times[Power[Log[3], -1], Log[#+1]]`.

We distinguish between the two cases by applying another function to the result. What applying really does is that it replaces the `head` part of an expression. Since integer results are atomic, applying any function to them does nothing at all. In particular `f @@ atom == atom`.

However, in the other case, the head does get replaced. The function we're using is `-1&` which is a simple function that ignores its arguments and returns `-1`. So we get something `-1&[Power[Log[3], -1], Log[#+1]]` in non-integer cases, which evaluates directly to `-1`. Special casing via magic.

Answer (score 13):

### Haskell, 35 bytes

```
f x=last(-1:[i|i<-[1..x],3^i-1==x])
```

Usage example: `f 26` -> `3`.

Comment: PS: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mUGGbk1hcoqFraBWdWZNpoxttqKdXEatjHJepa2hrWxGr@T83MTNPwVahoLQkuKTIJ09BRaE4I78cSKUpGJn9BwA "Haskell – TIO Nexus") supports Haskell! (Nice answer btw!)

Answer (score 13):

## Python, <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
lambda x:max(n*(3**n-1==x)for n in range(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQYZWbWKGRp6VhrKWVp2toa1uhmZZfpJCnkJmnUJSYl56qUaGp@b@gKDOvRCNNw8hMU5MLxrEwQOIYGhiZABUCAA)

In this case, `0` would be the falsy value.  Thanks to @mbomb007 for pointing out my incorrect output as well as a 2 bytes no `[]` savings.

Comment: you can rewrite as `[n for n in range(x)if 3**n-1==x]` for -4 bytes, empty list as falsy

Comment: Fixed, thank you!  @Rod then it would return [n] instead of n I think

Comment: @nmjcman101 that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Rod I'd prefer adhering strictly to spec for now

Comment: @Rod If outputting an integer is required, you cannot output it in a list unless the OP specifically allows it.

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
R3*’i
```

Outputs **x** or **0** (falsy).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x9krPWoYWbm/6N7Drc/alrj/v@/kY6CkZmOgqGBkQkA)

#### How it works

```
R3*’i  Main link. Argument: n

R      Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 3*    Map each k to 3**k.
   ’   Decrement the results.
    i  First index of n (0 if not found).
```

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
3IÝm<¹k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@2/seXhurs2hndn//xuZAQA)

**Explanation**

```
3        # push 3 
 I       # push input
  Ý      # range [0 ... input]
   m     # 3^[0 ... input]
    <    # -1
     ¹k  # find index of input, return -1 if not found
```

Comment: 05AB1E is apparently good at base conversion is this really the best approach?

Comment: @Jasen: My attempts with base conversion all turned out longer. If there is a better way than this I'm not seeing it. Feel free to prove me wrong though :)

Comment: fair enough, I've only read the description of the language, and, so  expected to see a 5 byte solution....

Comment: @Jasen `<3zm©.ïi®` is the closest I've got not using ranges like he did.

Comment: `3DÝms<k`... Nevermind... Can't shave off one more byte, could of sworn I could.

Comment: @carusocomputing: I'm pretty sure this is the minimum count using this strategy. Haven't found a different strategy able to improve on it, but it could be possible.

Answer (score 7):

## Brachylog v1, 8 bytes

```
,3:.^-?,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@69jbKUXp2uv8/@/kdn/KAA)

Outputs the value if true and `false.` if this is impossible.

#### Explanation

This is a direct transcription of the given relation:

```
,     ,      (Disable implicit unification)
 3:.^        3^Output…
     -?              … - 1 = Input
```

Comment: You can *almost* golf this down to 7 bytes as `+~^r~:3`, but unfortunately `~:` doesn't do what you might expect (likely because `:` is syntax rather than a builtin), and seems to be treated identically to `:`.

Comment: @ais523 That's correct, `:` is a control symbol, and `~` only works on predicates.

Answer (score 7):

## Prolog, 20 bytes

```
d(A,X):-A#=(3**X)-1.
```

This language is cool as hell.

```
| ?- d(1024,X).

no
| ?- d(26,X).

X = 3

yes
| ?- d(2,X).

X = 1

yes
```

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, 31 bytes

```pl
say grep{3**$_-1==$i}0..($i=<>)
```

Requires `-E` flag to run:

```
perl -E 'say grep{3**$_-1==$i}0..($i=<>)' <<< 26
```

Explanations:
`grep{3**$_-1==$i}0..($i=<>)` returns a list of the elements of the range `0..$_` (ie. from 0 to the input) that satisfies the test `3**$_-1==$i`. Only one element at most can satisfy this test, so this instruction will return an array of 0 or 1 element. We then print this list: either the `X` or nothing (which is falsy).

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 41 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0:i*0**n or n%3/2*f(n/3,i+1)
```

A recursive function that returns `0` for non-matching inputs. Repeatedly floor-divides the input by 3, counting the number of steps in `i`, which is output in the end. But, if any step produces a value `n` that isn't 2 modulo 0, the number was not of for `3^i-1`, so the output is multiplied by 0.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
?-JjQ3 2ZlJ
```

Converts to base 3 and checks equality to `[2, 2, ..., 2]`.

Comment: You can reduce this by one byte with `?-2JjQ3ZlJ`, since `<col> <num>` and `<num> <col>` are interchangeable for `-` in Pyth.

Answer (score 5):

## Processing, <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```processing
void q(float n){n=log(n+1)/log(3);print(n>(int)n?-1:n);}
```

Outputs `-1` if falsy.

#### Explanation

```processing
void q(float n){              // n is input
  n=log(n+1)/log(3);          // finds X in 3^X+1=n as a float (here we'll storing that in n)
  print(n>(int)n?-1:n);       // checks if the float is greater than
                              // the number rounded down (by int casting)
                              // if it is greater, output -1
                              // otherwise output X
}
```

`void` is 1 byte shorter than using `float`, so that's why this function directly outputs instead of returning a value.

#### Alternative Solution

```processing
void z(float n){int c=0;for(++n;n>1;c++)n/=3;print(n==1?c:-1);}
```

for 63 bytes, but I think this alt can be golfed to be shorter than the original solution. I'm working on it.

Comment: @FlipTack Yeah, I knew it wouldn't be in Java. I just asked since I wasn't sure that Processing hadn't added something along those lines. The "distinct value" to be used was -1 though, not 0. It's been changed since, though, so I'll probably clean up my comments about it.

Comment: Wait, so can I return `0` now?

Comment: I'd still say no. The question gives an alternative integer value to use if falsy, but `0` is never falsy in Java/Processing that I know of.

Comment: I thougt Processing was supposed to be *less* versbose than [Java](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105981/60042)

Comment: @Pavel But I don't use lambdas :/

Comment: does it work with 242 as input (result 5)?

Comment: @Jasen Yes, it outputs `5` for `242` as input

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES7), <s>38</s> <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```js
f=(n,k=33)=>3**k-n-1&&--k?f(n,k):k
```

Or just <s>30</s> 29 bytes if it's OK to exit with an error on failure:

```js
f=(n,k)=>~(n-3**k)?f(n,-~k):k
```

#### Test

```js
f=(n,k=33)=>3**k-n-1&&--k?f(n,k):k

console.log(f(177146))
console.log(f(847288609442))
console.log(f(5559060566555522))
console.log(f(123456))
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <strike>37</strike> <strike>58</strike> 67 bytes

```java
i->{String s=i.toString(i,3);return s.matches("2*")?s.length():-1;}
```

This lambda fits in a `Function<Integer, Integer>` reference and uses the simple base 3 trick.

This time it should work correctly.

Comment: Wouldn't that only print True or False when it can be written in the format? But I asked for the exponent when the result is True

Comment: That's genius! +1 for a very clever approach

Comment: This is clever... i believe you can remove the parens and just make it `i->`. Also, if you take `i` as a `Long`, you can then use `a.toString(...)` (ides will give some warnings about using static functions incorrectly, but should compile). However, as OP said, you need to return the value, not just True or False.

Comment: If the lambda is stored in a different function type then the static trick works. I also fixed the return value. I must have missed that part.

Answer (score 4):

## R, 24 bytes

A different approach from [plannapus' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105883/59052), and one byte shorter!

```
match(scan(),3^(1:99)-1)
```

Generates all integers from `3^1-1` to `3^99-1`, and checks if stdin matches. If so, it returns the index at which it matches, which is `x`. If not, returns `NA` as falsy value.

Incidentally, it will accept multiple values as input, and test all of them, which is a neat feature.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>25</s>  24 bytes

```perl6
{first $_==3** *-1,0..$_}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#LYzdCoMgAEbvfYqPiPWDE6vRTfgKe4KBRDMIHIVmLMRe3cW223M4x1mFrWVDR8hrx2WYnwoi@nEydkUqhWjKEuW1opyxVIY4zgac1rRuacXrGzwBzvBhlHV6hQD7ProTL25Fkkr4n2OLMjokFBnyHmOv7Y6t104VGd7I/4PjwH3SBQnxAw)

```perl6
{first $_==3***-1,0..$_}
```

Removing the space after `**` works because it is longer than the other infix operator that could match `*`.
So `…***…` is parsed as `… ** * …` rather than `… * ** …`.

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#LYzdCoMgAEbvfYqPiPWDE6vRTfgKe4KBRDMIHIVmLMRe3cW223M4x1mFrWVDR8hrx2WYnwoi@nEydkUqhWjKsrxWlDOWyhDH2YDTmtYtrXh9gyfA2T2Msk6vEGDfRXfixa1IUgn/c2xRRoeEIkPeY@y13bH12qkiwxv5f3AcuE@6ICF@AA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  first
    $_ == 3 ** * - 1,   # WhateverCode lambda
    #          ^- current value

    0 .. $_             # a Range up-to (and including) the input

}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
£İ3→
```

Returns `0` if there's no such **x**, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DiIxuMH7VN@v//v5GJEQA)

#### Explanation

This works because `£` assumes the list to be sorted and aborts the search once it sees a larger element:

```
£İ3→  -- implicit input N, for example: 80
   →  -- increment N -> 81
 İ3   -- list [3,9,27,81…
£     -- if it's in the list return index; -> 4
      -- else return 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```powershell
param($a)1..$a|?{"3*"*$_+"1-1-eq$a"|iex}
```

-2 bytes thanks to mazzy, by replacing the `[Math]::Pow`, nice one!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsIwEEX3c4ohjNLWtjQVVATRm5RBRxQSW1OLQpqzx7hw8Vfv897Qv8WNNzGmOvdOIl3xgD4O7NhmxLmua@L56NW6UAV1K6UrXcmTWM13@YQY4JS1JbabtG2Ju6ZE3TQ5zrhAD0CvpLPC4@QkBazlxwU9kpNxMj@2TEHqMIBK1/0fKIAA8Qs)

Comment: I also tried the `log` approach but couldn't make it shorter: `(0,($t=[math]::log(1+"$args",3)))[$t-eq[int]$t]`

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsIwEEX3c4ohjNLWtjQVVATRm5RBRxQSW1OLQpqzx7hw8Vfv897Qv8WNNzGmOvdOIl3xgD4O7NhmxLmua@L56NW6UAV1K6UrXcmTWM13@YQY4JS1JbabtG2Ju6ZE3TQ5zrhAD0CvpLPC4@QkBazlxwU9kpNxMj@2TEHqMIBK1/0fKIAA8Qs "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") :)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
DÝ3sm<Q1k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@9yeK5xca5NoGH2//9GZgA)

Prints -1 for falsy.

```
D         # Duplicate the input
 Ý3sm     # Push [0 .. input]^3 (e.g. [0^3, 1^3, 2^3, 4^3 ...])
     <    # subtract 1
      Q   # push a 1 everywhere that equals the input, and 0 everywhere else
       1k # push the index of the 1, or -1 if not found
          # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
o æ@U+1¥3pX
```

Try it [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.2&code=byDmQFUrMaUzcFg=&input=MjY=).

Big thanks to ETHproductions for helping!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>74</s> <s>66</s> 64 bytes

<sub>-10 bytes thanks to @mbomb007, @FlipTack and @nmjcman101</sub>

```
from math import*
def f(n):x=ceil(log(n,3));print((3**x-1==n)*x)
```

Comment: You can put all of your code on one line and use `from math import*`. Also `return n==3**x-1and x`.

Comment: [65 byte solution](https://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=ascii&t=from%20math%20import%2A%0Adef%20f%28n%29%3Ax%3Dceil%28log%28n%2C3%29%29%3Breturn%20n%3D%3D3%2A%2Ax-1and%20x)

Comment: @mbomb007 Functions are allowed to print the result to `STDOUT`, so you can change that return to a print.

Comment: If you present this as a [SageMath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SageMath) solution rather than a Python one, you can drop the first line altogether.

Comment: Along with the other reduction to 65 bytes, you can use `import math` and `math.ceil` for a single byte.  Also you can turn `3**x-1==n and x` to `x*(3**x-1==n)`

Comment: @nmjcman101 `math.log` is also in play, so `from math import *` compensates.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni please post your golf suggestion as comment, you can also add a link to an online compiler with the golfed code, but [edits on others' answers are not a good pratice](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/suggested-edits-reject-golfing)

Comment: @Rod, the suggested Sagemath solution, though related with Python, relates to another software entirely, making the edit suitable for a new answer altogether in this case.

Comment: @dfernan yep, I was just showing him why his (suggested) edit on your answer was rejected

Comment: @Rod I have already posted it as a comment, but it was ignored. I suggested it as an edit to make it more explicit. I will post it as a new answer now, as per dfernan's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
3i:^qG=f
```

This outputs the number `x` if it exists, or otherwise outputs nothing, which is falsy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@caRVX6G6b9v@/kRkA)

#### Explanation

```
3    % Push 3
i    % Input n
:    % Range: gives `[1 2 ... n]
^    % Power, element-wise. Gives [3^1 3^2 ... 3^n]
q    % Subtract 1, element-wise. Gives [3^1-1 3^2-1 ... 3^n-1]
=    % Test for equality. Contains 'true' at the position x, if any,
     % where 3^x-1 equals n
f    % Find. Gives index of the 'true' position, which ix x; or gives
     % an empty array if no such position exists. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) / Unix utilities, <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```bash
bc<<<`dc<<<3o$1p|grep ^2*$|wc -c`-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@UbGNjk5ACIo3zVQwLatKLUgsU4oy0VGrKkxV0kxN0Df///29kBgA)

Uses dc to convert to base 3, checks that the resulting string is all 2s, counts the number of characters (including a newline), and then uses bc to subtract 1.

If the number in base 3 is *not* all 2s, then grep outputs nothing (not even a newline), so the character count is 0, and subtracting 1 yields -1.

Answer (score 2):

## C compiled with Clang 3.8.1, <s>53</s>, <s>52</s>, <s>54</s>, 51 Bytes

```
n;f(y){y++;for(n=0;y%3==0;y/=3)n++;return y^1?0:n;}
```

@SteadyBox already posted a solution in C, but I'm using a different approach.

@Thanks to Jasen for helping save bytes.

Comment: yeah, but does it work? comparing floats for equality is often a recipe for unexpected failure (try large inputs)

Comment: @Jasen Hmm, haven't tried that, but in C `log` returns `double` so maybe it might work.

Comment: double is a type of floating point value so he problem persists.

Comment: seems to work ok  for 3^19 which is probably large enough.

Comment: @Jasen It doesn't work for 3^10

Comment: use a 16 bit compiler then :)

Comment: @Jasen Check my edit, interestingly enough, if I put the result from `log` into a `float` it works even for larger numbers.

Comment: with float fails on 4782967 (3^14) here  with double on 243 (3^5-1)

Comment: @Jasen Check my edit, this time I tried with simple divisions, works for all powers up to `19`.

Comment: yeah, that works. It now  seems quite similar, but superior, to my answer,  `y==1` and `y+=1` can both be golfed further. Also, `0` is allowed instead of `-1`. that would get you to 51

Comment: @Jasen Thanks for helping me save bytes.

Comment: `y%3==0` => `y%3<1`

Comment: `return y^1?0:n;` => `return--y?0:n;` if want to keep the word `return`; or yo can use some operation to give `EAX` the value, and directly go out

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 30 bytes

Returns `nil` (a falsy value) if no number was found. [[Try it online]](https://repl.it/FCkA)

```
->n{(0..n).find{|i|3**i-1==n}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 56 bytes

```
 n;f(a){n=0;for(a++;!(a%3)&&(a/=3);++n);return --a?-1:n;}
```

add one to the input and then repeatedly divide by three until a remainder is found, if the one is reached return the count of divides else -1

Comment: Save one byte with `a%3<1` instead of `!(a%3)`. One more with `0` for falsy.

Comment: Assuming you're using GCC to compile you can save a total of 10(11) bytes: you don't need to initialize n to zero if you know you'll call this function only once since then n will be zero by default (because it's global) - that's 4 bytes less; also you don't need the return statement, by writing `a=--a?-1:n;` you'll save 5 bytes. if a non-void function has no return, it'll just use the last assignment. Also what @Titus said.

Comment: Suggest `a%3?0:(a/=3)` instead of `!(a%3)&&(a/=3)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
←⁺3ĽĐĐƖ=*
```

Explanation:

```
←                Get input
 ⁺               Add one
  3Ľ             Log base 3
    ĐĐ           Triplicate top of stack
      Ɩ          Convert top of stack to integer
       =         Check for equality between top two on stack
        *        Multiply by log_3(input+1)
```

Saved a byte by using the increment function instead of explicitly adding 1

Comment: in what code page is that 9 bytes? (in UTF-8 it's 17 bytes)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
(⊢×⌊=⊢)3⍟1+⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSNR12LDk9/1NNlC2RoGj/qnW@oDWQBJRWMFIzMFAwNjEwA)

`1+⊢` increment

`3⍟` log<sub>3</sub>

`(`…`)` apply the following function:

`⌊=⊢` is the floor equal to the argument? (0 or 1)

`⊢×` multiply the argument by that

Answer (score 2):

## C, 42 Bytes, optimized from Wade Tyler's

```
n;f(y){for(n=0;y%3>1;y/=3)n++;return!y*n;}
```

[Try](https://tio.run/##TY7PCsIwDMbve4o4GLR2YsuOsT6JF9ms5GCUskHL2LPXrqLudwj58@VL@sO971NidCLK2T29YKsxNt3ZYDzaTrJS6G/j5HkX94xLIh7hcSUWEuYKMmuDWghYqmwBgqxBoJPRhZwq9VWvBLDgBEn8dciBCFvJystn6zyomwGa4cJ1W@5s1pbqHz9PgsZqSW8)

## C, 37 Bytes, without `return`

```
n;f(y){for(n=0;y%3>1;y/=3)n++;n*=!y;}
```

[Try](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwDIbvfYo4KLR2YsuOsT6JF9ms5GCUMmFl7NlrV1D3HULy5/@T/nDv@5wZg0p6Ds@o2FtMsjs7TEffaTYGee93CZdMPMLjSqw0zAIKq0AtTFinkgZF3iHQydlKaY35ulcm8BAUafwpFEBNW8vKK5bTZdHIAeRw4aatfzaxRfxrvI3vyGBRLPkD)

`n` is global but `(I)MUL` can only have its dest operand in a register, so have to put into `EAX`(the usual choice) and mov there

## JavaScript 6, 32 Bytes

```js
f=(y,n)=>y%3>1?f(y/3|0,-~n):!y*n
;[1,2,3,8,12,43046720].forEach(x=>console.log(f(x)))
```

If the "falsy" need to be same, 33 Bytes:

```
f=(y,n)=>y%3>1?f(y/3|0,-~n):!y&&n
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 6 bytes

```
ɾ3e‹ḟ›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwiyb4zZeKAueG4n+KAuiIsIiIsIjI2Il0=) The `r` flag reverses the arguments of all functions.

Explanation:

```
ɾ       # Range from 1 to n
 3e     # 3 ^ each number in the range (not n ^ 3 because of the r flag)
   ‹    # Decrement
    ḟ   # Index of the input
     ›  # Increment because ḟ is 0 indexed
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
3¨e‹ḟ›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiM8KoZeKAueG4n+KAuiIsIiIsIjI2XG4yXG4xMDI0Il0=)

Decided this was different enough from the other Vyxal answers to post.

```
    ḟ  # find the index of the input in
3¨e    # all powers of 3
   ‹   # -1
     › # and add 1 to that index
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
;3^₍-₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39o47lFTr@6jpsb//6P@G5kBAA)

Takes input through the Output variable.

#### Explanation

```
;3         [?, 3]
  ^₍       3^?
    -₁     3^? - 1 = Input
```

This will unify `?` with the right value if possible, and output `false.` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 64 bytes

Outputs `False` if the number cannot be written in that format.

```python
def f(n):L=[3**x-1for x in range(n)];print n in L and L.index(n)
```

This also works in 64 bytes, and prints empty string as a falsy output:

```python
def f(n):
 try:print[3**x-1for x in range(n)].index(n)
 except:0
```

A creative solution for 65 bytes, outputting `0` for falsy:

```python
lambda n:-~",".join(`3**x-1`for x in range(n+1)).find(',%s,'%n)/2
```

Comment: Does not output `x` nor `-1`.

Comment: The program should output `x` instead of `n` in case of a match.

Comment: No, it should output the positive integer that when replaced with X, you get the input. The question refers to X as a variable, not as a string

Comment: @P.Ktinos Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>34</s> 25 bytes

```
a=log(scan()+1,3);a*!a%%1
```

Calculate the base 3 logarithm of the input + 1. Test if the result is an integer, if it is it outputs it, if not it outputs `0` as falsey value.
Thanks to [@Billywob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56989) for the extra 9 bytes off!

Test cases:

```
> a=log(scan()+1,3);a*!a%%1
1: 1024
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 0

> a=log(scan()+1,3);a*!a%%1
1: 26
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 3
```

**Old version at 34 bytes** which outputs -1 as falsey value.

```
a=log(scan()+1,3);`if`(!a%%1,a,-1)
```

Comment: If you do `a*!a%%1` it will output `a` if true and `0` otherwise and you can skip the `if` thing.

Comment: The spec says *"If it can't, output -1 or a falsy statement."* and `0` is interpreted as `FALSE` in R so I would say it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 10 bytes

```
*J@hQ3!%J1
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aJ%40hQ3%21%25J1&input=26&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, <s>9</s> 6 bytes

```
3m^Qh@
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=3m%5EQh%40&input=26)

```
3m^    -  map(3**i, range(input))
     @ - V in ^
   Qh  -  input + 1
```

Old 9 byte version:

```
b3'l}\2q*
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=b3%27l%7D%5C2q%2a&input=26)

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 30 bytes

```
n->findfirst(n.==3.^(0:n)-1)-1
```

It's a simple function - it creates a vector that has a `true` only in the corresponding position in `3^a-1`, where `a` is a vector containing integers between 0 and `n`. It finds the "first" position that is `true` and subtracts 1 (if it's all `false`, the find evaluates to zero, and it returns -1).

As `0:n` has `0` in the first spot, the subtract 1 corrects for indexing and also enables the `-1` false response.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth 8 bytes

```
xm^3dUQh

     UQ  # generate all values 1..Q (Q is the input)
 m^3d    # map 3^d over this ^ list
x      h # find the input+1 (hQ) in the result of the last command
```

[Try here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xm%5E3dUQh&input=12%0Aprogramming&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A8%0A26%0A1024&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 81 bytes

```
i,j,k;f(n){for(i=0;++i<n;){for(k=3,j=0;++j<i;k*=3);if(n==k-1)return i;}return-1;}
```

Comment: I think you save bytes by using `pow(3,i)` instead of defining your own.  Gcc complains about the missing `#include <math.h>` but compiles it anyway.  I did have to cast to int.  You also may be able to gain some by adding an `r` variable, initializing to -1, and then `if(n==k-1)r=i;}return r;}`

Comment: @nmjcman101 Thanks, but `pow()` produces some incorrect results because of floating point inaccuracy. (When cast to int, 2.9999 will be 2, not 3). Adding a variable `r` sounds like a good idea, but it actually results in a 2 bytes longer code.

Comment: yeah, log doesn't work, pow probably won't either.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
o m!³a°U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5@vkKt4aHPioQ2h//8bmQEA)

This code expands into the following:

```
Uo m!p3 a++U

Uo            // Create the range [0...U).
   m!p3       // Map each item X to 3**X.
        a++U  // Take the index of U+1. Returns -1 if it doesn't exist.
              // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 23 bytes

```
@(x)find(3.^(1:x)-1==x)
```

[Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/#italI)

**Explanation:**

This is an anonymous function that takes a positive integer `x` as input. `.^` is element-wise power in Octave, so `3.^(1:x)` is `3^1, 3^2, 3^3 ...`. Subtracting `1` gives `3^1-1, 3^2-1, 3^3-1 ...` which can be compared to `x`.

`find(a,b)` takes a vector `a` as input, and attempts to find the scalar `b` in that vector and returns its index. If it's not found then it will output an empty matrix `[]`. An empty matrix is a falsey value in Octave.

`find(3.^(1:x)-1==x)` searches for `x` in the vector `3^1-1, 3^2-1, 3^3-1 ...`
and attempts to return its index. If it's not in the vector then it returns an empty (falsey) matrix.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 11 bytes

```
~..3\?\)%!*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@1@np2ccYx@jqaqo9f@/kRkA)

Uses the fact that 3<sup>*n*</sup> is divisible by *n*+1 if and only if *n*+1 itself is a power of 3.  Outputs its input *n* if *n*+1 is a power of 3, otherwise outputs 0 (which is falsy in GolfScript).

De-golfed:

```
~             # eval the input, converting it from string to integer
 ..           # make two copies of the input number
   3\?        # raise 3 to the power of the input number
      \)%     # reduce the result modulo the input number plus one
         !    # boolean negate the result, mapping 0 to 1 and all other values to 0
          *   # multiply the input number with the result
```

Ps. Here's a simple [test harness](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@29oAAQ61Qp6esYx9jGaqopaCrU6Cf//AwA) that runs the code above (minus the initial `~`, which is not needed since the inputs are already numbers) on all integers from 0 to 9999 and prints those for which it returns a truthy result:

```
10000,{ ..3\?\)%!* },`
```

The output of this program should be:

```
[2 8 26 80 242 728 2186 6560]
```

(The output doesn't include 0 because, even though the formula used does correctly detect it as one less than a power of 3, the result is still 0 × 1 = 0, and thus falsy.  Fortunately, 0 is not a positive integer, and thus isn't a valid input for this challenge anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

**c++ 60 bytes**

```
int f(n){float o=log1p(n)/log(3);return o/floor(o)!=1?-1:o;}
```

explanation:

```
int f(n){             
  float o=log1p(n)/log(3);       // eval for x using log3 function 
  return o/floor(o)!=1?-1:o;     // if no remainder output X 
}
```

Comment: I think you don't have to use `uint16_t`. You can use normal `int`.

Comment: I guess I could to save a few bytes but it seemed to me that if I wasn't safeguarding against negative integer input then I wasn't following the guidelines.

Comment: this compile to me: int f(n){float o=log1p(n)/log(3);return o/floor(o)!=1?-1:o;}

Comment: @mreff555 You don't need to safeguard against negative input, you can assume positive input.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 76 bytes

```
main(i,a,c){scanf("%d",&a);for(c=0,++a;i<a;i*=3,++c);printf("%d",(i==a)*c);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Sagemath, 45 bytes

This is simply @dfernan's solution repackaged as [Sagemath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SageMath) (which is basically Python + some math libraries loaded by default and syntactic sugar).

In Sagemath, we can avoid the `import math` and we can use `^` for exponentiation, so we save a few chars.

```
def f(n):x=ceil(log(n,3));print((3^x-1==n)*x)
```

[Test it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLSU1TSNPI07SqsE1OzczRyMlP18jTMdbUtC4oyswr0dAwjqvQNbS1zdPUqtDk5UrTMDIx0gQAufwPEw==&lang=sage)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda n:(~n>>3**n%-~n*n)**4/80%80
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcq9CsIwFAbQuX2KuxSSa4qJP1gC7YuoQ4JGA/q1XLq49NWjnVwPZ/rMzxG7kvpLeYV3vAWCVwuGYc@Mpl3A0MyHbWebzpY0CoEySAIed@WMs9Zq2tD512PraA3xH07GHfXV15X0SUHXVU4kfpKMmWBWKl8)

Works for all Python ints, up to at least 2^100.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
aTB:3MNa=2&#a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/McTJytjXL9HWSE058f///0ZmAA)

#### Explanation

```
               a is 1st command-line argument (implicit)
aTB:3          Convert a to base 3 and assign back to a
     MNa=2     Does the min of a's digits equal 2?
          &    Logical-and
           #a  Length of a
               If there are non-2 digits, we get the falsey value 0; otherwise, we get
               the number of digits
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
>3.n.ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzlgvT@/w@v//jQA)

`>` increments, `3` pushes a 3 to the stack, `.n` find the logarithm with base `3`, `.ï` checks if it is equal to its integer part.

Returns *0* for falsy: *If it can't, output -1 or a falsy statement*.

Answer (score 1):

## APL NARS, 14 chars or 28 bytes

```
{r×r=⌊r←3⍟1+⍵}
```

Test:

```
  f←{r×r=⌊r←3⍟1+⍵}
  f 2     
1
  f 26
3
  f 1024
0
```

Comment: This is 28 [bytes in NARS](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319), but exactly the same solution is only 14 bytes in Dyalog APL. Also, you can save two bytes by conversion to tradfn, `r×r=⌊r←3⍟1+⎕`, letting the program prompt for input.

Comment: @Adám i prefer functions

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
⊢|⊢⍳⍨¯1+3*⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OA5KOuRTVA/Kh386PeFYfWG2obawHZ//@nHVoBpI0NAA)

Uses `⎕IO←0`.

**How?**

`⍳` - range of 0 to `n-1`.

`3*` - raise 3 to the power of each element.

`¯1+` - decrement each by 1.

`⊢⍳⍨` - search the index of `n` in that list (if not exists, this would return the maximum index plus 1 - which is `n`.

`⊢|` - modulo by `n`. This would keep the index, if found, and zero-out numbers not contained in the list that would produce `n % n = 0`.

---

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
(∧/×≢)2=3⊥⍣¯1⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9hcGwtZHlhbG9n/@KOlUlP4oaQMP9m4oaQKOKIpy/Dl@KJoikyPTPiiqXijaPCrzHiiqL//2bCqOKNszMw)

Comment: "26 can be written as (3^3) - 1"  124 can be written as (5^3)-1 but your code for 124 not print 5 print 0

Comment: Ok I confuse exponent and base

Comment: @RosLuP you mind deleting the comments? people use to DV without much thinking when seeing these

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 26 bytes

```
&1+>:3%v
1+\^v-1_3/\
.@.$_
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X81Q287KWLWMy1A7Jq5M1zDeWD@GS89BTyX@/38jMwA)

Prints 0 as the falsey.

#### How it Works

```
&1+... Gets the input and adds one
......
......

...>:3%v    Check if the number is divisible by 3
1+\^..._3/\ If not, divide the number by 3 and increment a counter
...         Repeat until the number is not divisible by 3

.........   If the final number is a one, print the counter
....v-1_... Else pop the counter and print a 0
.@.$_       End the program
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 30 bytes

```
[ 1 + 3 over [0,b) n^v index ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsIwFEX3fMV1FKW0UUrRD5AuXcSpKMT4tEWbxuS1KOK3x1pxudzhnHNWmlsXdtu82KxwJWfohkZxNU7klLmQ//2evqiHdcT8tK42DE/3jowekLXIixW8dop1JcQETJ5RG9uxFy9IZJAxZIoklkvIJEvxDiUSzLBA25NDGc@PU5hDP1gnemAfGmX/obbjsRSFDw)

Port of [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105896/78410). The `index` word conveniently returns `f` (the only falsy value in Factor) when the item is not found.

```
[              ! anonymous lambda
  1 + 3 over   ! ( n+1 3 n+1 )
  [0,b)        ! ( n+1 3 {0..n} )
  n^v          ! ( n+1 {3^0..3^n} )
  index        ! 0-based index of n+1 in {3^0..3^n}; false if not found
]
```

---

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 45 bytes

```
[ 3 >base dup [ 50 = ] all? swap length and ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc3BDsFAFEbhfZ/i9wLSDhqpYCk2NmLVWFzTSxs1HXPvREQ8e0nF/uQ7Z7Lahf6w3@42Ba4cHLe4kdZjT0E4wAdWffrQOIXwPbKzLEPxy87RWW06J1gk210BsYHU1kkygrIoGuejSvKCwRwmhcmRpWYKk81zvPsSE6xOJIwqepSYpVjiCGrbNeRBHi27y/dFrsKxv5H/u13UAR73Hw)

A base-conversion approach.

```
[                    ! anonymous lambda, accepting a positive integer n
  3 >base            ! ( str ) convert to base-3 string
  dup [ 50 = ] all?  ! ( str ? ) test if it is all 2's
  swap length and    ! ( len/f ) if true, return the length of str
                     ! otherwise return false
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-æ`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs `undefined`, which is falsey, instead of `-1`.

```
NøÓ3pU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LeY&code=TvjTM3BV&input=MTAyNA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
›3•D⌊=*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigLoz4oCiROKMij0qIiwiIiwiMyJd)

-1 thanks to Steffan.

A different approach that's annoyingly longer.

```
›       # Increment
 3•     # Log 3
   D⌊=  # Check if it's an integer
      * # Multiply by that
```

Comment: @Steffan I guess, although it's kinda ambiiguous as 0 is an allowed output.

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 68 bytes

```lisp
(d F(q((N A)(i(l N A)()(i(e A N)0(a 1(F N(a(a A A)A
(q((N)(F(a N 1)1
```

The solution is the anonymous function on the second line. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxDoMwEAR7XrHlXocjUJLSjd35D4egsOQEQmh4vTncjWY0R/6eJf@3Wjkj8EcmeGFmQYMbF3gk6alwDEhUI2/Rd/bE9giDyQQnrrKsOqPkadf9lI4f3RBBd6x4PMVExPjuh5fUCw)

#### Explanation

The function `F` does most of the work. It takes a target number `N` and an accumulator `A`. If `N` is a power of three, it returns the exponent; otherwise, it returns nil, which is a falsey value.

```lisp
(d F               ; Define F
 (q                ; to be a function
  ((N A)           ; that takes arguments N and A:
   (i(l N A)       ; If N is less than A,
    ()             ; return nil
    (i(e A N)      ; Else, if A is equal to N,
     0             ; return 0
     (a 1          ; Else, add 1 to the result of
      (F N         ; a recursive call with the same N
       (a(a A A)A  ; and three times the A (A+A+A)
```

If `N` equals three to the `X`, the `0` base case will be reached at the `X`th level of recursion, meaning that `1` will be added to it `X` times for a result of `X`. If the `()` base case is reached instead, `1` will be added to it some number of times, but adding a number to nil gives nil (and an error message).

The submission function is then just a wrapper around `F`:

```lisp
(q          ; A function
 ((N)       ; that takes argument N:
  (F        ; Call F with arguments
   (a N 1)  ; N+1
   1        ; and initial accumulator 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$ 7 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
R3@1-Ah
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6FsuDjB0MdR0zIDyo4IKFFhAGAA)

##### Explanation

```python
R3@1-Ah  # D flag duplicates implicit input
R        # Push range(0, input)
 3@      # 3 ** each
   1-    # Decrement
     Ah  # Index of input in this list
         # (0-indexed, -1 if not found)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ö♥ô·ô₧
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=940393fa939e&i=2%0A26%0A1024&m=2)

This unpacks to the following:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 bytes

```
f3s#vx=
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=f3s%23vx%3D&i=2%0A26%0A1024&m=2)

```
f       # filter over 1..input
 3s#    # 3^n
    v   # -1
     x= # is equal to the input
```

Outputs nothing if falsy

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 5 bytes

```
3D←P∑
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FiuNXR61TQh41DFxSXFScjFUdMFKIy4jMy5DAyMTiAAA)

```
3D      Convert to base 3
  ←     Decrement every digit
   P    Check if all digits are positive
    ∑   Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

```
f=(n,p=0,k=1)=>n<k?n>k-2&&p:f(n,p+1,k*3)
```

Returns `false` or the power. A simple port of @Arnauld's ES7 answer would have taken 43 bytes.

Comment: I think `f=(n,p,k=1)=>n<k?n>k-2&&p:f(n,-~p,k*3)` works and saves 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 180 bytes

```
class A{public static void main(String[]q)throws Exception{int a,b=0;while((a=System.in.read()-48)>=0)b=b*10+(a);double k=Math.log(b+1)/Math.log(3);System.out.print(k%1==0?k:-1);}}
```

Really simple approach. Input, then add one, then log<sub>3</sub> the number, and if it's a integer, print it; otherwise, print -1. Could use some work.

Only works up to (3^19)-1.

Comment: Why is this non-competing? The Non-Competing status is only reserved for languages or language features that were added after the challenge was posted.

Comment: As I said, size doesn't matter, so this can compete.

Comment: @KritixiLithos Oh okay. I wasn't aware of the exact meaning of Non-Competing. Thanks. Also, I'll update the title.

Comment: You can use `interface A{...}` and drop the `public` from `main()`. Why do you have `(a)` instead of `a` in the while loop. I think you can use `float k=...` instead of `double k=...`. Should be -5 bytes if I counted right.

Comment: @RomanGräf I appreciate your suggestions; however, none of them are of any use for me, unfortunately. Your first suggestion only works in Java 8, and there is already a far better Java 8 solution out there. I have `(a)` in the `while` loop because I am doing a comparison of an assignment statement, and assignment has the lowest priority on the order of operations and thus requires a set of brackets around it. Finally, I have `double` because `Math#log` returns a double and casting would obviously be much slower. Regardless, thank you for the suggestions, but I will not be incorporating them.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>36</s> 47 bytes

If `log(input+1,3)` differs from its integer value, print `0`; else print the logarithm:
`<?=(0|$x=log($argv[1]+1,3))-$x?0:$x;` (36 bytes) fails for `242`.
`<?=strstr($x=log($argv[1]+1,3),".")?0:$x;` and `<?=(0|$x=log($argv[1]+1,3))-$x>1e-7?0:$x;` (41 bytes) may fail for larger `$x`.

This version is safe:

```
for(;3**++$x<$n=1+$argv[1];);echo$n<3**$x?0:$x;
```

1.Loop `$x` up from 1 while 3^$x is smaller than argument+1.
2.Print `0` if the expression is larger than input+1, `$x` else.

Takes input from command line argument. Run with `-nr`.

Comment: gives wrong answer for 242 input

Comment: @Jasen: The downvote was ridiculous, but it´s fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp (SBCL), <s>83</s> 50 bytes

```lisp
(let*((i(read))(r(log(1+ i)3)))(if(=(mod r 1)0)r))
```

Old version:

```lisp
(let((i(read)))(if(find-if(lambda(x)(not(eq x #\2)))(format()"~3R"i))()(log(1+ i)3)))
```

Feedback encouraged!

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 11 bytes

```
ri3b_2-!\,*
```

Basically it determines if the number's trinary (base 3) representation contains only 2's, and if it does, outputs the number of 2's. It outputs 0 if the number is not only 2's.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#VY@9TsNAEIT7PMUgCn4UJHAa6oBERQOUSGidjJ1TznfW3drIT28u9jnAVivtN7MzYzA4Dy/xQoVxbaeQCHFpV9YMK2BT/sGevOsZFOpRSiQ2uE6whCADfAU9EHtTG43JIBM3q5P269fjuWut2YlyOqC4Ww5vbHxPiLUoriKq4JvJcbJfZYOLDG@9t0y/HWtR490ag6HdR9zDBzwsOD5n/P1b2pS6RQFaNnQpYgocVXbHM4v1xH7IkdNjS1frYSmWC@d@/0KluT0pXzurprUDymGW5JC92I5zoZKVDxzHxx8)

**Explanation**

```
ri          e# Get input as an integer
  3b        e# Convert to base 3 (an array of the digits in base 3)
    _       e# Duplicate
     2-     e# Remove all 2's from the array
       !    e# Boolean negation. Yields 1 if the array contained only 2's (and is now 
            e# empty), 0 otherwise
        \   e# Swap top 2 elements of stack
         ,  e# Take the length of the base 3 digits array
          * e# Multiply by the boolean value from before
```

Comment: _"Trinary"_ is more commonly referred to as [Ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system).

Answer (score 0):

### C 90 bytes

```
f(x){i=1;for(;i<x;i++){if((pow(3,i)-1)==x){printf("%d",i);break;}if(i==(x-1))puts("-1");}}
```

Ungolfed Version:

```
void f(int x)
{
  int i=1;
  for(;i<x;i++)
  {
    if((pow(3,i)-1)==x)
    {
        printf("%d",i);
        break;      
    }   
    if(i==(x-1))
        puts("-1");     
  } 
}
```

Comment: for x=1 what would return/print that above?

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 32 bytes

```
INPUT X
X=LOG(X+1,3)?X*(X==X>>0)
```

Outputs `0` for false.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), 91 bytes

```
%
:
+
~
v~d<
0  /{<
+  A #-?+M?"-1"@
+  !   @.-<
+  M #  M!/        <
>~ # ^  } \       +^%
```

According to the specifications of Cardinal, this shouldn't work for inputs above 255. However, due to the implementation in TIO accepting values over 255, it will work past 255 up to 3^34.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#Lck7DoAgFETR/q1ihFgRVAofYIjiAtyBoXINNka2jp8wxS3OlJYmUpTpzEegAeivQApYIfWitkVoI@IHDYDY6f/cIN80PeoCzfmlBNzYq6nUlmKYrTXOsPfMPLJ7AA)

### Explanation

```
%
:
+
```

Input + 1

```
~
v~d<
0  /{<
+  A 
+  !  
+  M
>~ # ^
```

While divisible by 3

```
#-?+M?"-1"@
```

Output -1 if not divisible by 3 or equal to 1 and end program

```
   .-<
#  M!/        <
   } \       +^%
```

Output counter for how many times the input + 1 has been divided by 3 before equalling 1

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE) <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
logBASE(Ans+1,3)
Ansnot(Ans-int(Ans
```

All tokens used are one-byte except `logBASE(`,  which is two.

Explanation:

```
logBASE(Ans+1,3)   # inverse of 3^n-1 is log3(x+1)
Ansnot(Ans-int(Ans # if X is an integer, `X-int(x` is 0, so `not(X-int(X` is 1, which is multiplied by X
                   # if X is not an integer, `X-int(X` is not 0, so `not(X-int(X` is zero, which is multiplied by X
                   # last value evaluated is implicitly returned
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 18 bytes

```
:[a|c=3^b-1~c=a|?b
```

Explanation

```
:        Get 'a' from the cmd-line
[a|      FOR b=1; b<=a; b++  (this runs a lot longer than we need...)
c=3^b-1  Set c to be 3^b-1
~c=a     IF this is the input given
|?b      THEN print b
         END IF and NEXT are added implicitly
```

This would print multiple `b`s if it would be possible to have multiple solutions. Right now, it runs on after finding a solution. We could substitute `?b` for `_Xb` to quit after finding a solution, but that adds a byte. Also, the FOR-loop `[a|` could be initialised as `[a/3|` to save us a lot of iterations, but that adds another 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom,<s>72 65</s> 63 bytes

```
g(x:PI):INT==(z:=floor(y:=log(x+1.)/log(3.));y-z~=0=>-1;z::INT)
```

some test

```
(51) -> [[x,g(x)]  for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,26,27,79,80,242]]
   (51)
   [[1,- 1], [2,1], [3,- 1], [4,- 1], [5,- 1], [6,- 1], [7,- 1], [8,2],
    [9,- 1], [10,- 1], [26,3], [27,- 1], [79,- 1], [80,4], [242,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
[:(*>.=])3^.>:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WL9pKQ8tOzzZW0zhOz87qf2pyRr5CmkJqWWpRpYKRmYKhgZHJfwA)

Here's a variant using a range of powers and indexing (@Dennis's method).

```
(~:*])>:i.~3^i.
```

Here's a variant using base conversion (@orlp's method).

```
[:(#*&(*/)2=])3&#.inv
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 28 bytes

```perl
$_=(log$_+1)/log 3;$_*=!/\./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYjJz9dJV7bUFMfyFAwtlaJ17JV1I/R0///34jLgsuYy9DAyORffkFJZn5e8X/dghwA)

Outputs 0 as the error/falsy state.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 78 bytes

```kotlin
{val x=kotlin.math.log(it+1.0,3.0);if(kotlin.math.round(x)==x)x.toInt()else-1}
```

### `kotlin.math.log` and `kotlin.math.round` imported, 54 bytes

```kotlin
{val x=log(it+1.0,3.0);if(round(x)==x)x.toInt()else-1}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), 31 bytes

```
l=log_3(x+1)
f(x)=0^{mod(l,1)}l
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5wmteaqong)

Answer (score 0):

## [Brainlove](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainlove), 51 bytes

```
+[[-(>>[-]--<<+)-(>>[-]--<<+)->+<]>[<+>-]>+<<-(-)+]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLyS9L/a@NE/zXjo7W1bCzi9aN1dW1sdHWROXYadvE2kXbaNvpxgKZNroauprasf9BCmyAGGpGNFAZBAAVA@Vs9Oxi/wMA)

Just an increment and then iterative division by 3. The input is in the starting cell (cell 0) and output in cell 2. The printing in unary is just for demonstration and testing and is not a part of the actual solution. For falsy returns 255, as it is the best representation of -1 and due to limited cell space it cannot be the X.