# When integers join the queue

Tags: code-golf, number, array

#### Introduction

A [**queue**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) is an abstract data type where elements are **added to the front** (enqueue) and **removed from the back** (dequeue). This is also known as the [FIFO (First In First Out)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) principle.

It is best shown with an example:

[image]

---

#### Challenge

Given a **non-empty** array that contains **positive integers** and **elements that indicate a *dequeue*** (removing an element), output the final list of the queue.

Let's say that `X` denotes a dequeue in this example. Let's take a look at the following list:

```
[45, X, X, 37, 20, X, 97, X, 85]
```

This can be translated to the following queue-pseudo code:

```
                   Queue
Enqueue 45    ->   45
Dequeue       ->   
Dequeue       ->              (dequeue on an empty queue is a no-op)
Enqueue 37    ->   37
Enqueue 20    ->   20 37
Dequeue       ->   20
Enqueue 97    ->   97 20
Dequeue       ->   97
Enqueue 85    ->   85 97
```

You can see that in the end, the result is `[85, 97]`, which is the output for this sequence.

---

#### Test cases

**Note** that you may choose any other symbol or character for `X`, as long as it's not a positive integer.

```
[1, X, 2, X, 3, X]      ->     []
[1, 2, X]               ->     [2]
[1, 2, 3]               ->     [3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, X, X, X, 3]      ->     [3]
[1, 2, X, 3, X, 4]      ->     [4, 3]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: Can it be a space separated string Instead of an array?

Comment: @Riley Sure, whatever works best for you

Comment: Can we use a negative number for x (Haskell doesn't support heterogeneous lists)

Comment: ...or other non-non-negative integers like zero or a half?

Comment: @GenericDisplayName Hmm, good point. I'll allow it as long it's not a positive integer

Comment: @JonathanAllan I have changed the specs

Comment: Sorry, does that mean using 0 is allowed, or only negative numbers?

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, using zero is allowed.

Comment: Really any string for X? Including something like `q.pop();`?

Comment: @feersum Sorry, I meant character. Updated the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
F;@Ṗṛ?¥/
```

Uses any falsy value (**0** or empty iterable) to dequeue.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9m7fBw57SHO2fbH1qq//9w@6OmNe7//0dHm5jqKCgYQLCxuY6CEZRtaQ6hLUxjdbgUohUMocqMoLQxiFZAAghlRuhSuJUZE6fMAAkb41dmDKVNUJTFAgA)

#### How it works

```
F;@Ṗṛ?¥/  Main link. Argument: A (array)

       /  Reduce A by the link to the left.
      ¥     Combine the two links to the left into a dyadic chain.
F             Flatten the left argument.
    ṛ?        If the right argument is truthy:
 ;@             Concatenate the right argument and the flattened left argument.
              Else:
   Ṗ            Pop; remove the last element of the flattened left argument.
                This is why flattening is required, as Ṗ doesn't handle integers
                as intended for this challenge.
```

Comment: Actually it's not forbidden. Only *positive* integers are forbidden, 0 is neutral.

Comment: That's not what it said when I posted my answer, but thank for the heads up.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, <s>56</s> <s>53</s> 50 bytes

```py
q=[]
for i in input():q=[[i]+q,q[:i]][i<0]
print q
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19oGx3LlZZfpJCpkJkHRAWlJRqaVkDR6MxY7UKdwmirzNjY6Ewbg1iugqLMvBKFwv//ow11FIx0FHSBlDGEMolVAAA)

Dequeue is `-1`. This trick allows easy pythonic slicing of the queue.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 102 bytes

Definitely not the shortest solution, but I couldn't resist because it's kind of perverse.

```
r=Reverse@{##}&
a_~f~b___:=b
f[a_,b___,]:=b
ToExpression[{"r[","f["~Table~StringCount[#,"]"],#}<>"]"]&
```

After some helper functions, this defines a pure function that takes a string as input: in the string, numbers are separated by commas (whitespace is optional); the dequeue character is `"]"`; and the list does not have delimiters in the front or back. For instance, the first example in the OP would be input as the string `"45,],],37,20,],97,],85"`. The output of the function is a list of numbers.

The function counts how many dequeues `"]"` are in the input string, appends that many copies of `"f["` to the front of the string, and then surrounds the whole thing by `"r[...]"`. In the example above, this produces `"r[f[f[f[f[45,],],37,20,],97,],85]"`; notice the brackets are balanced.

Then, `ToExpression` interprets the resulting string as a piece of Mathematica code and executes it. The function `f` is conveniently defined to retain all its arguments except the first (and also ignores trailing commas; this is necessary to handle dequeueing empty queues anyway), and `r` converts the resulting sequence of numbers into a list of numbers in the right order.

Comment: Is the comma in line 3 at `b___,` meant to be there? It *works*, but the comma turns red because of it. (also, what's the difference between lines 2 and 3?)

Comment: Good eye :) Line 2 is equivalent to `f[a_,b___]:=b` (without the comma), while line 3 is equivalent to `f[a_,b___,Null]:=b`. In both cases, `b___` refers to any number of arguments (including none at all). Line 3 is more specific, so is always used before line 2 when appropriate. So the function `f` ignores its first argument, and also ignores its last argument if that argument is `Null`. This was necessary to handle dequeueing an empty queue. Note that a typical input will yield an expression like `r[f[f[f[5,3,],2,],],11]`, where each comma before `]` again denotes a `Null`.

Comment: Wow, very nice :). By the way, I think it's actually 102 bytes; you may have counted an extra newline character at the end.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 30 bytes

```
1+`\d+,(.*?)X,?|^X,
$1
O^$`\d+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/hvqJ0Qk6Kto6GnZa8ZoWNfExehw6ViyOUfpwIS///fUCdCxwiIjXUiuAxBLDBpDGGDIYwNVKFjAgA)

Repeatedly removes the first number that's (not necessarily immediately) followed by an `X` together with that `X`, or an `X` at the beginning of the string. Then reverses the remaining numbers.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>70</s> <s>63</s> <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 43 bytes

Thanks @Neil for golfing off 10 bytes with x.map instead of for loop and ternary expression

Thanks @Arnauld for golfing off 3 bytes

Thanks @ETHproductions for golfing off 7 bytes

```javascript
x=>(t=[],x.map(a=>+a?t=[a,...t]:t.pop()),t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9X2Frp1FiGx2rU6GXm1igkWhrl2hnYA8USdTR09MribUq0SvIL9DQ1NQp0fyfnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RphFtYqqjFKEExgrG5joKRgYQtqU5hLYwjdXU/A8A)

Dequeue can be any non-numeric value other than true.

Comment: This would be shorter if you used a ternary instead of an `if `statement, and shorter still if you used `map` instead of a loop, and even shorter still if you used an expression instead of a block. See the [tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/tips-for-golfing-in-ecmascript-6-and-above).

Comment: I had posted the first version I got working. Then I ate dinner :P

Comment: You can do `x=>(t=[],x.map(a=>a>0?t.unshift(a):t.pop()),t)` to save quite a few bytes on the `return`

Comment: `x=>x.map(a=>a>0?t.unshift(a):t.pop(),t=[])&&t` is even shorter.

Comment: (Or just `a?` suffices, I guess?)

Comment: The a>0 is so that strings return false

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>46</s> 45 bytes

*Thanks to ngenisis for saving 1 byte.*

```
Reverse[#//.{_Integer:0,a___,X,b___}:>{a,b}]&
```

Basically the same as my Retina answer, using pattern matching. We repeatedly match the first `X` and remove it along with the first number (if one exists). After we're done, we reverse the list.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
vi"@?@wh}IL)
```

Input is an array of numbers, with `0` for "dequeue".

Output is numbers separated by spaces. An empty result is shown as nothing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1@WqeRg71CeUevpo/n/f7SJqY6CARgZm@soGEGYluZgysI0FgA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmfoO6cWJyqoO4QlqFupZ7h8r8sU8nB3qE8o9bTR/N/bGyES8j/aEMdBQMdBSMwaQwkY7lAQkbILGOEGAyhCBmDSZNYAA).

#### Explanation

```
v        % Concatenate stack contents: gives []. This will grow to represent the queue
i        % Input numeric array
"        % For each entry in the input array
  @?     %   If current entry is non-zero
    @wh  %     Prepend current entry to the queue
  }      %   Else
    IL)  %     Remove last element from the queue
         %   End (implicit)
         % End (implicit)
         % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pure Bash, 72

Input given as command-line parameters.

```bash
for a;{
[ ${a/X} ]&&q=(${a:n++,0} ${q[@]})||((n-=n>0))
}
echo ${q[@]::n}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@WX6SQaF3NFa2gUp2oH1GrEKumVmirAeRY5Wlr6xjUAsULox1iazVrajQ08nRt8@wMNDW5arlSkzPyoXJWVnm1////NzH9HwGExub/jQyAtKU5kLAwBQA).

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>41</s> 40 Bytes

```
l#a|a>0=a:l|l>[]=init l|1>0=l
```

Function is `foldl(#)[]` (Also included in bytecount with a byte of separation in between)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#jY7NCsJADITvfYpAPShsYftHVWhfpOwhtqsGYrbURRH67nWL4EmwCWQgfDPMzDFO2Ogajzxx05qahDzwlIYfzzckgRp6B8NI4mEDZ8c9b@Nda9qiVDpsXqls0UMVzr40EXznhykNULa4lP5LZquYfE3Op@kqMjRThYmSREOHAicLox0YO9vDk/wVUF4gTpLB3cnTw0LIsRc7zm8)

X is any non-positive integer

EDIT: -1 byte thanks to nimi

Comment: You can flip the last two guards to save a byte: `|l>[]=init l|1>0=l`

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 41 bytes

```
x&y:z|y<1=init x&z|w<-y:x=w&z
x&y=x
([]&)
```

Comment: Ninja'd :) seems like we had the same idea

Comment: (Although you need parentheses around the y:z like `x&(y:z)`

Comment: It works in my REPL which is part of hugs. I'm not sure of the exact version though.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>78</s> <s>76</s> <s>73</s> 57 bytes

```
f(a)=(q=[];[x<1?q=q[2:end]:push!(q,x)for x=a];reverse(q))
```

Thanks to Harrison Grodin for some excellent Julia golfing suggestions. Replaced if/else with ternary and for/end with list comprehension for a savings of 16 bytes.

```
f(a)=(q=[];for x in a if x<1 q=q[2:end]else q=[q...,x]end end;reverse(q))
```

Removed some unnecessary spaces for a savings of 3 bytes.

Before negative numbers or zero were allowed:

```
f(a)=(q=[];for x in a if x==:X q=q[2:end] else q=[q...,x] end end;r everse(q))
```

Ungolfed:

```
function dequeue(list)
    queue = []

    for x in list
        if x < 1
            queue = queue[2:end]
        else
            queue = [queue..., x]
        end
    end

    reverse(queue)
end
```

I'm fairly new to Julia; there may be a better way. Uses `:X` for X, which is a Symbol in Julia. Updated: Now that 0 is allowed, uses 0 (or any negative number) for X, saving two characters. Updated again to remove some whitespace that I didn't realize wasn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 85 Bytes

```
<?$r=[];foreach($_GET as$v)is_int($v)?array_unshift($r,$v):array_pop($r);print_r($r);
```

-8 Bytes `$v` instead of `is_int($v)`if every dequeue value belongs to false

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to *Riley*

```
)Evyai¨ëy¸ì
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/pWlaZmHloxeHVlYd2HF7z/3@0oY6CkY6CeoS6joIxlDaJBQA)

**Explanation**

Dequeues are denoted by *any letter*.

```
)             # wrap stack in a list (pushes empty list)
 Ev           # for each y in evaluated input
   yai        # if y is a letter
      ¨       # remove the first element of the list
       ëy¸ì   # else, prepend y to the list
```

Answer (score 2):

## GNU Sed, 43

Score includes +2 for use of the `-r` and `-n` flags.

```
G
s/X\n( *|(.*)\b\S+ *)$/\2/
s/\n/ /
h
$p
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@@/OVawfEZOnoaBVo6GnpRmTFBOsraClqaIfY6QPlIrJ01fQ58rgUin4/9/ElCsCCI3NuYwMgLSlOZCwMP2XX1CSmZ9X/F@3KA8A).

#### Explanation

```
                            # Implicitly read the next line
G                           # append a newline, then the contents of the hold space
s/X\n( *|(.*)\b\S+ *)$/\2/  # If the input was an X, remove it, the newline, and any element at the end
s/\n/ /                     # Otherwise if the input was not an X, it is simply enqueued by removing the newline between it and the rest of the line
h                           # save a copy of the queue to the hold space
$p                          # since we're using -n to suppress output at the end of processing each input line, then this explicit print is required in the last line
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>95</s> 94 bytes

```python
def f(x):q=[];[*map(lambda s:exec(("q.pop(0)"if q else"","q+=[s]")[s!="X"]),x)];print(q[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#VY3NCsIwEITvPkXc066N0l@qKXkPIeRQbQKFVhPjIW9fS3qQHpbdmR2@WQZjmcVIwkulO3Wae4dTPz@GngVhonkigr@4t8OcYLTMMzMFA8DBZ1IFDaTCUcIdNPFIunOf8fVFr4Q4F5oWi6pu@PpOU7W8zNN1a9O6NpoOa6ZIqtxCPNE2u9yLauf/uXs7EXi91v8A)

Also 94 bytes:

```python
def f(x):q=[];[*map(lambda s:exec((("","q.pop(0)")[q>[]],"q+=[s]")[s!="X"]),x)];print(q[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 28 + 1 = 29 bytes

28 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
/\d/?$\=$_.$\:$\=~s/.*
$//}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@K8fk6JvrxJjqxKvpxJjBWTUFevraXGp6OvXVv//b8hlxBXBZQzEJlwA)

It uses a string (`$\`) as the queue: when the input contains an integer (`/\d/?`, we append it at the beginning of `$\` (`$\=$_.$\`), and otherwise, we remove the last one with `s/.*\n$//`. At the end, `$\` is implicitly printed thanks to `-p` flag (and those unmatched `}{`).

---

Other approaches:

- **33 bytes**, using an array as the queue (it's the most natural way to do it in Perl I think, but not the shortest):

  ```perl
  /X/?pop@F:unshift@F,$_}{$_="@F"
  ```

  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAtyPmvH6FvX5Bf4OBmVZpXnJGZVuLgpqMSX1utEm@r5OCm9P@/IZcRVwSXMRCbAAA)
- **52 bytes**, using regex and `reverse` (it happens to be quite exactly the same thing as Martin Ender's Retina answer - thanks to whom I saved 2 bytes on it). Reversing the list takes a lot of characters though, because to preserve the integers, I have to convert the string to an array to reverse it, then back to a string to print it. (`say for` instead of `$_=join$",` can save 2 bytes, but it requires `-E` or `-M5.010` and it's not that interesting).

  ```perl
  s/\d+ (.*?)X ?|^X/$1/&&redo;$_=join$",reverse split
  ```

  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@F@sH5OiraChp2WvGaFgXxMXoa9iqK@mVpSakm@tEm@blZ@Zp6KkU5RallpUnKpQXJCTWfL/v4mpQgQQGpsrGBkAaUtzIGFhCgA)

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 3, 70 bytes

Assuming we have an array of Ints like `let x = [1, 2,-1,3,-1,4]`

```
print(x.reduce([].prefix(0)){(a,i)in return i>0 ?[i]+a:a.dropLast(1)})
```

Note that `[].prefix(0)` is a sneaky way to get an empty ArraySlice

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <s>122</s> 119 bytes

```c++
#import<list>
void f(std::list<int>o,std::list<int>&q){for(int i:o)if(i)q.push_front(i);else if(q.size())q.pop_back();}
```

0 indicates a dequeue.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#dU5da4QwEHz3VywelATkaM8@abhfcnBYjXSpZjWJfaj42@0mpy09eiEMOzP7MesB@4GsVx06f04@CRtohfNNUQRFofFnyv7yp1HOLVnBNWBBEluBcjwOk3u/tpaMZ1rqzmlgZzw6/NJChgYarm9V/SFkuawHNHU3NRoUkvNWV/123Wvn7wIAGpnMCfC7M2jyZdQ5gskClRsnC7eAUET5NllzCUqxypBCWv4u3a30YlhekjDcV2jEfjoGm18yeM7gFDFnXLaDP@7pgZj/27n/R24e8TW4ybJ@Aw)

Comment: Suggest `i?q.push_front(i):q.size()?q.pop_back():(void)0` instead of `if(i)q.push_front(i);else if(q.size())q.pop_back()`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
def f(x,r=[]):
 for i in x:r=i and[i]+r or r[:-1]
 print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzBCoMwEETv@Yo5GppCTRTbgF8S9lCwoXuJsnjQr09DBKHCMrvzdphlX79zsjlPn4jYbEbGQNorxFnA4ITNy8h4pykw3QQFS/D3lhQW4bRCcmxC1xs86rjBwB7na6jr2ZNWJdNWZ49U0ZPai3F/n7P4Ql3VjnT@AQ)

Uses `0` as a dequeue value

-10 bytes [thanks to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114749/when-integers-join-the-queue/114761?noredirect=1#comment513447_114761) [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)

Comment: 58 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzBCoMwEETv@Yo5GppCTRTbgF8S9lCwoXuJsnjQr09DBKHCMrvzdphlX79zsjlPn4jYbEbGQNorxFnA4ITNy8h4pykw3QQFS/D3lhQW4bRCcmxC1xs86rjBwB7na6jr2ZNWJdNWZ49U0ZPai3F/n7P4Ql3VjnT@AQ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @pxeger Very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 160 bytes

```
@set s=.
@for %%n in (%*)do @if %%n==X (call set s=%%s:* =%%)else call set s=%%s:~,-1%%%%n .
@set t=
@for %%n in (%s:~,-1%)do @call set t= %%n%%t%%
@echo%t%
```

This was harder than it needed to be.

- Although Batch can enumerate the result of splitting a string, it can't easily remove an element from the enumeration.
- It can remove the first item, but only if there is at least one item. Otherwise you get garbage.

This means that I a) need to have an end-of-queue marker, which doesn't get removed, and b) have to manipulate the queue back-to-front, so new items get inserted in just before the end marker, so that old items can be removed from the front, which then means I c) have to reverse the queue before printing it.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 70 bytes

```
foreach($argv as$v)+$v?$r[]=$v:array_shift($r);krsort($r);print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 115 bytes +33 bytes for using

```
l=>{var r=new List<int>();foreach(var n in l)if(n<0)try{r.RemoveAt(0);}catch{}else r.Add(n);r.Reverse();return r;};
```

Anonymous method which returns a list of integers after performing the en-queuing and dequeuing operations. Negative integers are used for removing elements from the queue.

Full program with ungolfed method and test cases:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                
public class Program
{
    static void PrintList(List<int> list)
    {
        var s = "{";
        foreach (int element in list)
            s += element + ", ";
        if (s.Length > 1)
            s += "\b\b";
        s += "}";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<List<int>, List<int>> f =
        l =>
        {
            var r = new List<int>();
            foreach (var n in l)
                if (n < 0)
                    try
                    {
                        r.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                    catch
                    { }
                else
                    r.Add(n);
            r.Reverse();
            return r;
        };
        
        // test cases:
        var list = new List<int>(new[]{1, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1});   // {}
        PrintList(f(list));
        
        list = new List<int>(new[]{1, 2, -1});  // {2}
        PrintList(f(list));
        
        list = new List<int>(new[]{1, 2, 3});   // {3, 2, 1}
        PrintList(f(list));
        
        list = new List<int>(new[]{1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 3});   // {3}
        PrintList(f(list));
        
        list = new List<int>(new[]{1, 2, -1, 3, -1, 4});    // {4, 3}
        PrintList(f(list));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 97 bytes

```
type S=Seq[_];def f(a:S,b:S):S=a match{case h::t=>f(t,if(h==0)b dropRight 1 else h+:b);case _=>b}
```

As input, `f` takes a list with `0` as the "dequeue" element. It uses tail-recursion with a second parameter (`b`), acting as an accumulator. Initially, `b` is the empty `Seq` (`Nil`).

**Explanations :**

```
type S=Seq[_]                               // defines a type alias (save 1 byte since Seq[_] is used 3 times)
def f(a: S, b: S): S = {                    // a is the initial list, b is an accumulator
    a match {                           
        case h::t =>                        // if a is non-empty
            f(t,                            // recursive call to f with 1st parameter as the tail
                if (h==0) b dropRight 1     // if h == 0 (dequeue) then remove last element of b,
                else h+:b                   // otherwise, just add h at the beginning of b in recursive call
            )
        case _ => b                         // when the list is empty, return b (final result)
    }
}
```

*Note :* `b dropRight 1` is used instead of `b.tail` to avoid exception : `tail of empty list`.

**Test cases :**

```
f(Seq(45, 0, 0, 37, 20, 0, 97, 0, 85), Nil)     // List(85, 97)
f(Seq(1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0), Nil)                   // List()
f(Seq(1, 2, 0), Nil)                            // List(2)
f(Seq(1, 2, 3), Nil)                            // List(3, 2, 1)
f(Seq(1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3), Nil)                   // List(3)
f(Seq(1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4), Nil)                   // List(4, 3)
```

`f` can also work with other types (`String`, `char`, ..., even heterogeneous list of those types!) :

```
f(Seq(false, '!', "world", 0, "Hello"), Nil)    // List(Hello, world, !)
```

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 115 bytes

```
arg n
do while n>''
  parse var n m n
  if m=X then pull
  else queue m
  end
o=
do while queued()>0
  pull a
  o=a o
  end
say o
```

Takes a space-separated string, prints a space separated string

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>65</s> 54 bytes

```ruby
q=[];(eval$*[0]).each{|i|q=[i]+q;q=q[1..-2]if i<0};p q
```

The separator can be any negative number.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

-1 byte from @ngn

```
(){$[y;y,;-1_]x}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NSkOzWiW60rpSx1rXMD62olb/f5qCg7qChompggEQGpsrGIFoS3MgYWFqbQikjEDiCgZAthGUNIawITqgbKAKBRPN/wA)

Uses `0` as the dequeue element.

- `(){...}/` set up a reduction seeded with `()` (an empty list), over the (implicit) input
- `$[...]x` apply `x` (the queue) to the result of `$[]` (cond)
- `$[y;y,;-1_]` depending on the new value (i.e. if it is `0` or isn't), return a function projection either prepending the new value (`y,`), or dequeuing the last element (`-1_`)

Comment: `$[~y;-1_;y,]` -> `$[y;y,;-1_]` ?

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
(*@[;@{}:@];,)/@|.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NbQcoq0dqmutHGKtdTT1HWr0/mtypSZn5CtYmCpYmivoWimkKZiYAnUYKBibKxiBaKCwAVAaokxdHaLGEChmBFKkYACRMFKwBQuDBFEBRN4YKGMI02sE5GLII/SDbUeSMwHy4DrBdgKFFP4DAA)

- `(...)/@|.` Reverse and reduce by verb in parens...
- `}:@];,` Create the two options (regular vs deque, represented by `0`) as a boxed pair: left elm is the deque case (ie, accumlator with tail removed `}:@]`) and right elm is the normal case (new elm appended as head `,`).
- `(*@[...{` Pick the correct case, which is the signum of the left argument in the reduction `*@[`, from our boxed pair `{`...
- `;@` And unbox it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 46 bytes

```sh
for a (`<&0`)$a&&{shift -p;:}||set $a $@
<<<$@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVFBI8FGzSBBUyVRTa26OCMzrURBt8Daqrampji1REElUUHFgcvGxkbF4f9/E1MFKyA0NlcwMgDSluZAwsIUAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 41 bytes

```
!a=(q=[];a.|>i->q=i>0?[i;q]:q[1:end-1];q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//9fMdFWo9A2OtY6Ua/GLlPXrtA2087APjrTujDWqjDa0Co1L0XXMNa6UPN/hIKtggGXYrShjkKEjoIRmDQGkrEKNXYKBUWZeSU5eRBpI1yixrEKWBXDkHEsDmljMGmCLP0fAA)