# Numbers Increase While Letters Decrease

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting

Inspired by this Stack Overflow question: [Sorting a list: numbers in ascending, letters in descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541119/sorting-a-list-numbers-in-ascending-letters-in-descending). Your task is to solve the following problem and, as this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), you should do so in as few as bytes as possible.

You should take a list of objects as input containing letters (any reasonable form: `string`, `char`, etc) and numbers. You should then sort the numbers into ascending order and the letters into descending order. However, you should keep letters in letter positions and numbers in number positions. For example, if the list is:

```
[L, D, L, L, D, L]
```

The output list should be in the form of:

```
[L, D, L, L, D, L]
```

**Workthrough**

Input: `['a', 2, 'b', 1, 'c', 3]`

- Sort the numbers into ascending order: `[1, 2, 3]`
- Sort the letters into descending order: `['c', 'b', 'a']`
- Join them back but keep the order the same: `['c', 1', 'b', 2, 'a', 3]`

**Rules**

- The list will only contain letters and digits.
- The list may be empty.
- The list may only contain letters or only digits.
- **If** your language does not support mixed type arrays you may use digit characters instead of numbers. Note that if your language does support this you must use mixed types.
- Letters will only be `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]`, you may choose which one.
- Letters are sorted as `a` being lowest, `z` being highest i.e. `a = 1, z = 26`.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- I/O may be by any standard means including as a string.

**Test cases**

```
[5, 'a', 'x', 3, 6, 'b'] -> [3, 'x', 'b', 5, 6, 'a']

[ 3, 2, 1] -> [ 1, 2, 3 ]

[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] -> [ 'c', 'b', 'a' ]

[] -> []

[ 2, 3, 2, 1 ] -> [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65034/discussion-on-question-by-thelethalcoder-numbers-increase-while-letters-decrease).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 10 bytes

```
O`\d
O^`\D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fPyEmhcs/LiHG5f//RKMkw2RjAA)

The `O` stage in Retina can directly perform the kind of selective sorting required by this challenge.

Here the first line sorts digits while the second line sorts non-digits in reverse.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>53</s> <s>52</s> 51 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to g.rocket</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Frech</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to RootTwo</sup>

```python
def F(x):n=sorted(x);print[n.pop(-(e>x))for e in x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0xDsIwDEV3TuEtieQiEQRDKzr2ElEGSlPRxYnSDOH0wS5i@Xr/68lOn/KOZFtbwgqTrqanxx5zCQvzkPJGxdE5xaQ7HcZqzBozBNgIqm/CJexFqnM3BPVUHJXjinBnnJVHJ8UiXAR/xizxUsCLjBb/Cnjfn@B4e1xmrRtZHiYt1bQv)

The `sorted` list will have the numbers first and then the chars like `[3, 5, 6, 'a', 'b', 'x']`, then use `e>x` to filter what is number and what is char, in python any number is less than a list (input) and a list is less than a string.

Comment: This [version](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEADAu6/Y2ypYUFGnfIkIFRl5WRczsNebl2H4y3eksdZiAvGbpRJknpiyP2VRglOgbKnnyHLopF9xQ6WumMBDICiuVjtrwB0bpTFpWFoPdD8) fails with `IndexError: pop index out of range`. The former solution did work.

Comment: [This works though](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEADAu6/Y2ypYUFGnfIkIFRl5WRczsNebl2H4y3eksdZiAvGbpRJknpiyP2VRglOgbKnnyFL6FTdU3aCumMBDICiuVjtrwB0bpTFpWFoPdD8), with 55 bytes too. `1-(e<'\`')` should be `(e<'\`')-1`. You just placed them in the wrong order. BTW, you ninja'd me :/ I had [this](https://tio.run/##DcaxCoAgEADQ3a@47RSsoagpv0SEioxczsMMbOnXzeXx@M1XpKHWYgLxk6USZO6Ysj9kUYJToGyp58jy66RfcEWlzpjAQyAorlY7acANG6Uxaphbd3Q/)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanks for the help c:

Comment: save a byte with `e<=9`

Comment: Save two with `e>x`

Comment: Think you can save another one with `n.pop(-(e>x))`

Comment: @RootTwo That does the opposite of the intended behavior.

Comment: [Saved](https://goo.gl/U8ewo7) another byte.

Comment: @LyricLy no, RootTwo's golf is right

Comment: @pxeger fixed, thanks

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

Expects characters to be uppercase

```apl
(⍋⊃¨⊂)@(~e)(⍒⊃¨⊂)@(e←∊∘⎕A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wSNR73dj7qaD6141NWk6aBRl6oJFJmEJJIKVPSoo@tRx4xHfVMdNYG6FEx1FNQd1YFEBJAw1lEwAzKd1LnSQGwjHQVDIAsi7wQinEEyj3rXAAA)

This is just two applications of the form `f@g`, apply the function `f` on the items indicated by `g`.

For the first application we use:
 `f`: `⍒⊃¨⊂` the descending grades (`⍒`) each pick (`⊃¨`) from the entire argument (`⊂`).
 `g`: `(e←∊∘⎕A)` members (`∊`) of (`∘`) the **A**lphabet (`⎕A`), and store (`←`) this function as `e`.

For the second application we use:
 `f`: `⍋⊃¨⊂` the ascending grades (`⍋`) each pick (`⊃¨`) from the entire argument (`⊂`).
 `g`: `(~e)` not (`~`) members of the alphabet (`e`; the function we stored before)

Comment: I think this needs to cover for all integers, so replace the second filter with `83=⎕DR¨⍵`

Comment: @Uriel Doesn't actually seem to be a requirement, but did save a byte. Also, ⎕DR is not universally 83 for numbers, only for small integers.

Comment: is it always `3=10|⎕DR` for integers?

Comment: @Uriel Yes: 0=UnicodeChar, 1=Boolean, 2=ClassicChar, 3=int, 5=float, 6=pointer, 7=decimal, 9=complex. `⌊0.1×⎕DR` gives you the number of bits used to represent each scalar, except for pointers, which depend on the architecture but always are 326. Thus, all numbers are `2|⎕DR`.

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>71</s> <s>51</s> 47 bytes

*Saved 20 bytes by just using `sort()`, as suggested by [@JustinMariner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69583/justin-mariner)*
*Saved 4 more bytes thanks to [@CraigAyre](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68610/craig-ayre)*

Using a similar approach as [Rod's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138208/58563):

```js
a=>[...a].map(n=>a.sort()[1/n?'shift':'pop']())
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>[...a].map(n=>a.sort()[1/n?'shift':'pop']())

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['a', 2, 'b', 1, 'c', 3]))) // -> ['c', 1', 'b', 2, 'a', 3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([5, 'a', 'x', 3, 6, 'b']))) // -> [3, 'x', 'b', 5, 6, 'a']
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([3, 2, 1]))) // -> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['a', 'b', 'c']))) // -> [ 'c', 'b', 'a' ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([]))) // -> []
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([2, 3, 2, 1]))) // -> [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Am I missing something or couldn't you remove the whole `sort` function and just use `sort()` on its own? It seems to sort in the same way without a function (in Chrome/FF/Edge).

Comment: @JustinMariner At first, I thought the numeric values could be numbers -- in which case a simple `sort()` would fail. But since we're limited to digits, you are correct: that does work. Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution, could you shift/pop on `a.sort()` each loop instead of assigning to `x`?: `.map(n=>a.sort()[1/n?'shift':'pop']())`

Comment: @CraigAyre Good catch!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `+n` can be used instead of `1/n`

Comment: @ConorO'Brien That would work for the test cases, but the OP confirmed in the comments that the input array may contain zeros.

Comment: oh, I see. How about `~n`?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Then that would fail for letters: e.g. `~"a" === -1`.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>83</s> 76 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to Miff*

```r
function(n){u=unlist
d=n%in%0:9
n[d]=sort(u(n[d]))
n[!d]=sort(u(n[!d]),T)
n}
```

This is the same as the below, but it allows for mixed-type input as a `list` rather than an `atomic` vector (which would typecast everything as characters with mixed types).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT7O61LY0LyezuIQrxTZPNTNP1cDKkisvOiXWtji/qESjVAPE1tQECikiiwE5mjohQOHa/2kaIO0aSolKOkY6SklKOoY6SslKOsaamv8B)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>68</s> 61 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to Miff*

```r
function(n){d=n%in%0:9
n[d]=sort(n[d])
n[!d]=sort(n[!d],T)
n}
```

Anonymous function. All digits are cast to characters in this case. `n[-d]` is the array without the digits. Returns `NULL` (empty list) on empty input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT7M6xTZPNTNP1cDKkisvOiXWtji/qEQDxNIE8hURAkCmTghQrPZ/mkayhlKiko6RjlKSko6hjlKyko6xpiYXSFxT8z8A)

Comment: You can shave off a few characters with `d=n%in%0:9`

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 15 bytes

*Thanks @Shaggy for -3 bytes and for help fixing for arrays with `0`s.*

```
c ñc
®¤?Vv :Vo
```

First line is intentionally left blank.

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=CmMg8WMKrqQ/VnYgOlZv&inputs=WzUsICdhJywgJ3gnLCAzLCA2LCAnYidd,WzMsIDIsIDFd,WydhJywgJ2InLCAnYydd,W10=,WydzJywgNSwgJ2EnLCAneCcsIDMsIDAsIDYsICdiJ10=&flags=LVE=) using `-Q` to view the formatted array.

### Explanation

First line is blank to avoid overwriting the input array.
`[5, 'a', 'x', 3, 6, 'b']`

```
c ñc
```

Make a copy by flattening (`c`) the input array, then sort (`ñ`) with strings represented by their char code (`c`). This is stored in `V`.
`[3, 5, 6, 'a', 'b', 'x']`

```
£
```

Then map the input array by the function...

```
¤?Vv :Vo
```

Turn numbers into binary strings (truthy) or strings into `""` (falsy) (`¤`). If truthy, remove from the start of `V` (`v`), otherwise remove from the end (`o`).

Comment: [15 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=CmYg8WMKrrA/VnYgOlZv&input=WzUsICdhJywgJ3gnLCAzLCA2LCAnYidd)

Comment: @Shaggy Nice, that's really clever. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to switch `Vo` and `Vv` around. I'm convinced there has to be a shorter way, without the ternary.

Comment: @Shaggy Oh, whoops. And yeah, just if `o` could remove from the beginning with negative values or something...

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>164</s> <s>162</s> <s>158</s> 142 bytes

edit 1: 2 bytes less after removing a redundant assignment of v.

edit 2: 4 bytes less thanks to TheLethalCoder.

edit 3: 16 bytes less thanks to brilliant hints from Justin Mariner

```
x=>eval("n=v=>typeof(v)=='number';l=x.length;for(i=0;i<l;x[i++]=x[m],x[m]=w){for(v=w=x[j=m=i];++j<l;)n(e=x[j])==n(w)&&e<v==n(w)&&(m=j,v=e)}x")
```

It's my very first time in code-golf, so it can surely be improved... But still, worth a try.

The program performs a variant of selection sort, which only takes into account the values of the same type as the current one (swapping only a number and a number, or a letter and a letter)

Readable form:

```
x=>eval("
    n=v=>typeof(v)=='number';
    l=x.length;
    for(i=0;i<l;x[i++]=x[m],x[m]=w){
        for(v=w=x[j=m=i];++j<l;) 
            n(e=x[j])==n(w) && e<v==n(w) && (m=j,v=e)
    }
    x
")
```

Comment: `for(j=i+1;j<l;j++)` -> `for(j=i++;++j<l;)` and remove the increment in the outer loop.

Comment: Welcome PPCG too!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder if we increment the counters so early, we'll also need to change the lines where i and j are used... But the idea is really smart, I'll think how to make use of it anyway.

Comment: You can increment `j` as I suggested, I didn't see you use `i` further down just change `x[i]=x[m]` too `x[i++]=x[m]`

Comment: Ah, sure... Why didn't I think of ```x[i++]=x[m]```... Thanks!

Comment: Welcome and nice first answer! I suggest checking out the [ES6 Tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37624/69583), as well as the general JS tips linked there. By using `eval` to avoid `return`, moving some assignments and statements around, and moving the `typeof` check to a helper function, I golfed this down to 142 bytes [here](https://goo.gl/C4a2BW).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
OÞḢṪOƑ}?Ɱ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//8LyHOxY93LnK/9jEWvtHG9f9dzvcfnTSw50zNCP//4821VFQT1QHEhVAwlhHwQzITFKP1VGIBvGMdBQMwWyImiQQkayuABICCxvpwFQpxAIA)

Takes input as a flat array (Jelly typically treats strings as char arrays, so `[5, 'a', 'x', 3, 6, 'b'] -> [5, ['a'], ['x'], 3, 6, ['b']]`. The Footer flattens this array for you).

Similar to [PurkkaKoodari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30164/purkkakoodari)['s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138213/66833)

### How it works

```
OÞḢṪOƑ}?Ɱ - Main link. Takes an array A on the left
 Þ        - Sort by:
O         -   Ordinal
            This shuffles the strings to the end,
             sorting both the strings and the numbers
        Ɱ - Over each element E in A:
       ?  -   If statement:
    OƑ}   -     Condition: E is a number?
  Ḣ       -     Then: Pop and yield the first element of A sorted
   Ṫ      -     Else: Pop and yield the last element of A sorted
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
FOÞɓṪ}Ḣ}ẇØa$?€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/N//C8k5Mf7lxV@3DHotqHu9oPz0hUsX/UtOb////RpjoK6onqQKICSBjrKJgBmUnqsQA)

Basically a port of [Rod's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138208/30164).

Answer (score 3):

## q/kdb+, <s>54</s> 53 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x[w,q]:asc[x w:(&)d],desc x q:(&)(~)d:-7=type@/:x;x}
```

**Examples:**

```
q){x[w,q]:asc[x w:(&)d],desc x q:(&)(~)d:-7=type@/:x;x}(5;"a";"x";3;6;"b") / mixed list
3
"x"
"b"
5
6
"a"
q){x[w,q]:asc[x w:(&)d],desc x q:(&)(~)d:-7=type@/:x;x}3 2 1   / simple list
1 2 3
q){x[w,q]:asc[x w:(&)d],desc x q:(&)(~)d:-7=type@/:x;x}"abc"   / simple list
"cba"
q){x[w,q]:asc[x w:(&)d],desc x q:(&)(~)d:-7=type@/:x;x}2 3 2 1 / simple list
1 2 2 3
```

**Explanation:**

Find the chars in the list, sort descending, find the longs in the list, sort them ascending, join to get a list of, e.g. `("x";"b";"a";3;5;6)`, then assign the sorted values back to their original positions in the list, e.g. at `0 3 4 1 2 5`.

Golfing is just switching out q keywords (`each`, `where` and `not`) for their `k` equivalent (which requires them to be wrapped in brackets).

```
{x[w,q]:asc[x w:where d],desc x q:where not d:-7=type each x;x} / ungolfed
{                                                           ; } / lambda function with 2 statements
                                                 type each x    / return types of elements in mixed list
                                              -7=               / true where item is a long
                                            d:                  / save this bool array in d
                                        not                     / invert
                                  where                         / indices where true (we have chars)
                                q:                              / save these indices in q
                              x                                 / values of x at these indices
                         desc                                   / sort them descending
                        ,                                       / join/contatenate
                where d                                         / indices where we have digits
              w:                                                / save this in w
            x                                                   / values of x at these indices
        asc[           ]                                        / sort them ascending
 x[w,q]:                                                        / assign this list to x at indices w,q
                                                             x  / return x
```

**Edits**

- -1 byte as don't need square brackets around `desc`

Answer (score 3):

## [C++17 (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 219 bytes

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <set>
using V=std::variant<char,int>;void f(V*a,V*b){std::set<V>S[2];for(V*c=a;c<b;++c)S[c->index()].insert(*c);auto
C=S->rbegin();auto N=S[1].begin();for(;a<b;++a)*a=(a->index()?*N++:*C++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNa4NAEIbv/oohhcZ1NZCWtuCqPeSei@DFehjXjy6YNegqKeJfr101bVPoHIbdmXee@eDns1NyPk13QvKqy3LwemwEShUYv6E219@uFbKEyG9V5rpXkcffsbGFVrO@FhkUZmShHVkpGRaZLvSiIIwfElbUjU5yHxn3UkYpJ2HMnUDILL@YJNkJ2eaNMi1OGHaqNg5@6ARNmpdCmmsIjn4Y75Pdd2wmMlxgSCz0TfzBvVpHSl3rQClh43Sziahb1eR4ut2uU6IS6iMw9B5wwpkNgwHaIshQYZyADwM82bDFrXYX7R5teNbPdAsjW6SFCetccwWxIZfZ@gSyCpZ78LpT4HmwGWBzrasbMHktWwXRPfTgLi3JkputF61QJsTJVTQfQuuw0jP@ZerYgtZkGG2N@rfx@CZ159GYPnlRYdlOjs77nNL9yxc)

Hardly competitive. But I must support mixed-type arrays? FINE.

Accepts an array of variants in range style, and modifies it in place.  Copies the input into two sorted sets, and then back into the input/output array.

Comment: This is interesting. I wouldn't interpret "supporting mixed-type arrays" in this way. Otherwise, I'd have to use an array of `void *` in C ;) But, yes, interesting to see a solution jumping through such a hoop.

Comment: You can save two bytes by removing the spaces in the `#include`s

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I *knew* there had to be a (golfy) way to do this without any sort of conditional :)

Outputs an array of singleton arrays. Replace `£` with `c@` to output a flat array.

```
£=ñs)jÓXÌ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=oz3xcylq01jM&input=WzUgImEiICJ4IiAzIDYgImIiXQotUQ)

```
£=ñs)jÓXÎ     :Implicit input of array U
£             :Map each X (or flat map with c@)
 =            :  Reassign to U
  ñ           :    Sort by
   s          :      Converting to string if an integer, slicing if a string (which does nothing to the string if given no arguments)
    )         :  End reassignment
     j        :  Remove (mutating the original) and return the element at modular 0-based index
      Ó       :    Bitwise NOT of the negation of (i.e, decrement)
       XÎ     :    Sign of difference of X with -1 if an integer, last character if a string (resulting in 0 if an integer or -1 if a string)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>145</s> <s>139</s> 130 bytes

*6 bytes saved thanks to @officialaimm*

*9 bytes saved thanks to @Chris_Rands*

```py
g=lambda s,a:sorted(x for x in s if(type(x)==str)==a)
def f(s):l,n=g(s,1),g(s,0)[::-1];return[[n,l][type(x)==str].pop()for x in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LDsIgEEXX8hWzKySjsRpdYPBHCAu0RZsgJYAJfn2d1kTd3HncM4/4Kvcx7Kfpprx9XDoLGa3MYyp9xyu4MUGFIUCGwfHyij2vQqlcEqkVrOsdOJ6F9BjUjWdsBc5hK7SU69acUl@eKWgd0Bv9P282cYxc/A6YyYMCzVb6gNDYhqSS7BGOlF4ag2Qt/d1SI7QUrzOyWDNJTvspPgtmihBYeoYZ9j3nJVvFNITCKyHqTKCj18T0Bg)

Comment: [139 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY5NDsIgEIXXcorZFZLRWI0uMHgRwgJtURKkDWCCp6/TmujCzfy89@XNjK9yH@J@mm4q2Mels5DRyjyk0ne8ghsSVPARMngHVimffczFxmvPK@aShGBd78DxLGTAqG48YytwbluhpVy35pT68kxR64jB6L8AsxmHkYvfJTMFUKDZSh8QGttQqVT2CEcaL41BshZ9t@wILfXrjCzWTJLTfpZPwEwRAotmmGHfc0Gy1Zh8LPQONOpMoONViOkN "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: `type(x)==str` would save some bytes over using `isinstance(...)` i think

Comment: @Chris_Rands thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 203 bytes

```
(K=Reverse;B=Complement;L=Length;S=Position[#,_Integer];T=Sort@Cases[#,_Integer];G=K@B[#,T];V=B[Range@L@#,Flatten@S];R=K@Sort@#;Table[R[[Min@S[[i]]]]=T[[i]],{i,L@T}];Table[R[[V[[i]]]]=G[[i]],{i,L@G}];R)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvBasMwDEDv@4rhwOhAl620FyMwKSyMZlAc04sxxSlqakicEZsxKPn21ARGF4FAvPfU2Xh15zBdcFrtUdIPDYF4jru@@26pIx95iSX5Jl55hYc@uOh6rzM4ffpIDQ2GK6z6IYqdDRQWosC9yBNRhh8x19L6hkQpMvhobYzkRWW4TM38nnFl65a01PrLJaW1M2lQzQfcHJRCjeZRHf@K4l9RpEK@vkyHwfn4LC76tgFmGbBfBmvYAqvZaJ4ednZ12vOSr@Ed3hZkNNMd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
KSQm.(Kt>\@
```

**[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KSQm.%28Kt%3Cd%5C%40&input=%5B%275%27%2C+%27a%27%2C+%27x%27%2C+%273%27%2C+%276%27%2C+%27b%27%5D&test_suite_input=%5B%275%27%2C+%27a%27%2C+%27x%27%2C+%273%27%2C+%276%27%2C+%27b%27%5D%0A%5B+%27a%27%2C+%27b%27%2C+%27c%27+%5D%0A%5B%5D&debug=0) or [Try the Test Suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KSQm.%28Kt%3E%5C%40&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%275%27%2C+%27a%27%2C+%27x%27%2C+%273%27%2C+%276%27%2C+%27b%27%5D%0A%5B+%27a%27%2C+%27b%27%2C+%27c%27+%5D%0A%5B%5D&debug=0)**

---

## Explanation

```
KSQm.(Kt<d\@  - Full program with implicit input.

KSQ           - Assign a variable K to the lexicographically sorted input.
   m          - Map over the input (with a variable d).
    .(K       - Pop the sorted list at this location:
       >\@    - If d is lexicographically lower than '@', at 0 (the first element). Else, at -1 (the last element).
```

Comment: Wait, you don't need to order the entire array, just split in two homogeneous arrays which each should be easily sortable. APL cannot sort mixed arrays either (yet), but I sort each type separately.

Comment: @Adám What do you mean by *just split in two homogeneous arrays which each should be easily sortable*?

Comment: As described in the OP's "Workthrough": 1. Make note of which elements are numeric and which are character. 2. Extract all numbers into a separate array and sort that. Do the same for the characters. 3. Put the sorted number back into the number slots. DO the same for the characters.

Comment: @Adám If the OP considers this invalid, I will do exactly what you said (This would result in a much, much longer approach)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>125</strike> <strike>113</strike> 110 bytes

```c
main(i){char*b,*c,s[99];for(gets(c=b=s);*++c||*(c=++b);)i=*b&64,i^*c&64||*c>*b^!i&&(i=*c,*c=*b,*b=i);puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczBCsIwEIThu2/hJWQ38aQWSoigTyGIhe6gdQ9VafRkffa4nobhhw@rAah17PXulT649RNLZMRyattzuj4mP1xexSNLLpQ4BMwz2w1BKJFmFtdsonYMW0vYsXRLdc5bg0n570lWSs@3QYZ8a93uj@vmsPgB)

**Explained:**

```c
main(i)
{
    char*b,*c,s[99];

    // slightly modified stupid bubblesort, this line in fact
    // does nested looping with a single for statement
    for(gets(c=b=s);*++c||*(c=++b);)
    // (undefined behavior here, there's no sequence point between accesses to c,
    // so this could go wrong. Works with the gcc version on tio.)

        // determine whether the current b is a letter:
        i=*b&64,

        // for doing anything, b and c must be the same "type":
        i^*c&64

            // when c > b for letter or c <= b for digit
            || *c>*b^!i

            // then swap
            && (i=*c,*c=*b,*b=i);

    puts(s);
}
```

Letters are expected in uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
SaJ¹á{R¹þ{«vyay.;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/ONHr0M7DC6uDgOS@6kOryyoTK/Ws//9Pqyw1sTDLtLQwBwA)

---

```
SaJ               # Push 1 if letter 0 else, for all letters in string.
   ¹á{R           # Reverse sort letters from input.
       ¹þ{        # Regular sort digits from input.
          «       # Concatenate those two things.
           v      # For each letter in the sorted string...
            ya    # 0 if digit, 1 if letter.
              y.; # Replace first instance of 0/1 with digit/letter.
```

---

Using the sort-by closure actually was worse: `Σ©Ç®ai0<*}}¹SaJsvyay.;`

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 108 bytes

There may be shorter ways, but I just had to try it with the `Lens` library.

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.List
i(!)f=partsOf(traverse.filtered(!'='))%~f.sort
f x=x&i(<)id&i(>)reverse
```

I could define `f` to just be the composition of the two `i` invocations, but I'd still have to apply `x` to it to avoid a type error from the monomorphism restriction. Note that the type of `f` is `Traversable t => t Char -> t Char` so it can be used with `String`s which are lists of `Char`s as well as with arrays of `Char`s.

Here are the test cases:

```
*Main> map f ["5ax36b","321","abc","","2321"]
["3xb56a","123","cba","","1223"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 77 bytes

This answer is based on the comment that says you can use '1', '2', etc if chars and digits are not comparable in the language.  'a' and 1 are not comparable in Python 3.

```
def f(s):x=sorted(s,key=lambda c:ord(c)-95);return[x.pop(-(c>'.'))for c in s]
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 66 bytes:

```php
for($a=$argv,sort($a);a&$c=$argv[++$i];)echo$a[$c<A?++$k:--$argc];
```

takes input from command line arguments, prints a string.
Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0db1a4c24000e852a95ab9e6ad87ec30ce45c924).

Yields a warning in PHP 7.1; replace `a&` with `""<` to fix.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

```apl
a[⍒i][⍋⍋27>i←(⎕a,⌽⍳9)⍳a←⎕]
```

(uses `⎕IO=1`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CYYgFpBWSIx@1DspMxZIdgORkbldJlBUAyiZqPOoZ@@j3s2WmkAiESgIFIv9/1/dUV1HwUhHQd0JSBsCaWcgbQwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 24 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⍜▽(⊏⍏.)¬⊃∘⍜▽(⊏⍖.)⊐∵type.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_1_0__ZiDihpAg4o2c4pa9KOKKj-KNjy4pwqziioPiiJjijZzilr0o4oqP4o2WLiniipDiiLV0eXBlLgoKZiB7NSBAYSBAeCAzIDYgQGJ9CmYgezMgMiAxfQpmIHtAYSBAYiBAY30KZiB7MiAzIDIgMX0K)

```
⍜▽(⊏⍏.)¬⊃∘⍜▽(⊏⍖.)⊐∵type.
                       .  # duplicate
                 ⊐∵type   # mask of types (0 for number, 1 for character)
          ⍜▽(⊏⍖.)         # descending sort the characters
        ⊃∘                # keep the mask
       ¬                  # not
⍜▽(⊏⍏.)                   # ascending sort the numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 26 bytes

```
{x[>i]@<<1>i:x*1 1'`c=@'x}
```

Derived from @ngn's APL solution

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6quiLbLjHWwsTG0y7Sq0DJUMFRPSLZ1UK+o5eJKczDVUUpU0lGqUNIx1jHTUUpSAoqZKBgrmCsYKRgD2UpJiUUgMUUDANktEfw=)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 107 bytes

```
(s=#;s[[p]]=Sort[s[[p=#&@@@s~($=Position)~_String]],#2~Order~#>0&];s[[c]]=Sort@s[[c=#&@@@s~$~_Integer]];s)&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 171 bytes

```cs
a=>{var b=a.Where(x=>x is int).ToList();b.Sort();int i=0,j=0;return a.Select(x=>b.Contains(x)?b[i++]:a.Except(b).OrderByDescending(y=>y).ToList()[j++]);}
```

Byte count also includes:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJNb9swDL37VxC9REI8oR/oDnXlYVvToUCLHVKghyAHSWFWBY6USXLrIPBvz6R4q@ftkPJA0PTjE/lI5T8o63Bfe21@wHTrA67ZV1tVqIK2xrNvaNBpVWQDxL02P4ssM2KNfiMU/s5nuwyiqUp4D58PcZdJ5oMIWsGL1Qt4ENoQ@varByXLBl@3tVHX99qHaytXsasyh7uJqdfohKzwT7KEJfC94OXuRTiQXLCnZ3RIGl42oD1oEyh7tImH0EKyqXUpiGnQ/DRf8dPCYaidAcGmmKZPpTJKYULs1ZOGfpIzPR7PrwSbNAo3gUjKvrsFui/bG/QKzSIKRLa83PYvzVaxghbtvhjMlHrUZlMH4GDwFbohZvPZfAAbypLsbzDs4DKHkRhF10R3kcPHGMoRtPmxwog9z@HsHciOXyan3sN8HHGe988PsG0x3PwyHqZQz@SgVtSrk4wekWhJ9Jv8/SLYrXWTRNYALyFu1dsK2ZPTId4IjOEETigt/iMbAOPRI/kH1E/QRW3W7n8B)

Explanation:

```cs
a =>
{
    var b = a.Where(x => x is int).ToList(); // Filter to only ints and transform to list
    b.Sort();                                // Sort the list
    int i = 0, j = 0;                        // Create index counters
    return a.Select(x =>                     // Replace each input element with
                    b.Contains(x) ?          // If it is in list b:
                    b[i++] :                 // Get the next element from b
                    a.Except(b)              // Otherwise take input and filter out those in b
                     .OrderByDescending(x=>x)// Order them z to a
                     .ToList()[j++]);        // Get the next element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 107 + 1 (-n) = 108 bytes

```perl
y/][//d;@a=split/, /;@l=sort grep/\D/,@a;@d=sort grep/\d/,@a;@r=map{/\d/?pop@d:shift@l}@a;$"=", ";say"[@r]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcmxDsIgFIXhVyHEpAv1tpouEuIdXH0C7IBSlQTLDbA0xlcXMS5OX85/aIp@KGWBUQNYiUYl8i6DYCDRqxRiZrc4EZwOINBItP/N/lpUD0PP79xTILS7dHfXjP5VzxVXXDAuk1m4xjjyUnRjGsE2gjXnal@9VLfjO1B2YU6lPQ7rru9KO38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 265 bytes

```ruby
x.sort_by(&:to_s).select{|a| a.is_a?(String)}.zip(x.map.with_index {|a, i| a.is_a?(String) ? i : nil}.compact).each{|a,i| x[i] = a}
x.sort_by(&:to_s).select{|a| a.is_a?(Integer)}.zip(x.map.with_index {|a, i| a.is_a?(Integer) ? i : nil}.compact).each{|a,i| x[i] = a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc6xCoMwEIDhvU9xOBQFOWi7CeLcuaNIONOgBxolSWls9dnTdOjUxelfvuE3j3YJvqwTmeRwyiGh2EtsG3tugkc7GSfaJT0WbhI2Q6sGJd17pRUI2Qqq0pszrLtswxfPqceRZnyy6wXru/IQaQ78p6EChgI0DxvKaZxJugwVyf7rI/c1N1ACbYddD1ftVKfM3okf330RZvDhAw)

First timer here, My solution is definetly not the best one. But since this is my first answer, I thought in posting just for the fun of it.

Looking foward to see better Ruby answers, to see what is the best approach. I hope I improve in future answers =)

Readable

```ruby
x = ["c", 1, "a", 3, "b", 2]

b = x.map.with_index {|a, i| a.is_a?(Integer) ? i : nil}.compact
s = x.map.with_index {|a, i| a.is_a?(String) ? i : nil}.compact

o = x.sort_by(&:to_s).select{|a| a.is_a?(Integer)}
d = x.sort_by(&:to_s).select{|a| a.is_a?(String)}

d.zip s
d.zip(s).each {|a, i| x[i] = a}

o.zip b
o.zip(b).each {|a, i| x[i] = a }

p x
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 91 bytes

```
def f(s):x=sorted(s,key=lambda c:(type(c)==str,c));return[x.pop(-(type(c)==str))for c in s]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 151 bytes

```
#(map(fn[t c](nth((if(=(type 1)t)vec reverse)(sort((group-by type %)t)))(-(c t)1)))(map type %)(reductions(partial merge-with +)(for[i %]{(type i)1})))
```

Example:

```
(def f #( ... ))
(f [5 \a \x 3 6 \b])
; (3 \x \b 5 6 \a)
```

This calculates the cumulative <s>sum</s> count of integers and characters, and uses it to lookup the correct element from a sorted list of corresponding type's elements.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 43 <s>55</s> <s>70</s> <s>95</s> bytes

```
b=(${(n)@});for i;echo $b[$[#i>64?--k:++j]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvBCoMwGIPvPkXQHiyiTJ0eJtt8DxG0YtWNrcNWGHN99u6HXZJ8Cfno2cmQ795E4sQ5ZHv45LXllVQrlmocZgUmGtYEy6U8XuP4foqiW9s6W01g9XfVFkGSJN2qO9Dn0RsNM49Qm3ltxvMkemQQSDEgx4G4oOZNuYQgymlNyX2fJPuj@wE)
  <sub><s>[55bytes](https://tio.run/##NYvbCoMwGIPvfYqgIi2iTN28KRu@xxC04mljc7QVxqzP3v0wdpPkS8hHT25gfPNGEifPLNzYk1c7F8OiMAvGgvlSHjmPor6bFoTymiT32to/xfGtdrsYEVZW6R1BmqaN0g3o/2iNhpl6LKt5rcbzBrTIIZGhQ4ED8YmaN@USkqigNSP3fZL8h@4L)</s></sub>
  <sub><s>[70bytes](https://tio.run/##RYzdCoJAFITvfYpBRXaRLLW8kcL3EEFX/I0y3JVC3WffDnTRzcz5Zg6zyt60jG9WR2LElbkbe/JM87SdZgwpY85wS86ce15T9xNckfv@3aevN3eyY14d1kIX@/4vx8LotIOb7bPUcIIgKGdZguYelZJQfYNpUa9FWVaLChEEQtSIcSK@UPKhO4EgiqkNyW2bJPqh@QI)</s></sub>
  <sub><s>[95bytes](https://tio.run/##RYvLCoMwEEX3@YrBBkkIEh@t0Jq2/kfIIla0KrSgm2Kab08HsuhiZu45w923ZxgYdyNOsFdGHXvxVuo8OxvPof8bm@1oyPBeYWoYO0y3@ngXYrkIMXOepkop6qibYlfSXs/Gx5qkVi/GB9@MQNvvunlCBrBQQgcFPKCCHPmE5oO5hg6pwm@BN0lwlRHDDw)</s></sub>

Create a sorted array `b`, numbers first. Iterate over the arguments. If `i` is a letter (>ascii #64) then decrement `k` and print `b[k]`, (e.g. `b[-2]` is the 2nd to last value). If `i` is a number, increment `j` and print `b[j]`.

<sub>NB: Previously I forgot to **decrease** letters. Fixed now, and saved bytes!</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 290 bytes

```go
import."sort"
func f(I[]any){J,K:=StringSlice{},IntSlice{}
var L,M[]int
for i,e:=range I{switch e:=e.(type){case string:J,L=append(J,e),append(L,i)
case int:K,M=append(K,e),append(M,i)}}
Sort(Reverse(J))
Sort(K)
x:=len(L)
for i:=0;i<x+len(M);i++{if i<x{I[L[i]]=J[i]}else{I[M[i-x]]=K[i-x]}}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVBLTsMwEBVbn8LyKlbdihaBUEoOkJ-E6DKKkAlOa5G6UeKWVpZPwqZC4hCIk8BpGMctYmG_mec345n39r7cHD9bXr3wpcBrLhWS63bT6Qmp15p8bHU9vv25IGeyh5ugeqsqXAdxUXJ1oCZhaRgtdCfVctHIShjLYqVPIdrxDmcsL0qpNKo3HZZMhFHHFXwYm_5V6mqFgRGTQB9aQU3Fe4H7oV2YsCzibSvUc5AwQdkpzpikaNBB0zBl-VmU_hPlILIWLWDk4EHsRNeLIKHUEylF-zBqhAoy6qcKo8u5vNuPHJfTuRyNjKwxMCYuskKWZZTAbUXTC2DyQo73wKUDWmu9Vd9fgzfOyIBig_QKtuhxGOGiHNwyhnDC8Ixh8gQ4BawAryzD5hoS90j2jmH4ZhBZZlwCFVMn8gpXC4WOcGfG_iR22OaRSfepd9kPYZBUwyQS1QGEFN2DxbpRPrHotMLx6PEX)

#### Explanation

```go
import."sort"                 // boilerplate
func f(I[]any){               // boilerplate
J,K:=StringSlice{},IntSlice{} // J and K store the actual elements
var L,M[]int                  // L and M store their indexes
for i,e:=range I{             // for each element,
switch e:=e.(type){           // switch on their type
case string:J,L=append(J,e),append(L,i) // put strings in J/L
case int:K,M=append(K,e),append(M,i)}}  // put ints in K/M
Sort(Reverse(J))              // sort J reversed (descending)
Sort(K)                       // sort K normally (ascending)
x:=len(L)                     //
for i:=0;i<x+len(M);i++{      // combined loop
if i<x{I[L[i]]=J[i]}          // put the strings back in
else{I[M[i-x]]=K[i-x]}}}      // put the ints back in
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⍜⊕□⊐∵(⊏⍖⍣¬⟜∘.)⊐∵type.
```

[Try it!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAg4o2lKC3iiLZAMOKNnOKWvSjiio_ijZYuKeKKkOKItXR5cGUuKTIKZiDihpAg4o2c4oqV4pah4oqQ4oi1KOKKj-KNluKNo8Ks4p-c4oiYLiniipDiiLV0eXBlLgoKZiB7NSBAYSBAeCAzIDYgQGJ9CmYgezMgMiAxfQpmIHtAYSBAYiBAY30KZiB7MiAzIDIgMX0K)

Takes an array of boxes, where each box contains either a single number or character.

```
⍜⊕□⊐∵(⊏⍖⍣¬⟜∘.)⊐∵type.
                   ⊐∵type    type of each element; 0 if number, 1 if character
⍜⊕□⊐∵(         )        .   operate on each group...
            ⍣¬⟜∘              for numbers, negate; for characters, identity
         ⊏⍖     .             sort descending by the above
```

A fun 22 bytes:

```
⍥(-∶@0⍜▽(⊏⍖.)⊐∵type.)2
⍥(                      )2    do this twice...
                ⊐∵type        type of each element
       ⍜▽(   )        .      keep characters, operate on it, and put it back
                               to the original array:
            ⊏⍖.                 sort descending
  -∶@0                         replace each element with '0' minus that;
                               this changes characters to numbers and vice versa
                               and reverses the sorting order
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
{Ivydićˆë¤ˆ¨]¯
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9vc2FiaWX//3tJdnlkacSHy4bDq8Kky4bCqF3Cr///WzUsImEiLCJ4IiwzLDYsImIiXQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXS/@rKssqUzCPtp9sOrz605HTboRWxh9b/V9IL0zm05X90tFKiko6RjlKSko6hjlKyko5xrE60qQ5IVKkCyNMxA8kBxYyBqgyBNFgGqBqoFsgDIiMdiFQsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
{         # Sort the (implicit) input-list, which will put all sorted digits at the
          # front, and all sorted letters at the end
 I        # Push the input-list again
  v       # For-each over its items `y`:
   ydi    #  If the current character `y` is a digit:
      ć   #   Extract the head of the sorted-list; pop and push remainder-list and first
          #   item separated to the stack
       ˆ  #   Pop and add this first item to the global array
     ë    #  Else (it's a letter instead):
      ¤   #   Get the last item of the sorted list (without popping the list itself)
       ˆ  #   Pop and add this last item to the global array
        ¨ #   And then remove this last item from the list
  ]       # Close both the if-else statement and loop
   ¯      # And push the global array
          # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```