# Numbers Decrease while Letters Increase

Tags: code-golf, integer, alphabet

*Randomly inspired by [Numbers Increase While Letters Decrease](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/138200/42963)*

Given a list of mixed letters and integers (e.g., `['a', 2, 3, 'b']`) *increase* the letters by one position in the alphabet (wrapping at `z` to `a`) and *decrease* the numbers by 1. For the above example, the output should be `['b', 1, 2, 'c']`.

- The input can be a mixed-type list, a delimited string, a list of strings, etc.
- `z` wraps to `a`, but `1` goes to `0`, and `0` goes to `-1`, etc.
- The input will only ever be `[a-z]` and integers. You can choose capital letters `[A-Z]` as input if that's easier for you.
- The input is guaranteed non-empty.
- The input may contain only numbers or only letters.

Examples:

```
Input
Output

['a', 2, 3, 'b']
['b', 1, 2, 'c']

['a', 'b', 'z']
['b', 'c', 'a']

[-1, 0, 257, 'x']
[-2, -1, 256, 'y']

[0, 3, 1, 20382876]
[-1, 2, 0, 20382875]
```

#### Rules and Clarifications

- Input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print the result to STDOUT or return it as a function result.
- The output doesn't have to be the same format as the input (e.g., you could take input as a string and output as a list).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- If applicable, you can assume the input/output integers fit in your language's native `int` range.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: If the number is equal to Integer.MinValue or whatever the lowest value of a signed integer is in my language, should I underflow to Integer.maxValue or should I continue counting down?

Comment: @Nzall Undefined behavior. The 5th bullet point under Rules and Clarifications specifies that both input and output integers fit in your languages native `int` range, so you'd never get `Integer.MinValue` as an input.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
<AAÀ‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxtHxcMOjhoX//0crVSnpKBjqKBjpKCglK8UCAA)

```
<          # decrement the numbers
 A         # constant "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  AÀ       # same, but rotated left ("bcd...yza")
    ‡      # transliterate
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda a:[i-1if''!=i*0else chr(97+(ord(i)+8)%26)for i in a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LCoMwEEX3fsUUKZNUBY34aMEvSV3EFwasinVR@/PpqHXhLMIw595DxmVuhz40TfY0nXoVlQL1kNoLdIN4yfTNr7t3DWU7sXvisGGqmOZOyq8i5s0wgQbdg8rNOOl@Zg2TqNAF4ULoAhaYcw40tqTdhWAjWGJuWefChvF75I8CRelRp7xHFp9EUULo82/Y0iPzikQU0305VfztOyv0w1SkSbyW7M0kdtl@j3LzAw)

*-1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer*

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY7LDoMgEEX3fsUkpgEqJojx0ab9EsoCa4wkLRrjovbn6aB1IQuYzLn3hHGZ@8Hlvrs//Mu8m9aAuSpxs2dhXAvPfqKXKqHD1FLLkpqdZMmGCWyadeEB68BoP07WzbSjihjCQXLIOZCGaMYAT6xw5pCthDyJjqJjYcXku@f3AkbxMod8ihaBoqJC9Pk3YpWiOSBZlLhfDhWxfidAkdeyrspQileT3GTbvtD@Bw).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer integer vs string comparison does not seem to be working in your solution.

Comment: Oh right, you need Python 2 for that.

Comment: Ah yes, then it seems to work. Still the replacement of `-96` with `+8` saves a byte.

Comment: `''!=i*0` is three bytes shorter than my `str(i)>'9'`, good job

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (-p), 17 bytes

```perl
y/a-z/b-za/or$_--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79SP1G3Sj9JtypRP79IJV5X9///Ki4TIy5dI67kf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA)

Bonus 19-byter:

```perl
$_>$_++?$_-=2:s/a//
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3k4lXlvbXiVe19bIqlg/UV////8qLhMjLl0jruR/@QUlmfl5xf91C3IA). This one features some cool tricks, but fails to beat the straightforward solution above.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

For each element, attempt to return the element -1. Strings cannot do this, so they error out and are picked up by the `rescue` clause, which instead calls `succ` on it to return the next letter in the alphabet. `succ` "rolls over" on `z` and returns `aa` though, so we simply take the first character in the returned string.

```ruby
->a{a.map{|e|e-1rescue e.succ[0]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcWxCoAgEADQX7nNRaXItX5EHE45WwpEMyj1282W92K2T/drFxsWlCeGUqmSmCMllwlIpuycnkxrPYDXdOMBO13JdM2QcWD25x2ImcM0UhwWZT4)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 55 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(s=>1/s?s-1:B([(B(s)[0]+8)%26+97])+'',B=Buffer)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc5LDoIwEAbgvafoxkwbChQID03AhGuQLipSo0EgVI16eRzwtcBZNJn8803nqK7KlP2hO9tNu6sGnQ4qzZRzUh01aea5ZmNsb53TgubUsEJIK2FLP7JWsWQWAM/T/KJ11bOhbBvT1pVTt3uqaQEKOPE5CTiBLUjGCJbrkgI7TrwpgxLk4p@bZuDxYT@HAh81ZzZuFLg0jDG/veHIbPxnDP0wwuQ@l2K6cZwQQeIncTTaSb6OFN8klMMT)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>182</strike> <strike>130</strike> 118 bytes

*-51 bytes thanks to @AdmBorkBork and @Black Owl Kai, -1 byte thanks to @Black Owl Kai, -12 bytes by replacing `.append()` with `+=[]` and replacing `n+1` with `-~n`*

```python
def a(x):
 b='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';c=[]
 for d in x:
  try:c+=[d-1]
  except:c+=[b[(-~b.find(d)%26)]]
 return c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcw7DoMwEATQnlNsE9lWIOKjACLiJIgC2xCcjyGOSQxFrk5WdDRbzJvZcbb9oJN1lW0HDXWs8ICXpOECg2uvbvfHUw/jy7zt9Pm6eSEXUVa1B91gQILS4HAB1syFOJaVDCI0aJ1oR7slvKLBj586pSWV7BCnrMaGae1kNIh1NEpb2tCKNMSH2IfEB8JJzZi3JwzxLHsJIh9CnJ0zNLe3cPuFhThM8jjPUtT1Dw)

I made this while the question was in the Sandbox but didn't see it posted until just now. :P

### Ungolfed

```python
def a(x):
    b = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    c = []
    for d in x:
        try:
            c.append(d - 1)
        except:
            c.append(b[((b.find(d) + 1) % 26)])
    return c
```

### Explanation

For each element in the inputted list `x`, it tries to subtract 1 and add it to the eventual returned list. If an error occurs (because the element is a string), the letter's index in the alphabet is added by 1 and that mod 26 is taken. The mod 26 wraps an index of 26 back to 0.

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf SE! I'm not an expert at Python, but I think you can swap 4 spaces for tabs to save a bunch of bytes.

Comment: I got it to [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYzNDoIwEAbvPMVeTNsIBkoEovFJCIe2FMWfUmvVwsvj6sVw2cPMfGtHfxpMPs@t7kDQwHYRyAMRUiE4nvrz5Xozg727h3@@3mGcyF4d6iaCbnDQQm8g4AK8G3dqI6zVpqVtkjFkOiht/R/LmlK56fpvwda8ZCtesAZLp/3TGVCzdb3xVNCaCBIDjyGPgUjSMBYtFUI809IkWQwpzrYlurB06e8XBjzNK16VBdr5Aw) just by eliminating whitespace. One further byte can be golfed by realizing that `(x+27)%26` has the same result as `(x+1)%26`

Comment: @AdmBorkBork BlackOwlKai Thank you for the help! I've edited the post.

Comment: You can use a ternary with `str(d)==d` to check if it's a string or not, instead of relying on try/except. Then, since you no longer need try/except, you can do the whole thing in a list comprehension! I'll let you think about it a little more but you can easily get under 100 bytes this way ;)

Comment: [89 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcxBDoIwEAXQvaeYjSkkxUCJQEx6EmTRWipFKFiqFhZevTbu2Ewy/82febXdpHPP6NUPbOSCgcOcIsZvopX3TvWPYdTT/DSLfb0/bt3QpeZ18uUnqbSIRHwkRaMkCEoXa8LeDksLIsnkZECA0uAaPxulbcSiGjGEgWDIMSCOmjg@7CmEYWx7STIMaaidy2Bub@n/VzggaV6RqiyC@h8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Oh, Jitse's solution is basically the same idea but better :( well, it's up to you whether to use something like this

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 30 bytes

```
<: ::((26|>:)&.(_97+a.i.]))&.>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY67CsJAEEX7fMXFwklws2wm5OGOplCwEgtbWUIUg9rYqvjv6wpGxGKKczhc5uJHmnrMLQgKBjZcqrHcrld@ZmFtHHP5bGwy1nE7rSadPmuXBGp8Eh0Ppyt6UEdCe/pFlvxfBRR6fFWbiREuKqEbYbPQ2KWskGYKXJQKdCc3pCaMZQI2ec11VX7qdxk@VoMvXORf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#transliterate-t-and-y), <s>52</s> <s>50</s> <s>48</s> <s>58</s> <s>41</s> 37 bytes

```
T`zl`l
\b0
-
\d+
*
-_*
-$.0
_(_*)
$.1
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@FryAmTheEggman* (and for mentioning I had a bug: `1 → -1` instead of `1 → 0`).
+10 bytes to fix a bug with `1` and `0`.. Such an annoying edge case which screwed me over for quite a while.. But golfed it to 41 bytes now. (Now I'm curious about the <40 bytes versions *@Neil* and *@CowsQuack* mentioned in the comments.. Thanks *@Neil* for the tip of converting the `0` to `-`, and dealing with the negative values first. Converting those right back from unary to integer helped a lot.)
Apparently I don't need the boundaries at this point, so -4 bytes.. >.>

I/O is comma-separated.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Fck7CoUwFEXR/oxDwc@J3Bt56AycgKWQD1oIYiGvkEw@arF3s67tv59Bc1lNPs8@Hf7AEgUGy9qigXFvRSdwlWtqFJ3mHGjZMyIwMsEohfY38GZioEJeVFrpRwo@VPn2AA)

**Explanation:**

Transliterate all `"zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy(z)"` to `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`:

```
T`zl`l
```

Replace all standalone `0`s with a `-`:

```
\b0
-
```

Convert all numbers to unary, by replacing them with that amount of underscores:

```
\d+
*
```

For all negative values, with zero or more unary-lines behind it: keep the minus sign, and get the total length of this match (including the `-`), converted back to an integer:

```
-_*
-$.0
```

As for the positive integers: match a positive integer by matching a single unary-line, followed by zero or more unary-lines. And then replace them with the length of that capture group to remove that single unary-line and convert them back to integers simultaneously:

```
_(_*)
$.1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 55 characters

```
<N>=@sub{$1;1}
z=a
<L>=@int-char{@add{@char-int{$1};1}}
```

Dirty solution. Wrapping around on letter increment is painfully long, so got a separate rule.

Input can be quite anything, just use some separators. (You can even omit separators between numbers and letters. With the price of 1 character for changing to `<L1>` you could omit separators between letters too.)

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema '<N>=@sub{$1;1};z=a;<L>=@int-char{@add{@char-int{$1};1}}' <<< "['a', 2, 3, 'b']"
['b', 1, 2, 'c']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/38bPztahuDSpWsXQ2rCWq8o2kcvGByiUmVeim5yRWFTtkJiSUu0AYuoCxYDKaoHqav//j1ZPVNdRMNJRMNZRUE9Sj@WCCACZQKIKxNc11FEwACoxNQeKVIBEDMCqgcJGBsYWRhbmZrEA)

#### Gema, 66 characters

```
<N>=@sub{$1;1}
<L>=@cmpi{$1;z;@int-char{@add{@char-int{$1};1}};a;}
```

Clean solution. Half relatively efficient, then half pure pain.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema '<N>=@sub{$1;1};<L>=@cmpi{$1;z;@int-char{@add{@char-int{$1};1}};a;}' <<< "['a', 2, 3, 'b']"
['b', 1, 2, 'c']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/38bPztahuDSpWsXQ2rCWy8YHyE3OLcgE8ausHTLzSnSTMxKLqh0SU1KqHUBMXaAYULYWqLzWOtG69v//aPVEdR0FIx0FYx0F9ST1WC6IAJAJJKpAfF1DHQUDoBJTc6BIBUjEAKwaKGxkYGxhZGFuFgsA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 77 <s>85</s> bytes

Thanks @Giuseppe for a whooping 8 bytes

```r
function(l)Map(function(x)"if"(i<-match(x,L<-c(letters,"a"),0),L[i+1],x-1),l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsIwFET3niJkk//xB5IUbRf1BvUE4iKGBgOxShshePkYXEg2A/MeM2vxp@Lfi0vhuUDEs33Bv2bkwXMIo3zY5O6QaRqlgzinNK8bccuRFNJ0CXt9pSw1UsTiIYYtgbCCmCHWERM3gbhreSU1Pg2Wmpiqg0NfRW6E@l1Ua1Q3mKE/IpYv)

Takes the input as a list.  After a big change by @Giuseppe, this makes use of `Map` to apply a function to the list. It makes use of `match` to test for a character.  During the test the extended letter list and index are saved for the return.

Comment: I suppose `character`s aren't finite because they are cast to `numeric` by `is.finite` and are thus `NA`?

Comment: @Giuseppe thought it would be something along those lines.  Even though it's the same bytes as is.double I needed to use it :)

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsIwFET3niJkk//xB5IUbRf1BvUE4iKGBgOxShshePkYXEg2A/MeM2vxp@Lfi0vhuUDEs33Bv2bkwXMIo3zY5O6QaRqlgzinNK8bccuRFNJ0CXt9pSw1UsTiIYYtgbCCmCHWERM3gbhreSU1Pg2Wmpiqg0NfRW6E@l1Ua1Q3mKE/IpYv)?

Comment: sorry to get rid of your `is.finite`, I thought I'd take a crack at it myself

Comment: @Giuseppe very nice,  Wouldn't have thought of `Map` and `match`.  It's good to learn something each day :)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 14 bytes

```
▄\╧¿ò'z=¿Å'a)(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtJaYR1OXH9p/eJN6lS2QalVP1NT4/189UZ3LkAtE6gKpMnUu9Sp1AA)

Takes letter as lowercase.

### Explanation

```
▄\╧              Is the element in the lowercase alphabet?
   ¿ò            If so:
     'z=           Is it equal to z?
        ¿Å         If so:
          'a         Push 'a'
            )      Else: Increment the string
             (   Else: Decrement the number
```

Answer (score 1):

## dzaima/APL, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```apl
{0::⍵-1⋄⎕l(⍳⊇1⌽⊣)⍵}¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/qG@qp/@jtgkGXGlAUuN/tYGV1aPerbqGj7pbgHI5Go96Nz/qajd81LP3UddiTaBU7aEV/zW5gHIKQA0KaQrqieoK6knqCkYKxgrqVepIMofWGyoYKBiZmiuoV6j/BwA)

-1 thanks to ngn.

Comment: `(⎕l⍳⍵)⊇1⌽⎕l` -> `⎕l(⍳⊇1⌽⊣)⍵`

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 50 bytes

```php
for(;''<$a=$argv[++$i];)echo$a<a?--$a:(++$a)[0],_;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKzV1W1UEm1VEovSy6K1tVUyY601U5Mz8lUSbRLtdXVVEq00gKKJmtEGsTrx1v///0/8n/S/6r/Bf8P/Rv@NAQ)

[Tests](https://tio.run/##LU3tCoMwDPzfpyij0IoKzrEPVsUH6Ypko7ODTaXq2Ad7dpeqgQvJ3SXX2nbMita2hLDedH1Hc6qI4sAjniI2iDPX0UKdEZ95jdc4J9623WN/zWyy3HgxTTaH9LDfeUVLQq6NM3CxVCxJ0NFpCuiXUCwGrnpiPjgH7/JhXGWEqof7XUeLUY74Q0jOMwb5ZFdhyG5aBuZiGwYZFHHM4CiQhUAlOirl6F97ma5O9UpOSUPdmV6wWyDJb/wD)

Outputs letters/integers separated by `_` with a trailing separator.

In PHP you can increment letters directly, so I took advantage of it. But the `z` is incremented to `aa`, to convert it to `a`, the `(++$a)[0]` is used which only outputs the first character of the incremented value.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

-1 byte thanks to Shaggy

```
;¤?UÉ:Cg8+Uc
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=O6Q/Vck6Q2c4K1Vj&input=Wy0xLCAwLCAyNTcsICJ6Il0)

### Explanation:

```
;o ?UÉ:Cg8+Uc
-m              // Map U through the input:
 o              // Try to create a range [1...U]
   ?            //   If that creates a range (number):
    UÉ          //     Return U-1
      :         //   Else, return:
;      C        //     alphabet (a...z)
        g       //     Index:
         8+Uc   //       8 + char-code of U
```

**Note**: `;` turns `C` into the lowercase alphabet

Comment: It doesn't look like this wraps from `z` to `a`.

Comment: @Shaggy Whoops, I missed that. I added a temporary fix for +2 bytes

Comment: Couldn't figure out a way to fix mine (yet) without a ternary, which makes it too similar to yours for my liking so I'm deleting for now. `o` -> `¤` will save you a byte here.

Comment: @Shaggy Ah! I tested `¤` earlier but noticed that it turned `0` into `0` which I assumed would fail the ternary-test...turns out it returns `"0"`! Thanks for spotting that

Comment: `+2` and then `-1` thanks to Shaggy would be more accurate! :D

Comment: @Shaggy The `+2` was thanks to Oliver :P

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 103 bytes

```
	U =&UCASE 'A'
N	X =INPUT	:F(END)
	U X @P	:F(D)
	U POS(P) LEN(1) . OUTPUT	:(N)
D	OUTPUT =X - 1	:(N)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNUwVYt1Nkx2FVB3VGdy48zQsHW0y8gNITTyk3D1c9FkwuoIkLBIQDEh/AC/IM1AjQVfFz9NAw1FfQU/ENDwOo1/DS5XDghPAXbCAVdBUOIINCY//8duQy5DLicuKIA)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```
map q
q"z"="a"
q x|x>"`"=succ<$>x|1<2=show$read x-1
```

As Haskell doesn't allow lists of mixed types, letters and numbers are taken and returned as strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBDoIwEEDRPaeYTLq0iSUxbhguoiZMKhVixZZqGAlnt9rN@6s/cLr33mdH5/zgALGKuCIhYxVBNmmxQ0pvaxvVymaamtLwXNTc8xVEm/8zTkAQ5nF6gQIHcEJtcAe4L9SHY4kUPoUVL/lrnedbytqG8AM)

Check for every list element: if the string is `"z"`, return `"a"`; if the first character of the string is > `` '`' `` (i.e. a letter, not a digit), return the successor of the char(s) in the string; else it must be number, so convert to an integer, subtract 1 and turn into a string again.

Edit: -1 byte thanks to @cole.

Comment: [Does this work](https://tio.run/##FctBDoIwEEDRPaeYTLq0idUYNwwXURInlQqxYksljoSzW@3m/dXvOd0777Ojc35wgFhFXJCQsYogqzR4QUqztbVqZDX1nlL/fKup4yuINv9nGIEgTMP4AgUO4ITa4AZwW9gdjiVS@BQWbPPXOs@3lLUN4Qc) for 51 bytes?

Comment: @cole: yes it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
®i‘ị®µ’e?€Øa©
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9qZWxsef//wq5p4oCY4buLwq7CteKAmWU/4oKsw5hhwqn/4bqOw4fFkuG5mP//WydhJywgMiwgMywgJ2InXQ)

Clever fix by [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Note: This is not a full program, the footer over TIO makes it possible to input using a command-line argument to test the function.

Comment: Wont work with negatives in the input (or over chr range). `®i‘ị®µ’e?€Øa©` is a fix for zero I believe.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Hah, I forgot that `Ọ` doesn't exactly work in that case. Ironic, since I avoided using `~` as the condition to account for `-1`s in the input... Also, how am I going to shorten `®i‘ị®`...

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 27 bytes

```
{$[9+@x;`c$97+26!8+x;x-1]}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWiXaUtuhwjohWcXSXNvITNFCu8K6Qtcwtlb9f5qGUqKStZGxtVKVkuZ/AA)

-8 thanks to ngn and dzaima :)

Comment: 31 bytes `{$[-9=@x;x-1;90=x;"A";\`c$1+x]}'` inlining the special-case & using uppercase (and the `'` has to be counted as the input should be a list)

Comment: @scrawl i think dzaima is right - the `'` should be counted. here's a slightly longer expression that doesn't need `'` and also takes care of "z"->"a": `{\`c\`i[t]$(-26*x~'"z")+x+1-2*t:x~'0+x}`

Comment: or even better - make a list of projections and apply them with `@'`: `{(\`c$97+26!-96+;-1+)[x~'0+x]@'x}`. here `-96` (which is +1 minus the ascii code of "a") can be replaced with `8` as it's taken mod 26.

Comment: another -1 byte by opting for capital letters: `{(\`c$65+26!14+;-1+)[x=_x]@'x}`

Comment: @dzaima yours can be shortened through `-9=@x` -> `x=_x`

Comment: 27 bytes, combining ideas from both and using lowercase input: `{$[9+@x;\`c$97+26!8+x;x-1]}'` (sorry for the spam)

Comment: been meaning to update this for the longest time. thank you to you both :)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++17 (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 120 bytes

```cpp
#define O int operator()
struct V{O(char&c){c++-90?:c=65;}O(int&i){--i;}};int f(auto&l){for(auto&x:l)std::visit(V{},x);}
```

Here `f` is the required function; `l` is both the input and output parameter, and it is expected to be a container of objects which are compatible with `std::variant<char, int>` or vice versa.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJda4MwFIbv/RWHFvygCralH1Pr2KB3g@6qjLEbSbUL2CgxlkLIX193Eru11DEvNDkf73nPg6Sugz0h5yFlpGx3OSTHjNOMifQ83OUFZTlsgDIBVZ3zTFTc9axG8JYI2MqNSz4zbhNPktEoeAgfI7Kaz2K1cbHDpp4MAhorFev@ws1aUdmlJwsUMedTVHqN2EXRkTZUuFup/JMXqxsvJW1Eal3vtMLZeXZIrbahbA/rVdffWU60Gx@HpbF1rOgOao6XF9RwScUaAaZYaybr1IbSA2kBPiZMqlZAksBAwiC@hM2ar1pkqx1WHCQY4SsMQwAISt3JOAP9IZdzDKrXqanQXiPVpapzgKSgQwUniIxhuAF26wzZAcK7M@GDnvzHkgp3VB0kkSOfWzJXMFd@ZU8aglSLFyb1T6HzwRw9S297yChzf8TNXAnOk@PDxIepD86zA8qLe1mM4@u9lwzGPoTYPFtg@q2XDo0o1kzC6XKyXMx/C3guWs4gRF/nL1KU2b45B@h6hb/xePEN)

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 36 bytes

```
\$ka'~?*3({':+1\
R';$ >i::0Sqn=?/1-$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z9GJTtRvc5ey1ijWt1K2zCGK0jdWkXBLtPKyiC4MM/WXt9QV@X//0QFIwVjhSoA)

General process is to read input, prepend with a 0 (coercion to string), convert back to a number (single char will always return -1), compare with input. If same, it must be a numerical value, subtract 1 and print. If not same, it must be a char, subtract 1, compare with `{`. If less than, print, otherwise replace it with `a` and print.

Repeat until program performs a stack underflow.

Output is separated by `;` in order to [save 1 byte](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z9GJTtRvc5ey1ijWt1K2zDGmitIXUFFwS7TysoguDDP1l7fUFfl//9EBSMFY4UqAA) (and has a trailing one). Input is space-separated.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
àºÇ╝'♫d▬♣ΩÜEƒ6╩╬ó
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=85a780bc270e641605ea9a459f36cacea2&i=[%27a%27,+2,+3,+%27b%27]%0A[%27a%27,+%27b%27,+%27z%27]%0A[-1,+0,+257,+%27x%27]%0A[0,+3,+1,+20382876]&a=1&m=2)

This feels like it should be possible to do shorter, but I can't resist the opportunity to use a new stax feature from the last release.

Treating the entire input as a string:

1. Regex replace runs of digits with `eval(match) - 1`.  This is the new feature, as the regex block replacement is not a string, but an integer.
2. Regex replace runs of letters by ring-translating them around the lower-case alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 66 bytes

```
lambda X:[x-1if type(x)==int else chr(97+(ord(x)+8)%26)for x in X]
```

Edit:

I didn't see the solution of Jitse until now. The trick of if''!=i*0 is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>93</s> 86 bytes

```c
f(int**s){for(char**p=s,*z;z=*p++;)64&*z?*z=*z-'z'?++*z:97:sprintf(z,"%d",atoi(z)-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDJboMwFEXX9ldYjtJ4gBY6qnFofiBi1xVlgRiCpdYgDFLriG@ndk277OroXb1731CG57JcloZINTKm6aXpBlK2xcBYn@iAGWES1nMu6OP9FTNHZksT7szuyDkz@@enve4H622ICfC2wkExdpIYGsZUzMtGqvJ9qmp00GNV1c11@wKh7UYfhVSEogsEbhYaW6nOOsuzOMpR4mSAH3Dg8Olx5/HlEd96Rh4GQzALuLETpKpRioiWpu4a4nMpukGrwFaFroOZVP006izlcS4gsMcj9wkk7RaRsDig1IJzawBrr3QrrhtL5/rNcHr6ejq5IOJF@n/oz6Xr//BWvykc/AU76wzBUI/ToKwPzss3)

The input is a `NULL`-terminated array of `'\0'`-terminated strings, e.g. `{"a", "b", "c", "17", NULL}`.

-7 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 148 bytes

```
(object[] o)=>{var l=new List<object>();foreach(var h in o){try{l.Add((int)h-1);}catch{var c=((char)h+1);if(c>122){c=97;}l.Add((char)c);}}return l;}
```

[Repl.it link](https://repl.it/repls/AshamedLightyellowCompilers)

Ungolfed:

```
var inputList = new object[] {'a', 2, 'z', 6};
var outputList = new List<object>();
foreach (var currentItem in inputList)
{
    try
    {
        outputList.Add((int)currentItem-1);
    }
    catch
    {
        var currentItemPlusOne = ((char)currentItem + 1);
        if (currentItemPlusOne > 122)
        {
            currentItemPlusOne = 97;
        }
        outputList.Add((char)currentItemPlusOne);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＷＳ⟦⎇№βι§β⊕⌕βιＩ⊖ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYoxC8IwEEb3@xUZL9CCdXWSipBN0E0cYnLYQLyWeG2tfz6mOLh973vPdTa53sac5y5EUmh4GOUsKfADtVanMgSvF0ps04JtPxa8VyroSu3FsKf3ioZdoiexkMdjYP9LdIla@xI80F@v903vcq4bWGADH2jAwhZyPcUv) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input on STDIN, each line being either a single lowercase letter or an integer, and outputs on separate lines on STDOUT. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ
```

Repeatedly input from STDIN until an empty line is reached.

```
⟦
```

Make this expression output on its own line.

```
⎇№βι
```

Is this a substring of the predefined lowercase alphabet?

```
§β⊕⌕βι
```

If so then print the next letter cyclically indexed.

```
Ｉ⊖ι
```

Otherwise decrement the value and cast back to string for implicit print.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 47 bytes

```sh
a=({a..z} a)
for i
<<<${a[$a[(i)$i]+1]:-$[--i]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKgq6uga6hgoGCokKhQqVD1P9FWozpRT6@qViFRkystv0ghk8vGxkalOjFaJTFaI1NTJTNW2zDWSlclWlc3M7b2/38A)

```sh
a=({a..z} a)                  # append extra 'a' to the end to handle 'z' case
for i                         # for i in "$@" arguments
<<<${a[$a[(i)$i]+1]:-$[--i]}
       $a[(i)$i]              # first (i)ndex of $i in list (if not found, set to after last index)
      [         +1]           # increment
   ${a[           ]        }  # value in array at index. if lookup fails, empty string
   ${              :-$[--i]}  # if empty, decrement $i and substitute instead
<<<                           # print to stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 31 bytes

```perl6
*>>.&{(try $_-1)||chr ord ++$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY29DoIwFEZ3nuIOhCqUppTws0ji4ObsQhqDCNEExRQHq/js9dImLt9w7jm5j04NublpCHrYgAmrigWf1VNp8I9xsp7n9qJgVGeIIv/4NVOjge0O2z1Dvx8VDNd7N9WcpoyxUJqaNISCoJBSICcivRqXQmIZaRF4TrGYvP8G3nAaK8SocyyyAtFrUWKsFyqyHJG2FrdPFsjTUpRFLl0pXOxgJn8)

Anonymous Whatever lambda that maps each element to the list and attempts to subtract one from it, otherwise incrementing it and taking the first character in the case that `z` wraps over to `aa`.

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL 2012, 61 bytes

Capital letters needed in input.

Using table variable as input.

```sql
SELECT iif(x<'a',left(x-1,9),char((ascii(x)-64)%26+65))FROM @
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/IBUMDE60459)**

Answer (score 0):

## SimpleTemplate, 80 bytes

This was written on a language I've made.

Due to limitations in the compiler, I can't reduce it any more.

```
{@eachargv}{@if_ is matches"@\d+@"}{@incby-1_}{@echol_}{@else}{@inc_}{@echol_.0}
```

And now, ungolfed:

```
{@each argv as value}
    {@if value is matches "@\d+@"}
        {@inc by -1 value}
    {@else}
        {@inc by 1 value}
    {@/}
    {@echo value, "\n"}
{@/}
```

And the explanation:

- `{@each argv as value}` - loops through all values in `argv`. (`argv` contains all the arguments passed).
  If the `as <var>` isn't present, the default `_` variable is assumed.
- `{@if value is matches "@\d+@"}` - checks that `value` matches with the regular expression `"@\d+@"`.
- `{@inc by -1 value}` - increments the value by -1 (basically, a decrement).
- `{@echo value, "\n"}` and `{@echol_}` - `echol` outputs the values passed and appends a line at the end.
- `{@else}` - self-explanatory
- `{@inc by 1 value}` - increments the value by 1. If the `by <value>` is missing, it is assumed to be 1.
- `{@echo value.0, "\n"}` and `{@echol_.0}` - `echol` outputs the values passed and appends a line at the end.
  This is required because of the challenge rules: `z wraps to a`.
  When an `@inc` is used on a string, it increments the chars and, once it hits `z`, it wraps to `aa`.
  Outputting the first character satisfies the challenge, at the cost of 7 bytes.
- `{@/}` - closes the `{@else}` above (optional).
- `{@/}` - closes the `{@each}` above (optional).

You can try this on: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7533641a0aa1fc8bf4699a9c758690de186b052f

Each passed argument to `render()` will be a new value that is considered.

Answer (score -1):

### Perl, 64 bytes

```
foreach (@ARGV){$_=~m/[a-zA-Z]/?++$_:--$_;print substr $_,0,1;}
```