# Create this "String Mix-Up" function in as few bytes as possible

Tags: code-golf, string

This is my first time here at Code Golf SE so feel free to add your input/advice/suggestions to improve my post if necessary. The week after my computer science exam, the solutions were publicly published. One problem had a 45 line example solution but my solution was only 18 lines, (which I was very proud of), but I bet you guys here at code golf SE can do better.

**Here are the requirements:**

- Takes two inputs, string1 and string2.
- Delete the first occurrence of string2 found in the string1.
- Add string2 in reverse order to the beginning of string1, and
- Add string2 in reverse order to the end of the string1.
- If string2 does not occur in string1, do not modify string1.
- Output the modified string1

**Example:**

Input:

```
batman
bat

thebatman
bat

batman
cat
```

Output:

```
tabmantab

tabthemantab

batman
```

**Note:**
The problem was intended to handle basic inputs. Assume all expected inputs are restricted to characters A-Z, numbers, or other special characters visible on your keyboard. It does not need to handle tabs or newlines.

Submissions with shortest byte counts in each language win.

Comment: Can you give an example test case where string 2 doesn't occur in string 1? Also - which characters can appear in the string? Printable ASCII? Tab? Newlines?

Comment: @user202729 Input "batman, robin" has output "batman"

Comment: Out of curiosity, which language did you use in the exam?

Comment: @user202729 I used C++

Comment: We also need an example where string1 contains string2 twice or more.

Comment: And an example where string2 contains characters that are special in a regex and make naive `s/string2//` fail

Comment: Also a test case with string 2 being a palindome might be a good idea.

Comment: Perhaps a test case containing the second input multiple times, since we only should replace the first? Something like: `"batman_and_his_bat", "bat"` → `"tabman_and_his_battab"`

Comment: As newlines are insignificant in C++ (unless after a preprocessor directive), you can just solve it in 2 lines. Also that's why we don't measure line count here.

Comment: I can't believe nobody has said this: Welcome to PPCG! This is a good first challenge, and in case you didn't know, we also have a [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) for feedback before you post a challenge, to ensure you aren't missing anything from yours. I'm looking forward to more of your posts here, and hope you enjoy the time you spend here :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <strike>16</strike> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÄE┘¢8·╦Ωb•∩
```

[Run and debug it online](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8e45d99b38facbea6207ef&i=%22batman%22+%22bat%22%0A%22batman%22+%22robin%22%0A%22thebatman%22+%22bat%22%0A%22thebatman%22+%22.*%22&a=1&m=2)

The corresponding ascii representation of the same program is this.

```
Y#xyz|eyr|Sx?
```

This fixes the bugs in original version.  It uses conditionals and stuff.

```
Y                   Save 2nd input in y.  Now the two inputs are x and y.
 #                  Occurrences of y in x. (a)
  xyz               x, y, ""
     |e             replace first occurrence
       yr|S         surround with y reversed. (b)
           x        first input. (c)
            ?       a ? b : c
```

The result is printed implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

## C#,  148 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;using System.Text.RegularExpressions;(a,b)=>a==(a=new Regex(Regex.Escape(b)).Replace(a,"",1))?a:(b=string.Concat(b.Reverse()))+a+b
```

Comment: Perhaps include a [tio](https://tio.run/#) link? (I edited your post to capitalize C# and add syntax highlighting.)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and nice first answer! With lambdas you are allowed to leave out the types and the trailing semi-colon, but all required imports are mandatory for the byte-count I'm afraid, so it would becomes this instead: `using System.Linq;(a,b)=>a==(a=new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(b).Replace(a,"",1))?a:(b=string.Concat(b.Reverse()))+a+b` (128 bytes). Also, as _@Ourous_ suggested, perhaps add a TIO link to your answer. [Here is an example of how it might look like.](https://tinyurl.com/yaszgcv4) It's unfortunate the `Regex` import is so long in .NET... :(

Comment: Hmm, it seems to fail for `"this.is.a.test", "."`. Expected output: `".thisis.a.test."`, actual output: `".his.is.a.test."`. Can be fixed like this: `using System.Linq;using System.Text.RegularExpressions;(a,b)=>a==(a=new Regex(Regex.Escape(b)).Replace(a,"",1))?a:(b=string.Concat(b.Reverse()))+a+b` (148 bytes). [Try it online.](https://tinyurl.com/y938j6es)

Comment: Thanks Kevin.. wow, c# is impressively unsuitable for golfing.. :) I tested my code in linqpad which I guess adds some commonly used namespaces by default. And yep, missed the need to escape it as someone pointed out in your java port of my code :) I think I am gonna use JavaScript next time. Thank you very much for taking the time.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Look ma, no regex!

Anonymous infix lambda, taking string2 as left argument and string1 as right argument. Assumes `⎕IO` (**I**ndex **O**rigin) to be `0`, which is default on many systems.

```apl
{r,⍵[(⍳≢⍵)~(f⍳1)+⍳≢⍺],r←⌽⍺/⍨∨/f←⍺⍷⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OAZHWRzqPerdEaj3o3P@pcBGRq1mmkATmGmtowoV2xOkVAlY969gLZ@o96VzzqWKEP0gvkPurdDtRT@/@/elJiibpCmoJ6bmKeOhecB6QxBDDEgDyoGAA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; `⍺` is left argument, `⍵` is right argument; e.g. `"bat"` and `"manbatmanbat"`:

`⍺⍷⍵` find where string2 begins in string1; `[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]`

`f←` assign to `f` (**f**ind)

`∨/` OR-reduction (does string2 occur at all?); `1`

`⍺/⍨` use that to compress string2 (`""` if not found); `"bat"`

`⌽` reverse that; `"tab"`

`r←` assign to `r` (**r**everse)

`⍵[`…`],` prepend string2 indexed by the following indices:

`≢⍵` the length of string2; `3`

`⍳` the indices of that; `[0,1,2]`

`(`…`)+` add the following to that:

`f⍳1` index of first 1 in `f`; `3`

Now we have the indices to be removed; `[3,4,5]`

`(`…`)~` the following indices except those indices:

`≢⍵` length of string2; `12`

`⍳` the indices of that; `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]`

Now we have the indices we want to keep; `[0,1,2,6,7,8,9,10,11]`

This gives us the remaining parts of string1 followed by a reversed string2; `"manmanbattab"`

`r,` prepend `r` to that; `"tabmanmanbattab"`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda s,t:s.replace(t,'',1).join(2*[t[::-1]*(t in s)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XctBDsIgEIXhvadgx9BgE7rE9CRtF6A0HUMHAmOMp8e6MDHuXr68P794SzS0dZxbdLu/OVE129qXkKO7BmAtpTaqvyckGLqJJ2vPZumABZKoalHtuWEMwtgjHJHyg0FdckFiscJhqoH0jndHUovPkur0KyV5pK/9Hd8)

Using `join` to get the `a+b+a` pattern. This lets us write expression for `a` only once while still using a `lambda`. Compare:

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes**

```python
def f(s,t):r=t[::-1]*(t in s);print r+s.replace(t,'',1)+r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBCsIwEEX3nmJ2M7FRiMuUnkRcpJrSgToNkxHx9FERQdw9Hu//8rB5lUNrlzzBRNWbizrYMcZdOG3JgAWq64uyGGhX95rLks6ZzCP64Dpt95mXDCG@tgNLuRm5/vPUCMdk1yTo4U3oNr9G15Hl6/7CJw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 35 bytes

-3 bytes due to a neat trick by Asone Tuhid

```ruby
->x,y{(x[y]&&="")?y.reverse!+x+y:x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165Cp7JaoyK6MlZNzVZJSdO@Uq8otSy1qDhVUbtCu9KqovZ/QWlJsUJatFJSYkluYp6SDoihFMsFEy7JSMUhAxdOBgn/BwA)

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165Cp7JaoyK6MlZNzVZJSdO@Uq8otSy1qDhVUbtCu9KqovZ/QWlJsUJatFJSYkluYp6SDoihFMsFEy7JSMUhAxdOBgn/BwA)

Comment: Wow, I was thinking for ages, how to get rid of that duplicated x[y], but didn't even know _this_ was possible

Comment: It's the same idea as `||=`, `+=`, etc. I think all `a=a<op>b` can be reduced to `a<op>=b` (or `a<op>a=b` in this case) if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda s,t:[s,t[::-1]+s.replace(t,'',1)+t[::-1]][t in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFYp8QqGkhEW1npGsZqF@sVpRbkJCanapToqKvrGGpqQ2Vio0sUMvMUimP/FxRl5pVopGmoJyWW5CbmqesogFjqmppcWGSK8pMy89Dl0DX@BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>126</s> 113 bytes

```java
(a,b)->a.equals(a=a.replaceFirst(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(b),""))?a:(b=new StringBuffer(b).reverse()+"")+a+b
```

[Port of *@lee*'s C# .NET answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157376/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lY/BasMwDIbveQqRk01SP8BKNthht5XBjmMH2VU7p4mTxnK2MfLsmQKG3cYGwkjW/0ufWpxxN4wU2uNldR3GCI/ow1cB4APTdEJHcNhKgGeefDiDUznBOidW70WwFPJERvYODhCggVVhbfXuFg1dE3ZRYYNmorGToQ9@iqxaWW8S@06@z/RhnpBlaTDXNDApq@uy1PoOb5RtAr1ngvt0OtEkXTHNNEVSuhJdhZVdNxCJMdlOMDLNPPgj9HJWJn95RZ1P@oxMvRkSm1E63AUVjFOlRe4xlDVsmSDsf1XzG/3P8KN2fxrvo5FAwxTZbDaTTUuxrN8)

**Old 126 byte answer:**

```java
a->b->{Object r=new StringBuffer(b).reverse();return a.contains(b)?r+a.replaceFirst(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(b),"")+r:a;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nY/BasMwDIbvfQqRk00bP8CyZrBDb2OHHscOsqtszhzH2HJGKXn2zKNhjF02BgJJ/P@H9Pc4YT0G8v3pbTEOU4IHtP6yAUiMbA30xaEyW6e67A3b0avDOtweOVr/svuT59rbFgzsYcG61XV7edQ9GYa49/S@Ou5z11EUWqpIE8VEQjaROEcPqMzoubyXinwXt1gswaGhg42Jhd5VldzGG2zmpSkBSoWsXcmwRplGe4Kh8OJ66ukZ5WdSgOM5MQ1qzKxCUdh5YRSG4M6i0sgD@kp@2yspm185fqX/oj8588XNm3n5AA)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->b->{                    // Method with two String parameters and String return-type
  Object r=new StringBuffer(b).reverse();
                           //  2nd input reversed
  return a.contains(b)?    //  If the 1st input contains the 2nd:
    r                      //   Output the reversed 2nd input
     +a.replaceFirst(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(b),"") 
                           //   Removed the first occurrence of the 2nd in the 1st input,
                           //   escaping any characters like dots, pluses, etc.
                           //   and then append that to the result
     +r                    //   appended with the reversed 2nd input again
   :                       //  Else:
    a;}                    //   Simply output the 1st input
```

Comment: Fails with `b = "..."` ("Assume all expected inputs are restricted to characters A-Z, numbers, or other special characters visible on your keyboard." : `.` is a special character visible on every keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 35 bytes

```
^(.*)¶(.*?)\1(.*)
¶$^$1$2$3$^$1
0A`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P05DT0vz0DYgaa8ZYwjicB3aphKnYqhipGIMorkMHBP@/09KLOEqyUgFUrmJeQA) `$^` is new in Retina 1 and reverses its argument which is just what's needed here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl`, <s>38</s> 34 bytes

```perl
$s=<>;s/\Q$s//&&s/^|$/reverse$s/ge
```

*-4 thanks to Ton Hospel*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@l2NbGzrpYPyZQpVhfX02tWD@uRkW/KLUstag4FSiUnvr/f1JiSW5iHheQ@pdfUJKZn1f8X7cgBwA)

Comment: Good method but can be golfed a bit more: `-pl $s=<>;s/$s//&&s/^|$/reverse$s/ge`. Both versions really need to use `s/\Q$s//` though since characters like `*` and `.` seem allowed

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
DIåiIõ.;IR.ø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fxfPw0kzPw1v1rD2D9A7v@P8/KbEEiHIT87iAFAA)

**Explanation**

```
D             # duplicate 1st input
 Iåi          # if 2nd input is in first input
    Iõ.;      # replace the first occurrence of 2nd input with the empty string
        IR.ø  # surround with 2nd input reversed
```

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is 13-bytes: `õ.;©Ê²si®¹R.ø` but it's pretty different order-wise.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, ES6 - 73 bytes

```
b=x=>y=>{v=[...y].reverse().join``;u=x.replace(y,"");alert(u==x?x:v+u+v)}
```

Comment: please support me to improve it!

Comment: Several of the [JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2682) and [ES6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37624) tips will let you shave off a number of bytes.

Comment: Also, we format code blocks with 4-spaces indentation. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: @user202729 thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>69</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>x.match(y)?(k=[...y].reverse().join``)+x.replace(y,'')+k:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcpNCsIwEIbhvRfJDNU5gJB6EBE6jVP7kyYlCSU5fZRuBDfuPt7nm3nnaMK0pYvzT6mDrlm3RbeZVk5mhII3WPSdiMqDguwSogDS7CfXddjkT9ssG4FyVgqb5Zqr8S56K2T9CwZQPaeVncJjKcTTj6dR/l2@bg6vbw)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! / (1) In the way how we normally count byte count, the `m=` is not counted if you don't use it in the function (i.e., it doesn't call itself). (2) You can save a byte [by currying](https://tio.run/##DchJDsMgDADA59gWqR9QCfqQqgcDTpdAiLJU8HqSOc5P/rKF9bvst7lE7T3bal2zrnKWPXyw0QMn@2Tm9uJV4xEUUQZP1nkjRKZeuyS5ug0AZKZ77aHMW0nKqbwxI4jnEFlHIAQGon4C).

Comment: Also you may find [Tips for golfing in Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) useful.

Comment: You can use `[...y].reverse().join`` ` to reverse a string, save 2 bytes.

Comment: Doesn't work when y contain `|`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
œṣ⁹Ḣ;jɗ⁹ṭṚ};Ṛ}ðẇ@¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Ic7Fz9q3PlwxyLrrJPTQaydax/unFVrDSIOb3i4q93h0ML///8nJiWnJKf@T04FAA)

Full program.

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 36 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{$[#s:x ss y;r,(x_/(#y)#*s),r:|y;x]}
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k){$[#s:x ss y;r,x_/(#y)#*s,r:|y;x]}["batman";"bat"]
"tabman"
q)k){$[#s:x ss y;r,(x_/(#y)#*s),r:|y;x]}["batman";"bat"]
"tabmantab"
q)k){$[#s:x ss y;r,(x_/(#y)#*s),r:|y;x]}["thebatman";"bat"]
"tabthemantab"
q)k){$[#s:x ss y;r,(x_/(#y)#*s),r:|y;x]}["batman";"cat"]
"batman"
q)k){$[#s:x ss y;r,(x_/(#y)#*s),r:|y;x]}["batbatbat";"bat"]
"tabbatbattab
```

**Explanation:**

If string 2 (y) is found in string 1 (x) then drop first indices of first occurrence.

```
{$[#s:x ss y;r,(x_/(#y)#*s),r:|y;x]} / the solution
{                                  } / lambda with implicit x,y
 $[         ;                   ; ]  / $[condition;true;false]
      x ss y                         / string-search for y in x
    s:                               / save result as s
   #                                 / count length
                              |y     / reverse (|) y
                            r:       / save as r
                           ,         / join with
               (          )          / do this together
                        *s           / first (*) s
                       #             / take
                   (#y)              / length of y
                x_/                  / drop (_) over (/)
             r,                      / join with r
                                 x   / (else) return x
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript 85 bytes

```
a=>b=>a.includes(b)?[...b].reverse().join``+a.replace(b,'')+[...b].reverse().join``:a
```

If someone knows how to avoid using `split('').reverse().join('')` for reversing string, please let me know

```js
f=a=>b=>a.includes(b)?[...b].reverse().join``+a.replace(b,'')+[...b].reverse().join``:a


console.log(f('batman')('bat'))

console.log(f('thebatman')('bat'))

console.log(f('batman')('cat'))
```

Comment: for help, you can't get much better than the [Tips for golfing in javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript), and I'm sure somebody will come along to help -- I don't know javascript.

Comment: There's really no better way to reverse a string. What you could do is ```...?(c=[...b].reverse().join``)+a.replace(b,'')+c:a``` to save quite a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
œṣµḢ;j⁹$ɓ;;@ðU}
ç¹w?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9qZWxsef//xZPhuaPCteG4ojtq4oG5JMmTOztAw7BVfQrDp8K5dz////9hYmlqY2lqZGVpamb/aWo)

---

Ouch! Why can other languages get 11~12 bytes? Am I doing something wrong?

And *finally*, I *think* I know how chain separators works...

```
œṣµḢ;j⁹$ɓ;;@ðU}   Helper link (dyadic). General structure:
œṣ                <dyad>                    - given x and y, split x at
                                              sublists equal to y.
   Ḣ;j⁹$                <monad>             - given x, join with y except at
                                              first index.
         ;;@                   <dyad>       - given x and y, return y+x+y.
                                              Note that this link is flipped.
             U}                      <dyad> - reverse right argument.

ç¹w?    Main link. Evaluate the last link if the second input is a substring
        of the first input, otherwise - apply identity (do nothing).
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 62 Bytes

```
def f(a,b):b*=b in a;a=a.replace(b,"",1);b=b[::-1];print b+a+b
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 73 bytes

```
	S =INPUT
	T =INPUT
	S T =	:F(O)
	T =REVERSE(T)
	S =T S T
O	OUTPUT =S
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNYwdbTLyA0hIszBM4KVgCyOa3cNPw1wcJBrmGuQcGuGiGaIDnbEAWgAi5/Tv/QEKByBdtgLlc/l///kxJLchPzuJITSwA)

What's a regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 58 bytes

```
def f(a,b):z=(b in a)*b[::-1];return z+a.replace(b,'',1)+z
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 85 bytes

```
{for(;x++<N=split($0,a,"");)p=a[x]p;$0=NR%2?L=$0:sub($0,"",L)?p L p:L}!(NR%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/usBWSck6Lb9Io8LWwLpCW9vGz7a4ICezREPFQCdRR0lJ01qzwDYxuiK2wFrFwNYvSNXI3sdWxcCquDQJpERJScdH075AwUehwMqnVlEDpEDz//@kxJLcxDwuIMVVkpGKxIMykxNLAA)

Input is: primary string on odd-lines, replacement on even lines. Replacement is case sensitive.