# Add Rainbow Pairs

Tags: code-golf, number

The rules are as follows:

- Take in a string of integers separated by spaces. Add the first and last numbers, the second and second-last numbers, and so on.
- The program must output the numbers separated by newlines.
- The program must handle negative numbers, but may not handle decimals.
- If an odd amount of integers are inputted, just print the lone integer at the end.
- This is code golf, fewest bytes wins.

Here are some test cases:

```
> input
output
more output
etc.
-------------------
> 2 2
4

> 1 2 3 4 5 6
7
7
7

> 3 4 2 6
9
6

> 1 2 3 4 5
6
6
3

> -5 3 -8 2
-3
-5
```

Comment: "*The program must deal with invalid input*". I'd strongly suggest rethinking that requirement; input validation doesn't go down too well here. I'd also suggest loosening the I/O formats. Need we handle negative numbers?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I have a few questions, but this seems like it can be a good challenge. In the future, I would consider using [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get some feedback. :)

Comment: Like Shaggy, I would reconsider having to handle invalid input, especially since we have a consensus to [allow programs to error on invalid input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/should-answers-have-to-handle-invalid-inputs/8858#8858).

Comment: I think the 4th test case should output `6 6 3`.

Comment: Along with the requirement that invalid input must be dealt with there are a number of other restrictions here that I would remove.  Input as a space separated string is unnecessarily complicated allowing answers to take input as a list of integers would be much nicer.  Otherwise answers become almost entirely a parser.

Comment: Is the input a string or a list?

Comment: May we also take as input a list of integers and return a list of integers?

Comment: "May not handle decimals"?  So what if there is a decimal in the input?

Comment: I would upvote but the I/O requirement on strings and newlines is just fluff detracting from the actual challenge.

Comment: Do we have to handle `0`?

Comment: What exactly does "may not handle decimals" mean - must programs error if such input is encountered or is casting to an integer acceptable? (I am firmly in the "relax I/O requirements camp)

Comment: ... I had started commenting on answers that appear to break the ruling about handling decimals, but have given up since almost all answers may not comply.

Answer (score 9):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <strike>9</strike> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

*Thanks to Weijun Zhou for -1 bytes*

It actually conforms with the required output format!

```
Φ┴⌐Öâ9|Ö
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e8c1a99983397c99&i=2+2%0A1+2+3+4+5+6%0A3+4+2+6%0A1+2+3+4+5%0A-5+3+-8+2&a=1&m=2)

Here's the ungolfed ascii representation of the program.

```
L   Concatenate all inputs into list
2M  Create two equal-ish size batches, with the bigger piece first
Er  Push the two parts to the stack, and reverse the second one
LM  Put two parts back together as 2-row matrix, then transpose
m|+ For each zipped pair, print the sum on a separate line
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=L%09Concatenate+all+inputs+into+list%0A2M%09Create+two+equal-ish+size+batches,+with+the+bigger+piece+first%0AEr%09Push+the+two+parts+to+the+stack,+and+reverse+the+second+one%0ALM%09Put+two+parts+back+together+as+2-row+matrix,+then+transpose%0Am%7C%2B%09For+each+zipped+pair,+print+the+sum+on+a+separate+line&i=2+2%0A1+2+3+4+5+6%0A3+4+2+6%0A1+2+3+4+5%0A-5+3+-8+2&a=1&m=2)

Comment: [8 bytes](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e8c1a99983397c99&i=2+2%0A1+2+3+4+5+6%0A3+4+2+6%0A1+2+3+4+5%0A-5+3+-8+2&a=1&m=2).

Comment: @WeijunZhou: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 23 bytes

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -a
say$'*s//a/+pop@F for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFXatYXz9RX7sgv8DBTSEtv8jB7f9/QwUjBWMFEwWzf/kFJZn5ecX/dRP/6/qa6hka6BkAAA)

Perl is unusual in that it is valid to change an array while you are looping over it. So you can have `$_` walking from front to back while using `pop` to effectively walk from back to front while removing array elements which will stop the loop when they meet in the middle:

```perl
say$_+pop@F for@F
```

This however fails for an odd number of elements because in the middle both `$_` and `pop@F` are that middle element so you get twice the value.

So instead I use another odd fact of perl loops: the loop variable is not a copy of the corresponding array position but is an alias for it. If you change `$_` then you change the corresponding array element. In this case I want to both get the value of `$_` ***and*** change it to `0` so that the `pop@F` returns zero when processing the middle element. The shortest way (without needing `()`) to do that is `s//a/` which changes e.g. `6` to `a6` which evaluates to `0` in a numeric context. The part after the substitution is preserved in `$'` which will be `6` in the example. And since `s///` returns the number of substitutions (`1` in this case) the expression `s//a/*$'` will both set `$_` to zero and return the original value.

This however would require a space after `say`. So finally I use yet another perl oddity, the fact that the expression stack also uses aliases of the values and variables you are processing. Therefore `$'*s//a/` also works. When `$'` is put on the expression stack it is not set yet but when next `s//a/` is executed it changes to the old value of `$_` in place just before the multiplication is done. This is also the reason why the simpler seeming

```perl
say$_+($_=0)+pop@F for@F
```

does ***not*** work. The first `$_` gets changed to `0` just before the first addition. You would need to force a copy with something like

```perl
say "$_"+($_=0)+pop@F for@F
```

to make that work

Comment: @msh210 added an explanation

Comment: Great explanation.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes, relaxed I/O

```python
def f(a):
 try:x,*a,y=a;return[x+y]+f(a)
 except:return a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI1HTikuhpKjSqkJHK1Gn0jbRuii1pLQoL7pCuzJWGyTPpZBakZxaUGIFkVBI/F9QlJlXopGmEW2ko2AUq6nJBRcwBAroKBjrKJjoKJjqKJjhlkSRgYgZoWvQNQUr17WAWPMfAA)

First time to see `try..except` in golfing.

### `print` version, 57 bytes

```python
def f(a):
 try:x,*a,y=a;print(x+y);f(a)
 except:print(*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI1HTikuhpKjSqkJHK1Gn0jbRuqAoM69Eo0K7UtMaJM2lkFqRnFpQYgUR10rU/A9hpWlEG@koGMVqanLBBQyBAjoKxjoKJjoKpjoKZrglUWQgYkboGnRNwcp1LSDW/AcA)

`print`ing instead of `return`ing gives the same length.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes, strict I/O

```python
a=*map(int,input().split()),
while len(a)>1:x,*a,y=a;print(x+y)
print(*a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCsIwEETv@Yq9JRtToVsjUqn/skiggRhDjTT5@hjx4GXm8Rgm1bw@49RccXclpWy86Acn5WM2PqZ3Vnh8peB7oxH76oOD4KJivI1zMZpNXfiatr5X5VBR/FAztv6mLTYCEiMQTHACC@c/i29SN4PtYrgAfQA)

This prints an extra newline at the end if the number of elements is even.

Answer (score 4):

### [JavaScript ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript), <strike>100</strike> 97 bytes

```
_=>{for(_=_.split(' ').map(Number);0<_.length;)console.log(1<_.length?_.shift()+_.pop():_.pop())}
```

https://jsbin.com/nufanenehu/edit?js,console

First golfing answer ever. Be gentle.

Comment: Welcome to the site! A fair few people here use JavaScript so I'm sure you'll get some golfs in a while. Be sure to read [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/tips-for-golfing-in-ecmascript-6-and-above) tips as well!

Comment: A simple thing you can do to save bytes is to drop the `f=`. Unnamed functions are fine as long as you don't need the function name for a recursive call or something like that.

Comment: Welcome! There are a few golfing tricks you can use here: 1) `x<_.length` is essentially the same as `x in _`, so using `0 in _` and `1 in _?` can save you a few bytes. 2) you can use [this trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52204/42545) to do ``_=_.split` `.map(Number)``, saving 2 bytes. 3) `~~x` converts the value of `x` to an integer, or `0` if this fails; combine this with the fact that `_.pop()` on an empty array returns `undefined`, and you can turn the entire final expression into `console.log(_.shift()+~~_.pop())`.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
#2ä`R+»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f2ejwkoQg7UO7///XNVUwVjBR0LVQMAIA)

**Explanation**

```
#          # split input on spaces
 2ä        # divide into 2 parts
   `       # split separately to stack
    R      # reverse the second one
     +     # add the lists of numbers
      »    # join on newlines
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan: "must handle negative" + "may not handle decimals" sounds to me like it means "does not have to handle decimals" rather that "must not handle decimals", but we'll see what the OP has to say.

Comment: You could well be correct with your interpretation as it is not a separate bullet point.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>77</s> 58 bytes

```javascript
a=>g(a.split` `)
g=a=>+a.shift()+~~a.pop()+`
`+(a+a&&g(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcvLDsIgEIXhPU8xq3YmRKJ42dFnYVILYkghQlz21SkLVya6O/n@nCe/ucyvkOthTfelOdPYTB5ZlRxDtWBJeNNJdnkEV5HktrHKKfdlhZXIkoehP4janNaS4qJi8uhw1KBHIvGlJ9Bwhgtc4fav/mjHT2s7)

Thanks to @Neil for chopping off 17 bytes at once. Also, I found that `~~` works instead of `|0`, which removes a pair of parens.

## Original submission, 77 bytes

```javascript
a=>g(a.split` `.map(x=>+x))
g=a=>a.shift()+(a.pop()|0)+`
`+(a.length?g(a):'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fczNCgIhFAXg/TzF3elFksl@FoHTqyiTOoappMQsenczaBXU8pzvcK76oct897luYrqYZmXTcnJU85KDrwoUv@lMVzmxFXFwsmu3xdtKkfVZTpnic0SmBvXOwURXl3N/wBMh2OYUSwqGh@SopUSAIP3nq92CgB3s4QDHf/rDxo@1Fw)

Input as a space-delimited string, output as a newline-delimited string. First converts the input string into an array, then passes to a recursive function that generates the output string.

Comment: You don't need to `map`, just use `+a.shift()`, also you can use `a+a&&g(a)` instead of `a.length?g(a):''`, saving 17 bytes in total if I counted correctly.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 61 bytes

```
>>+[>,]<[<]>->[[-<<+>>]>[>]<[[<]<<+>>>[>]<-]<[<]>]<<<[<]>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fzk472k4n1ibaJtZO1y46WtfGRtvOLtYu2g4oBhQEc8E8XYgioAiYjtazi/3/38bAVtHY0A4A)

This program takes a null-terminated list of base-256 ASCII numbers as input :)

**Commented Version**

```
Read input chars until \0
>>+[>,]<
Clear initial 1
[<]>->
[
  Copy two to the left
  [-<<+>>]>
  Head to right side
  [>]<
  Subtract from right side add to left side repeat
  [[<]<< +>>> [>]< - ]
  Start at next spot
  <[<]>
]
Print it all out
<<<
[<]
>[.>]
```

**Satisfying I/O requirements, 81 bytes**

```
>>+[>,>,[-]<]<[<]>->[[-<<+>>]>[>]<[[<]<<+>>>[>]<-]<[<]>]<<<[<]>[.[-]++++++++++.>]
```

In this version the input characters must be separated and the output is split by newlines.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
œs2U2¦S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5GKjUKNDy4L///9vqKNgpKNgrKNgoqNgCgA)

Takes a list of integers, such as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Outputs as an array, such as `[6, 6, 3]`.

[11 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk1hj5rWHJ1cbBRqdGhZcOT///8NFYwUjBVMFEwB) to conform to the strict input specifications.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>68</s> 66 bytes

```r
cat(c((n=scan())[y<-1:(x=sum(n|1)/2)],rep(0,x!=x%/%1))+rev(n[-y]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQq0wLYYYUPxFE5EnEhYjLJLRCobvbe2WMGG6MiNnWGDISuX4IvWOz9Tkxf5qkIc9LulDxNtnGJNNEc0kvZie6JxpihQUUiA3M@AE)

Takes input from stdin as in the examples, and prints the output on stdout. Since using `scan()` is typically shorter than defining a function and taking an array as input, this is the shortest way to take input.

Reads in data, takes the first half (rounded down) of the list, and appends a zero (if necessary), then adds it to the reverse of the second half of the list.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 28 bytes

```
>.@-:@#({.|:@,:@+/@,:|.@}.)]
```

### ungolfed

```
>.@-:@# ({. |:@,:@+/@,: |.@}.) ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7fQcdK0clDWq9WqsHHSsHLT1gWSNnkOtnmbsf00urtTkjHyFNAVDBSMFYwUTBVOIgLo6hoSCGboUSNhIwew/AA)

My J is rusty and surely this could be improved -- suggestions encouraged.  Almost all the complexity arises from the odd length case and the newline requirement.  I had 22 bytes before I noticed the newline requirement:

```
>.@-:@# ({. +/@,: |.@}.) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x[1:]and[x[0]+x[-1]]+f(x[1:-1])or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRocKqItrQKjYxLyW6ItogVrsiWtcwNlY7TQMkDGRq5hcpVPwvKMrMK9FI04g20lEwitXU5IILGAIFdBSMdRRMdBRMdRTMcEuiyEDEjNA16JqCletaQKz5DwA)

`x[1:]` is just a shorter way to write `len(x)>1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes

```python
lambda a:[a[i]+a[~i]for i in range(len(a)//2)]+len(a)%2*[a[len(a)//2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKjoxOjNWOzG6LjM2Lb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjJzVPI1FTX99IM1YbwlY10gIqh4vHxv4vKMrMK9FI04g21DHSMdYx0TGN1dTkwhTVMQOK/wcA)

+32 bytes for strict input:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 102 bytes

```python
a=[*map(int,input().split())]
l=len(a)
for q in[a[i]+a[~i]for i in range(l//2)]+l%2*[a[l//2]]:print(q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxDsIwDEX3nsILUtwiKlJYkHqSyIOHApaM64YwsHD1kE5P/@nr@bc8V5tq5Tn1L/YgVo5i/ikBT29XaUTqdNbFAmN3XzNsIJY4CQ2cfkK7kqYgsz2WoOMYkQY9xL6d9kV089y6YcNazxBhggtc/w)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) + `-p`, 52 bytes (spec compliant)

```ruby
a=$_.split.map(&:to_i);loop{puts a.shift+(a.pop||0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P9FWJV6vuCAns0QvN7FAQ82qJD8@U9M6Jz@/oLqgtKRYIVGvOCMzrURbI1GvIL@gpsZAs/b/f0MFIwVjBRMF03/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

A full program, taking a string of space-separated integers and printing the results separated by newlines.

Normally the `-p` flag forces you to reassign the `$_` variable, as it will be implicitly printed at the end of the program. However this code terminates with an `NoMethodError` when it calls `+` on `nil` (the result of `shift`ing the head off an empty array), before that implicit print can happen.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes (relaxed IO)

```ruby
->a{puts a.shift+(a.pop||0);redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwEETv/YoBL4rbotGKIPojpYfYJrRQmpKkFDF@e9y26G3eDLM7dny@or7H9CHfw@gdZOaaVvv9VmaDGUI47G5W1eYTiwQoBImSZnEkQSc6U06X1ZhB/OCfrpjmTOmVu0mZKVk1qA1C2/PDwLkuFlnCKleNCn3bYQM3ya4zE5S1xkJ6@EZB9TWMxnKj4pzb8@qE/Ri/)

This lambda skips the integer parsing code, and it is able to save 2 bytes by replacing `loop{}` with `redo` since it is already inside of a repeatable block. This also terminates with `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org) `-n`,  <s>58</s>  42 bytes

```perl6
.&{$_,{S:s/(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)?$ {say $0+($2//0)}/$1/}...''}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/19PrVolXqc62KpYXyMmWFtTQUNPyx5Igtj2KgrVxYmVCioG2hoqRvr6Bpq1@iqG@rV6enrq6rX//xsqGCkYK5gomP7LLyjJzM8r/q@bBwA)

```perl6
.say for .=words[^*/2]Z+ |.[$_-1...$_/2],0
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1@vOLFSIS2/SEHPtjy/KKU4Ok5L3yg2SluhRi9aJV7XUE9PTyUeKKJj8P@/oYKRgrGCiYLpv/yCksz8vOL/unkA)

---

If the input/output restrictions are relaxed **40 bytes**

```perl6
*.[^*/2,{$_-1...$_/2}].&roundrobin».sum
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##VZDdasJAEIXv5ykOkkpM3A1GTVtCgreF0pv2Tq20ZguBmCz5gYrow7SXfYTSG1/IR0gnMfSHYZcz35yd2V2t8sSrN1v011mkENSWnD9ajjvcGSsxklIaK8fdL2U/z6o0yrPnOD1@yqLa1D6RYd3cySKpco3DAQ4BJi/g9PUW8vYOc3FvD2xcNKQFi7Q1/PA275RNDvfkq8xKVZQIYB8/DGdu@RxLHnobFyUbqkLhQTVSJ0/p2ey4Pr1keXdShJjFqa7KIWbqVat1qSLseFBciEgpnWzRPNY8m9q@gz/WIXpdRfPnmAME4W@xYz3a1yFcuDQhCjFiOcYEU3h02QbDBrgMrsn75@HUo3GDxJSJuOIuYkxi@g0)

Comment: You don't need to include command line flags to the byte count, as per [this meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends). You can just specify the flags used as a part of the language, such as "Perl 6 `-n`, 58 bytes".

Comment: You can use the `Z+` operator for 41 bytes: `(.=words[^*/2]Z+ |.[$_-1...$_/2],0)>>.say`

Comment: @nwellnhof `».say` can cause the results to be printed in any order so `.say for .=words[^*/2]Z+ |.[$_-1...$_/2],0` would be more correct. (At one point the implementation would intentionally run them out of order)

Comment: @nwellnhof Note that `».sum` is fine as even though they can be calculated in any order, they are put back into the right order in the result.

Comment: Right. `Z+` also doesn't guarantee that the left operand is evaluated before the right operand, so you'd actually need `.=words;.say for .[^*/2]Z+ |.[$_-1...$_/2],0`. But relying on implementation quirks is [OK according to meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7832/whats-the-policy-on-interpreter-bugs/7833#7833), so it's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: @nwellnhof Actually `&infix:«+»` does guarantee that the left operand is evaluated first.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Is this also true for zip operators? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 76 bytes

```java
a->{for(int i=0,l=a.length;i<l--;)System.out.println(i<l?a[i++]+a[l]:a[i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBT4QwEIXv/Io5grSNomt0u6wHz572SDhUtmCxtIQOmxjCb8fCEiPRJpM232vnvWktLoLaVpr6/Pk8qaa1HULtIetRaVb2pkBlDbvhQaGFc/AmlIEhAGj7d60KcCjQbxerztB4LTxhp0yV5SC6ykXLVYBXa1zfyO6gDGb5EUpIg0nQ41DaLvQMVHpLdCqYlqbCD64OmlIenb4cyobZHlnru6I2oVdeRKbiOI9FpvO9P@cRHye@@CztvTdKhw7S1X1eAyQEEhjJL3JHZnhP4IHAjsDjVr3y5A/fvNpKdLcI9GljNV6zraOu6fbXjNFPxJKJopAthjOP@Er/@YFVG4O5xukb)

### With strict input

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 115 bytes

```java
s->{var a=s.split(" ");for(int i=0,l=a.length;i<l--;)System.out.println(i<l?new Long(a[i++])+new Long(a[l]):a[i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NT4QwEIbv/IoJJ@oujaJrzHZZD171tMcNh8oWLJaW0AFjNvx2LB9BTGwyaeZ5J5NnCt7ysLh89rKsTI1QuJ42KBXNGp2iNJreMC9V3Fp441LD1QOomnclU7DI0X2tkRcoXRacsJY6PyfA69yScRTgxWjblKI@TOkRMoi93obHa8tr4LGltlISAx98wjJTB1IjyPh2q2JOldA5fjB5UGHIyOnboiipaZBWbhcqHbjkWYsveDU6D/hZbjYJ2ayASsje4YSwrmejzyKJwqKFeNYcnh9B5G9/2zuI4B4eYAePazyg6C9aJtcw3DkWPq12dpPCcOWkMUrsJxWymGSUp6moMBg4YTP95/o567yhuv4H)

### Credits

- -10 bytes on strict input thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: Nice trick with `i<l--`. I'll delete my longer answer. Although, you currently are ignoring the rule "_Take in a string of integers separated by spaces._".. [It would be **119 bytes** with that rule](https://tinyurl.com/yc2tet9o) (probably more golfable).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oops, I didn't see your post... Sorry. Thanks for the reminder on the strict input and for the following nice golfs!

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>93</s> 80 bytes

<sup>Saved 13 bytes thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)!</sup>

```hs
f s|x<-read<$>words s=mapM print$zipWith(+)(take(div(1+length x)2)x)$reverse$0:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxLCsIwAAX3nuIRskiQgI1WRFpv4Np1IKkN/ZKEGsS7x7aCq/J2b5iplW9M26ZUwX9iIZxRuqC31@C0hy87Nd4xOtsH@rbjw4aa7TkLqjFM24ll@9b0z1Ajcskjp85MxnlDD9eYOmV7lNDDDqhAMkgccUKOM5mftQkiBPlhiXVb6G9uwQXI7aTIZ01clmj6Ag)

Comment: `div(1+length x)2` instead of ```(1+length x)`div`2``` saves two bytes.

Comment: You can get rid of the `splitAt` with `zipWith(+)(take(div(1+length x)2)x)$reverse$0:x`.

Comment: @Laikoni Thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>78</s> <s>72</s> <s>70</s> 67 bytes

```hs
mapM print.f.map read.words
f(x:r@(_:_))=(x+last r):f(init r)
f e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzRCoIwAEXf/YrLnjZsQisjBCXotUDoJciQkc5GtmQz8uuzWdDbOVzuuUp3q9t2bNJivMtuj85q00cq8gJbyyp6PWzlAkWHxG5omZSMpXQIW@l6WJYoqo2eKFCo09o3tEGKb4oWjmfonv2htzsDClKYDARhCAeGLEMDx3AiAoLMQOYQWGCJGKtJJxQ//C@T8NgzX/vPeXxfVCsbN/LjNs8/)

*Edits:*

- -6 bytes by using `mapM print` instead of `unlines.map show` from [GolfWolf's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159694/56433).
- -2 bytes by removing `+0` which I though was necessary for type inference but wasn't. Thanks to GolfWolf for pointing out.
- -3 bytes by adding `r@(_:_)` to make the `f[x]=f[x]` pattern superfluous. Thanks again to GolfWolf.

Comment: Very nice solution! I think the `+0` can be safely removed.

Comment: Here's an even [shorter one](https://tio.run/##PYxBC4IwAEbv/oqPnTZsQpYRwiToWiB0CbLDyM0kW7IZWT@@pQXd3uPje2fpLqppfCUKf5XtFq2tTRfpaBBYJcvocbOlCzTtU7uiz/TFmKB92EjXwbJU09rUIwUaSqihURsIfFO0cDxDe@92nd0YUJDCZCAIQzgwZBkqOIYDiRGTCcgUMWaYI8Fi1BHjH/6XUXgyMF8On6N/n3QjK@f5fp3nHw).

Comment: `x+last r` doesn't need parentheses around it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 124 bytes

```clj
#(loop[l(map bigint(.split %" "))](println(+(first l)(or(last(rest l))0)))(if(>(count l)2)(recur(concat(butlast(rest l))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcvBCsIwEATQX1kiwixSkYrgyR8pHtLQSmRNwmbz/bH15tzmDRMkv5suHf0AyblMgo8vNMdXTIZzLRKNjo4c8xNFN5SEE9ao1UgYWSG@GnT5db4wM@KKB0JuaaeRtzE03SAFb5ib/T32dDfc6ErDnUbH/Qs)

Ungolfed:

```clj
#(loop [l (map bigint (.split % " "))]
   (println (+ (first l) (or (last (rest l)) 0)))
   (if (> (count l) 2)
     (recur (concat (butlast (rest l))))))
```

An anonymous function that takes the input string and splits it. `loop` is rerun with every iteration with the "middle" items of the changing list if there are enough items left. Combining `butlast` and `rest` creates the "middle" list.
Interesting is the part where the sum is printed. Simply adding `(first l)` and `(last l)` only works for an even number of items. When an uneven number of items is passed, `first` and `last` will hit the same item. Using `rest` will remove the first item, in this case the only one, and return an empty list. Using `last` will return `nil` which is converted into zero by the `or` function.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 56 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>([a,m='',b]=x.split(/ (.*) | /),b?a- -b+`
`+f(m):a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc6xDoIwAIThnae4ra1tIVYxRlN9EDWhIDWYQokQw@C7V1wcdOh2w5fLfzdPM1SPph9l5691CFZP@kBPRrSaEFFe9JQOvWtGmoGmC4YXMibKo5GQJS@Sglvasp1hofLd4F2dOn@jsBREQREwcJBzN4998ieWUFhhjRybiPwoFVXfv4iT@czk9qcvvAE)

Split the string by all the middle numbers and capture them all as a group, add the ends (coercing strings to numbers via `a- -b`, which is shorter than any alternatives I know of), and concatenate the result with a line break and `f(all captured middle numbers)` where available.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>111</s> <s>107</s> 103 bytes

```python
i=map(int,input().split())
for y in[i[x]+i[-(x+1)]for x in range(len(i)/2)]+[i[x+1]]*(len(i)%2):print y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczLCsIwEIXhvU8xFISM8UJi7ULwScIsuqg6UKdDTCF5@piCqwMfh19Lei/ia@XHZ1TDko4suiaD56/O3BZ3zyVCAZbAIZPlcDLZOqSNc2OIo7wmM09iGC8eyW5H64gOf9x7vGtsbSi1dg48XKGHGwzdDw)

Takes input in "strict" format (space separated string of numbers) <s>and outputs a trailing newline if the count is even</s>. Works because in Python 2, list comprehensions leak the last value of the variable `x` so it can be used later to identify the middle number.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>79</s> <s>75</s> 69 bytes

```python
lambda i:[i[x]+i[-(x+1)]for x in range(len(i)/2)]+[i[x+1]]*(len(i)%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcrBCoQgEADQX5lL4KQRuu1loS@xORhlO1BTSAf7eiPo@njHdf53cSX2Q1nDNk4B@OfZZ9LsG5W1RYp7ggwskIIss1pnUYytQ9JP1JaofrFyWI7EckJU3hpnPqYzX8JyAw)

Shorter version with input and output as lists. <s>Adds an empty string to the output for even numbers.</s>

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 108 bytes

```python
i=[*map(int,input().split())]
l=len(i)
for a,b in zip(i,i[:int(l/2-.5):-1]):print(a+b)
if l&1:print(i[l//2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsMgEADvvmJPxW1NRNNchLxEPBho6MJ2I6k9tJ@3FnoaGGbKu953mVqjJZ4fuWiSakjKq2ocn4WpE5PihW@iCdW2H5DNCiTwoV4biqEvmq0fxhnD4BKGcvxUvqyoaAM@ub@hyNb6hK058DDBFeYv)

Non competitive, just thought it would be nice to share this zip approach :)
Too bad slicing and reversing in python is a bit finicky

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 105 bytes

```
func[s][b: to-block s
l: length? b
repeat n l / 2[print b/(n) + b/(l - n + 1)]if odd? l[print b/(n + 1)]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcyxCsMgFIXh3ac4ODUECbFNKS55h6ziUKO2oWKCsc9vDYHSdLrw/YcbrcmDNZCKOJHdO4xyVVILpJlpP48vrMQLeBse6dlDk2gXe08I8GjA5RKnkKCbU6hQb9eDlVijrdTkMBvTw/@s9qKyA@XglOyFUlKgBccZF3S4HsOG/B@/6yOzrii7ld/5Aw)

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 91 bytes (Relaxed IO - a list ot integers)

```
func[b][l: length? b
repeat n l / 2[print b/(n) + b/(l - n + 1)]if odd? l[print b/(n + 1)]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoMwEIXhfU7xcFWRIKa1FDfeodshi8ZMWiGkEtLzpxGhVFcD3/@YyDbf2YK0cEN2nzCR0eQHeA7P9BphROSFHwkBHi0ULXEOCaY9hRrNej1kiQ26Ws8Ob2tH@L/VVnR2IAWlxVaqShTooHDGBT2u@7CiOuJvvWfZF5W38jt/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## **FORTH** 76 Bytes

```
: A BEGIN DEPTH 1 - ROLL + CR . DEPTH 2 <= UNTIL DEPTH 1 = IF CR . THEN ;
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 a
6
6
3  ok

2 2 A
4  ok

-5 3 -8 2 A
-3
-5 ok
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 112 bytes

```
def f(s):
 s=[int(i)for i in s.split(' ')];s.insert(len(s)//2,0)
 for i in range(len(s)//2):print s[i]+s[-i-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6/Rakudo](https://perl6.org/) 45 bytes

`Perl6 -ne`

```
{say .shift+(.pop||0) while $_}(.words.Array)
```

Super simple, shifts and pops, Perl makes the empty list (with odd count) easy with `.pop||0`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 136 bytes

```python
def f(x):
 x,o=[int(i) for i in x.split()],[];y=len(x)
 for i in range(int(y/2)):o+=[x[i]+x[-i-1]]
 if y%2!=0:o+=[x[int(y/2)]]
 return o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcvNCgIhFIbhvVdxWsR4mJl@nN2EVyIugrQODEcxA716Syjafu/zxZofgZfWbs6DlwVXAWUK2hBnSQg@JCAghnJ4xo2yRDsZe6l6c/zR4g/Sle9O9ls9KsQ1jNoUQ3YsZqb5bK0A8lD3aqdPv/jFvSWXX4khtJj67OWgQA2I7Q0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

This can probably be improved, but I'm not sure how...

```ruby
def x(a);puts a.shift.to_i+a.pop.to_i;return if a.length==0;x a;end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLCoAgEADQq8yyaJD@BeJJIsJISwgTG8FOb9HuLZ4P65PSpjTETObcBbpBsvswmhhdiykkc5f7yb2i4C0Y/Y1T2Z0OIUoeQXJltxRhqrDGBlvssMcBRxzn9AI)

Answer (score 0):

## C, 128 bytes

This version is more in keeping with the terms of the challenge, but has a hard-coded maximum of 9 numbers that it can accept.

```
i[9],j,k;f(char*s){for(s=strtok(s," ");j++,s;i[j]=atoi(s),s=strtok(0," "));while(--j>=++k)printf("%d\n",i[j]+(j==k?0:i[k]));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3LDoIwFET3fMWNxqQPanzExAjFD0EWWChcwGIAdUH49lqMG13OOZMZJQql7BKNah5ZDmE/ZA1e12Xk/TBs/1GHpnDMol/5rA40UWXaMdbTsZYEzcBoH7xKbHLSx5xjQusYE5kOLTrg4ldyXoVSCKR3NzhoslhlF7Pw5zInKGV13pzquEooDSbrGnBL0cz7kHaF8mF@BcZceFIYPQBADWR2EMGWgiYfFXiTteJg91Yc7e4N)

I let C do the tokenizing for me, which allows me to send each string directly to `atoi()`. Afterwards, I just add the mirror indexes until the start>end.

As I couldn't get a array length and `strtok()` destroys the original string, making backtracking difficult, and I didn't want to have to `realloc()` to resize arrays, I hard-coded an array with a maximum of 9 values.

## C, 107 bytes (uses `argv`)

```
i,j,*k;f(char**s){k=(int*)s;while(s[++i])k[i]=atoi(s[i]);while(++j<=--i)printf("%d\n",k[i]+(i==j?0:k[j]));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3LDoIwFET3fMWNxqQPanzExAjFD0EWWChcwGIAdUH49lqMG13OOZMZJQql7BKNah5ZDmE/ZA1e12Xk/TBs/1GHpnDMol/5rA40UWXaMdbTsZYEzcBoH7xKbHLSx5xjQusYE5kOLTrg4ldyXoVSCKR3NzhoslhlF7Pw5zInKGV13pzquEooDSbrGnBL0cz7kHaF8mF@BcZceFIYPQBADWR2EMGWgiYfFXiTteJg91Yc7e4N)

This version makes use of the fact that `argv` already has been tokenized; as a bonus, it doesn't have a hard-coded limit on the number of numbers! It does, however, assume that `sizeof(int)==sizeof(char*)`, which is truly evil and non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

## **PHP**, 107 bytes

New to this, so please forgive my lack of correct formatting.

```
for($i=0,$a=explode(" ",$argv[1]),$c=count($a);$i<$c/2;$i++)echo$i==$c-$i-1?$a[$i]:$a[$i]+$a[$c-$i-1]."\n";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvtCoIwFMbxWzmM82FDrbQ3SJcXYiJjTh3EztAVXX3L8NOPPw@Pn3yMVT3QzNHKQ4pKmo9/Um84A7bmPL6bvBUpaqnp5QJHJUq0Fep9sZokAoyeCNa3RJ2hzfIaVYO2vW0kf7ah3bGHY2V9jzHmUMARTnCGC1y/5IMlt8Ssh2WiOXTkjeuCGiW5Hw)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! It looks like you've hardcoded the input into your solution. That's not generally valid (among other reasons because it means that your byte count depends on the specific input you chose). Answers either need to be full programs or callable functions. You can have a look at [this list](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for valid I/O methods. (I don't know which option is the shortest in PHP.

Comment: OK thanks, Ill see what the best input mechanism is and update accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 163 bytes

```java
a->{String[] b=a.split(" ");int c=b.length;a="";for(int d=0;d<c/2;d++){a+=(Integer.parseInt(b[d])+Integer.parseInt(b[c-1-d]))+"\n";}if(c%2>0){a+=b[c/2];}return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY@xasMwEIb3PMUhKEgYO4nalIKq7B2aJWOa4SzJrlJHNrIcKMbP7srB7dRM2XT3/3z67oQXTOvGuJP@GlWFbQvvaF2/ALAuGF@gMrDr98FbV4Kn8wOZGGKlDRisgh04kDBiup2LhyPkErO2qWygBAgTEQZK5lllXBk@BUpCRFF7Ou21XAn9qpZc6CRhPSaSvsW/S@OzBn1r4kDzgz6y5J@1StdpjFhCPhwRgy2oeuDb1RUT0yU/isGb0HkHKIZRROumy6toPctfaqvhHG@mv@7IpvMB9t9tMOes7kLWxCRUjrrMU7IGDo/wBBt4JoyJW93byZUyEfhdhD@POxjpJiLSF@AzY1gM4w8)

Well It’s sure not going to win me the bounty, but all in all I’m pretty happy with my work here.

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{String[] b=a.split(" ");    //Create String array to get rid of the pesky spaces
int c=b.length;    
a="";    //Since we now only need the array, we can reuse the original string to save a few bytes
for(int d=0;d<c/2;d++){    //Loop half(even) or half-1(odd) of the array length
  a+=(Integer.parseInt(b[d])+    
   Integer.parseInt(b[c-1-d]))+    //Add the ‘rainbow pairs’ to the output string
  "\n";}    //Add a newline to each sum and end the loop
if(c%2>0){a+=b[c/2];}    //If the number of input numbers is odd, print the middle digit
return a;}    //the Output string is the Input string
```

Comment: Save 28 bytes by using a few tricks and switching to Java 10: `a->{var b=a.split(" ");int c=b.length;a="";for(int d=0;d<c/2;d++)a+=new Long(b[d])+new Long(b[c-1-d])+"\n";return a+(c%2>0?b[c/2]:"");}`