# Sing Baby Shark

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

> "Baby Shark" is a children's song about a family of sharks. Having long been popular as a campfire song, it has been popularized since the mid-2000s by social media, online video and radio. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Shark)

Write program that takes no input, and writes the following text to the standard output or an arbitrary file:

```
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark!
Daddy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Daddy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Daddy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Daddy Shark!
Mommy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Mommy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Mommy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Mommy Shark!
Grandpa Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandpa Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandpa Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandpa Shark!
Grandma Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandma Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandma Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandma Shark!
```

This is code golf — shortest code wins.

Found this on Reddit^[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/aqz4ed/_/)^[2](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/aqkdf9/baby_shark/), and it seems like an interesting challenge to golf.

**Updates:**

No newline between stanzas, that makes it too easy :)

Leading/trailing newlines are okay.

Comment: Is a newline between each stanza (each shark) acceptable? (That's always how I've seen the lyrics written)

Comment: (See above comment, since you've responded to my other ones but seem to have skipped this one)

Comment: Updated original post. I know you could save a few bytes by doing \n before every stanza (that way you don't have to avoid making a newline at the end), but people already started doing it this way so I think keeping it as is is fair.

Comment: Eh, missing a few verses, like all the ones about the swimmers swimming and losing limbs in shark attacks.

Comment: Are leading or trailing newlines or spaces permitted? Can we return an array of lines?

Comment: Leading/trailing newlines are okay, arrays wouldn't be (unless they printed to stdout/a file in the correct format.

Comment: Why is the mommy/daddy and grandma/grandpa order switched in your post? I'd be susprised if any of the answers change byte counts if you corrected it.

Comment: "doo doo doo doo doo doo" is really over-simplified.

Comment: As a parent, I feel the strongest urge to downvote this one.  I'm repressing the urge because that's not how Stack Exchange works.  But if I find myself humming "doo doo doo doo" later today, I'm coming back here and holding you accountable!

Comment: How many people's days ruined now that this is on HNQs?

Comment: @CactusCake, our days are often ruined here by some of the challenges that make into HNQ! :D

Comment: I find myself restraining myself to say "doo doo doo doo" after reading this challenge.

Comment: @CortAmmon I personally found the song so bad I couldn't listen to it long enough for it to become an earworm.  I see "doo doo doo" and think "come on and do the conga" instead. Well, that or "push pineapple, shake a tree"

Comment: How does the Wikipedia article for this not have any lyrics or describe the hand motions?  I guess adults are just _that_ tired of this song...

Comment: The new FizzBuzz? :)

Comment: @CortAmmon been there, done that, got the t-shirt (Christmas present from my daughter).  In fact now I'm humming in danger of humming it to a metal backing track!

Comment: Amazing! I can't believe this is the first time this was thought of.

Comment: @nija I don't think removing the newline makes it any harder...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 40 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
o⅝ηvΒvPΝ┘÷ΖnΨ‘θ{"nOe;‘+ū:" doo”6*+TTPPļ!
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=byV1MjE1RCV1MDNCN3YldTAzOTJ2UCV1MDM5RCV1MjUxOCVGNyV1MDM5Nm4ldTAzQTgldTIwMTgldTAzQjglN0IlMjJuT2UlM0IldTIwMTgrJXUwMTZCJTNBJTIyJTIwZG9vJXUyMDFENiorVFRQUCV1MDEzQyUyMQ__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 83):

### Emojicode, 292 bytes (140 characters)

```
Baby➡️bDaddy➡️yMommy➡️oGrandpa➡️gGrandma➡️a Shark➡️s doo➡️db y o g a➡️fm fi⏩⏩0 3❗️m s d d d d d d️❗️m s!❗️
```

[Run it](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9JNfv//8P8/sYP83vbP8yfssQpMakSRD@at/D9jv4kENMlMSUFSQzM9M3PzUUSywcx3YsS81IKEhGi6XDRXCRRMFMhOCOxKBshWAwWTMnPRwilAJ20IkmhUiFfIV0BqKm3DSKeBlTSlKuQBnVxU@aH@W1TH/WvBCIDBeNHc6cD1UDkZjQA6VW5CsUKKQgIEgKqgKvrRFIHslwRRID4yCp6O///BwA)

Expanded out:

```
  Baby ➡️ b
  Daddy ➡️ y
  Mommy ➡️ o
  Grandpa ➡️ g
  Grandma ➡️ a
   Shark ➡️ s
   doo ➡️ d
  b y o g a➡️f
  m f
    i⏩⏩0 3❗️
      m s d d d d d d️❗️
    
    m s!❗️
```

Explained (per the [Emojicode](https://www.emojicode.org/docs/reference/welcome.html) doc):

The same as a `{` and `}` (e.g. a code block)

The "program start" (e.g. `int main()`)

```
Baby ➡️ b
```

Variable assignment (e.g. `const char* b = "Baby";`)

```
b y o g a➡️f
```

Says, create a list of values between  and  and assign (➡️) to `f` (e.g. `const char* f[] = {b,y,o,g,a};`)

```
m f ...
```

This line says to loop over the elements in `f` using the alias `m`, where the `...` is the code between  and .

```
 i ⏩⏩ 0 3❗️ ...
```

This line says to loop over the range [0,3), where the `...` is the code between  and .

```
 ... ️❗️
```

This line says to print the format specified in `...` (e.g. `printf("%s\n");`)

The code translated to C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const char* b = "Baby";
  const char* y = "Daddy";
  const char* o = "Mommy";
  const char* g = "Grandpa";
  const char* a = "Grandma";
  const char* s = " Shark";
  const char* d = " doo";
  const char* f[] = {b,y,o,g,a};
  int m = 0, i = 0;
  for (; m < 5; ++m) {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      printf("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s\n", f[m], s, d, d, d, d, d, d);
    }
    printf("%s%s!\n", f[m], s);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Following this, the original code (posted below for posterity) had some issues; mostly that the  block was not included for those who wish to run it, and the emoji's were not actually properly escaped, to that, here is the actual running version of that code:

### Original modified to run: Emojicode, 224 bytes (67 characters)

```
➡️fm fi⏩⏩0 3❗️m️❗️m!❗️
```

Expanded out:

```
  
    
    
    
    
    
   ➡️ f
   m f 
     i ⏩⏩ 0 3❗️
      m️❗️
    
    m!❗️
```

Which produces the output:

```
!



!



!



!



!
```

[Run it](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9JNfv//8P8/sYP83vbgXjFh/lTlnyYP3EbhAazVyDYSzYiiW9BYm@F0L1tj@YtfL@jPw3IbcpVSIOYOqUp88P8tqmP@lcCkYGC8aO504FqIHIzGoD0qlyI9mUdH@ZPWokdg41fBdQH192JoVsRpgxZTW/n//8A)

Where in you have the individual emoji's representing the words:

```
 -> Baby
 -> Daddy
 -> Mommy
 -> Grandpa
 -> Grandma
 -> Shark
 -> doo
```

### Original: Emojicode, 138 bytes (47 characters)

```
➡️fm fi⏩⏩0 3❗️m❗️m!❗️
```

Expanded out:

```
➡️f
m f
   i ⏩⏩ 0 3❗️
     m ❗️
  
   m !❗️
```

Comment: Points for creativity, but this doesn't produce the required output

Comment: Welcome to the site! As JoKing was getting at we require that answers do exactly what the question ask here.  This means that while your interpretation of the challenge is creative this answer should either be fixed to produce the correct output or deleted.

Comment: While this answer is creative, it does not follow the requirements of the challenge, and thus is not valid - the text must be output exactly as stated in the challenge.

Comment: Please either modify this answer to produce the correct output, or delete it.

Comment: You need half the poop emojis, since  is "doo doo" :) While I agree it's not a valid entry, you definitely deserve points for creativity.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When I try to [run this code online](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9JNfv//8P83vUf5k/c9mH@lCVOiUmVIBrIXwGiXRJTUqACSzaCaN/83FyYii0g2r0oMS@lIBEqtBUulAsVWtYBooMzEouyIQKTVoJohZT8fAi/t@3RvIXvd/SnAblNuQpAqrcdxMz8ML9t6qP@lUBkoGD8aO50oBqI3IyGXIi5IKMwMVxpJ1ypIkLs/38A), I get an error. (It also counts 98 characters instead of 94). Am I missing something?

Comment: +1 now you've also included the textual output. :) But I indeed noticed the same thing as @DJMcMayhem in both Emojicode and Emojicode 0.5 on TIO. Is TIO a different version and it therefore errors? Or is your submission a function instead of full program and do we need anything more in the header/footer? I don't know Emojicode, but I'm curious why it doesn't work on TIO.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem .. I honestly didn't think this would get such recognition, so I learned Emojicode in about 5 minutes and threw together this answer in about 15 minutes for fun :) That being said, I've since had a few more minutes to learn the language more and have modified the answer to run properly. That'll teach me to joke around!❗️

Comment: This answer has earned more reputation than I have. Emojicode for the win!

Answer (score 42):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>108</del> 107 bytes

```
00000000: bd42 01e8 1600 bd47 01e8 1000 bd4d 01e8  .B.....G.....M..
00000010: 0a00 bd53 01e8 0400 c646 056d b409 b104  ...S.....F.m....
00000020: 8bd5 cd21 ba5b 01cd 21e2 06ba 6701 cd21  ...!.[..!...g..!
00000030: c3b3 06ba 6201 cd21 4b75 fbba 6801 cd21  ....b..!Ku..h..!
00000040: ebde 4261 6279 2444 6164 6479 244d 6f6d  ..Baby$Daddy$Mom
00000050: 6d79 2447 7261 6e64 7061 2420 5368 6172  my$Grandpa$ Shar
00000060: 6b24 2064 6f6f 2421 0d0a 24              k$ doo$!..$
```

Unassembled:

```
BD 0142         MOV  BP, OFFSET BABY        ; Baby Shark
E8 011C         CALL VERSE
BD 0147         MOV  BP, OFFSET DADDY       ; Daddy Shark
E8 011C         CALL VERSE
BD 014D         MOV  BP, OFFSET MOMMY       ; Mommy Shark
E8 011C         CALL VERSE
BD 0153         MOV  BP, OFFSET GRAND       ; Grandpa/ma Shark
E8 011C         CALL VERSE
C6 46 05 6D     MOV  BYTE PTR [BP][5], 'm'  ; change 'p' to 'm'
            VERSE:
B4 09           MOV  AH, 9                  ; DOS API display string function
B1 04           MOV  CL, 4                  ; loop verse counter
            LOOP_VERSE:
8B D5           MOV  DX, BP                 ; load shark name from BP
CD 21           INT  21H                    ; display shark name
BA 015B         MOV  DX, OFFSET SHARK       ; load 'Shark'
CD 21           INT  21H                    ; display 'Shark'
E2 06           LOOP LOOP_DOO               ; if not last line, write 'doo's
BA 0167         MOV  DX, OFFSET BANG        ; otherwise end with a bang
CD 21           INT  21H                    ; display !, CRLF
C3              RET                         ; return from CALL or to DOS
            LOOP_DOO:
B3 06           MOV  BL, 6                  ; loop 'doo' 6 times
BA 0162         MOV  DX, OFFSET DOO         ; load 'doo' string
            PRINT_DOO:
CD 21           INT  21H                    ; display 'doo'
4B              DEC  BX                     ; decrement doo count
75 FB           JNZ  PRINT_DOO              ; if not last doo, start again
BA 0168         MOV  DX, OFFSET CRLF        ; load CRLF string
CD 21           INT  21H                    ; display CRLF
EB DE           JMP  LOOP_VERSE             ; repeat verse

BABY    DB  'Baby$'
DADDY   DB  'Daddy$'
MOMMY   DB  'Mommy$'
GRAND   DB  'Grand'
PA      DB  'pa$'
SHARK   DB  ' Shark$'
DOO     DB  ' doo$'
BANG    DB  '!'
CRLF    DB  0DH,0AH,'$'
```

[Try it online!](http://twt86.co?c=vUIB6BYAvUcB6BAAvU0B6AoAvVMB6AQAxkYFbbQJsQSJ6s0hulsBzSHiBrpnAc0hw7MGumIBzSFLdfu6aAHNIeveQmFieSREYWRkeSRNb21teSRHcmFuZHBhJCBTaGFyayQgZG9vJCENCiQ%3D)

***Output***

[image: DOS DIR, SHARK]

*(TODO: update this screenshot for one less byte...)*

Comment: You absolute madman.

Comment: When you said `Download SHARK.COM!`, I immediately thought of computer viruses.

Comment: @gwaugh I was kidding

Comment: @gwaugh But it's 109 bytes

Answer (score 21):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 93 bytes

```python
for w in"Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma".split():w+=" Shark";print(w+" doo"*6+"\n")*3+w+"!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SKFcITNPySkxqVLBJTElpVLBNz83t1LBvSgxL6UgEULnJirpFRfkZJZoaFqVa9sqKQRnJBZlK1kXFGXmlWiUaysppOTnK2mZaSvF5ClpahlrA4UUlf7/BwA)

**94 bytes**

```python
for w in"Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma".split():print((" doo"*6+"\n%s Shark"%w)*4)[25:]+"!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SKFcITNPySkxqVLBJTElpVLBNz83t1LBvSgxL6UgEULnJirpFRfkZJZoaFoVFGXmlWhoKCmk5OcraZlpK8XkqRYrBGckFmUrqZZraploRhuZWsVqKykq/f8PAA)

Answer (score 20):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>50</s> 41 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
“‡ÍÊÐ¢×myîºpaîºma“#ð«'ã¢«™v…doo6иyšÐy'!«»
```

<s>Last part `v4FN3Qiy'!«ë…doo6иyšðý},` can definitely be golfed a bit..</s> And I was right, -9 bytes thanks to *@Emigna* (even more than I was expecting).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AVAAr/9vc2FiaWX//@KAnOKAocONw4rDkMKiw5dtecOuwrpwYcOuwrptYeKAnCPDsMKrJ8OjwqLCq@KEonbigKZkb2820Lh5xaHDkHknIcKrwrv//w)

**Explanation:**

```python
“‡ÍÊÐ¢×myîºpaîºma“ # Push dictionary string "baby daddy mommy grandpa grandma"
 #                 # Split by spaces: ["baby","daddy","mommy","grandpa","grandma"]
  ð«               # Append a space to each
    'ã¢«          '# Append dictionary string "shark" to each
        ™          # Title-case each word
v                  # Loop `y` over these strings
 …doo              #  Push string "doo"
     6и            #  Repeat it 6 times as list
       yš          #  Prepend the string `y` at the front of the list
         Ð         #  Triplicate this list
 y'!«             '#  Push string `y`, concatted with a "!"
 »                 #  Join everything on the stack by newlines
                   #  (and each list implicitly by spaces)
                   # (and after the loop, output the result implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“‡ÍÊÐ¢×myîºpaîºma“` is `"baby daddy mommy grandpa grandma"` and `'ã¢` is `"shark"`.

Comment: You can golf 9 bytes of that last bit with `v…doo6иyšÐy'!«»`

Comment: @Emigna You even golfed more than I was expected, thanks! Smart way of using the triplicate and `»`!

Answer (score 14):

## PowerShell, <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>85</s> <s>80</s> <s>79</s> 76 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to @mazzy
-1 byte thanks to @Joey
-3 bytes thanks to @AdmBorkBork

```
echo Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma|%{,(($a="$_ Shark")+" doo"*6)*3;"$a!"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PzU5I1/BKTGpUsElMSWlUsE3Pze3UsG9KDEvpSARQucm1qhW62hoqCTaKqnEKwRnJBZlK2lqKymk5OcraZlpahlbK6kkKirV/v8PAA)

We've certainly come a long way.

## PowerShell (with Text to Speech), 156 bytes

This is NOT up to spec, but it's kinda funny. Thanks to @rkeet for the idea!

```
Add-Type -a System.Speech;echo Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma|%{(New-Object Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak((($a="$_ Shark")+" doo"*6)*3+" $a")}
```

.NET Text to speech pronunciation is... well... interesting. Keep this in mind when listening. Enjoy!

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X7e4ICezRMkpMalSwSUxJaVSwTc/N7dSwb0oMS@lIBFC5yYq1ahW62goqcQrBGckFmUraSsppOTnK2mZaWoZW8OFFZVq//8HAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Comment: You can save another byte by assigning `"$_ Shark"` to a variable and re-using it.

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PzU5I1/BKTGpUsElMSWlUsE3Pze3UsG9KDEvpSARQucm1qhW62hoqCTaKqnEKwRnJBZlK2lqKymk5OcraZlpahlbK6kkKirV/v8PAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") using `echo` instead of `-split`.

Comment: I think you should have a "text to speech" in there as well :p For the hell of it tried to combine it a bit with [this code](https://www.pdq.com/blog/powershell-text-to-speech-examples/), didn't quite work :-)

Comment: @rkeet Challenge accepted! I am currently puzzling this out.

Answer (score 12):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 135 bytes

```java
v->{for(var s:"Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma".split(" "))System.out.println(((s+=" Shark")+" doo".repeat(6)+"\n").repeat(3)+s+"!");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4/T8MwEMX3forjJltRvSAxUNoBkJg6RWIBhmucFKf@J/scKary2YMpYnq637t370aaaDvqy9pZyhmOZDxcNwCxnKzpIDNxlSkYDa56ouVk/PnjCyids7ytAoz1iCpsrBqK79gEr16Cz8X16em9Rg8w7Ndpe7gOIYmJEuRHfKbTDK@k9QzH4NwMb4m8jvSnjlDlaA0LBJSynTP3ToXCKtZ@tl4IkZs9QvtN6YKyQdAhoEp97InFQwWfHuX/fC@b3OAdyt2y7m4vD4q6ro8sfLFW/rJls6w/)

Comment: Which JDK version? I'm guessing 8+ (lambdas).

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Given the `repeat` method, it's version 11+

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>122</strike> <strike>113</strike> <strike>108</strike> <strike>106</strike> 104 bytes

```hs
s=" Shark";m=do x<-words"Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma";("aaa">>x++s++(s>>" doo")++"\n")++x++s++"!\n"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCsIwEEbhq4yzShk8QU0WIrhy1a2bX0aotJOUpGJz@qh09fF4I8r0nOfWimcaRuSJe/OaaDsdPylr4TMelS5QrXRLZpWuGVEX7Bq4dwyAQ9hEiogrITBpStyJ8D3@2Q8fftUMr0ielvc6rNlZ174)

- `"aaa">>x` replicates `x` 3 times, as `"aaa"` has length 3.
- `s>>" doo"` replicates `" doo"` 6 times, as `" Shark"` has length 6!
- *2 bytes saved thanks to @Fox*
- *2 bytes saved thanks to @Laikoni*

Comment: Welcome to the site! We allow just [generating a fixed output string as an expression](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12924/20260), so you can omit the `main=putStr`. See also the [Haskell rules summary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11935/20260).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Nice saving with `s>>`.

Comment: @xnor thanks for the links!

Comment: @starsandspirals I also recommend taking a look at the [Haskell golf tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell) if you haven't already.

Comment: `m=(stuff)` can just be `m=stuff` for two fewer bytes

Comment: 104 bytes by using `do`-notation: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCsIwEEbhq4yzShk8QU0WIrhy1a2bX0aotJOUpGJz@qh09fF4I8r0nOfWimcaRuSJe/OaaDsdPylr4TMelS5QrXRLZpWuGVEX7Bq4dwyAQ9hEiogrITBpStyJ8D3@2Q8fftUMr0ielvc6rNlZ174 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>77</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```
Baby¶Daddy¶MommyGpaGma
G
¶Grand
.+
$&s$&s$&s$&S!
s
S6$*O¶
O
 doo
S
 Shark
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fyykxqfLQNpfElBQg5Zufm1vpXpDonpvI5c51aJt7UWJeCpeeNpeKWjEMBStyFXMFm6lo@R/axuXPpZCSn88VzKUQnJFYlP3/PwA) Explanation:

```
Baby¶Daddy¶MommyGpaGma
G
¶Grand
```

Insert the relations on separate lines.

```
.+
$&s$&s$&s$&S!¶
```

Expand into four lines.

```
s
S6$*O¶
O
 doo
S
 Shark
```

Expand the placeholders.

<s>69</s> 68 bytes in [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) 1:

```
Baby¶Daddy¶MommyGpaGma
G
¶Grand
.+
$& Shark
.+
3*$($&6*$( doo)¶)$&!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8spMany0DaXxJQUIOWbn5tb6V6Q6J6byOXOdWibe1FiXgqXnjaXippCcEZiUTaIbayloqGiZgYkFVLy8zUPbdNUUVP8/x8A) Explanation:

```
Baby¶Daddy¶MommyGpaGma
G
¶Grand
```

Insert the relations on separate lines.

```
.+
$& Shark
```

Append Shark to each.

```
.+
3*$($&6*$( doo)¶)$&!
```

Expand into whole verses.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, <strike>105</strike> <strike>97</strike> 96 bytes

```
for x in"Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma":z=x+' Shark';print((z+' doo'*6+"\n")*3+z+"!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPySkxqVJJR8klMSUFRPvm5@aCaPeixLyUgkQYKzdRyaqgKDOvREOjQltdITgjsShbHchIyc9X1zLTVorJU9LUMtau0FECSykqaf7/DwA)

A simple Python 3 solution. (9 bytes saved by Jo King and Quintec)

Comment: The parentheses around `' doo'*6` are unnecessary and you have unnecessary whitespace there

Comment: What quintec said... [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPySkxqVJJR8klMSUFRPvm5@aCaPeixLyUgkQYKzdRyaqgKDOvREOjQltdITgjsShbHchIyc9X1zLTVorJU9LUMtau0FECSykqaf7/DwA)

Comment: Huh, didn't know you could do lists without `[]`, or that you didn't need a newline for `:`. Thanks!

Comment: @ReverseCold technically where there's no `[]` it's a tuple not a list, but that's not relevant to this program

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPySkxqVJJR8klMSUFRPvm5@aCaPeixLyUgkQYKzdRyarKtkJbXSE4I7EoW926oCgzr0RDowookpKfr65lpq0Uk6ekqWWsXaWtpKik@f8/AA) by setting `x+' Shark'` to a variable

Comment: This seems to work in 2.7 as well?

Comment: @uhoh In 2.7 you can get rid of the brackets in the print function and cut it down to 94 bytes

Comment: You can shave one more character if you do `x+=` instead of `z=x+` (replacing subsequent uses of `z` with `x`)

Answer (score 9):

## bash, 78 bytes

```
printf %s\\n {Baby,Daddy,Mommy,Grand{p,m}a}\ Shark{" `echo doo{,,}{,}`"{,,},!}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##FcY7CoAwDADQq0TBLacQwcnJtUNTq1SkH1qXEnL2iG96jlpQLfVO7wVTMyYBz@Q6LuR9xy3H2HGtlDwXjEJiYA9UHx7BnkfI4HNmRGEUO/7BQVQ/)

73 bytes if trailing space is allowed

```
echo '
'{Baby,Daddy,Mommy,Grand{p,m}a}\ Shark{" `echo doo{,,}{,}`"{,,},!}
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>79</s> 78 bytes

```perl6
(<Baby Daddy Mommmy Grandpa Grandma>X~" Shark"X~ |((" doo"x 6)xx 3),'!')>>.say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1/DxikxqVLBJTElpVLBNz83N7dSwb0oMS@lIBFC5ybaRdQpKQRnJBZlK0XUKdRoaCgppOTnK1UomGlWVCgYa@qoK6pr2tnpFSdW/v8PAA)

Pretty simple.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
 <...>X~                                  # Combine family members
        " Shark"X~                        # With "Shark" and
                   |((" doo"x 6)xx 3)     # doo repeated 6 times then 3 times
                                     ,'!' # Then !
(                                        )>>.say  # And print each line
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 82 bytes

```ruby
%w(Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma).map{|a|puts [a+" Shark"]*4*(" doo"*6+?\n)+?!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X7VcwykxqVLBJTElpVLBNz83t1LBvSgxL6UgEULnJmrq5SYWVNck1hSUlhQrRCdqKykEZyQWZSvFaploaSgppOTnK2mZadvH5Glq2yvW/v8PAA)

Comment: It took me a while to understand that you used the "doo" part as array seperators. Good job :)

Comment: `?\n` can be replaced with `$/`.

Answer (score 6):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 124 bytes

```
/*/$!
//)/Grand//(/Baby//'/Mommy//&/Daddy//%/ doo//$/ Shark//#/a")//"/$%%%%%%
/("("("(*&"&"&"&*'"'"'"'*)p#p#p#pa*)m#m#m#ma$!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcY7DsIwEADRPqdI1s7HbuYOCImKihNs5EiRwBjFVU5vop3XTP1o3bfaGhE/dBB4HPpNsHDT9YSZZ8n5mom7pnTNSJ9KAU//2vV4g0MlgOBHq2MREycxcRYTw88ZjSE7o35o7Q8)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 104 bytes

More golfing to follow.

```
_=>`Baby
Daddy
Mommy
Grandpa
Grandma`.replace(/.+/g,x=>(s=(x+=` Shark`)+` doo`.repeat(6)+`
`)+s+s+x+`!`)
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##JYrLDsIgEADvfEW9LUHbmzd6MCY9efID3BVofZRuA42Br0eimcMkk3nRh6IJz3U7LGxdGXW56R5PdM/iTNZmcWHvsxgCLXalvz1hG9w6k3HQtaqb9kn3EDUkpbG5Pii8USpsLPNvdLTBsQZRa6wkhTuUxfASeXbtzBOMIGX5Ag)

Comment: This technically isn't a valid solution since it neither writes to a file or logs it. Though if you make it a valid solution by wrapping with a `console.log()`, you can make it not a lambda declaration (only 10 character gain)

Comment: @Delioth, returning from a function is *perfectly* valid on this site. Have a look on Meta for our default I/O rules.

Comment: I would generally agree, but this question specifically states that the program "writes the following text to the standard output or an arbitrary file"

Answer (score 6):

## PostgreSQL, <s>162</s> <s>156</s> 138 bytes

```sql
select a||' Shark'||replace(b,'1',repeat(' doo',6))from unnest('{Baby,Daddy,Mommy,Grandpa,Grandma}'::text[])a,unnest('{1,1,1,!}'::text[])b
```

Ungolfed

```sql
select 
    a || ' Shark' || replace(b,'1',repeat(' doo',6))
from unnest('{Baby,Daddy,Mommy,Grandpa,Grandma}'::text[]) a
    ,unnest('{1,1,1,!}'::text[]) b
```

Saved <s>6</s> 24 bytes thanks to [`@Nahuel Fouilleul`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745/nahuel-fouilleul)!

- use `||` instead of `concat()`
- use `unnest('{foo,bar}'::text[])` instead of `regexp_split_to_table('foo,bar')`

[DB<>fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3eXzvhDLVnxsuwRy3qAuJs/5)

Comment: -6 bytes using `||`instead of concat 
[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3eXzvhDLVnxsuwRy3qAuJs/4)

Comment: `select a||' Shark'||replace(b,'1',repeat(' doo',6))from unnest('{Baby,Daddy,Mommy,Grandpa,Grandma}'::text[])a,unnest('{1,1,1,!}'::text[])b`

Answer (score 6):

## [Emotion](https://github.com/Quantum64/Emotion), 65 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0///?state=JTdCJTIybW9kZSUyMiUzQSUyMmNvZGVwYWdlJTIyJTdE)

```
❤
```

Explanation

```
 Push literal doo
 Push five copies of the first stack value.
 Collapse all stack values into a string seperated by spaces, then push that string.
 Push literal  Shark 
 Push the difference of the second and first stack values.
 Store the first stack value in the a register.
 Push literal Grandma
 Push literal Grandpa
 Push literal Mommy
 Push literal Daddy
❤ Push literal Baby
 Push literal 6
 Push stack values into a list of the size of the first stack value starting with the second stack value.
 Enter an iteration block over the first stack value and push the iteration element register at the begining of each loop.
 Push three copies of the first stack value.
 Push literal 3
 Enter an iteration block over the first stack value.
 Push the value contained in the a register.
 Push the sum of the second and first stack values.
 Print the first stack value, then a newline.
 Ends a control flow structure.
 Push literal  Shark!
 Push the sum of the second and first stack values.
 Print the first stack value, then a newline.
 Ends a control flow structure.
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0///?state=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)

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>158</s> 115 bytes

*Saved a lot of bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*

```
>4>1-&0'krahS '0l3-.
~ ^oa~<
ooo:?!/1-'ood 'o
\ao'!'^?$6:&~
\!?:o
^'ybaB'
^'yddaD'
^'ymmoM'
^'apdnarG'
^'amdnarG'
;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/387EzlBXzUA9uygxI1hB3SDHWFePq04hLj@xzoYrPz/fyl5R31BXPT8/RUE9nysmMV9dUT3OXsXMSq2OK0bR3iqfK069MinRSR1Ep6QkuoAZubn5viBGYkFKXmKRO5iZC2Va//8PAA) You may also want to paste the code in at [fishlanguage.com](https://fishlanguage.com/), where you can see an animation of it <s>swimming</s> running.

Comment: [121 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/385EQUHBzlBXzUA9uygxI1hB3SDHWFePS6FM0d5KwSYfCNQVUoCEriFXvl1dYn6cGVecXZ2alX2cuqJ6fiKXTRxQYT5XnHplUqKTOohOSUl0ATNyc/N9QYzEgpS8xCJ3MDMXyrT@/x8A), mostly through rearranging the baby/daddy/... to multiple lines instead of one line. There's more to golf though

Comment: [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/387EzlBXzUA9uygxI1hB3SDHWFePq04hLj@xzoYrPz/fyl5R31BXPT8/RUE9nysmMV9dUT3OXsXMSq2OK0bR3iqfK069MinRSR1Ep6QkuoAZubn5viBGYkFKXmKRO5iZC2Va//8PAA)

Comment: @JoKing Ah, thanks. I tend to assume (mostly from working with BitCycle) that fewer lines are better, but in this case that's not true because of the different string lengths.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 97 bytes

```hs
unlines[x++s++p|x<-words"Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma",p<-[a,a,a,"!"]]
s=" Shark"
a=s>>" doo"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcW9DoIwEADgnac4by28AWUwJk5OjMBwUhRCfy49iDTx2a0x5hu@mWSdrM1O93n3dvGTdIdSohS/j7p6hWgEz3RPcCFjEtyCcwmukbxh@u8IS66rjsofPOEwFKIR2pniigVpaRoEEwJmR4sHDbxv7RbB5c/4sPSUXI3MXw)

This is an optimization of [the Haskell solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180033/20260) by [starsandspirals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85486/starsandspirals). The new trick is to iterate over the rows of each stanza with an inner loop, and join the lines using `unlines`, saving the need to explicitly insert newlines.

The suffixes of the four lines are `[a,a,a,"!"]`, where `a` is `" doo"` replicated 6 times with `a=s>>" doo"`, where starsandspirals cleverly reuses the six-character-long `s=" Shark"`. Writing `[a,a,a,...]` looks a bit silly, but I'm not seeing a shorter way.

A list-monad version is the same length but it looks cool.

```hs
unlines$(++).(++s)<$>words"Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma"<*>[a,a,a,"!"]
s=" Shark"
a=s>>" doo"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcWxDoIwEIDhnac4Lwwi6hPQDsbEyYlRHU6KQui1TQ9i@vJWjfmT7x9Ipt7azOqaF2dH10u5rutq/0WqptQvH43gge4JjmRMgrNnTnCK5Eyg/5mw2egLbX/hCm@FKIR2oDhhQUq0RjDeY2YaHSgIy9zOETi/u4elp@RdF8IH)

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>153</s> 131 bytes

```cs
foreach(var i in"Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma".Split()){var a=i+" Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo\n";Write(a+a+a+i+" Shark!\n");}
```

Thanks to @Destrogio for saving 30 bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb8oNTE5Q6MssUghUyEzT8kpMalSwSUxJaVSwTc/N7dSwb0oMS@lIBFC5yYq6QUX5GSWaGhqVoP0JNpmaispBGckFmUrpOTnY8MxeUrW4UWZJakaidogCNegCJTRtK79/x8A)

Comment: 133 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb8oNTE5Q6MssUghUyEzT8kpMalSwSUxJaVSwTc/N7dSwb0oMS@lIBFC5yYq6QUX5GSWaGhqVoP0JNpmaispBGckFmUrpOTnY8MxeUrW4UWZJakaidq2YATXogiU07Su/f8fAA "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [whenyouaccidentallylose100endorsementsinnationstates](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/whenyouaccidentallylose100endorsementsinnationstates) - <s>123,065</s> <s>121,716</s> <s>113,695</s> <s>100,889</s> 98,554 bytes

[The program](https://pastebin.com/CSyW5wSz)

<s>I'll golf this later.</s> Done.

<s>I'll golf this more (later)</s> Done.

<s>I'll golf this even more later.</s> DONE.

<s>I'll get the byte count to 5 digits later.</s> YAY.

I'll get the byte count to 4 digits (I don't know if this is possible, but I do know it is impossible to get 3 digits with my current approach).

Comment: What the hell is this? I love it

Comment: @AdrianZhang A programming language hard to program it. Also, the program looks like it's a person screaming ('AAAAAAAAAAA...')

Comment: Both links are dead.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>131</s> <s>122</s> 120 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

-2 more bytes, also Giuseppe

```r
`?`=c
s="Shark"
for(x in "Baby"?"Daddy"?"Mommy"?"Grandpa"?"Grandma")cat(rep("
"?x?s?rep("doo",6),3)?"
"?x?paste0(s,"!"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8E@wTaZq9hWKTgjsShbiSstv0ijQiEzT0HJKTGpUsleySUxJQVE@@bn5oJo96LEvJSCRBgrN1FJMzmxRKMotUBDiUvJvsK@2B7MTsnPV9Ix09Qx1rSHiBckFpekGmgU6ygpKmlq/v8PAA)

Quite proud of this actually, especially with R being rather poor at handling strings. I started out using `cat(sapply(...))`, but realized a for loop shaves off a few bytes.

Abusing the `"?"=c` significantly reduced the amount of parentheses needed.

I also tried to do `"*"=rep` to repeat the individual lines of the stanzas and the "doos", but that did not shave off any bytes.

## 111 bytes

Giuseppe and ASCII-only's alternative, (and better) solution that fixes some spacing issues.

```r
write(paste0(rep(c("Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"),,,4)," Shark",c(rep(strrep(" doo",6),3),"!")),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVoyCxuCTVQKMotUAjWUPJKTGpUklHySUxJQVE@@bn5oJo96LEvJSCRBgrN1FJU0dHx0RTR0khOCOxKFtJJxlsQnFJEYhSUkjJz1fSMdPUMQYqUVTS1NQx1Pz/HwA)

Comment: [122 bytes](https://tio.run/##Nci9CsIwFIbhPVdRvykHMggFt3BABKdO3kCPTUWR/HDSoV59JEOn9@HV1mae/WKqx@Mt@oVJHgbmldXuwycNuMrzB8ZNQuidcoy9d5UUihyKAlpks7oWm3jnyl0IOcNdyI3E/Rap23q21eEEotb@)

Comment: As always, thank you for your wise input @Giuseppe. I should have noticed those golfs

Comment: [120 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8E@wTaZq9hWKTgjsShbiSstv0ijQiEzT0HJKTGpUsleySUxJQVE@@bn5oJo96LEvJSCRBgrN1FJMzmxRKMotUBDiUvJvsK@2B7MTsnPV9Ix09Qx1rSHiBckFpekGmgU6ygpKmlq/v8PAA)

Comment: I think you should ask OP whether leading spaces are ok

Comment: @ASCII-only I'm pretty certain it's a leading newline, and the additional rules near the bottom say that that is okay. The OP even detailed this concern in the comments, saying "Updated original post. I know you could save a few bytes by doing \n before every stanza (that way you don't have to avoid making a newline at the end), but people already started doing it this way so I think keeping it as is is fair."

Comment: Do you not also print two spaces before every line since you're printing a vector :|

Comment: @ASCII-only I found a [120 byter](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0ErwTaZK0E7wbYgsbgk1YCrvCizJFWjKLVAQ8kpMalSSUvJJTElBUT75ufmgmj3osS8lIJEGCs3UUlbSSE4I7EoW0kn1dZEUxukubikCGyGQkp@vpKOmaaOsaaWkqKSjiEQ6igpaf7/DwA) that has none of these problems.

Comment: @Giuseppe wow, vectorization, nice. I forgot R has nice vectorization like this. [114?](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0ErwTaZK0E7wbYgsbgk1YCrvCizJFWjKLVAQ8kpMalSSUvJJTElBUT75ufmgmj3osS8lIJEGCs3UUlbSSE4I7EoW0kn1dZEUxukubikCGyGQkp@vpKOmaaOsaaWkqKSjqHm//8A) [also 114?](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0E7wbYgsbgk1YCrvCizJFWjKLVAI1lDySkxqVJJR8klMSUFRPvm5@aCaPeixLyUgkQYKzdRSVNbSSE4I7EoW0kn1dZEUzsZbEJxSRGIUlJIyc9X0jHT1DHW1FFSVNLUMdT8/x8A)

Comment: [also 114](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0E7wbYgsbgk1YCrvCizJFWjKLVAI1lDySkxqVJJR8klMSUFRPvm5@aCaPeixLyUgkQYKzdRSVNbSSE4I7EoW0lHR8dEUzsZbEJxSRGIUlJIyc9X0jHT1DHW1FFSVNLUMdT8/x8A)

Comment: @ASCII-only hah, I had found a very similar [115 byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179998/sing-baby-shark/180096#comment434387_180133) commented below...So naturally we can combine to get this [111 byte monstrosity](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVoyCxuCTVQKMotUAjWUPJKTGpUklHySUxJQVE@@bn5oJo96LEvJSCRBgrN1FJU0dHx0RTR0khOCOxKFtJJxlsQnFJEYhSUkjJz1fSMdPUMQYqUVTS1NQx1Pz/HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>123</s> 122 bytes

-1 byte thanks to ceilingcat

```c
#define A" doo doo"
f(i){for(i=20;i--;)printf("%.7s Shark%s\n","GrandmaGrandpaMommy\0 Daddy\0 Baby"+i/4*7,i%4?A A A:"!");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxCsIwFABn8xXxSSHRVosUCgaRiuDk5Nrl2TT6kCQldSml3x6rHMdt12TPpolxpVtDruUVcO39T2BGkByND4KO@1xRlinZBXIfIyDZlj2/vzC8k752kMI1oNMW/@nw5q0d6pxfUOtfz/gYYEO7Yl2mlBSnis8cYAlSTXE@covkhGQjWxghFZviFw)

Comment: What are the rules for C? No need for `main()`, or `#include` for `printf`?

Comment: @BoBTFish: Not C-specific but generally it is allowed to use any function (name doesn't matter, indeed it can be an unnamed lambda or similar). And languages are defined by their (any) implementation, since this works on `gcc` (only generates warnings, but compiles fine) it is valid.

Comment: I realised the lack of `#include` was only an error because I was still compiling as C++, but I still couldn't get it to compile without renaming your function to `main`.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 104 bytes

```
foreach([Baby,Daddy,Mommy,Grandpa,Grandma]as$s)echo$t=$s.str_pad($u=" Shark",30," doo"),"
$t
$t
$s$u!
";
```

Run with `php -nr '<code>'` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83c8946a85d4bd60c23e1666dc05cb703d2bd98d).

Comment: [103 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLUhOTMzSinRKTKnVcElNSKnV883NzK3XcixLzUgoSIXRuYmxisUqxZmpyRr5Kia0Sl0qxgpJecUlRfEFiikZwRmJRto6RpY6SQkp@vpKmjpJKiUoJSA1YRlHJ@v9/AA "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://r-project.org), <strike>139</strike> <strike>138</strike> 137 bytes

```
s='Shark';d='doo';cat(paste(rep(c('Baby','Daddy','Mommy','Grandpa','Grandma'),e=4),c(rep(paste(s,d,d,d,d,d,d),3),paste0(s,'!'))),sep='
')
```

There's probably a better way to do the 'doo's but I wasn't able to get it.

**Edit:** 
Replaced '\n' with actual new line at JDL's suggestion;
Removed trailing newline at  Giuseppe's suggestion.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RYy9CsMwEIP3vEUn@eCGQLsFLyGQqVOe4OozBIJrY2fp07v5IQQNn5CQcq3FYpolL@jUQmNE52Q1ScrqTfbJOINePj8wBlHd@Y4h7ByzfDXJ5YKA2NsXsTuG50VhvUX8JD7ydivwABFx8cmiAdX6Bw)

Comment: welcome to ppcg! At the very least, replacing the "\n" with a literal newline will save one byte.

Comment: Thanks, I did so, and then realized my output was bit off so I updated that, sadly it resulted in more bytes.

Comment: I believe you have a trailing newline for an extra byte

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>126</s> 125 bytes

```
cat(paste(rep(c("Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"),,,4),c(rep("Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo",3),"Shark!")),sep="
")
```

This doesn't feel as 'clever' as either [CT Hall](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180114) or [Sumner18](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180096)'s answers, but by avoiding the overhead of defining variables it comes out smaller.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMgsbgkVaMotUAjWUPJKTGpUklHySUxJQVE@@bn5oJo96LEvJSCRBgrN1FJU0dHx0RTJxmsUSk4I7EoWyElPx8bVtIx1tSBKFFU0tTUKU4tsFXiUtL8/x8A)

Edit: Saved 1 byte by using carriage return as per comment by Jonathan Frech

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! I have added links to the user's answers you mentioned to better compare your solutions. Congratulations on outgolfing both, could you add a link to an online testing environment for ease of verification?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @JonathanFrech. I have now added a link to test the code online (which added a byte to my answer!).

Comment: You can use an actual new line instead of `\n` to bring your byte count one back down again.

Comment: [125 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKNEI7@0JLVII1lDySkxqVJJR8klMSUFRPvm5@aCaPeixLyUgkQYKzdRSVMnWaMotUBDKTgjsShbISU/HxtW0jHW1IEoUQRqKUgsLknV1NQpTi2wVeJS0vz/HwA)

Comment: Well I've been totally outgolfed; sometimes the simplest option is best. Also highlights how difficult it is to work with strings in R.

Comment: [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcyxCgIxEITh3qc4p8rCFILHdTYiWF3lE6xJ4EBiwibNPX00gtX3F8NY716bK1pbPDmLxXmHqz53EDcNYbjmlIZ303co@q@kEJKzENNjU3uB/vdQmw0whZzBRXj@To4QYY3lggOk9w8) -- this is quite similar to my suggested edits to Sumner18's answer, but I've worked on improving all three of the R answers, so now all three approaches have been sloshing in my head and I don't know whose to comment on...

Answer (score 3):

## Plain TeX, 147 Bytes

`\input pgffor\def\D{doo~}\def\d{\D\D\D\D\D\D}\def\S{Shark}\def\y{\x~\S~\d\par}\foreach\x in{Baby,Mommy,Daddy,Grandma,Grandpa}{\y\y\y\x~\S!\par}\bye`

Rather disappointing, but I haven't posted a TeX answer in ages.  Loops are very verbose in teX (and looping over strings isn't even built-in so even this is a bit of a stretch)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 42 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“¡N³»ẋ6Wẋ3;”!ṭ€;Y
“¡ʂɓṙṢ®ÑR+£ṭỤṙ»Ḳç€“¤⁾ċ»Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDC/0ObT60@@GubrNwIGFs/ahhruLDnWsfNa2xjuQCKzjVdHLyw50zH@5cdGjd4YlB2ocWA@Uf7l4CFANq3LHp8HKgYpDKJY8a9x3pPrQ78v9/AA)**

#### How?

```
“¡N³»ẋ6Wẋ3;”!ṭ€;Y - Link 1: make a verse: familyMember; space+animalName
                  -                        e.g. "Baby"; " Shark"
“¡N³»             - dictionary word " doo"
     ẋ6           - repeat 6 times -> " doo doo doo doo doo doo"
       W          - wrap in a list -> [" doo d..."]
        ẋ3        - repeat 3 times -> [" doo d..."," doo d..."," doo d..."]
           ”!     - literal '!' character
          ;       - concatenate    -> [" doo d..."," doo d..."," doo d...","!"]
               ;  - concatenate inputs ["Baby Shark"]
             ṭ€   - tack for €ach  -> [["Baby Shark"," doo d..."],...,["Baby Shark","!"]]
                Y - join with newline characters
 
“¡ʂɓṙṢ®ÑR+£ṭỤṙ»Ḳç€“¤⁾ċ»Y - Main Link: no arguments
“¡ʂɓṙṢ®ÑR+£ṭỤṙ»          - dictionary words "Baby"+" Daddy"+" Mommy"+" Grandpa"+" Grandma"
               Ḳ         - split at spaces -> ["Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"]
                  “¤⁾ċ»  - dictionary word " Shark"
                ç€       - call last Link (1) as a dyad for €ach
                       Y - join with newline characters
                         - implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
”‡ÍÊÐ¢×myîºpaîºma”#„o€·À6×3и'!ª”ã¢”ìâ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcRw0LD/ce7jo84dCiw9NzKw@vO7SrIBFE5iYCZZUfNczLf9S05tD2ww1mh6cbX9ihrnhoFVDi8OJDi0DUmsOLDu3@/x8A)

```
”‡ÍÊÐ¢×myîºpaîºma”                # compressed string "Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma"
                  #               # split on spaces
„o€·                              # dictionary string "o do"
    À                             # rotated left: " doo"
     6×                           # string-repeat 6 times: " doo doo doo doo doo doo"
       3и                         # list-repeat 3 times
         '!ª                      # append "!" to that list
            ”ã¢”ì                 # prepend "Shark" to each element of that list
â                                 # cartesian product
 »                                # join by newlines
                                  # implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 72 bytes (SBCS)

```apl
↑,(,∘' Shark'¨'BabyDaddyMommyGrandpaGrandma'(∊⊂⊣)⎕A)∘.,'!',⍨3⍴⊂24⍴' doo'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HbRB0NnUcdM9QVgjMSi7LVD61Qd0pMqnRJTEmp9M3Pza10L0rMSylIBFO5ieoajzq6HnU1PeparPmob6qjJlCrno66orrOo94Vxo96twDljEyAtLpCSn6@@n@gmkdtEx719j3qan7UuwYocWi9MdBSoHhwkDOQDPHwDP4PAA)

Explanation:

```apl
↑,(,∘' ..'¨'...'(∊⊂⊣)⎕A)∘.,'!',⍨3⍴⊂24⍴' doo'
                                   24⍴' doo'⍝ repeat 'doo' 6 times
                                  ⊂         ⍝ box the 'doo's
                                3⍴          ⍝ make three copies
                           '!',⍨            ⍝ append a `!` at the end
           '...'(∊⊂⊣)⎕A                     ⍝ split the long string on capitals
   ,∘' ..'¨                                 ⍝ append to all family members
                        ∘.,                 ⍝ construct a table where each row is
                                            ⍝ a full verse of the song
↑,                                          ⍝ flatten the resulting verse table
```

-28 thanks to @Adám

-2 bytes (-14 before; but I did a few golfs before checking the golfed version) thanks to @Razetime

Comment: [-14](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR77xHbRM0HnU16@gb6z/qanrUu1VHXSE4I7EoW10nR@dR7wojk0e9W9QVUvLz1TV1kKQVgfJAvY/6poY6BysYGtceWqHulJhUqa6g7pKYkgKiffNzc0G0e1FiXkpBIoyVm6j@/z8A "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Comment: [-28](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HbRB0NnUcdM9QVgjMSi7LVD61Qd0pMqnRJTEmp9M3Pza10L0rMSylIBFO5ieoajzq6HnU1PeparPmob6qjJlCrno66orrOo94Vxo96twDljEyAtLpCSn6@@n@gmkdtEx719j3qan7UuwYocWi9MdBSoHhwkDOQDPHwDP4PAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám that's a whole lot smaller, I'll analyze that in a short while. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), <s>93</s> 89 bytes

```
|
#20&bk)~" Shark"~(" doo"6,Z,Z,bk)~" Shark!"
:"Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/v4ZL2chALSlbs05JITgjsShbqU5DSSElP1/JTCcKCJFkFJW4rJScEpMqlXSUXBJTUkC0b35uLoh2L0rMSylIhLFyE5X@/wcA)

Note that as of posting TIO is not updated to the latest version, so the TIO link may not work.

### Explanation

```
|                               Set delimiter to newline
#20                             n = 20
   &                            Output first n terms in sequence
                                k = 1
                                First term is
    bk)~" Shark"                 kth term from the third line concatenated to " Shark"
                ~(" doo"6,        concatenated to " doo" repeated 6 times
Z,Z,                            Second and third terms equal the first term
    bk)~" Shark!"               Fourth term is the kth term from the third line concatenated to " Shark!"
                                k += 1, restart

Third line                      5 terms, each a string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 132 bytes

Probably very golf-able. Generates the "doo doo" line, then creates three of those with the "!" line after, and repeats this for each shark.

```javascript
a=""
c=" doo"
for(b of["Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"]){b+=" Shark"
t=b+c+c+c+c+c+c+"\n"
a+=t+t+t+b+"!\n"}console.log(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYu9CsIwGEX3PEW9U0vUN8gigpOTozrcJK1/Tb6SBkHEZ4/tIMgZzuXAvfPJ0aXbkFdRfFsKDaCcQeVFoDpJta2kO2JD@8ISW3o/ey8hzN4lRj/wtwJxbt5WT//DlekBlY3V7g@cIhS1yXrGaiym8HESR@nbdS@Xmk0pXw)

Comment: A slightly changed solution in Javascript, no gain though:
a="";c=" doo";for(b of["Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"]){b+=" Shark";t=b+c.repeat(6)+"\n";a+=t+t+t+b+"!\n"}console.log(a)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt `-R`, 55 bytes

Pretty naïve first pass.

```
`baß'adÝcomæ²T\`èT\`µ`qi Ë'!i4Æ` Srk`iDhDÎuÃqRi6ç` ºo
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YGJh3ydhZN1jb23mslRcYOgTVFxgtWBxaSDLJyFpNMZgIFOVcmtgaURoRM51w3FSaTbnYCC6bw==&input=LVI=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 43 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÇÉ╕µM%╠2'§t╪╝½ôòn=n╢/╬╦Φ▲Vêø■T⌂g^N┴W.ìC↕ƒ·Φ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8090b8e64d25cc32271574d8bcab93956e3d6eb62fcecbe81e568800fe547f675e4ec1572e8d43129ffae8&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>153</s> 147 bytes

```php
<?php $s='Shark';$d=str_pad('',23,'doo ');foreach(explode(' ','Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma')as$a){echo str_repeat("$a $s $d\n",3),"$a $s!\n";}
```

Thanks to @manatwork for saving 6 bytes by pointing out `str_pad('',23'doo ');` is shorter than `rtrim(str_repeat('doo ',6));`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xCsIwEEB/5SyBSyCTHWMRRHBychXk7EUCmuZIOhjEb4@VTo@3vCdBWtvtJQioMuAlUH6iUzyUOd@EWCPabW@RUwI07pGypzFo/5ZXYq8R0OKB7hWOxFzhnGKscMo0sdDKSGioKDIfP4YE/2724mnWnaJlCoqvU2d7Y1ffLOa@rf0A)

Comment: Unfortunately even `$d='doo doo doo doo doo doo'` is shorter than that `rtrim()`+`str_repeat()` combination. :( But fortunately `$d=str_pad('',23,'doo ')` is even shorter. For more optimization tips, see [Tips for golfing in PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php).

Comment: @manatwork Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the post to reflect

Comment: In meantime found some time to play a bit more: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxC8IwFAb3/ooaHqSFN4lbLIIITk6OIvLZVwlImkfi0Pz6WJEbjltOvda6P6jXlvJw9UhvRzLkT3oopLOWtzu2rcRoe/eKacLou9sRz8IniBS@xBAKnxNmUfwdcEcm9NPoIy2DIaxvksawoWXll5vGuFq/ "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcqxCsIwEAbgvU9RjxtaCI4utQgiODk5ishvEzkw8Y6kS54@Dp2@5TOx1o4nE@u4zHdB/k4fzQGLDI8z3tVd4H11N02pumvGzxs2E54ojDEsohxn6hg9F9qXNb9ysIB1oN6rkjuMjjhy3MaOptb@). Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Oop, didn't see your last comment before posting mine, @manatwork.

Comment: [109 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcqxCsIwEAbgvU9RjxtaODq4iRahCE6dHEXkt6kETLwjccnTR8TpWz7zVuvhaN6ap6YVi@@uEx5FTnCuyKwxFjknvJ3hb8QNmdGvi1cOIzWMlob8SXeD6ziPF4/0ku1OqHWq1Atx4PBrnDe0r/UL)

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript (<s>134</s> 126 bytes)**

-2 bytes thanks to Stephen!
-6 bytes thanks to mgthomas99!

```
["Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandma","Grandpa"].forEach(a=>console.log((a+" shark"+" doo".repeat(6)+"\n").repeat(3)+a+" Shark!"))
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31tLadye/)

Comment: Can save two bytes: `a + "` -> `a+"`

Comment: Wow I was working on a JS solution and barely managed to get to 170 bytes.  Your use of repeat is genius!

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by removing the parentheses around the arrow function parameters (so that `(a)=>` becomes `a=>`). You can save another 2 bytes by removing the braces around the arrow function body. I'm also not certain you need the explicit newline at the end of the `console.log` statement, and removing that should save you another 2 bytes.

Comment: The first `shark` should be capitalised

Comment: You can save 1 byte by converting the array to a single string with separator characters, and then splitting on those separator characters, and another 4 bytes by changing `forEach` to `map` (if you run directly in console, it could print out the return of the map, which is an array of undefined's, but if you run from a file, it doesn't print out that array) `"Baby|Daddy|Mommy|Grandma|Grandpa".split\`|\`.map(a=>console.log((a+" shark"+" doo".repeat(6)+"\n").repeat(3)+a+" Shark!"))`

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 87 characters

```
" Shark"as$s|("Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma"/" ")[]|(.+$s+" doo"*6+"\n")*3+.+$s+"!"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -nr '" Shark"as$s|("Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma"/" ")[]|(.+$s+" doo"*6+"\n")*3+.+$s+"!"'
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Baby Shark!
Daddy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Daddy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Daddy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Daddy Shark!
Mommy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Mommy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Mommy Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Mommy Shark!
Grandpa Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandpa Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandpa Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandpa Shark!
Grandma Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandma Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandma Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo
Grandma Shark!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19JITgjsShbKbFYpbhGQ8kpMalSwSUxJaVSwTc/N7dSwb0oMS@lIBFC5yYq6SspKGlGx9Zo6GmrFGsrKaTk5ytpmWkrxeQpaWoZa0NEFZX@//@vm1cEAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 51 bytes

```
;“¤⁾ċ»;“¡N³»ẋ6¤;”¶ẋ3;;“ß<Ė»
“þɗ“¡þ"“£H$“æf⁵“æeⱮ»Ç€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/6UcOcQ0seNe470n1oN5iz0O/Q5kO7H@7qNju0BCgw99A2INvYGiR3eL7NkWmHdnOBmPtOTgerPrxPCUQv9lABiS5Le9S4FcxIfbRx3aHdh9sfNa2J/P//v1J8fLwSAA)

Jelly isn't the best for string manipulation. Still pretty good.

If you expand out the strings to their ungolfed form, the code looks like this:

```
;“ Shark”;“ doo”ẋ6¤;“¶”ẋ3;;“ Shark!”
“Baby“Daddy“Mommy“Grandpa“Grandma”Ç€Y
```

(The string compression was done using [user202729's compressor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151721/68942)).

```
;“ Shark”;“ doo”ẋ6¤;“¶”ẋ3;;“ Shark!”   Helper Link; take a string and format it into a stanza
;“ Shark”                              Append " Shark" to the string
         ;                             Join
                  ¤                    Previous links as a single nilad
          “ doo”                       " doo"
                ẋ6                            repeated 6 times
                   ;“¶”                Append a newline
                       ẋ3              Repeat 3 times
                         ;             Append the string
                          ;“ Shark!”   Append " Shark!"
“Baby“Daddy“Mommy“Grandpa“Grandma”Ç€Y  Main link
“Baby“Daddy“Mommy“Grandpa“Grandma”     ["Baby", "Daddy", "Mommy", "Grandpa", "Grandma"]
                                  Ç€   For each of these words, format it into the stanza with that family position
                                    Y  Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Farm](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Farm), <s>1157</s> 897<sup>†</sup> bytes

<sup>-260 bytes: apparently only `cock a doodle doo` needs spaces..</sup>

No sharks on my farm:

```
cock a doodle doomoocotmoobzzcoucoumewmewmewmewmewmewmewgobblehihihimoopiuarfarfarfarfarfarfarfrouuuleomoopiumoosquealhihihimewmooleoarfarfarfrouuuleomoomoocotmoopiuarfarfarfmooleoarfarfarfarfmoomoocoucouarfarfarfssscoinsssgruntcoinblatcoinssscoinblatcoinssscoinblatmoosssgruntmooblatarfarfarfarfarfarfsssmoogruntmoogruntmoogruntgruntcoincoincoinmewblatmoosssmooblatmoosssmooblatcoinmewblatcoinsssgruntcoinblatcoinssscoinblatcoinssscoinblatmoosssgruntmooblatcotarfgruntsssmewblatmoosssmooblatmoogobblesquealmewmoopiuarfmoopiumooroararfmooarfarfarfarfarfarfarfarfarfarfmoohihihimooarfarfmooarfarfarfmoopiumoosssmewmooarfcoinblatroararfarfarfmoomoohihihimooleoarfarfrouuuleomooleomooleoarfarfmooarfarfarfarfarfarfarfarfarfmoomoohihihipiumooleoarfarfarfmoopiuarfarfarfmoomewmoopiumooleoarfarfarfarfarfmooroararfarfarfarfarfarfmooarfarfarfarfarfarfarfarfarfarfmoohihihimoomewmewmewsssmooblathihihihowl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Txrc9s4kp/DX4HhxmcpI8uPmezuyXZqZI0c62JbXtlaX5LJeCkKslimCIUP24qS/S37R66u6v7Q/YRcPwCQsqw48c7UVl3JDxFo9AuNRqMBkup5yfDzH8SJUvHayItWE1G6uZRpJfXiysi7kmVH@kMl1iLhPt10xQvhJWl1FBagWzk0KIB/QLCvRuMglLMEP2LLwItHs@DnCA7lrYwBXmz4IzaMvTihlkmh5U/YcgRaDkCIg@qKF@t9eb0eZWEotl7826bjOH8Qr6Qcgyp9KYIIrnEs/TSciMgbyb4gUt9LSdu@rKJiYmen2d7/7Cv/Sniir1Q/lHgZKeWrFD57Hz74KoO/kbyZ/7tUvV4ohwH@AvI4yLx4MP8XqyzLQqkYBT6T95n0Qk0HnJSC1vvQrR5F1nfQGUKYqKgFJkniqyCCy2WcRSmWe6GXatiCKiqnCbD3AJnvDiBAm8GZuVpJ5h96l7PVHGcqBaTfQluwFmhIEJRxv3QeNh4ENj@b145PDNbl@r3jWbS7HXwLKbbq4SZNuMmorkUUx8@ysqNb8AT7OS/nXr0sP1ah6DDz7mSNMO9ajDCjbbHh6@1jJ00@FNw2VDfhZ5iFNIM7WSTSoRTjGBzKGwkv6oskjYMxTN84SUV6o0QYRFKUfBWlHkzzaxkngYrKTnWdZnQeFtaCwkT/KAAbYNH3P3z@XHrmCPjZx4brqvixulV9LkpaZhBditCLLjPvUoqBCkN1gyDWCrw6GEOMUAPRi0H8IPOvys7//vd/CfxvqPEkDi6HqSg1ymJrY@PP4j@yMJCR6DRbjYNm54w69NfgGmFH9dZp@/i42f1r07EszoZBYnsPxUEspUjUIL3xYlkTE5UJ34tELPsB2qWXpRDsUmS7rmIxUv1gMLHMoCGL@jIm5VMZjxJUHCsvj7vipYxk7IXiJOuFgS8OA19GiYQIL8YISYYQNHs5MyTbR21OtTZiXwF3LwXrV4QMoD02oyF@MII014pQseVUgiAMHYmFGiNxGbSfgMnTnL662CB5v/sY5VHGUI2he0PgCh2@CWDoe1JkiRxkYcXyAQpx3jo7aHfPRP34tTivdzr147PX20CRDhW0ymvJ/ILRGAatL6CTsRelE@gLsRHiqNlpHABVfa912Dp7DZ0S@62z4@bpqdhvd0RdnNQ7Z61G97DeESfdzkn7tFn9n3@IU4n6SavLF6w/oFEE4/YlOmwClkBXrSc09EPvWopIpTD@vgyuQUcPfHw8eXhYiYsXKvBk7C9g52atiAQU3Bmm6bi2vn5zc1O9jLKqii/XQyZO1l84z8qOk07A0PJ2HItd0c68Icyqo8ADveAqM6w2ILzB5WWosjFeY6hfITwL4PP0fRb4Vwz3Yuej2PvwAWoHwdBDqj3QAlmk8NnB0AfXQ6m2t7VkiP1pnPnoM6DA6VWAIva8hKYjqfVRnA8Dnp5FZHBm5Hma4jp/f1sLuhmnVpRxuN05XEQpPROXMiFQXyZCQqKRxeCaMFMnEJVupQBryVtfkn@L00nUjGMYWBBdOpS3EE6qY5UE1PhM3IGUt7eXAWoZoJYBahmglgFqGaCWAer/U4ACO0egSuo4oUxFX4EE6JjXg3mMACitQrEOVptU6ZijtAUTkOuhjC5Rrtcriw0HRg57GuxuiFTNYYg1sQnsiWG1FJTFzhqWqdhXkdymFgwVKFaf3lxQiCqVStBWGUNgTMuVEh6bQCUplysjOVJBLC@Un8q0LHDEd8Ugiyj2gHk@csxde0GmEiyQ@Vj5uvq92NzWWF8rjwRwNF8kIRjMQHbFBo5pJLaePxcyTORM69pjVcCFxGoAIonMjtrsGBg9UQuQkg84C/t@8wFx@EOaF1V8kEovc/cpuVHUaADzg3zZ3fdScHhJi0ANokJf3tL4YpTGGJW4i5RZe1gZXmxntUlwgYQwBOuKthidz32VcmNQDLGFHI3TyYxmdx0iSi/U4MIfejHpWH0Lkt@VHxh3sO/9/eBkwXYEDASqEHcyVglLKA9NXdCk/Cg/w4xkkaP/@58exVKnN4u4bm5tPYotJUsLuf7x@aOYYua1sPsbj2LJadwipj/@@XF6QuBfxPL544YJE8xFLH/49iEinpyuWq4Y9akZpmFRQhDdL3aG5cMaFDoD@fHCznwj1zv9wtWLli9Yyu0SprPhr1/FTLWQRif3LG1v30EvvmkYS5j/12rvy0j426v3nmTg5qKEy3Z5oaTHL@7E9yENaD9TCo38PMbfuxL/Pnaw4R@9gVmuMs9VzRSryWrOdhV1@u2VCU33F/X0YbUW8p6xNJmet4S/n4uV7m35SWjxtFvNR/7xCoR6IIu5KN5o5EWe5iI1lS4qFwvGrVRImX/cEhvlCv6zzA2QuFEWMIORFfKF4cGNaHoRyRu@m7Dc0y73tMs97T@xp@UzIi6feDBcprKv4pGXcrnBE5fOp/hMSvQzehQAhz3DCt3@hxowxinPSf8VbEigBRRMUi9OL8ZCRn343HU4k8Em3DfjzgKxdoWbKpiQ1zJ0ed0hMC0RLgUVV/zKMEp4OO6ouK83JrBsJXjcdRFGGdjBVn2owq7OVHsqLJdzDiVWLqxoLX0IQiVUFCB48TF2lViO7kdFi6XuaFY9eQkeDDbzh9xxHBlKpf4GRjZLrKQANhAuGt632yOgXEnELyaVWunXVvpr9Fn@qepqQ2k9jcI@7sbLpEPICjOEZZ5OojmZp3SI@BiRRiILI1lACFfM/qAnqdjUSd0FjC4VBoE/DGRc4Y1fRe@6KsKMMBo1loPCkFcE1e9cYamQZOJ6fFklNxNvSemSuxYADoJ5RypKkPkJH9c0LVzUYNXZzkVCdeCBN8EIu5EaoeMaTLwvLSMIEOATZiqNpKv3gCBLLZLFHSNR9/DFs1sVp4Fm9c7JCXlHTHSOO7t89SZ31xrndCz9ABwGQmN0leDh0fzKU3VuZA/22nryjyH@qqoPYS@hAPD3WIJWkHuspzJJ6b57dTwcOxlO@5rQd@J3Cjv1Em82IEhLb1R@gffmdwhJWwggSuywBV44MI8jJYrtGOMTVHyAIbjGfgRhjnDMsGg6bcc7FAiKZZKFsPGJgL4PaO42knzHekLQcO@ePDT1mQM/fODFl9lIwsiOMqjBamL5AyOKVrcw9LTS@cBuHzqOjx5VwVT@1UWSDQbBrfjODGjJrWIU8sknSXMIITkHF7vmio8fc4piWCsvUtUYzOgI0/MZPQIBOnLSA7ONkh7XmfEVNgZq8Z31c5JBAclESXCaiOYcBnTIwHLtLA7E8142wP1TrEYXhsJcCS2NJ47ZhmJCtktrhoyrRvtDejwsVVcgn/k5TzBJ0sKgDykmHQU1eBCB@xMOGrjjMUgcBqiRoyvKf3JDd2IwLOBJaZECptJ3xfqvoqTPqijB3BQlksYnP7Mqlfl8FbjjqDQhwKnBBU0BiiZfkuH@srGx4TpPPhKuibUH0rue6JSXsioOuzUIuhheSyeIJ299MNZFwiFFljmiPvFDlWCafEfHbWt73ufiHNCTZueFnQVkWUQwbbR88sQx5wTFZH2mN4DDUqwKevwZer9ExqVjR0NOS8IGZjt2FdwHl88gFXJDSjlqfAooyFfc@9rZi1KlBCY6rlnNQopHehnW@YQoYTIykhcmz2DfqwgNZjQG2sMSXgZpcbaTYSZPIbXrSVq199lKs4LtxlmzwjX3C6x0D0tfcWpLG7N84W7Mu9E9VOBXJKcVXXth0L8wca/k5rss5vwlxqA33syE3H0AmyXDc6Hudw51H2R/l2JOQGHuPcxNFiZqz@vDbiqDDZvhKecyoMa3zceCM285IMtxaDJxZP1nJ6I5AvOyW9jIQtp0J8z/ErXDvjjyxc8q8qA09Pp65ayI5lprDf/bMAbu9hcDOAiEafwvDd9iGb/z@P3F2KudwVlGzmXk/B0iJ0j@FwROvOfNfv24LAJ0/TzFw4flOd/ynG95zvet53xC2NM9GZuaPvfTmUMQBTZ9GODel47o9CEdHa1xYxUuF34WxxCd9Vow37CzJqZIpNcv/MFTN82X@W8LfRCHt5i4gmd2UNv8ZJQyh/wmrfnNNdISi4eG9IBLQbc7J4io3Cc@3ooUfKa0u3/762p9dW31zapY9eD6Aa4r8P9LtPrOceIMkx1akHf5lJRv7EoY/KlotvfFJwa4KvOGuJy7N95AXzO69rz4igperBuU4gKQDDhiu21Dfa6pzzX1nqGua@pzQ90uUHfrB9xY39fXLlPXO6@YuqMb2m0uAAkUpgJJoQ/EZoSP@VDrSKobV4MyW9AgaZsAiSmPLOWRoTwylEeW8kjappyyVW@zrkfN9rmrQV1b0KCmbUKkqSAyq7fM2HgjpQxbAzrKQc0uG@mo3SYWUDcc8P0ganufQRLgMgiKmrRhmv9imxvF5nbrmJu79QbbuwF2baAUbDNSLvGJHNeWEnYPAjLCS4vwMkfYKyIctrsn93OYCmq0suipGUbF97IMgxz8sgjugJqs@ctO9/gMNWeY4ZckLAxCWKKJTjXooAA6PWVQCwtTAXXDoEeLjWuKmmAvh@4VoIf1s2bHNUXkxCA7XllAreOAfQwyz5gNl0JRl24CmeqSlIZ1Q1OeaMqGpTyzlGeW8qxI2W0xZYu9s3HQ6vBYnEFRl85bzTNdajZJcSCzNqQHgVxdlF6hGBoD5iinOcrpDMpfui3tZVBs1gvFQ7I5tRf8wGP7UsF6gQZ2CsBOu8425wJ5QN2avPfhAw9eBgU9TBq0VwC9ecOgLhZg2N68MQyG@BwQ@5CUQ@/GFNewzCgHFuUgRzmYRWlBLsDwZvOgfm6Ka1SeCmq3OkupHU7mvqVhe0VYs6mdram9rdnMQwO7gh9C2mnjAcMaRVibB75x2MXRwZl/ZheHTrvb7WpEeiZIl@lVQ0QmBCPysNnW7YfSRK8QSoAHTQYLegq/ueXg17WWxgpbA34NBQQl@LN9wPdWXdNJqpDWiGMoMKTgP0eG9h4YqBCqMAZxC73a6eZRzrbwS5/kTJqVtYmvfBUHviK8q@BKxsFVoEPvnReDGSW7kqG8yqz@BfJXRfLGveSv7pC3G@1Oq9HmttarZqf1qqVDN8yeuvi53f75sIkXRum@ah42X3XZRkxrPZtHkUo3ZpoeWOBBAUh@wKVzmq0HeuC5fcXFdARTj2eUgQDCbB61LYrHO1oBm8xM77ZS81vIZoBbuvpOzGMgwtdJ@uysTJe7uOUubrmLe/wuDt9BmN3CFbZ3ekeXvyCUvx1UeC3Ivg/kOCswwVd4luKb3LoIOZcpctJkaiZsmTqFHlOhfQBn1ZQYU96qU0BMYXRWwSkBruq80OJCiQsd5Z6GFy9msFRZSbQM5XrgEmNqZl2ArvDtZW1aaMc3rnbwHNLerjZtzsqK4@hKjWIYbsWm@LQZhzQbogsP0V3QO10ccKfi6ZZG5SO9qYCghA/ZF848JyPYRpqjVdiAlsow3gykw00Clcvi0zYeks3KYa2Kb4mBdk83jX7FhjkVQblNUauRirOsmSs9UzrlV9wAkzliqq2T5Cm/BJfD5yRYRH4vztpCr/5z@Hbxnuq35SyFzjCm@k05XHNQPVaUnGrK76cwOnvYVL9RomHob1N@w8OoAc435dcpGMJ7m6l@qUHD2Dun5g0BTdtFbfAxft1/dtypeQzf0tY7TOrFGoZePaUn4G3X6qgGP8CuccDfp/T0udH0jBRNzWLb0e7FT34zEiZtU3ok@9Nnp1E/OmzsKt8bhT5VDpv/yVVYaQnwut7QCBPP9x2nenLQPn5dEz5krJHjeGFYo/tIjoOfNfpyGH@kzHe4YJG/5wVL5itisGy@FObJ0xJpUcbHP57@JJ7@6jjEvOY8gXV9bSCeET5@BvZhD9NmvyomyIv2i2VAPdampr@zRmsXFIX64umOQQxq9stt5jAKutcK33VjOjxPYLSoFb7oRiOBlcsFHGJpkKy5goINF3EnlW1355CsSWrF79TRaDiy5Vm04KvwSN3c2hYaLLZFjlOgvMfIMLJfdiHnCfni6Aowv@xr4E3oJ/8H)

---

<sub>†: Could be 9 less by using `cocorico` over `cock a doodle doo`..</sub>

Comment: Why not use cocorico then :P

Comment: @ASCII-only: Because I found the language by searching `doo` on esolangs, lol

Comment: The self-graduating add-on for PPCG leaderboard thinks that this is 1 byte. Can you change the <sup>1</sup> to <sup>see bottom</sup>

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, <del>125</del> 123 bytes

```
['Baby','Daddy','Mommy','Grandpa','Grandma'].flatMap(x=>[...[,,,].fill(' doo'.repeat(6)),'!'].map(y=>x+' Shark'+y)).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYuxDoIwFEV3vwKn14b6RjcYjIkTk2NjwpNWBdq@phADX19hcDo3J/cM9KWpS32cT4GNzR2HiZ1Fx2@RNVzouYKCKxmzs2Hvd94SBRPpvzzBA1@O5oaiWKpaI6JWSm2yd05AYZgBk42WZnGWUsFxC/x2Xqt6KaG4fyiNUK5S4sB9EO2hlVnmHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language)) **121 bytes**

```kotlin
"Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma".split(" ").map{(println(("${"$it Shark${" doo".repeat(6)}\n".repeat(3)}$it Shark!")))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYoxCgIxEAC/si5X7DZphHuACFZWtjYrOTFcsgkxV4SQt0fh4KqZgVlj8U7He1MI4pS4DbzIq8JVrK1wjyFUuGVRm2RnEDTf5F0hBGQTJDVK2WnxSoRTw8kVeHwkr38HGyOavKRFCs3cn3rUmftxnpCZ@@jjBw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 527 bytes

```
vv          <<
3v       v,<           v   v     v
0>" ybaB">:| p
<v         <^6#
         v,< 1
>>"krahS">:| "
 v06$      <0<v,,"!"*25
        v,<>^"$v       <
 >"ood ">:|^_^3         v,<
 ^0_v#:-1$< : \>" yddaD">:|
^   >$52*,1-^ "^0$ <      >
^             v     v      < v,<>
>">":62*1p62*#"1+1p^>" ymmoM">:|
^p-1:*27"1"p61<     0    >     >^
v p1-1*46">"p6<     $     v      <v,<
>"6"72*:p    #p     ^     >"dnarG">:|
v     p1*39">"<          ^  ,,,"pa "<
>"v"72*82*p            >$0^
v   p*28*48"m"<
>"@"72*6p              ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFRa8MgEIDf/RW3i082AbWt7YIcYwz2tKe9DktKug1GWylMGOy/Z2qSJRE8SPzuuzs9nt6/Lx@nrgsB/pe1bD1@htJOBxCGHSOThPBzbB6R6l/wzE4C60zBppxoUIwIv27N52umkUGQhg@0tKEs8Q6F3rJZEjnko9MyILxeW0jp7uDWczsDJw@hqCvFLdTwlvpq2@YpscxFhvhWi1JVDtBJDsNAlM@Ws40xMqkDRkhYGy2Uj6FAtVLeJf35fH3p9b5StdA7VOiN6s0y2/sajgXwqlJiY6LKm57gi1JpBEKDOy1qn/4UOULfHmF7aW7PuVqf4ZVY30fb7GEiWsY79A1gcoXk2mvh5/MRly4bvNB7sdnjObMPiTULMvq67g8)

I didn't really try to golf it much, I just wanted it to work. It does, and I'm pretty proud of it. I used the "p" command heavily to reuse a lot of code.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 85 bytes

```
echo('Shark'(,&'!',~(24$' doo')(3#,:)@,~])@,~]);.2'Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19DPTgjsShbXUNHTV1RXadOw8hERV0hJT9fXVPDWFnHStNBpy4WQljrGak7JSZVKrgkpqRUKvjm5@ZWKrgXJealFCRC6NxEBfX//wE)

Note: This assumes a blank line between stanzas is ok.  If that's not the case, prepending `,/` to my solution for +2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 79 bytes

```
$Baby'$Daddy'$Mommy'$Grandpa'$Grandma+" Shark":>Print@{(_+" doo"*6+lf)*3+_+"!"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/X8UpMalSXcUlMSUFSPnm5@YCKfeixLyUgkQoIzdRW0khOCOxKFvJyi6gKDOvxKFaIx4olpKfr6Rlpp2TpqllrA0UUFSq/f8fAA)

An attempt at compressing the above iteration array is `NTS@N=>Split[S@FromBase[Ords@")!-ZOW]NE.kK3(*F(a3\\z6fXD_\\yEM"-32,95],"00"]`, which is significantly longer than the trivial encoding above. Compressing the string using base conversion in its entirety would likely come out to be longer.

### Alternatives

**81 bytes:** `Print@{(_+" doo"*6+lf)*3+_+"!"}=>($Baby'$Daddy'$Mommy'$Grandpa'$Grandma+" Shark")`

**82 bytes:** `Output!{(_+" doo"*6+lf)*3+_+"!"}=>($Baby'$Daddy'$Mommy'$Grandpa'$Grandma+" Shark")`

**86 bytes:** `Output!(""'3&(" doo"*6+lf)'"!")&Join=>($Baby'$Daddy'$Mommy'$Grandpa'$Grandma+" Shark")`

**87 bytes:** `` Output!(""'3&(" doo"*6+lf)'"!")&Join@`+&" Shark"=>$Baby'$Daddy'$Mommy'$Grandpa'$Grandma ``

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 84 bytes

```perl
print (map{join(" doo"x6,("\n$_ Shark")x4),"!"}qw(Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvREEjN7GgOis/M09DSSElP1@pwkxHQykmTyVeITgjsShbSbPCRFNHSVGptrBcwykxqVLBJTElpVLBNz83t1LBvSgxL6UgEULnJmpq/v8PAA)

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxVZJISU/X6nCzLo4sVIhLb/IptopMalSxyUxJaVSxzc/N7dSx70oMS@lukAntzaxVkkhOCOxKFupWkklRalaR6dWR0lRqdbu//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwB)

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxVZJISU/X6nCzLo4sdJGqdopMalSxyUxJaVSxzc/N7dSx70oMS@lukAntzaxViE4I7Eou1olJaZaR6dWR7FWRV/J7v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMAQ "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## VBA (Excel), <s>152</s> 118 bytes

-34 bytes. Thanks @TaylorScott

Using Immediate Window.

<s>`a=Split("Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma"):b=" Shark":c=" doo":For d=0To 19:?a(Int(d/4))b &IIf((d+1)Mod 4=0,"!",Join(Split(String$(6,"."),"."),c)):Next`</s>

```
a=Split("Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma"):b=" Shark":For d=0To 19:?a(d\4)b;IIf((d+1)Mod 4,[Rept(" doo",6)],"!"):Next
```

Comment: You should use integer division instead of casting an int over division - so `Int(d/4)` goes to `d\4` , you can rearrange the arguements of the `IIf` statement to get rid of the `=0` and then you can convert that really nifty join split statement with a `Rept` statement. All together this becomes `a=Split("Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma"):b=" Shark":For d=0To 19:?a(d\4)b;IIf((d+1)Mod 4,[Rept(" doo",6)],"!"):Next` for 118 Bytes

Comment: Totally forgot `Rept` function lol. Your answer is way better than mine you should've post it as your own answer. Anyways, thanks for cutting off huge bytes to my wall of code. lol. `d\4` <-- Didn't know this until now. Thanks! :D

Comment: I get far more joy out of helping others get better with VBA, than I do writing it myself - Cheers

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 134 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text
r=repeatn
f=join"\n"[e+" Shark"+concat s\\e<-split" ""Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma",s<-r 3(r 6" doo")++[["!"]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc6xCsIwEIDh3ac4b1LaToJTu0hFBAWhbm2Ha5JqNLmUNIp9eaPQ6efbfmEUcbROvowCS5qjtoPzAaog9/xOr@oTFr7walAUeNEXD6cZG8ZaJQjVnfwTE@FYUICxaVSejYPRAQFxR90EJUk5wdlZO8HBE8uB5lrCdMwzD5uVhy2CdA7XSVLXuMS2bWMV6H9RQB@/ojd0G2N2PMVyYrJazLgYCr3zNmbdDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 179 bytes

```fs
["Baby";"Daddy";"Mommy";"Grandpa";"Grandma"]|>Seq.map(fun i->([0..2]|>Seq.map(fun _->i+" Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo")|>String.concat "\n")+"\n"+i+" Shark!")|>String.concat "\n"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/P1rJKTGpUslaySUxJQVE@@bn5oJo96LEvJSCRBgrN1EptsYuOLVQLzexQCOtNE8hU9dOI9pAT88ITTxe1y5TW0khOCOxKFshJT8fG1bSBOopKcrMS9dLzs9LTixRUIrJU9LUBpHacN2K2JX9r7FTKAAKlqTlKSipFiv9BwA)

No input, export to a string and to std output in a console.

## 145 bytes

```fs
for i in["Baby";"Daddy";"Mommy";"Grandpa";"Grandma"]do(for _ in[0..2]do printfn"%s"(i+" Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo"));printfn"%s"(i+" Shark!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Py2/SCFTITMvWskpMalSyVrJJTElBUT75ufmgmj3osS8lIJEGCs3USk2JV8DpC0epM1AT88IKKBQUJSZV5KWp6RarKSRqa2kEJyRWJStkJKfjw0raWpaY9WgqKT5v8YOZpgCSPI/AA)

No input, export to std output

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>160</s> 156 bytes

```fs
let c,r,s=String.concat,List.replicate," Shark"
let p n=r 3(c" "(n+s::r 6"doo"))@[n+s+"!"]
["Baby";"Daddy";"Mommy";"Grandpa";"Grandma"]|>Seq.collect p|>c"
"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY69CsIwAIT3PkU8EFoauwgOlRYRwUWnjqVDTFItpklMsgh995gOTvfDwXej33HjZIxKBsKpo77pgpv0s@JGcxbobfKhctKqKSVJQboXc29k694S3TiyzzkIcl36unbkAGEMiuLUp6LEBkPW48weXxxxYUKsejfzvOrVMS0s@7uZYVjaTn4SWynJE2BpOTLEpbXpUxg1th7xBw)

And based on @aloisdg version, I get this one:

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>130</s> 129 bytes

```fs
let p,d=printfn"%s Shark%s"," doo doo"
for i in["Baby";"Daddy";"Mommy";"Grandpa";"Grandma"]do(for _ in"123"do p i (d+d+d));p i"!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxC8IwFIR3f8XzoNBiHdSxuIjg1KmjiDx9DQZNXki6@OtjMshx3N3wnUnbp8Y558@8UOjlGKL1i/FoEk0vju8moQeJajVWRiNZsv6KEz@@GHBmkZqjOlfzEtlL4H9zjJtoW7F7wbDbHyBKoZy0sinquqEMrJHzDw)

Gaining 1 more char by changine [0..2] by "123" wich is also a sequence of 3 items...

Answer (score 1):

### groovy, 96 bytes

```
'Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma'.split().any{n="$it Shark";println((n+" doo"*6+'\n')*3+n+'!')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P9f3SkxqVLBJTElpVLBNz83t1LBvSgxL6UgEULnJqrrFRfkZJZoaOol5lVW59kqqWSWKARnJBZlK1kXFGXmleTkaWjkaSsppOTnK2mZaavH5Klrahlr52mrK6pr1v7/DwA)

Comment: Protip: esc -> s -> g on the TryItOnline page for a well formatted post

Comment: [close](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P9f3SkxqVLBJTElpVLBNz83t1LBvSgxL6UgEULnJqrrFRfkZJZoaOol5lVWR@fZKimk5OcraZnp5AGhkqJSLFgiT9euoCgzr0RJJbNEITgjsShbJS8mT6m29v9/AA)

Comment: [also close](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P9f3SkxqVLBJTElpVLBNz83t1LBvSgxL6UgEULnJqrrFRfkZJZoaOol5lVWaxjr6RlAmHm6dgVFmXklSiqZJQrBGYlF2SrVefZKCin5@UpaZlZKikq1MXlKtbX//wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>627</s> <s>593</s> 573 bytes

```
Initialise Array with "Baby\0Daddy\0Mommy\0Grandpa\0Grandma"
Loop runs 71 times
++[++++++++++++++++++
    Get array cells to approximately correct values
    >>>+>>+++++>>+++++>>-->>>>+>>+++++>>+++++>>+++++>>-->>>>+>>-->>-->>-->>-->>>>+>>-->>+++++>>-->>+++++>>-->>+++++>>>>+>>-->>+++++>>-->>+++++>>-->>+++++
    [[<<]<<]>
]
Finish getting cells to correct values
>>>---->>->>>>++++++++>>+>>-->>->>++>>++>>++++++++>>+>>+++++++>>-->>---->>---->>++++++++>>+>>+>>+>>->>--->>++>>->>->>+>>+>>+>>->>--->>++>>---->>-
Inject ones between each cell in the array
[-<+<]>[>>]+

Initialise an exclamation mark; newline; and the string " Shark"
>>>+++++++++++[+++++++
    >------->+>>+>----->+++>+++>---->+++
    <<<<<<<<<
]
>->-->>--->++>->-------->-->++
[<]
Go to the end of the "Baby" Array to loop
<<<<<<[
    >>>
    Loop 3 times
    +++[-
        Go to the first value of the baby array
        <<<[<<]>>>
        Print the word out
        [.>>]
        Go to the shark array
        >[>>]>>>>>
        Print " Shark"
        [.>]
        <[<]
        Loop 6 times
        ++++++[-
            Print a space
            >.
            Change the 'a' in " Shark" to a 'd' and print
            >>>+++.---
            Change the 'r' in " Shark" to an 'o' and print twice
            >---..+++
            <<<<<
        ]
        Print newline
        <<.
        <
    ]
    Go to start of baby array
    <<<[<<]>>
    Print and consume the first string in the array
    ->[.[-]>->]
    Go to shark string
    >[>>]>>>>>
    Print " Shark"
    [.>]
    <[<]
    Print "!\n"
    <.<.
    <<<<
]
```

-20B thanks to Jo King

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBbCsMwDDuQsU8QfBGTj20wGIN9DHr@TLaTNFv7MVO3qh@S8PV9ebzu2@3ZGpHRIVQV2WH/MOtZ@bfrYM1ZXAaP8J8ps1IqHq3q1RCIzWl6yHtt5NKbOL3t7@@p5IleknTK01ayGBeCMVOttDii/bgx6cPB0SHKo@WgjKjQ6O5chcdyVMHpZ/Cw1II6sK@pmsBDGPHT@G9Fq3YzrJIrkmQsMnRBKcGbRIxVYzdywoZJiZ3WPg)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 151 bytes

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(a.value+' Shark'+b.value,'Q',REPLICATE(' doo',6))
FROM STRING_SPLIT('Baby,Daddy,Mommy,Grandpa,Grandma',',')a,STRING_SPLIT('Q,Q,Q,!',',')b
```

Line break for readability only.

SQL's built-in function names are annoyingly long.

`STRING_SPLIT` works in [SQL 2016 and later](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql).

Order isn't 100% guaranteed without an `ORDER BY`, but this seemed to work in my testing.

Comment: It seems sql answers are not popular, very nice answer. Which means a lot comming from me

Comment: Thanks, @t-clausen.dk!

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-R`, <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```
`BabysDaddysMommysGÎÀpGÎÀµ`qÅË±` Srk` +` ºo`³²+R ³+D+'!
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YEJhYnlzRGFkZHlzTW9tbXlzR87AcIZHzsC1YHHFy7FgIFOVcmtgICtgILpvYLOyK1IgsytEKych&input=LVI=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), <s>93</s> 89 bytes

```
(Grandma)(Grandpa)(Mommy)(Daddy)(Baby)(~( Shark)*:( doo)::**:**(
)*::**S(!
)*S):^:^:^:^:^
```

Since Underload is really good at duplicating and concatenation with strings, I decided to give this a go.

Saved 4 bytes by re-arranging things.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fw70oMS8lN1ETwigAMnzzc3MrNTVcElNSgJRTYhKQrNNQCM5ILMrW1LLSUEjJz9e0stLSAiINLqAIkA7WUASygjWt4mDw/38A)

## Explanation

```
(Grandma)  Pushes 'Grandma'
(Grandpa)  Pushes 'Grandpa'
(Mommy)  Pushes 'Mommy'
(Daddy)  Pushes 'Daddy'
(Baby)   Pushes 'Baby'
(  Add the next bit of code to the stack
~  Swaps so the name of the Shark (eg: Baby) is on the top of the stack
( Shark)  Pushes ' Shark' to the stack
*  Concatenates ' Shark' to the name of the Shark
:  Duplicates the top of the stack
( doo)  Pushes ' doo'
::**:*  Turns it into ' doo doo doo doo doo doo'
*  Concatenates it to the '[name] Shark'
(<Newline>)*  Concatenates a newline to the string, making it '[Name] Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo[Newline]'
::**   Duplicates it twice
S  Outputs the first three lines of the stanza
(![Newline])*S Concatenates '![Newline]' to the '[Name] Shark' string and prints it
)  Ends the code being added to the stack
:^:^:^:^:  Runs the code in the bracket 5 times, for the 5 different stanzas
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Babylang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Babylang), 2866 bytes

```python
aaag aaag gagu aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gagu gagu gugu gugu guga gugu gugu guga gaga guga gaga gaga gaga uuug uuug uuug uuug gaga gaga uuug gaga gaga gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag gaga gaga aaag aaag gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga uuug uuug uuug uuug gaga gaga uuug uuug uuug uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga uuug gaga gaga uuug uuug uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag gaga gaga uuug gaga gaga uuug gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga aaag gaga gaga uuug gaga gaga uuug uuug uuug gaga gaga aaag aaag gaga gaga uuug uuug uuug uuug gaga gaga uuug gagu uuug gugu aaag gugu guga gaga gagu gaga gaga guga aaag gaga gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gagu aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gaga uuug uuug uuug uuug uuug uuug uuug gaga aaag gaga gaga aaag gaga uuug uuug uuug uuug uuug gaga aaag aaag aaag gaga aaag aaag aaag gaga uuug uuug uuug uuug gaga aaag aaag aaag gugu gugu gugu gugu gugu gugu gugu gugu gugu guga gaga uuug gaga uuug uuug gaga gaga uuug uuug uuug gaga aaag aaag gaga uuug gaga uuug uuug uuug uuug uuug uuug uuug uuug gaga uuug uuug gaga aaag aaag gagu gugu guga gugu gugu gugu gugu gugu gugu gagu gaga gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag gagu uuug gugu gugu gugu gagu gugu gugu guga gaga gaga gaga gagu guuu gaga gaga guga gaga gagu gaga gaga guga gaga gaga gaga gaga gaga gagu guuu gaga guga gugu gagu gugu guga aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag aaag gagu uuug gaga guuu gaga gaga gaga aaag aaag aaag guuu uuug uuug uuug gaga uuug uuug uuug guuu guuu aaag aaag aaag gugu gugu gugu gugu gugu guga gugu gugu guuu gugu guga gugu gugu gugu gagu gugu gugu guga gaga gaga uuug gaga gagu guuu gagu uuug guga gaga uuug gaga guga gaga gagu gaga gaga guga gaga gaga gaga gaga gaga gagu guuu gaga guga gugu gagu gugu guga gugu guuu gugu guuu gugu gugu gugu gugu guga
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 70 bytes

```
"Baby
Daddy
Mommy
Grandpa
Grandma"n/{" Shark"+" doo"6*n++...-25<"!"n}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X8kpMamSyyUxJaWSyzc/N7eSy70oMS@lIBFC5yYq5elXKykEZyQWZStpKymk5OcrmWnlaWvr6enpGpnaKCkq5dXq//8PAA)

#### Explanation:

```
"Baby
Daddy
Mommy
Grandpa
Grandma"n/                                       Push shark names, then split by newline
          {                               }/     For each name:
           " Shark"+                                 Concatenate with Shark
                    " doo"6*n++                      add doo * 6 then newline
                               ...                   Duplicate line 3 more times
                                  -25<               Cut off the "doo"s
                                      "!"n           Add "!"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>151</s> 125 bytes

```
cut "Baby,Daddy,Mommy,Grandpa,Grandma" in N with ","
while N
roll N in S
let L be S+" Shark"+" doo"*6+"
"
say L*3+S+" Shark!"
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 48 bytes

```
`÷Ċ ₈Ȧ Mummy ∆ƛpa ∆ƛma`⌈` Ẏ꘍`+ƛ3(` doo`6*+,)\!+,
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%C3%B7%C4%8A%20%E2%82%88%C8%A6%20Mummy%20%E2%88%86%C6%9Bpa%20%E2%88%86%C6%9Bma%60%E2%8C%88%60%20%E1%BA%8E%EA%98%8D%60%2B%C6%9B3%28%60%20doo%606*%2B%2C%29%5C!%2B%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

A mess.

```
`...`⌈                         # Names, split on newlines
      `...`+                   # Append ' Shark' to each
            ƛ                  # Foreach...
             3(          )     # Three times
               ` doo`6*+,      # Append six doos and output
                          \!+, # Append a ! and output
```

Comment: That uses and outputs "Mummy Shark", not "Mommy Shark" as in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

**C (compiled with VC++ (Visual Studio 2017)) 536Bytes**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define d "doo "
#define p(x) printf(x);
#define n p("\n")
#define b p(f[i])p(" Shark ")
#define l(x,y) for(int x=0;x<y;x++)
void main(){const char*f[]={"Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"};l(i,5){l(k,3){b;l(j,6)p(d)n}b;p("\b!\n")}}
```

this is my naive try: it started from the "good version" where everything is done the neat and tidy way and i just removed the blanks, semicolons where possible and curly braces if possible. i changed main from int to void in order to be able to leave out the return Statement in the end 
if using a different Compiler (say gcc) the stdafx.h can be ommitted (visual Studio throws an error though (or i just dont know how to do it better...))
although then the use of printf means you either have to include stdio.h instead (=1byte win) or you have to use a Compiler flag to add this to the build path although not mentioned in the Code....
if its no dealbreaker if the exclamation mark is one space away from Baby Shark then the \b can be ommitted (=2 Byte win)

Comment: removing the space between include and " makes a 1byte win. and removing the space between ) and for makes another  Maybe you can squeeze out a bit more by modifing the l makro to make curly braces and therefor take one Argument more (=the loopbody)

Comment: Would also work with a non const char array, no?

Comment: i used to compile that with visual studio and that throws an error if not. maybe other compilers aint that strict

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 145 bytes

Nothing special, still thinking of a shorter method.

```
a={"Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"};c=" Shark";b=c<>StringJoin@Table[" doo",6];Do[Do[Print[a[[i]]<>b],3];Print[a[[i]]<>c<>"!"];,{i,5}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYyxCsIwGIRfpf5zNtElTREpCIIg1C38w6UpNtgkUrJI6bPHdHAQDr7jOziPNA4eyfXIGWqhM8yHBLWwduMter/xMiPYN37Ng1bZK6q6EfOLpFF93XRpduF5jS6cHjDToKmyMZI4smyjLrmXPWlo7ZjrxrDYs/x35YV2xFIsThxWzvkL)

Comment: [141?](https://tio.run/##VYyxCsIwGIRfpf5zNtElTQcpOAnFjuEfrkmwQdKUkEVKnz2mg4Nw8B3fwQXk2QVkb1AK1EY3TB8S1MPag48YwsF7wmJX/FoA7dIoasYZ6U1yUqbtxpz88nq61SFramyMJK4s@6hrhrplDa09c9tNLM4s/119oBOxFJsXl51L@QI)

Comment: [137?](https://tio.run/##PYq9CsIwFEZfpd45m@iSpoMUnASxY7jDlx9skDQlZJHSZ49m0OmcAyeizD6iBItaoTa6wLxJ0AjnGm8pxsZrxuJW/CyCdmkVddOM/CJp1FRyWJ4Pv3oUTZ1LicSZ5Zi0U9A6MPeDbXn/fkW7fjAsjiz/SQdiKbYgTjvX@gE)

Comment: [116?](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98lPxqIAooy80qiE23slCFIzUFJISU/H4SVYnWMY63hCpQUgQLViTpAVUoKwRmJRdlKavoO1UpOiUmVSjpKLokpKSDaNz83F0S7FyXmpRQkwli5iUq1tbH//wMA)

Comment: btw, join works instead of stringjoin

Comment: [105?](https://tio.run/##NcaxCsIwFAXQX6l3fluLk3SQgjgIgm4hw21TaaivkZBFQr490sHpHGVaZmXyE2sdgrlHvyVDQfNYGFec@uvL@L4VHCBPju/ZoHEhQI7WWsmUjDPHLwQDndu9BdXdS@TmPvxPiVIke@mKrfUH) also join works only because you <> right after

Comment: [also 105](https://tio.run/##JcWxCsIwEAbgV4k336Y4SREpiIMgWHAIGf6aSINeT9IMDaXPHge/5RPkIQhyfKLWVu0txTFbMJn7gPSmQ3N52dhsmTbEHfpPsGS8KvHeOccLuAtzfmjy05FO6Itp4X0xVxUp5pww@i/@C2jlJfJudbX@AA)

Comment: [95?](https://tio.run/##JcWxCsIwFAXQX6lvvpviJB1KQRwEQbeQ4bapNOhrSsgSQr49Dp7lKNO6KJOf2doYzCP6LRlCuufK@JFLf3sb3x8hB8GL03cx0rkQBGdrLQpRBk4ZI53LuAfVjGvk5nb@V9aK4nGqtrUf)

Comment: [also 95 but stolen from Haskell answer](https://tio.run/##JcWxCsIwFAXQX6lvvrOTdigFJ0HQLWS4SQot@hoJWULIt0ehnOEo87oo8@bZ@xzNI217NoQMz5XpLZfRWVSiTnQFM0MouEfVglviHr48VraG6lD99UX3WYwMIUbB2cL/yUlas73/AA)

Comment: @ASCII-only nice improvements. I think that you can take credit for those though, you went a long way from where I started!

Comment: :P well I still did base it off your solution (I barely know Mathematica), plus as you can probably see I was mostly just reordering things

Answer (score 0):

## [Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), 177 bytes

```
(defmacro w()`(princ(concat i" Shark doo doo doo doo doo doo\n")))
(defmacro z()`(princ(concat i" Shark!\n")))
(loop for i in'("Baby""Daddy""Mommy""Grandpa")do(and(w)(w)(w)(z)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 139 bytes

```cs
"Baby Daddy Mommy Grandpa Grandma".Split().ToList().ForEach(x=>{string a=" doo",m=x+$" Shark{a+a+a+a+a+a}\n";Write(m+m+m+x+" Shark!\n");});
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P9fySkxqVLBJTElpVLBNz83t1LBvSgxL6UgEULnJirpBRfkZJZoaOqF5PtkFoMYbvlFronJGRoVtnbVxSVFmXnpCom2Sgop@flKOrm2FdoqSgrBGYlF2dWJ2nBYG5OnZB1elFmSqpGrDYIV2lBVikAZTetaTev//wE)

Any thoughts on improvements?  I started aiming for a Linq-based solution with a `SelectMany` but the deferred execution failed me, along with `string.join` and `return x;` being quite verbose syntax

Comment: [137 :P](https://tio.run/##LYnNCgIhFEZfxS4tFGteQKZF9LOp1QRt2tw0GpnUQV0owzy7jRSHj@/AkWErgy4F9vjM5IBKZXJ1xmRy9mjViL83CE03fnSkrLm5iw5VTs4fUfY0tbspRK/tm2ALRDlXBxvTJr4G0vXohwn5wvywIO5exxc1vJL4v6@WwsTMRClf) (2x3 = 5 occurrences is shorter than 6)

Comment: [134](https://tio.run/##LYm9DsIgGABfBYkDhNoXIJho/JmcOri4fIKxpALNBwOk6bNjG83lcsPpuNPR1npAhNJeAp5B94we4VnICYwp5BacK@SK4M0IvzqgbTd@bGK8yWo/xYTWvwkoSkwIq7RxKostJV0POEwgFuaHp/KONr2YEytZ/P9mOVzOXNb6BQ)

Comment: [131](https://tio.run/##LYmxCsIwFAB/5flwSIj6A6WLCE5OHVxcnkm1QZOUlyAJpd8eW5TjuOF03Otoa30E7kkP4kMMGazHI90LnMiYApfgXIEzkzcj/eoID934tklIOcXE1j@BWgQTwiruXJvVFqEbiF8TqYX55rG5sk29cGolq//fLEc2c61f) which is basically the same as the other solution

Comment: [132, close](https://tio.run/##LYmxCsIwFAB/5flwSIgW9xIHEZycMri4PJuiQZOUJIWE0m@PLcpx3HBd3HfR1IonehQ4k9YFrt7aApdATg/0qyVs1PAxifFGjZZleZxiCsY9gSSC9n4Vd1ZmsUVQLwrvicTCfHfY3oJJPbNiJYv/3yyHt6FPY3BwaGde6xc)

Comment: [also 132](https://tio.run/##LYnLCsIwEEV/ZQwuElL7AxJB8bFy1YUbN2MiNug0ZZJFgvjtsUU5XA7cY@PKRl9rTOyHB6AR4EKYJxpab5mxtMfAB7S9FDu8FdijcwXOgajAiXFwI/5MKNpufPkkVZPN5sI@3aUkk/VSQNcjP9@oJz7XQShNE1n/w2K@VK1f)

Comment: [Another 132 with foreach](https://tio.run/##JYhBDsIgEEWvMs6mEKoXaLoxJq5cdeGmmwGqJQo0AzHl9NhqXn5e/jPpaJKrNWV24QnUI9gY92GrtzPMxC9sffeIPJGZxYcYVnABz6QLXMjaArfofYErU7AL/e0JT8PydllIeWeXJyF8vyqt6EczhkYqv7E3PIwBZVfrFw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 149 bytes

```swift
var s=" Shark";for i in["Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"]{for _ in 0...2{print(i+s+(0..<6).map({_ in" doo"}).reduce("",+))};print(i+s+"!")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYu7CgIxEEV/ZZwqYZcgIjarjQhWVpYiMppdDJIHk1WRkG@Pm0KszuVyTnybYVyW8iKGuEE43okf2A2ewYBxJ9zS9YMt7kjryoO3tnLP5HSg37KE51SjyxTBXCm1SIGNG4VpYiOmY72SylIQqRoI2nvMUnGvn7deILaNlLn7JzhDmUv5Ag)

Comment: [126](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsJAEER/ZZ3KkJR2IY0IVlaWEmRlCS5yd2EvRELIt59uEYbhzTQvf3WYTqUMyUhJ4wNnfi1ocGER5y2F4LwaRxl5X4HRrzMb5U5r0P3N9kEjHUhS8qJ15fOvBBFhHU3jdMy1eKqt3T8OqLZSfg)

Comment: [119](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/LLFIIcVWSSElPx@ElXRSbVO0gdA6Lb9IIVMhMy9aySkxqVJJR8klMSUFRPvm5@aCaPeixLyUgkQYKzdRKbYapCkLpClVBwSVFIFiBUWZeSUamdpKCsEZiUXZStpZmrW1//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 95 bytes

```
Do[Print[a," Shark"<>If[i>3,"!",Table[" doo",6]]],{a,{Baby,Daddy,Mommy,Grandpa,Grandma}},{i,4}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcWxCsIwFAXQX6lvvpviJB1KQRwEQbeQ4bapNOhrSsgSQr49Dp7lKNO6KJOf2doYzCP6LRlCuufK@JFLf3sb3x8hB8GL03cx0rkQBGdrLQpRBk4ZI53LuAfVjGvk5nb@V9aK4nGqtrUf)

Answer (score 0):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), <s>114</s> <s>113</s> 110 bytes

```
-(h)~temp t="{Baby|Daddy|Mommy|Grand{ma|pa}} Shark"
-(l){t}<>{l%4<1:
!
{h>5:->END}->h
}
-(d)\ doo{d%5:->d}
->l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v9fVyNDs64kNbdAocRWqdopMamyxiUxJaWyxjc/N7eyxr0oMS@lOjexpiCxtlYhOCOxKFuJS1cjR7O6pNbGrjpH1cTG0IpLkas6w87UStfO1c@lVtcug6sWqCZFM0YhJT@/OkUVJJMCFLLL@f8fAA)

## Explained

```
-(h)                                                   // A gather, we can jump here and keep track of how many times we've visited.
~temp t="{Baby|Daddy|Mommy|Grand{ma|pa}} Shark"        // The sequence takes on the next value each time it's visited, and we can nest them. Save into local variable t
-(l){t}<>{l%4<1:                                       // Print t and no newline, then if the number of times we've been here is divisible by 4...
!                                                      // Print an exclamation mark
{h>5:->END}->h                                         // Go to h, or halt if we've already been there more than 5 times
}
-(d)\ doo{d%5:->d}                                     // Print " doo" until we've done it a number of times that is a multiple of 5
->l                                                    // Go to l to print the next line
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), <del>110</del> 108 bytes

```
Fn.new{["Baby","Daddy","Mommy","Grandpa","Grandma"].map{|i|((i=i+" Shark")+" doo"*6+"
")*3+i+"!"}.join("
")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xDsIgFEV3vwLfBKVhMXHrYoxOTh2Nw7NgRMujwVbStP12LIPTOblnuTEYSl8M7DFQwyqWTqTIxOkKB7yPUMIRtc68eOcyzwFJd/g3h3BTDrtptjPntrISWP3E8AaxmvYeir2EDYhiJ9e2hUW9vCWepyXV46c3TsVge8PzA9Vg23Ih0g8)